# Any way to send a personal message to another user?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, private-messaging

There has been quite a few times that I wished I could send a message to another user on SO - not ask a question for everyone to see, but just a short message informing them of something or requesting them to do something.  Are there any plans to allow this to happen in the future?

---

#### Related: [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)

Comment: It could even be an opt-in thing, so that most casual users wouldn't ever get bothered by it.

Comment: I can see this being used by recruiters and contracting folks.  For example, there's been times where I've seen someone's answer and I've wanted to say, "I'd give you $X to do some short contracting for me, because you've got exactly the kind of experience I need for a quick project."  We talk a lot about the expert economy, and in order for that to work, we need a way to pay people to do work.

Comment: I think people can achieve recruitability by putting links out to contacts (perhaps blind) in their profile.

Comment: Great idea - so many times I had wished to be able to send a follow-up message to a person asking a question......

Comment: I would love to have this for two reasons: (1) I like to thank people for their contributions and sometimes my comments left behind don't get seen. (2) And sometimes I have short questions unrelated to the topic at hand that don't need much of a reply. -- As for the accusation that problem solving could go on behind "closed channels", I say that Private Messages should be limited to something 128 or 160 characters, and the functionality that detects when code has been pasted in could pop-up a Javascript window reminding the user that maybe this should be in a new topic.

Comment: I also don't like the notion of Opt-In. Everyone should be available to chat with. At the very least, there should be a way to poke someone and say, "Hey, I'd like to ask you about X. Are you willing to chat with me?" And then give the user the option of allowing an exchange or not...

Comment: I think PM should be possible and would be useful on SO - particularly when it comes to Area51, and communicating with other people who have 'followed' or 'committed' to your site proposal.  You could coordinate the site much better with people if you could PM them.

Comment: i wish i had this because i had some really cool information i wanted to post on a certain question but the question is protected from ppl with reputation<10 and i wanted to msg Will the moderator but he doesn't list contact info on his profile so nyah!  further testing showed the information wasn't that cool anyway.  ;)

Comment: Anyone who voted this question up, I encourage you to go [HERE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93896/a-proposal-for-private-messaging-within-the-stack-exchange-network) and vote up this proposal for a PM system.  It proposes in great detail a workable PM system for StackOverflow, and has (at the moment) been voted down a lot.  If you support the idea of introducing PM to StackOverflow, go and vote it up!

Comment: @Ranger: No. You've already disturbed them by that point. Nothing irritates me more than reading constant "are you available to talk" messages and then having to keep writing "no"; it's quite obviously counter to my desires.

Comment: It is really frustrating, I would contact someone who is obviously working on the same subject as me. I really need to share experience with him. Is it really impossible?

Comment: I'd love to see a "wall"-type feature implemented.  This would allow messages to be sent to specific users, while at the same time keeping the messages public.  In order to curb harassment and spamming, only users with a certain amount of reputation could be given the ability to make wall posts (for example, 500 rep).

Comment: Vote here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172688/vote-for-private-messages

Comment: Here's another use case that is what I want it primarily for:  Say a new user does some kind of [minor] formatting mistake.  I would like to be able to say "hey, did you know you can use underlines to demarcate your headings?  It makes posts easier to read", without having to publicly call them out on it.

Comment: @zebediah49 excellent point! Looks you can read my thoughts, since I too wanted to contact a user once because I wanted to tell him to stop playing the wise guy, with my grammar and all. Well, it mightn't have been 100% grammatically correct English, but the question was perfectly readable. However what he did is rewrite nearly all of my sentences and that really annoyed me. -- Contacting him would be the ONLY way out because what would others say if I started an off-topic dispute right in the comments telling him to stop that? That wouldn't be a good idea either, so ... sometimes you need it.

Comment: Just one example: I would rather get a PM to suggest an edit in my question than have someone just do it over the top of me. And who wants the comments clogged with editing suggestions?

Comment: I guess that you can't because if you could, more things would be solved via private messages and other people with the same issue/question could not benefit from it.

Comment: Another use case is when someone's answer gets deleted - there is no way to contact the moderator who did it.

Comment: Slack would be better.

Comment: There's this user that has been helping me with my python project. I'd like to send him a pm every time I need help with something.

Comment: I just want to note that there is literally no way to ask someone who deleted their answer to "undelete" it because it was actually a correct answer, happened a number of times to me.

Comment: I would love to have this feature and I would like to use it to express to people who post useful information to me. The community doesn't want people to use comments to say thank you, but rather to up vote, but sometimes I find it hard to express how much I **appreciate** the people who answer.

Comment: If this were to be added, within 2 weeks, we would all have message boxes full of spam. We have the option to add social media accounts, and so if someone wants to get ahold of us, they know how.

Comment: @Carson I agree, especially when youve spent hours pulling your hair out, and someone swoops in and saves the day with a couple of sentences. Maybe we could use some sort of padded version of a 2nd upvote for these instances. Make it cost a bit of rep, as do the downvotes, and be an option only once every X hours or days, so it is only used in situations where it is deserved. If the user were to be notified after recieving, that would send the message to which you refer, no? It would say "I sacrificed my rep and my 2nd upvote to show you how thankful I am"

Comment: Such feature would be really useful.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

Nope.

This has been suggested many, many times, going all the way back to the earliest days of the site. Prior to the creation of Meta SO, feature requests were posted on UserVoice:

- [Messaging between users](https://web.archive.org/web/20110924110331/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/14640)

> Declined without comment.

- [User messaging or wall](https://web.archive.org/web/20110506032829/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/general/suggestions/16805-user-messaging-or-wall)

  > it's possible we might have some kind of messaging function later, so as not to expose emails but let users communicate. But it's low priority.

*Comments were added to the system to allow users to communicate with each other **in the context of a specific post**.*

- [Allow private messages](https://web.archive.org/web/20151225040228/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/forums/1722-general/suggestions/99462-allow-private-messages)

> it's about the questions and answers, not social networking. But if you want to contact someone, check their profile -- they will provide an URL or email address there.

- [How do you send a message to a stackoverflow user?](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507022423/https://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/forums/1722-general/suggestions/216825-how-do-you-send-a-message-to-a-stackoverflow-user-)

> Declined without comment

*Later on, the system was [expanded to allow notifying other users of comment-replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).*

Even with the ability to communicate with other involved users in regards to a specific post, the requests kept on coming. When Meta Stack Overflow replaced UserVoice, the number of feature-requests exploded:

- [Private message system unlocked by reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/how-user-messaging-could-be-realized)
- [Why don't we have instant messaging on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11635/instant-messaging-on-so-sf-su)
- [Is there a way to contact another member of stack overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18266/is-there-a-way-to-contact-another-member-of-stack-overflow)
- [Is there plans for an IM Capability?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18970/is-there-plans-for-an-im-capability)
- [Request a specific expert on a subject to answer your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41474/request-a-specific-expert-on-a-subject-to-answer-your-question)
- [Feature Request: "WAKE UP and accept my answer please"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50452/feature-request-wake-up-and-accept-my-answer-please)
- [My Social Network Integration for Private Messaging, Commenting, Etc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74952/my-social-network-integration-for-private-messaging-commenting-etc)
- [how can I get in touch with a stackoverflow member privately?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76420/how-can-i-get-in-touch-with-a-stackoverflow-member-privately)
- [Many, many more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22private+message%22)

The consistent response to this is that it's a bad idea, *because*:

1. It could hide information from the community: useful information transmitted privately is unavailable to other readers, subverting the core purpose of the site.
2. It could be used to harass other users ("Answer my question!", "Accept my answer!", "Yer momma so fat she overflows the stack!", etc...)

However, there is [some value](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/29/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/) in being able to communicate with other users outside the context of a specific question or answer. This point was conceded with the implementation of [a chat system](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/15/stack-overflow-chat-now-live/): users on every Stack Exchange site can create and participate in chat rooms, integrated with the normal user accounts. There are still no truly *private* messages between users, but for those who want to chew the fat or discuss *whatever* outside the confines of the sites themselves, this can provide a viable solution.

Finally, it became apparent that *moderators* occasionally need to contact users about sensitive topics, and relying on email for this created problems. [So the ability for moderators to send a private message to another user was implemented](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/02/moderator-messages/). The use of these messages are heavily restricted, reviewed by the system administrators, and reserved for critical messages *only*.

For normal users, the advice remains: if you *want* others to be able to contact you privately, add basic contact info to your profile's bio page.

Comment: "This has been suggested many, many times"  And you continue to deny it.  Your users want it.

Comment: What I really REALLY dislike is that it takes every user a lot of time to find out that this feature does intentionally not exist.  My first thought never was "well, let's see if I even _can_ send a PM"; my first thought just was "Okay, I want to send a PM; where do I have to click?"  And then I went on searching for the presumed hidden button.  And didn't find it.  And didn't.  And got frustrated.  And only much later I thought about searching for the topic on Meta.  I'd suggest to make the intentional non-existence of the feature more obvious. Make a "Send PM" button which displays a dialog.

Comment: @Alfe A button for a *non-feature* is **never** a good idea. Next thing you know, there's one that says *"Make me a sandwich"* which displays a dialog: *"We're sorry, we are currently unable to transform you into a delicious snack. Stay tuned though, as we are working with CERN and NASA on it!"* I would reckon that some form of FAQ can address the issue instead, like *Q: "How do I send a private message to a user?" A: "SE believes in open communication and therefore it is not in our plans to introduce private messaging (etc etc)."*

Comment: Okay, that's convincing (non-feature buttons are bad, alright).  Then I suggest a "Why can't I send a PM?" clickable info line somewhere at the spot where that non-existing button expectedly might be.

Comment: This is disappointing. I disagree with most of the reasons why not to implement this. I have a very specific use case: I absolutely DO NOT want to put my email in my profile. But I DO want to let a specific user know my email so that we can chat privately elsewhere. I cannot let him know my email without publicly posting it in some way, because chatrooms are never private. I do not want anyone else contacting me or sending me spam; just this specific user who I don't personally know, except via stackexchange. A PM system would be great for this use case, which I think is pretty common.

Comment: @AndresF.: Your use case suggests a slightly different feature. Rather than "send a private message," it suggests the very specific feature: "Share an email address, privately, with user X." This would solve your problem without having to provide a general private messaging feature. (While I also disagree with some of the reasons not to implement PM, I also agree with some of them.)

Comment: And, very occasionally, users sometimes need to contact a specific moderator over a private (or sensitive) matter, and this policy leaves no reliable way to do that.

Comment: The reason it has been suggested many, many times is that people want it. I have read the reasons for not implementing PM's and find them at all unconvincing. Just allow users to block PM's from people who prove to be pests. It might also be a good idea to display do's and dont's the first time someone starts a PM.

Comment: For the record, my use-case is that sometimes I spend an hour writing an answer - and I'm excited to show the OP, but then the question was closed. I don't want to 'chat' with the OP, but just send them a link so that my effort was not a waste.

Comment: If you want to share your email with another user, you could always use one of those temporary-throwaway-address services, post that publicly, then when the user emails you just reply with your true email address. Anyway while there are many downsides I think I agree with not having it, because 1) harassment would be worse, 2) useful discussions would get hidden.

Comment: Actually beyond harassment you introduce the potential for what I'll call "negative coordinated activity." For example a small group of people could easily decide to jointly downvote every new question that comes in from X user or having Y characteristic. When you force those discussions to be public, you implicitly let other users see that it's happening, and decide whether they agree / optionally counter it / etc.

Comment: @Stephen - Bit late to the party, but brigade plans generally happen on a site other than the one where the brigade will occur.  Otherwise, admins on the site where it occurs would have all the necessary evidence to ban the brigade's participants.  Other concerns notwithstanding, I don't think this is an issue.

Comment: Also late to the party, but, as someone who has been in on-line support for over two decades I'm very glad to *not* have a system where people can message me - asking for free help. My contact info can be found if someone really wants it. But I detest being "spammed". Being able to contact me over a Comment is good enough!

Comment: It might be interesting to charge $1 to send a PM. I'm sure this opens a can of worms. It's interesting, not a deeply considered idea.

Comment: I note that at the bottom of my question, it says, "Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Twitter, or Facebook." I think it should be reasonable to invite someone who has previously answered a similar question, without knowing their "email, Twitter, or Facebook" contact info!

Also note that this is NOT really a "private message," but fulfils the stated goal of fostering good answers.

Comment: @ADTC If the "make me a sandwich" button doesn't work, use the "sudo make me a sandwich button" ([xkcd 149](https://xkcd.com/149/))

Comment: Seriously Mr Anonymous hiding behind "Community Wiki" pseudo alias ? :-))))))

I had to scroll down to timestamp since I was sure that the "answer"  must have been posted 10-20 yrs ago before Facebook, Twitter and Instagram were even created. This is not 1999. You can virtually copy 90% of the things (organization, msg propagation, protection, fine-grained privacy control) that all these services had to design/establish/adapt in a very parsimonious way, not to overwhelm anyone.

Try to reply with something honest, not with 
 platitudes like they came out of Bill Clinton's bottom mouth :-)

Comment: "This point was conceded with the implementation of a chat system... for those who want to chew the fat or discuss whatever outside the confines of the sites themselves" If chat were discoverable, and useful, and used enough to make a meaningful impact on the main site, it would no longer convey any sense of privacy.

Answer (score 155):

I suggest doing this like on Wikipedia.

All registered users already have an email address associated with their account. Add "Enable e-mail from other users" to user prefs. For those who have the option enabled, "E-mail this user" link appears on their user profile. Clicking that takes you to a [form for writing a message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:EmailUser/Jonik).

[image: archived screenshot]

This would be pretty cheap to implement and unobtrusive for potential recipients (opt-in required; email address is never revealed to the sender or general public), yet effective.

Comment: Would love to see this feature around! Private in-site messages would be great.

Comment: post as a feature request.

Comment: There's already a related feature request [right here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user). Seriously though, I'm certain the dev team is aware of this suggestion already; if they don't want to do it, re-posting it probably wouldn't help.

Comment: The freehand circle is awesome, though.

Comment: The SE community features are generally socialistic. This feature provides individualism. With few exceptions (namely reputation, having an identity and moderator/status privilege), you can safely assume any such feature will not be added to SE.

Comment: This is a great idea, especially because it maintains privacy.  I would add to it that when a user enables email from other users, that the enabling user should be able to specify a minimum reputation from which they are willing to recieve emails.  For example, I might not want to recieve emails from anyone with a rep less than 500 or 1000 (to help avoid spam).

Answer (score 79):

Some people argue that private messaging is not a good idea for the community.

This I don't get.

When you disallow private messages you ultimately get people shouting over the heads of everyone else (i.e. over posts, comments) in order to communicate 1-1.

I remember such horrors from other Q&A/Sex-Change web sites that shall not be named where at some point half the questions became `"eh, this question is for [highest ranked C++ guy], ..."`. This might not occur exactly the same way in SO since people do vote down and close annoying messages, but it does occur in milder ways.

Other reasons why it should be easy to send a private message to a member:

1. You may want to ask them a private question or offer them a job.
2. Your question may not to be public for some reason, perhaps due to company IP issues, and so you need to seek help privately.
3. The question may only be answerable by a specific person. E.g. someone who is a writer or major contributor of some library that you use, and posting it on SO might be a big waste of time since very few people use it and know it well enough. This happened to me. I asked a bunch of questions about some library that turns out only select people actually used. I didn't know who they were beforehand, and most of my questions didn't really get answered because the probably missed them.

But above all, I really dislike seeing comment threads that have in-jokes and personal chats. If people want to talk they should be able to do so in private. I don't think that would hurt the site at all.

Comment: Except that important content that would benefit everyone would then be private thereby circumventing the system. The issue is not private messages like "hey, how are you doing?" - it's "hey, you helped me on this problem last time and I am still having this issue..".. now it is taken offline and no one can benefit from the subsequent troubleshooting

Comment: The idea is to enable a private message like "hey, please have a look at this question I posted". And to get rid of personal chats as well. I no longer kid myself that SO has any motivation to allow personal messaging regarding job offers. even though it's perfectly reasonable and fair to allow high ranking participants to contact other participants for such reasons. (definitely better than to allow only paid recruiters to do so).

Comment: (-1) StackOverflow is not a forum, and it is specifically not designed to be a social website. people who want to be spammed can post their email addresses. Everyone else should be able to use the site in peace.

Comment: (+1) I think the reasons Assaf gives would increase the value of SO. I believe the site would be most effective by providing a messaging/contacting service and letting the the culture of SO encourage posting a question once there is one to ASK, as opposed to forcing all types of SO dialog to be public and risk polluting the stream with less relevant content.

Comment: @assaf for that there is http://careers.stackoverflow.com -- check it out

Comment: SO not a forum? Could've fooled me. If I took this question, this answer and these comments and formatted them like a forum, nobody would be any the wiser.

Comment: @user227849 Which is why this question, this answer and these comments are not posted on SO.

Comment: @1999 2 years late, nicely done, I forgot I even wrote this.

Comment: _But above all, I really dislike seeing comment threads that have in-jokes and personal chats._ I couldn't agree more!

Here is a perfect example (and these are high rep members) [link to question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357059/error-sending-file-attached-with-email-html-php)

Answer (score 48):

No there isn't and I like it that way. It's a Q&A site and this strongly encourages that all answers and comments are part of the record rather than, say, the OP and someone else getting into a private chat and solving the problem to the benefit of noone else.

So I'm strongly opposed to private messaging.

<s>The biggest weakness of the current system is that someone can leave a comment on one of your posts, you essentially reply to them and theres no way to bring this to their attention (unless they've subscribed to the question, which lets face it doesn't happen). This can be an issue if you've been marked down and want to correct the issue.</s>

Comment: Yeah, I thought of the possibility that you would end up getting a private chat going on, but what about limiting the number of messages that can be sent? Its just that I get really frustrated when I leave a comment and the questioner doesn't reply to it, and I wish that there was a way to really get their attention (I know that there is the "New Responses" page, but that one sometimes takes a few hours to actually show that there are new responses, and sometimes it doesn't show it at all!

Comment: +1. I always feel unclever when I leave comment on my own answer - basically talking to myself.

Comment: I have met through a StackOverflow post someone else that is closely involved with similar problems to me and I would like to at least offer to keep in touch with them privately, but I have no way of doing that other than putting my email address on the site, which I want to avoid for obvious reasons

Comment: So… you're saying that off topic messages like "Hey, didn't I work with you at DEC?" should be in the public Q&A comments? I hate SPAM as much as the next user but I should be able to opt-in/out of PM's if I want. YMMV.

Answer (score 43):

The ways that propose this is done (and I like the idea):

- Allow messaging only after a certain amount of reputation is acquired. This is to stop a million new users messaging Jon Skeet. But, if Jon Skeet messaged a person with 1 rep, they could respond.
- Allow users to opt out of messaging, and/or set a "reputation threshold". If a users reputation threshold is X, then only users with reputation > X can message them.

I think private messaging would be a great feature. There are plenty of times I want to take a conversation (going on in comments) offline. Also, I have gotten to know/recognize some users as I have used stack overflow because these people post on the same posts I do. It would be nice to be able to recommend posts to people because they might be interested in reading the question or would have good input. I am not inclined to put my personal email on stack overflow, so having an integrated messaging system would be nice.

In fact, if people don't want to have messaging supported, it would be nice even to just have "question recommendations". Just something that lets you say to another user "hey, have a look at this question, you might really like it!".

Comment: I totally agree! In a couple of occasions I wanted to leave messages for other users, but there is no way...

Comment: I also agree. Today I tried to find someone whose university web site has gone away, to ask him, "Are you the Brian who wrote the Freezerware utilities," and, "do you have a new web site?" and I found what might be his ID, but there's no way to send him a message.

Answer (score 21):

By choice, I have my e-mail/blog etc in my profile; but I've spent years on usenet etc, and this information is very easy to come by anyway.

In all the time on SO, I haven't been pestered. I've had 2, maybe 3 people asking me about a question - which I've either taken back to the site, or (in one case) pointed out that I was the editor, not the answerer - and that I couldn't help.

My conclusion is that **in terms of regular questions/answers** there isn't a huge demand for this; the only times I can see it being used are in the off-topic flames etc that start; and that isn't a good thing to encourage.

Actually, I **would** like to have a user-specific **moderator** ability to add a message to a user, but that is because I sometimes need to get hold of people who haven't provided an e-mail address, to tell them why I've done something; or to "cease and desist" (kindly). But that isn't an issue for most users.

Comment: For those reading this later, I believe the idea in the final paragraph has now been implemented.

Comment: @Jon good spot. Of course, in the end it ended up being me that wrote it! Cosmic justice taking over.

Comment: Your first paragraph sums it up for me. Most people can be contacted 1 to 1 either way, if they so wish (by filling out their profile information). SO works so well, because it is fairly simple and straight forward. Adding features on top will just diminish the return from the core use experience, which is, finding answers to questions.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not certain a PM feature would benefit *this* particular site with *this* particular community.

Right now the unavailability of PM creates a certain atmosphere.  Everything you say has to be said publicly, to be rated or berated by the community.

So that's something *special*.  Public communication being the only communication creates automatic policing -- prevents harassment of [certain users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139284/sara-chipps) (c'mon you know at least 10 nerds wrote marriage proposals in obfuscated C++ and planned to post them as comments..) and actually protects [high rep users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77901/thoughts-on-censorship/77966) from private abuse and harassment except [as they would otherwise receive from Jeff Atwood](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/threatening-emails-from-jeff-atwood).

Do you really want people to be able to PM Mr. Skeet and be like

> yo skeet... its dave.. i kno ur busy an all ..

I don't think so. Building messaging into the site has consequences -- namely that consequence that *it will be **used***, appropropriately and inappropriately by certain parts of the user base.

Is it going to add or detract from the site?  I think rolling it out as an *experimental* feature might be a good idea, but I'm *not sure* what its overall effect (+/-) will be to the communication that happens on the site.

Answer (score 13):

It is possible to send semi-private messages using the chat system, at least if you have enough reputation.

To do this, create a private chat with that user. While (I think) private chats can be viewed by others, they don't show up by default so people will only find them if they're looking for them. Also, inactive chats with few messages are deleted after a while, so once that happens they'll be private.

This is not high security, and there's no guarantee others won't see it, but it's good enough when you want to notify a user, but your communication isn't useful for the rest of the community.

Answer (score 12):

I would request this feature due to a situation I recently came by.  I had asked a question and was in the process of trying to find an answer with a particular user (userA).  In the course of working it out with userA another user (userB) came a long and offered the exact answer I needed.  UserB nailed it on the first time.  Shortly afterwards userA posted the same answer in a comment.

Since UserB had far less reputation than UserA and had nailed the answer, I accepted his answer and voted both of their answers up.

I later came back to discover that UserA had voted down my question and deleted all his answers and comments in it, apparently in a fit of rage over my not accepting his answer.

This is a situation where I would very much have liked some sort of direct message to another user.  UserA hadn't posted any sort of contact info in his profile.  And in an effort to contact him and explain my reasoning for accepting UserB's answer and perhaps apologize for offending him, I ended up commenting on one of his questions.

It doesn't have to be private, but I believe that some sort of way to directly contact other users would be of great use to the SO community in situations such as this and many others.  It could be a public wall like facebook, or a direct message - publicly viewable like twitter.  If it contained Q/A information that could be useful to the community at large it could be migrated into a question and answer.

If such a thing existed it would be easier to contact UserA in order to explain that I had meant no offense by accepting UserB's answer and that I greatly appreciated his help!

Comment: UserA frankly sounds like a jerk; you shouldn't have to explain yourself in this situation, accepting answers is done on the merits of the answer, not the answerer's reputation. That's ridiculous.

Comment: @AdrianPetrescu - Well, without being there, you and I can't really know what happened. Maybe UserB only saw the answer because of the collaboration between UserA and the op. Still, deleting all the answers and downvoting the question is a little ridiculous, since a post can only have 1 accept of 15 points but can get many many upvotes that could lead to hundreds of points potentially. People give accepts way too much credence... UserA basically cut his nose off to spite his face. ;)

Answer (score 11):

> Any way to send a personal message to another user?

Yes.

Go to the user's page, click on one of their questions or answers, and leave a comment.

When they next visit they will be notified that you have responded to their post.

It's not a *private* messaging system, but it is a *personal* messaging system, and it's the only one provided by SO.

Comment: Yes, that works, but it certainly isn't ideal, because that isn't what the comments are for.  It subtracts from the flow on the page.  The comments are really only for responding to the answer/question and to clarify a few things.

Comment: @a_m0d, and that's exactly why in-site private messaging IS compelling!

Comment: I could physically do this, but then I'd be polluting that question with non relevant information and noise. Feels very contrary to the beliefs of the site.

Comment: I received just such an off-topic comment addressed to me after a comment I left on a post. It asked why I voted to reject a particular edit. I replied with a comment (same place, so also off topic). When I returned 30 sec later to see if there was a reply I saw that the message-comment to me was gone. So I deleted my msg-response comment also.  So no more off-topic comments at that post. However, I have no way of knowing whether the user asking me about my vote ever saw my response.  Perhaps there is a way to see the deleted comments?

Answer (score 10):

Keeping SO impersonal and limited to a Q&A forum does quite a lot to keep discussions from dissolving into flame wars.  It also helps to keep discussions on-topic, which is a good thing for a Q&A forum.  IMHO, if SO was turned into a social networking site the quality of material would degrade rapidly.  Therefore I think there is a reasonable argument that SO should discourage personal contacts or conversations by design.

If some enterprising bod wants to start a 'Stackers' web site or mailing list they could but it needs to have a certain distance from SO and strictly discourage discussion of SO Q&A material so the actual Q&A doesn't get dragged off SO and lost in the social networking fluff.

It might be argued that there's a niche for a geek version of LinkedIn and the requests for contacts and messaging facilities are indiciative of that demand (in fact, that facility used to be known as 'Usenet' before it got destroyed by spam).

However, the objectives and design for such a site are in tension if not in conflict with the design objectives of Stackoverflow and it should maintain a deliberate distance from Stackoverflow even if Joel and Jeff decide to build it.

Answer (score 8):

I like the idea... I have my email address on my user profile and have gotten several interesting comments from people who don't otherwise seem inclined to post, or where the comments would have been off-topic to the question at hand.

Comment: Yes. Exactly!!!

Answer (score 8):

Rather than posting my email address in my profile for all to see, I'd like the idea of having a section of my user profile that is visible to other users that I designate as "contacts" (or "friends" though I hate that term). I'm somewhat paranoid about posting personal info to the general public.

I don't see the need for private messages / chat / etc., however: it seems like it would be an unnecessary resource drain for this site, something that should be carried on in an out-of-band channel.

Comment: definitely - I would hesitate publishing my home or work e-mail here, too many harvesters........ but I'd like to be able to designate certain people with the right to get in touch with me (first through SO, later directly, possibly)

Comment: I'd like to keep my private information secret. Why would I want to make anything public if I could message system right on SO?

Answer (score 7):

Well I think there isn't any IM sort of mechanism as of now.

However if you only want the target user to look at something, you can post a comment under one of his questions or responses.. that should light up his/her envelope icon. Also consider deleting your 'look here' comment once your goal is achieved. 
Also use with extreme discretion.

I think I've only had this need once - and it was to have a top poster look at one of my questions which didn't seem to be going anywhere with the answers.

Comment: I did try that... It did not go well: the user wanted to flag my comment as inappropriate, since it was not about the current question...

Comment: @VonC, fortunately downvoting comments doesn't have a high impact afaik

Answer (score 4):

A couple of times, I've started answering a question only to see the question closed before I can submit my answer. This can be frustrating and I have even resorted to digging up the user's email address and contacting him that way. Being able to answer closed questions would be ideal, but some way to direct message the user who asked the question would have saved a lot of clicking.

Answer (score 4):

Since one problem is that many people don't *choose* to not put links to off-site accounts but rather *forget* to (me included).

So why not add a <del>Social Network</del> **Related Accounts section** in the user's profile so they realize that this is the only way for people to contact them?

Answer (score -4):

Why not charge for those who wants to send a private message? Most of them are recruiters so they have company budgets.

Comment: As far as recruitment goes, there's already [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: No offense to recruiters or to you, but that just sounds downright evil. Taking money to allow people to bother users who (likely) don't want to be contacted? I think we'll pass. (As a side note, we have 100-ish other sites where the "they're recruiters anyway" line of reasoning wouldn't apply.)

Comment: Sounds cool, I am not a recruiter but I suddenly realize that there's much less hiring ads here than on LinkedIn :) nice point

Comment: This is a free-to-use, community-driven site. I feel like forcing people to pay for a communication feature goes against that model.

Answer (score -4):

Messaging can be enabled by providing Twitter handle. Those users who want to have messaging enabled can provide their Twitter handle. Any messages sent will be sent as a tweet. Ofcourse, max 140 characters!

Comment: How is this the business of [se]? If a user chooses to promote their twitter handle or email in their "about me" section it is their prerogative.

Answer (score -11):

There should be Private Messaging, especially given that there's moderators who close peoples [mine] questions. There's no way to get their attention to appeal. The best you can do is comment on your own question, but this isn't intuitive, will they see this new comment? Who knows.

Comment: They will if you @-mention them by their name. You can also flag the question, which is pretty much a means of sending private messages to moderators already.

Comment: You can flag your own closed (or even deleted) question and appeal.

Comment: @YiJiang your definition of "private" and my definition is very different