# Providing source code as public domain

Tags: discussion, feature-request

One question was so interesting that I worked out a solution as program.
While I would like to share it, I am not happy with the Creative Commons License.
I have read the already existing posts and I find the legal problems as much too
unspecified and problematic (When it is code, when a snippet, does other laws
apply to me etc. etc.)

I would prefer to offer it as Public Domain. No restrictions at all, no enforced
copyleft, no need to tag me as author. The opportunity to get rich by exploiting
me, you name it. ;-)

As the idea of the Creative Commons is that content will be available on SO even
if the author later disagrees, I see no conflict with this goal because releasing
all rights would automatically give SO the right to retain and modify the code.

So, is it possible to post this code under Public Domain ? Or use less restrictive
licenses in general ? I think (hopefully) that many people here would like to share
their code and snippets as Public Domain, too.

Comment: What specifically is restrictive about CC-by-SA?

Comment: Add a license comment that states so. Or add a link to an external repository. Which you should do for longer code samples anyway.

Comment: Enforcement of share-alike (which is copyleft) and that the work must be attributed. Another problem is that I come from another country and it is doubtful that the law *here* does recognize such licenses as legal binding at all. By giving up all rights no legal problems arise.

Comment: @BoltClock What else should it be? The SA clause is clearly copyleft.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/licencing-code-snippets

Comment: Posting code is no problem, you can always dual license or use public domain. There are several users who do that. But SO's current practice is problematic for people using code posted on SO.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Exactly that is the problem why I don't like the CC SA license.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Looks like I completely missed the meaning of "copyleft" back there. D'oh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no problem at all with you posting your own code *somewhere else* and explicitly placing it into the public domain. Such dual licenses are quite common. There's no mechanism for licensing different bits *as posted on the SE network*, but if you distribute the code through your own channel, you may do it however you wish.

Comment: Well, if it settles this...The problem I see here are broken links in future which must be cleaned up. What I do not understand is the argument against less restrictive licenses. Would you support them if someone magically do all the work or is there another reason for insisting on Creative Commons ?

Comment: I was unclear, I guess. Post the code here, *and also* post it elsewhere. When you post it elsewhere, include a declaration that the code is placed in the public domain. Here on SE, just post it.

Answer (score 2):

Anything you produce, you own the copyright to. You can release that to the public under whichever license(s) you wish. (Note the potential plural.) By posting it on SO, you release it under the [CC-BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license. There’s nothing stopping you *also* releasing it under [CC0](http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) or [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/) (or both).

Or you can “release it to the public domain” (possibly). As the FAQ for the WTFPL says,

> Unfortunately, the definition of public domain varies with the jurisdictions, and it is in some places debatable whether someone who has not been dead for the last seventy years is entitled to put their own work in the public domain.

Wikipedia has a template for that: [PD-Self](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Template:PD-self):

> I, the copyright holder of this work, release this work into the public domain. This applies worldwide.
>
> In some countries this may not be legally possible; if so:
> I grant anyone the right to use this work **for any purpose**, without any conditions, unless such conditions are required by law.

This seems reasonable. And I don’t see why you’d need to host it elsewhere to put such a license on it. There's nothing stopping you putting some code here with a comment at the top:

```
// License: WTFPL (http://www.wtfpl.net)
```

That’d be sufficient.

Alternatively, you could put a note in your profile to the effect that *all* your code snippets on this site are available under such-and-such a licence.

<sub>(This answer is licensed under both CC0 and WTFPL.)</sub>