# Are moderators notified about flagged comments?

Tags: support, flags, moderator-abilities, comment-flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)

Since the comment-flagging-system is pretty autonomous (enough flags and the comment will be deleted and a punishment will be issued), I wonder if moderators are notified of flagged comments?

Comment: @Helen, I *could* imagine that flagging posts is different from flagging comments? (But I really don't know.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we see when a comment is flagged, but can't see who flagged it.

We can clear flags if we disagree or directly delete it from the 10k mods page.

Personally, I always check what the context is before deciding what to do.

Comment: Personally, I never clear a flag on a comment, and I never delete a comment unless it's too offensive, but in these cases the community takes care of them.

Comment: Jeff [once wrote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15290/are-all-the-1-comments-really-necessary/15292#15292) *the flagging comment process is basically 100% automated and doesn't require any mod intervention*. Though your answer does not makes Jeff's statement false, I wonder: is flagging very intrusive for the moderators? (Sounds fine to me to advertise something as "100% automated" if mods only see the flags when they really want to. But if the flags are shown using popups with `<blink>` tags and freehand circles, then maybe Jeff's statement should be changed a bit?)