# Are ban suggestions a legitimate reason for using mod flags?

Tags: support, flags, ban

When you cross paths with a troll or otherwise troublesome user on an SE site, is it okay to submit a mod flag that says something like "hey, check out user X in the comments, I think he might deserve a ban/mod intervention"? Or would that be considered an abuse of the flagging system?

Comment: FYI: Flagged to ban Popular Demand.

Comment: @26 years of Welbog: ... by popular demand :D

Comment: @26y: The system does not accept bans longer than a million years or so, so "ten hundred thousand million billion trillion years" is more than I can help you with. Also, this is merely a site about Stack Overflow (the question and answer site for programmers). To ban Mr. Demand from the solar system, you'll have to take it up with the authorities on Meta Solar System.

Comment: @mmyers: Can you provide me with the Meta Solar System link? I seem to have misplaced it.

Comment: @26y: It should be at the top of all Solar System pages. Right next to the Solar System FAQ link. Which nobody ever reads.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Moderators are in charge of assigning suspensions. Flagging for moderator attention is the most direct method of communicating to the moderators.

That said, a lot of suspensions accrue due to a high amount of flagged content. I suggest that if you must flag a user for this kind of reason, flag it because of the bad behavior and not to suggest a suspension. Leave it to the staff to conceive whether suspension is even a reasonable resort or not.

Comment: Ah, perfect. This is the conclusion I came to myself; it's nice to see someone else say it.

Comment: FYI: Flagged to **not** ban Grace Note.

Comment: There is an August 2009 [remark from Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15290/are-all-the-1-comments-really-necessary/15292#15292) **about comments**, stating: *the flagging comment process is basically 100% automated and doesn't require any mod intervention.* If this remark is still valid, then explicit flagging *for moderator attention* might still be needed for comments? (In order to make them aware of any pattern?)

Comment: @Arjan Jeff's comment is true, but in that case you should still flag the moderators to report the comments, not to suggest people get suspended.