# Should we be flagging more comments? Or should the description be changed?

Tags: discussion, comments, guidelines

I'm just going to get straight to the point.

The [comment privilege page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) show us when to comment:

> **When should I comment?**
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the
>   post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a
>   link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the
>   question has been updated).

Now, whether it's on Stack Overflow, Programmers.SE, or any other SE site, I see a lot of:

- "+1 for mentioning [fill in blank]"
- "What a great answer!"
- "I loved this answer so much I just had to leave a comment!"

None of these comments are relevant to any of those guidelines. So my question is:

*Should we be flagging more of these types of comments, or have the guidelines changed over time and just have not been edited.*

**Related:** [Is the official comment policy obsolete, and should we change it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104981/is-the-official-comment-policy-obsolete-and-should-we-change-it)

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't flag them, especially the second two examples you gave (which serve no purpose).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see a problem with those unless they're clogging the comments.  One or two "nice answer" comments aren't going to push valuable comments out of the way.

These sort of comments are just natural, and they're going to keep happening.  Making moderators clean them up when they're not hurting anything isn't a good idea, IMO; the mods are busy enough already.

The description doesn't need to be changed to allow for these comments — it's one thing to say that they're going to happen regardless and another to explicitly encourage them.  On the whole most comment threads are fine, and I think the current guidelines are sufficient for determining when you need to go to chat or flag for a mod to clean them up.

Comment: So my question is should the guidelines be changed?

Comment: +1 - you beat me to it.  Trying to enforce rules against this would be sisyphean.

Comment: @Jae See my edit.

Comment: *(me trolling the comment flags)* dismiss dismiss dismiss (repeat 100 times) oh look a valid flag!  Rainbows!

Comment: The flag dialog *does* have "too chatty" and "not constructive" options. In the rare cases that those "nice answer" comments *are* pushing valuable comments out of the way, you should use those flag options. I do this occasionally, and none of the moderators have tried to beat me with a stick yet.