# Ablity to cross section users

Tags: feature-request, users, tracking

I would like to have the ability to take an users profile on StackOverflow and run a query to see our interactions in the past. Like if he (or she) comments on a question of mine, or I answered a question of theirs, that would show up in the cross section.

One use case for the cross section query is to help with the moderator voting that is currently in progress. Looking over the moderators nominees I recognize familiar names, but I honestly can't recall our interactions in the past or if those interactions were pleasant. Using the tool that I am proposing you could run a query against the nominee and see where in the past your paths have intersected.

Comment: Why would you want to cross anyone, let alone a section user? Oh wait...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is too social for SOFU. The focus here should be on the quality of the questions and answers, and not the interactions with other users.

Your point about the mod elections is valid, but just looking at the candidate's activity in general should do the trick (not just where you were also involved).

Comment: <strike>Some</strike> All of the candidates have long and expansive histories that can be extremely difficult to parse.

Comment: Think of it not as a social tool, but a search tool.

Comment: @James: just look at what they've done *lately*. That'll give you a better impression of how they're likely to act anyway, especially compared to (say) reading questions they posted during the SO beta!

Comment: @Shog9: True, but I see where @James is coming from here. While recent activity is most likely to accurately represent the nominees' current tendencies, one very quickly loses history of comments and editing -- and there is no public, easily-traced history of closure activity. These three things are probably most important to the elections, way moreso than question/answer activity, IMHO. And a cross-section gives the voters more information which is easier for them to parse by being immediately relevant to them.

Answer (score 1):

This would be great for when you know someone had answer or comment you liked, but you can't remember which question to look under for it.  The **user:** advanced search feature is limited.

Answer (score 0):

But I don't *want* to be cross sectioned! It sounds painful, and messy...

Comment: Nonsense, you'll love it. Now hand me the saw!

Comment: Judging by your picture, I think you've already been cross sectioned.

Comment: I've been already cross sectioned *in the future*. Probably due to the implementation of *this very suggestion*...
(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/how-user-messaging-could-be-realized)