# Rolling back post edits occasionally kills formatting

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, rollbacks

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628966/what-are-the-main-php-5-myths-you-have-to-confront), closed yesterday, was bumped by its OP requesting reopen votes. I decided to roll back the edit (I know this doesn't 'unbump' it but that's not my point), but it seems the formatting has gone kaput and no longer works. However, if I click on 'edit', the formatting shows up OK in the editor's live preview. Resaving the edit doesn't fix the problem though.

This is my first rollback on a closed question, and it's also the first time I see this error so I'm wondering if it has anything to do with its closed status.

**EDIT:** R. Bemrose chipped in with an extra newline and the formatting is back. But I did experience the formatting bug when I rolled it back before that.

**EDIT 2:** waffles inadvertently uncovered this issue here on Meta, for [this open question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63270/revision-summary-field-isnt-handling-special-characters-properly), so it's nothing to do with closed status then.

**EDIT 3:** gah, [it just hit me again](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3671900/revisions) on another open question. I think SO doesn't like me rolling back edits anymore. Fixed it also by adding blank lines. I also edited the question title because it doesn't just affect closed questions.

**EDIT 4:** looks like this is affecting [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/how-user-messaging-could-be-realized/11499#11499) too, thanks Shog9.

### FOR REALS THIS WAS FIXED

Comment: Can you explain what formatting broke, exactly? As you mention, the revision history does not show the issue; moreover, I have done rollbacks on closed questions without seeing any noticeable deterioration, so knowing what exactly broke would help in trying to replicate it.

Comment: @Grace Note: all the formatting disappeared and the formatting characters showed up in raw plain text.

Comment: It appeared as plain text with no line breaks.  I didn't think to view the HTML source to see what it looked like.  Even the link section at the bottom appeared in it.

Comment: Confirmed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63270/revision-summary-field-isnt-handling-special-characters-properly

Comment: I've seen this too. It's really getting on my nerves...

Comment: So this is just `[status-wtf]`? Hit me too today and its especially annoying when already dealing with a messy question.

Comment: Well, this just happened on Gaming earlier. Really made a mess of the question and drove me nuts. Wonder what the cause is...

Comment: @GraceN: fixed.

Comment: [Reproduced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/how-user-messaging-could-be-realized/11499#11499)

Comment: @Shog9: **on one of Welbog's posts at that!!!**

Comment: Heh... FWIW, the reason for the rollback was a previous bug that truncated long posts at an arbitrary point.

Comment: [Screenshots](http://meta.ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/306/markdown-isnt-parsed-after-a-question-rollback) of another occurrence

Comment: My bad, will be fixed in the next deploy

Comment: fixed now (on meta) will be rolled out on the rest of the sites later

Comment: @waffles: thanks! Was that **FOR REALS THIS WAS FIXED** edit there to test the fix? :)

Comment: @Bolt yerp, it was :)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that post rendering is skipped after a rollback and the result is saved in a cache. Changing the source forces a rerendering and fixes the issue -- even if the change doesn't actually translate in a rendered difference.