# Rollbacks are breaking links

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, rollbacks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rolling back post edits occasionally kills formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63390/rolling-back-post-edits-occasionally-kills-formatting)

If you rollback an answer, the links/formatting is broken.

Let's take [this answer f.e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075769/getting-up-to-date-with-the-new-features-of-c/3075783#3075783). It seems like that the markup is not parsed, but if you have a look at the revisions or you click on edit, everything is fine in the preview (and most likely it will be if you hit save).

Comment: This is a known bug - see: [Rolling back post edits occasionally kills formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63390/rolling-back-post-edits-occasionally-kills-formatting) - and yes, it is very annoying.

Comment: @Shog9: Good find, I missed that one. Voting to close. ;)