# Reduce the threshold for comment deletion with flags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, flags, deleted-comments

I have it [on good authority](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138119/if-you-really-want-to-reduce-the-snark-level#comment387982_138119) that it takes six flags from ordinary users to delete a comment.  This makes no sense;  it only takes five community votes to close a question, and three to delete a post.

[Comment flags are not surfaced to 10K users.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93623/feedback-on-tools-flagged-changes)  That makes it harder for the community to handle comments on its own (without moderator intervention), and essentially limits the audience for comment flagging to the participants in the post.

Please lower the threshold for deletion of comments from six flags to three.

Comment: Sounds good to me. From what Anna Lear said earlier more than 2 flags is already rare

Comment: Looks like my info was slightly off. The actual formula is `3 + Score / 3`. Doesn't seem like it exactly works like that, though, cause comments with 0 score aren't deleted after just one flag. (Also, comment flags age away after 4 days.)

Comment: Um, it depends on your order of operations.  If the score is zero, it should be `3 + (0 / 3) ==> 3`.  A comment with a score of 3 would require 4 flags to delete.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, apparently I just suck at reading math. Which is ironic, being a math major and all.

Comment: Honestly, it's starting to sound like we need an etiquette guide for comments.

Comment: That last thing you said - that's the right answer.

Comment: Wish I knew how to write it.  My threshold for rudeness/incivility is higher than yours.

Comment: If this is status completed, maybe re-open and self-answer to describe the new rules?

Comment: @AnnaLear: You mean you forgot "Please Excuse (My Dear) (Aunt Sally)"? :-) Must've been all that high-level integral stuff.