# Comments looking odd to my answer

Tags: discussion, comments, edits, answers, feedback

I am writing an answer and someone gives some comments for my answer. I faithfully change my answer based on the comments and my answer looks the best now. Yet the comment added before remains and looks odd to my perfect answer.

Anyone reading my answer would go through the below comments and he would be definitely confused. What can I do to remove those comments? of course I am happy they helped me frame a perfect answer

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Ok. .removed the feature request tag. Just the difficulty here

Comment: You could `@reply` and ask for the now obsolete comment to be removed. If it doesn't happen, flag the comment as obsolete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reply to him/her and tell them that you have updated the answer, and ask them to remove the old and odd comments. Wait for some times until he/she removes the comments.

If still the commentator does not reply then you can flag it as *obsolete*. If a moderator finds it okay then they will remove it.

Comment: will the moderators also check whether my answer is correct. I also want my answers to be verified since it is going to be there forever  :)

Comment: @Sibi - It depends on the comment. E.g. if you flag a comment like *your answer is wrong* as obsolete then moderator will see your answer (IMO).

Comment: Worth to mention here that flags alone are usually enough to delete comments. For comments having two upvotes or less [three flags are enough](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138168/reduce-the-threshold-for-comment-deletion-with-flags?lq=1#comment388189_138168) to auto delete it, without a moderator intervention. So in most cases users will flag as "obsolete" all by themselves and the comment will be gone quite quickly.