# Can obsolete comment flags be added to the review queue?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, flags, comment-flags

An issue was raised [on the Arqade Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8361/31825) by a user who was mass-flagging obsolete comments. The moderator over there [claims](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8363/31825) that the mod team of 6 (soon to be 9) mods cannot handle that amount of flags.

Can a review queue be added for obsolete comment flags? I don't see why handling such flags have to be a mod-only activity that high rep users cannot help out in.

Comment: Closely related and might be a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213694/152859

Comment: Reading through that post, the problem is in mass-flagging. If that is not done, or even made impossible (*"We're actually thinking of blocking this script from functioning any further on our API."*) does this still need a solution? These comments are no problem that needs an immediate solution, so if you just flag them when you encounter them, I wonder if there is a problem left that needs to be solved.

Comment: Note: Users _can_ get rid of bad comments; I think 3 obsolete flags kills them. But yeah, a queue would make this actually useful.

Answer (score 7):

This was suggested in comments here https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180086/147247 and in an answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180327/147247 and got thrashed out a bit if you'd like a starting point for the details.

- It was just to be another queue, and would show the question and all the comments on it
- there should be a link to edit the question since once a comment has been edited into the question it's obsolete
- some people were concerned because deleting a comment cannot be undone

Comment: Interesting on that last bullet-point, since *that* has changed since then.

Comment: @FEichinger to be specific, only mod-deleted comments can be undeleted. But that's tweakable I guess.

Comment: @Manishearth Well, yeh, but the functionality exists *at all* now, which is a big improvement over the last time this was brought up.

Answer (score 2):

I support this feature, and I don't see any reason why we can't have "Too Chatty" in the same queue.

It's really not that bad if comments get deleted, in fact it happens all the time; I think this would be a really great way to take more work off the moderator's plate and let them work on more important problems.

I do think that this queue should have quite a high rep threshold, though, as it's a "deletion" queue. Probably 10k, and it would require three votes for instant deletion.