# How to contact a StackOverflow user?

Tags: support, users, contact

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a way to contact another member of stack overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18266/is-there-a-way-to-contact-another-member-of-stack-overflow)
>   [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

Why there is not a way to contact a user?

There was a question on email/multiplart and spent **30 mins** figuring out the problem. And when I was about to click Post Answer the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272095/php-mail-attachment-appearing-as-text-in-inbox) got deleted?

Now I desperately want to show [abs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51649/abs) his sins.

Comment: No, there isn't a way to contact another SO user directly. I'm almost certain that this is intentional as the potential for acrimony is far reduced without the ability for back-channel sniping. And wanting to show **anyone** their "sins" is pretty much fightin words (even if you were using "sins" in a metaphorical and humorous sense).

Comment: How would you know the question asker deleted their question themselves?

Comment: This question got derailed because the asker had a somewhat malicious intention (Grace, learn not to do that).

Anyway, I want to contact someone for a good reason. Why can't I do that?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that showing someone the sins of their ways is precisely why there is no easy contact mechanism. If something is relevant to the the conversation at hand and a question, then it by definition should remain on the site, or here on meta. If it isn't, then I don't blame SO for not wanting to get involved in things outside its ken. I've had questions deleted after having worked on them too, I'm sorry for your time loss. It just means you're a hard worker, and you'll be a good member of the SO community over time, that's all. :-)