# How can I get the email of a stackoverflow user?

Tags: discussion, email

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I contact a stack overflow user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15969/how-do-i-contact-a-stack-overflow-user)
>   [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)

How can I get the email of a stackoverflow user?
(or how to contact him)

Comment: Find their website (if they're on SO, they're reasonable likely to have one) and then see if there's an email posted there.

Comment: belongs on meta, if there even

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15969/how-do-i-contact-a-stack-overflow-user http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57532/how-to-contact-a-stackoverflow-user-closed  and various other.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Read your own profile. The e-mail box says "never displayed". The closest we have to private messaging is commenting as a reply to that user.

(In before migration)