# How do I contact another user?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)

Is it possible to contact another StackOverflow user? He had the exact same problem as me and I'd like to find out if he ever solved it.

Comment: If you have commenting privileges, you could comment and ask him about that. (but seems you can't). I guess the only way is asking it as new question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user's profile has an email address, you can contact him that way.  You can get to his profile by clicking on his name.

If the user's profile doesn't have an email address, that means the user has chosen to interact only through the site directly, and does not want to be contacted privately.

Answer (score 2):

The user's profile may have a link to a web site (maybe a blog) which could have contact information.