# Calling the attention of a particular user to a question

Tags: feature-request, notifications, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)

Is there a way that we can call the attention of a particular user by just mentioning her/his name in our question? I have some follow up questions that I wanted to be answered by a particular user, but since it's an old question, it will hardly get that person's attention.

Can this be added as a new feature?

Comment: *i have some questions that have a follow up questions that i wanted to be answered by that particular user* — SO is not your personal helpdesk!

Comment: (And please use proper uppercasing. Thanks!)

Answer (score 4):

I just answered this question within the last few months, but can't find the dupe.

The short version is this:

SO doesnt support personalized support requests.  If it did, the experts would be constantly battered by specific requests for both difficult questions and trivial questions. It doesn't scale well, and those that contribute the most would eventually be driven away.

Second, your follow up question is as likely to be answered just as well by someone else as your original question was when you didn't know who might answer it.  There's no need to specify a particular user just because they helped you in the past. Lots of other users are perfectly capable of answering a well defined, complete question.

Lastly, if you really want to get the attention of the person who answered you last time for your follow up question' it's easy to do so.  Post your new question, then add a comment to their answer on your old question asking them to take a look at tour follow up question. If they visit the site and pay attention to their comment notifications, and most of the experts do, then they will get your message.  They may even answer your follow up question if no one else has answered it by then.

But chances are good that someone else will beat them to it, and so much the better for you.  Fast answers to good questions, isn't it great?

Answer (score -1):

You can get another users attention by mentioning their name after the @ symbol in a comment.

Comment: Only if they've already posted in the question, I think - you can't draw e.g. Jon Skeet into your question by mentioning him which I think is what OP wants.

Comment: @Rup - You are right. Check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work?rq=1#comment380372_43020).