# Route a question to certain user

Tags: discussion, users, private-messaging

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Ask a question and notify users on specific users list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71727/ask-a-question-and-notify-users-on-specific-users-list)
>   [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

Is there any way that a user can route a question or notify other user about it? For example I found a question that I know that certain user can answer, is there a way that I can notify this user about this quesio

Comment: What if the other user doesn't want to be notified?

Comment: then he can configure that, should be there in his options

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user), [How do I contact other users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users), [Calling the attention of a/some paticular user/s to a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88827/calling-the-attention-of-a-some-paticular-user-s-to-a-question)

Comment: I think that you'll find that as it is now, you'd get a much more receptive answerer who is interested in your question and wants to provide an answer and who finds it on her/his own, not someone that's "paged"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No, there is no feature on the site that allows you to do this.**

Put yourself in the other user's shoes. Do you want anyone and everyone to be able to spam you with links to questions? I didn't think so.

The Stack Exchange sites are not social networks nor forums. There is no support for sending private messages to other users. That's completely by design and unlikely to change. <sub><sup>(And if it ever does, you'll see a whole bunch of us leave. I'll be first. Form a line—single-file, please. No shoving.)</sup></sub>

Of course, if a user chooses to disclose his/her contact information in their profile, you can use this to contact them. Or if you both hang out in the same chat rooms, you could post a link to the question.

Answer (score 2):

**No**.  This functionality is not available.

Further, I don't believe this will ever happen as it's designed to be a community website, not a message board from one user to another.