# No Answer Accepted For Old Question

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature)

Is there any facility to force an acceptance of an answer if the OP doesn't?

For example, I've answered numerous questions by users with 1 reputation or by users with a very low acceptance rate (on SO or other SE sites). If the OP never accepts my answer - or someone else's - (even if it's correct, and they may have posted comments related to it) is there no way for it to be accepted?

I'll admit, this question is purely related to reputation (mine). But I'll be honest... it makes me not want to waste my time answering questions from new users or users with low acceptance rate (and I'm sure I'm not alone here). I'm totally fine with a better answer being accepted, but when no answer is selected and the OP has obviously abandoned the site or just doesn't care about selecting an answer, it just makes me not want to bother. If I'm going to spend 20-30 mins creating a jsFiddle or otherwise writing/testing code only to see that no answer (mine or anyone else's) is never accepted, it irks me.

And yes, I'm generalizing in the 1 rep users. I'm sure that there are tons that will continue to use the site properly, but I'm also sure that there are an equal (or greater) number that post one question, read the answers, and walk away. From a rep perspective (and my personal experience), answering questions from 1 rep users then never seeing an acceptance really aggravates me.

So, I suppose my question is - is there nothing that can be done in these scenarios? Email follow-up to the OP? High-rep users allowed to accept an answer? Moderator intervention if a question (with 1+ answers) goes "unaccepted" for a year or more? I don't have a solution, but I do see it as an issue.

Comment: So, the answer is: currently no, but there's a feature request for that. (Or maybe [How do I contact other users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users) can help.)

Answer (score 0):

A low acceptance rate is a deterrant. Plain and simple. And you should also not force anyone to accept an answer, since the correct answer is in the eye of the beholder.

There are a lot of questions regarding this and this has been talked about a lot.

Comment: As I said in my question, I'm sure it has been talked about a lot and I'm not the first one to identify it. I just haven't been able to find any concrete (or even play-doh) solutions to it. I apologize for the rehash, just didn't know where else to turn other than here on meta and asking (isn't that what SE is all about? :)

Comment: I actually removed that noise from your question, @dosboy. Being sure is no excuse to stop searching! ;-)