# How to send Request to join room to particular user on Stack overflow?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)

I want to send request to user to join my room on stack overflow for android ? how can i send the request ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post a comment somewhere? Of course, you've probably got to post it on one of his answers or questions, and label it @user's name, so that he will definitely get it in his inbox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if the label @ user's name doesn't works. Just like your's @Thursagen