# How can I invite people to my chat room?

Tags: support, chat

I have created the chat room for magento. I would like to invite top users of magento tag. How can I do this?

Comment: Manually, one by one, on the room "info" page.

Comment: possible duplicate: [How to send Request to join room to particular user on stack overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98617/165097)

Comment: @Thursagen that possible duplicate appears to be irrelevant; it also states that it is a possible duplicate of another question which was closed nine years ago, but the link to what it duplicates is broken.

Answer (score 23):

If those users are not already involved in "chat", then there is (by design) no *direct* way to do this unless you are a moderator, as we do not want users bugged unless they want to be there. If they *are* on chat, you can request them individually, but please don't get carried away there. Where there *is context* you could also add a comment in the Q&A site "we could discuss this more in chat [link]"; however, again: do **not** go and spam everyone with a link - that would be... unappreciated.

We are also considering beefing up our relationship of rooms to tags, which would allow us to do a very targeted display of on-topic rooms, so the users could see the room naturally in the Q&A site.

Answer (score 14):

To invite a user to a room, the particular user must be in chat. Once the person is in chat, you can click on their avatar & select: "Invite this person to a room.."

[image: Invite user to chat]

Alternatively, you can drop a comment to the user with a link to the room requesting the user to join the room