# How can I ask someone to chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I invite people to my chat room?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99393/how-can-i-invite-people-to-my-chat-room)

I want to start a chat with someone on Stack Overflow, but I have never used the chat rooms before. I've created a chat room. Now how can I invite him to the room?

Comment: Have you interacted with the person before, eg in comments? That would be the most natural way then....