# Where should I put a question for the author on stackoverflow?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)
>   [How do you ask a question in another question and not have the moderator delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114494/how-do-you-ask-a-question-in-another-question-and-not-have-the-moderator-delete)

My answer was deleted

( [How to obtain model attribute or spring's bean in sitemesh decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952755/how-to-obtain-model-attribute-or-springs-bean-in-sitemesh-decorator/8412094#8412094) )

because it wasn't answer (I have the same problem, but I don't have enough reputation to comment the questions or answers).

Where should I ask it in order to not duplicate the existing question? 
The answers provided there didn't help me.

Thank you!

Comment: The title does not match the question in the body. What do you want to know? Maybe [How do I contact other users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)

Comment: I want to ask an author of this question if he solved the problem and if he can help me with it. I cannot comment the actual question

Comment: Then you're stuck and need to earn some more reputation first. After that: the question above. Sorry, welcome... (See also the "Linked" section in the rightmost column of the question you linked.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You posted this "answer":

> I have the same problem. Have you solved it somehow? Thanks!

The information that you have the same problem helps nobody, it is just noise. It certainly is not an answer. So the answer to "where do you put that" is "nowhere".

That said, here are a few Meta questions that could be of interest to you:

- [What to do when your question has an old, stale, unanswered duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40389/what-to-do-when-your-question-has-an-old-stale-unanswered-duplicate)
- [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)
- [How do you ask a question in another question and not have the moderator delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114494/how-do-you-ask-a-question-in-another-question-and-not-have-the-moderator-delete)

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest that if the answers to the original question didn't solve your problem, **you don't have the same problem**. If and only if that's the case then it is perfectly acceptable to [ask your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

To make sure it isn't a duplicate and doesn't get closed as one, you could:

- Hyperlink to the original question from your question, and explain why your problem is different and why the answers to the previous question didn't help.
- Take care to explain your problem well and include a (preferably, compilable) piece of code that illustrates your specifically problem.

But note that posting your own version of the question as an answer on the original question is never acceptable, regardless of whether you have enough reputation to post comments or not.

Comment: Thanks, the old question wasn't answered. I just didn't want to duplicate the question

Comment: it's possible that the old question wasn't answered because it was badly written. If you write your version of the question better, and attract an answer, you'll be providing a service. It's also possible that the old question was just asked at a bad time, when someone who could answer it wasn't around. Your question still serves a purpose since it may attract an answer. Eventually the two questions may be deemed duplicates, but if you try on focus on writing a great question, with the info someone needs to answer, you'll be helping yourself and the site.