# How do I ask a question related to someone else's post?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I'm new to this forum and I'm reviewing the following post:

[AS3 using PrintJob to print a MovieClip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422259/as3-using-printjob-to-print-a-movieclip)

I want to ask a question specific to this post… how do I do that? All I see here is "Post your Answer". Surely you don't just start a new thread?

Comment: First of all, welcome! Are you looking to ask the question owner something, or are you wanting to ask a similar question?

Comment: As Jesse said, welcome! Second of all, great job at coming to the meta to ask about what you should do (that is actually the correct thing to do to come on the meta to ask about it!)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114494

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ask the OP to clarify something, you should leave it as a comment on the question.

If you want to ask a question related to the original one, ask it as a new question but add a link to the original one, referencing it.

And we don't really do threads on stack exchange :)

Comment: Chat is also an excellent place to ask a question about a question. However, you will need [20 reputation to talk in chat](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat) and [fifty to leave comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) (you can always comment on your own posts).

Comment: The OP doesn't yet have 50 rep on SO, so commenting on others' posts isn't an option (right now).

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to flag like that. It just increases the mod's workload, esp. on SO.

Comment: I agree @nhahtdh - but it is a workaround

Comment: Please don't suggest that low rep users abuse the system by posting comments as answers and flagging them. While this might work on some smaller sites it's not a good idea at all on Stack Overflow. You are more likely to get the "answer" down-voted and deleted.

Comment: @chrisf I removed my 'update' - forgot the dramatic scale difference...

Comment: Thank you for all of the info above. It does help considerably. From this it seems like I should just ask this as a new question and link to the original.