# Do you think SO turns you into an answering machine by disallowing personal communication?

Tags: discussion, community

It is forbidden to send [private message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) to users. It is forbidden to leave [comments that are not related to the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57538/174127). It is allowed *only* to answer questions.

Do you feel that these constrains are turning you into an answering machine forcing you answer more questions and in this way increasing the price of Stack Overflow for the people behind it?

Comment: Yeah, sure, this feels like it was asked in good faith...

Comment: It would be nice if downvoters would leave short comment.

Comment: Ok, people think it doesn't even deserves a comment.

Comment: Downvotes are anonymous by design. On meta, they mean "we disagree with you". Nobody owes you a comment for a downvote, the downvote itself is comment enough.

Comment: @meagar SO imposes dictatorship and it's not set by community, but by a limited number of people.

Comment: @LonelyOne No, the community defines how SO works. If you don't like it, you're at odds with the community, not some StackOverflow "dictator".

Comment: @meagar Yeah, we've been told that too, roughly 65 years ago.

Comment: @LonelyOne Elaborate please. Did you just compare SO to the Nazi's? Because that's going to fly really well.

Comment: There is [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)...

Comment: @meagar (You could think of USSR too.) No, by no means. I just feel a this constant pressure and I wondered if the others also do. And it remembered me some examples from history. I could go to other websites. However that's not so easy. This brilliant idea with rep has brought may brilliant people here, you can get feedback on your code from the top of the top. Those people do not visit forums, at least such forums I'm aware of. That's why I'm forced to stay here.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I'd like to have public communication. Chat is also public but it's visited by several people only.

Comment: And the reason "brilliant people" come here is because we are strict on the rules, because we don't allow mindless chatter, and because we allow people to focus on what they're interested in. The rules aren't arbitrary; they're here for a reason.

Comment: @meagar There is talk page at Wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Using_talk_pages

Comment: "Do you feel that these constrains are turning you into an answering machine forcing you answer more questions." You do, of course, realize that answering questions is the entire purpose. People ask questions. Other people provide answers. We're not another social network.

Comment: @LonelyOne And we have chat. If you really want to talk, the option is there. But it doesn't belong on the main site where it would clutter up the Q/A format.

Comment: @meagar People cannot be invited unless they've commented somewhere and one references them with '@'.

Comment: @LonelyOne Good. I don't want to be invited to a chat about something I haven't already expressed an interest in.

Comment: @waiwai933 absolutely not. A lot of them are answering newbie questions here. So I do not see how can they be focused. Top experts had a lot of friends/colleagues to discuss there questions before.

Comment: @meagar This is good point. However you do want to get acquainted with some other people here, or? If so, there is no *legal* way to do it.

Comment: @Lonely, *that's not the point of the website.* Again, it's about *asking* and *answering* questions. If you want to get acquainted with people, view their profiles. If they are so inclined, they'll provide means of communication: an email address, blog, or website. Maybe they'll show their twitter or facebook. Follow them with these vehicles, Stack Overflow is not meant to replicate that functionality.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I see your points, but imposing this and other rules you make some people suffer (I know people, that are suffering because of other rules. I will not name either other people or rules. I do not want to disclose their personality and also I want to make this discussion focused.)... that has actually brought me to asking this question.

Comment: You really *should* [take this to chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta). It doesn't seem like the sort of thing that's going anywhere here; if you're wondering about the reasons behind no private messaging or lengthy comment discussions, these are well-discussed in various places here already (you've linked to one of them).

Comment: This "closed question" explanation looks like a copy/paste from SO. Perhaps it should be somewhat more specific to meta, since I do believe opinions and debate are allowed here?

Comment: @TLP I think the whole format of Q/A does not fit meta at all. Once you've came up with some questions that "community" in the face of up to 15-10 don't like, you'll be banned for asking. Is this really what we do in real life?

Comment: @TLP Imagine you've banned opposition party from saying something after it has said, something you do not like. That is exactly what is happening here.

Comment: @Beginner You've been banned for asking questions? It happened to me as well, for what I saw as very flimsy reasons. They have an automatic filter (which IMO is a little too sensitive), so don't take it personally. You can appeal the ban by emailing team@stackoverflow.com. Also, it is easy to go on tilt here on meta, so go easy, read more than you post.

Comment: @TLP Yes, I was. That's why I created another account to ask. But they detected me (let us think it was automatic and not spying because of this question) and merged this question with previous account. I do not want to appeal. The whole point of meta should be a democratic discussion, not banning. It seems however that "community" has setup other rules and you either must follow them or go away. I'll pick the latter. Fortunately the "community" is not controlling everything.

Comment: @Beginner Like I said, it is easy to go on tilt, and it is clear that you have gone on tilt -- no offense. This particular community is harsh towards new users, and many high rep people post things which IMO are inflammatory and borderline trolling, and yet when you complain, other people side with the "trolls". However, only you can decide if you let that affect you or not. Like I also said: Read more and post less, until you get a feel for the "rules" of the community.

Comment: @TLP Yes, I completely agree with you. I've read your first questions, they are similar to mine. You could read my too. My point is: such a "community" should not call itself *the community*.

Comment: @Beginner There is an inconsistency problem, IMO, between the SO format and the meta format. People seem adversed to repeated questions, very keen on closing questions and shutting down discussion. Something which is good for other SE sites, but hardly for meta, where discussion and new perspectives should be emphasized. Somehow this short circuit mentality leaks over into meta, encouraging people to strive to shut down newbies as quickly as possible. And also encouraging conformity in the community.

Comment: Not exactly seeing the "new perspective" here, @TLP. Stating the obvious isn't insightful; if you walk into your local library and start complaining loudly about the lack of frozen turkeys for sale and how it's a secret plot to make readers starve, you'll be asked to leave... Showing up on a Q&A site and going on about how it's all a scam to get folks to answer questions is similarly ridiculous. Also: **[chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta)**

Answer (score 17):

Nobody is forcing you to do anything. Stack Overflow is a reference, not a forum, and its explicit purpose is to be useful to future users who have similar problems to the ones you're seeking answers for. Your communication is expected to reflect this. If you don't like the format, there *are* forums out there for you, but again: Nobody is *forcing* you to do anything.

Put it this way: Do you turn to Wikipedia for "personal communication"? No. You look there for information. You should behave the same way with StackOverflow. We don't want your personal communcation. We want StackOverflow to be the very best Q/A site on the Internet, and your desire for personal discourse is at odds with that goal.