# can I share my personal contact with users?

Tags: discussion, users

If users ask my personal contact for projects, can I give them in Stack Exchange?

Comment: It's your contact details, you can give them to anyone you want. Just don't blame us if something goes awry...

Comment: In chat room or comment? or i can give anywhere in stackexchange?

Comment: See also [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431) and [How do I contact other users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537) for background discussion.

Comment: thanks man... @AakashM

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Contact information is a fuzzy case. If the following appears in an answer or a comment (or even a question):

> Please email for my project at `NinjaGuruRockstarProgrammer@example.com`

It's likely to get flagged and deleted.

I know because we get flags about it nearly daily.

If you want someone to contact you, refer them to your profile, and have that information in your profile.

You may be curious as to why this is the case.

We get a lot of users that like to say, "hey, email me answer @ ...." or "Hey, what's your IM to help me fix more problems?".  *That's not what Stack Overflow is meant for*.  We're meant to be a Q&A resource.  We can't very well do that if the Qs and the As aren't here, can we?

If you're the lone hapless Googler, what would you rather come across:

- A complete question and answer that solves your problem

or this:

[image: From XKCD]

(Source: [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/979/))

Comment: HEY, THAT'S MY EMAIL!

Comment: I thought you were `GuruNinjaRockstarProgrammer@example.com` ?

Comment: Nope, I was a ninja before I became a guru ;P (seriously though, @example.com would be preferable, some poor soul might actually be using that email, no need to feed it to every spam bot out there)

Comment: I am confused, yannis saying i can give but george saying in "Answer 1" i will get flagged... which is correct ? please any moderator give answer for my question @YannisRizos

Comment: @Dhamu George is a moderator (notice the diamond next to his name). Also, I posted a comment, not an answer (answers are always more serious than comments).

Comment: @YannisRizos ok..  sorry george stocker i didn't noticed that your a moderator.. thanks for the answer..

Comment: I had my Skype ID on my profile for the first few months after being elected. **HUGE** freaking mistake.

Comment: @TimPost My twitter account sometimes attract people who like to discuss their *ahem* concerns about moderation.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker We all get that occasionally. My e-mail is also remarkably easy to uncover. The only thing that was actually 'abused' was Skype, go figure.