# How do I contact the people that closed my question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question)

How do I PM (private message) the people who closed my question? And how do I reopen my question?

Comment: You ​​​​​​can't.

Comment: Questions get flagged or marked if there is a lack of detail or it does not belong to the community (Not programming related). Try posting your question again with greater detail, include examples of code you've tried as well as errors you've experienced. We need to know what you've already tried before we provide assistance.

Comment: `closed as not a real question by Darin Dimitrov, slugster, Yahia, Lucifer, L.B 2 hours ago`  No admins were involved.

Comment: You can't. First of all there are moderators, yes. But it normally requires five people to vote to close your question. Normally when closed it will show why. Also see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: The fundamental problem I see is that you think stackoverflow is a forum, with admins. It's a community-driven questions & answers site where users themselves drive the quality of the content - hopefully for the better.

Comment: I am getting old: What is PM?

Comment: "Private Message". A standard feature on most discussion forums.

Comment: related: [How do I contact other users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

But you can comment on the post to try to glean why it was closed and try to fix your post so it will get opened again.

You can go to chat to try to get them to open it (if they can).

Or you can flag for moderator attention explaining why you think it should be opened (last resort).

Answer (score 0):

The way I've seen some people approach this is by adding detail to their existing question (I believe a closed question can be edited by you), and flagging the post for reopening. The most important thing is to come up with a good description of you problem, and produce reproducible code in an example.

Comment: Doesn't matter if the post is opened or closed. It can be edited (or suggested edited) by anyone.