# Are you able to send another stack overflow user a message?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a specific user a question. Am I able to send them a message or email?

Comment: Dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users

Comment: If that's a technical question you want to ask them, it defeats the purpose of SO. If you want to socialize, it also defeats the purpose of SO.

Comment: Anyone who is open to this kind of contact has an email in their profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I able to send them a message or email

Yes you can send a user message in his chat box *but do not consider it as a social media option you can chat with user to share your question or answer*

The chat option is available on the top on the right hand side of your profile name

There are different chat rooms for each site on Stack.

For meta there is http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/

as like this there are more other chat rooms

for sending mail you will have to manually send an email from your email id if you have any stack users email id

Answer (score 7):

There is no direct way to contact a user by message or email - this is by design, as Stack Overflow (and the Stack Exchange network) is not a social network. It is a network of Question and Answer sites.

You can, however, add a comment to the question or answer of a user, which they will see. If this is not directly about the post, however, it is discouraged.

Another thing you can try is look at their profile - some users do post their contact details on their profile.

Answer (score 5):

No, that is not possible. Stack Overflow concentrates on Q&A and does not work as a social network. You can check the profile page of a specific user and see if he/she left contact information though.

But if you post something and someone comments that you can address him/her directly in another comment with the `@` symbol followed by the user name:

```
@Hank: Example message.
```

Comment: Fortunately. We already have too much of them.

Answer (score 4):

There is no private messaging system via Stack Overflow.  My suggestion would be to look at the users profile page to see if they have contact information.