# How can I start a chat with a particular user?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, private-messaging

While I am searching for answers on the Stack Overflow site, there are some users that know the technology of my concern and have often answered related to the same term that I am asking for.

How do I start a chat with one such user for my answer?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If both you and the other user have at least 20 reputation points, you can follow the below steps to start a chat with that user:

1. Open that user's chat profile link. To find the chat profile link, first, go to the site's profile link (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/users/3061020/jatt-net). Then, follow the relevant bullet for your site:

   - **Stack Overflow or Meta Stack Exchange:** Add "chat" in the URL before the domain name, e.g. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3061020/jatt-net
   - **All other sites:** Follow the link to the user's "Network profile" on the top right corner, which may be under the "Profiles" dropdown. You should end up with a link like https://stackexchange.com/users/3674664/jatt-net, which is the user's network profile. Change the URL to the form `https://chat.stackexchange.com/account/[network profile ID]`, e.g. https://chat.stackexchange.com/account/3674664.

     If the user has marked their profile on the site you're on as a hidden community, or if they only have a profile on one site, the "Network profile" link will not be present. In that case, you can use [this user script](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/blob/master/add-network-profile-link/add-network-profile-link.user.js) which will fetch a link to their chat profile and put it next to the Profiles link. (It works for all users, including non-hidden profiles.)
   - **Note:** In either case, if the user has never visited the chat site before and created their chat profile, you'll get a 404 error when following the above methods.
2. Click on **start new room with this user**, or you can also invite to existing room you're inside.

In case either you or the other user don't have 20 reputation, or the user has never signed into chat before, it's not possible to have a chat without moderator intervention. (Moderators can give explicit chat access that bypass reputation restrictions, and can "super-ping" users to send chat notifications even if they don't have a chat profile.)

If you don't see a "start new room with this user" button, the likely cause is that you've been automatically banned from creating rooms as a result of being repeatedly kick-muted from another chat room. Go to `/rooms/new` on the relevant chat server (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new, https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/new, or https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new); if you get a page that tells you you're banned from creating rooms, you must contact a moderator to remove your ban before you can start rooms with other users (or invite users to existing rooms).

Comment: ok, how to Open that user's chat profile link?

Comment: add "chat" word before stackoverflow in user profile link.

Comment: @ShadowWizard if user never came in chat room then it will give me that user's name in list?

Comment: seems like this method would led to an erroneous chat account unrelated to the main profile.

Comment: There is no "start new room with this user" button.

Comment: I am trying to do this on SharePoint Stack Exchange with `https://chat.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/user-number-here/user-name-here` and it gives me an error in Chrome browser `Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from chat.sharepoint.stackexchange.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards)`.  Should this work on SharePoint Stack Exchange?  (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)  Edit:  Same error here:  `https://chat.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/account/user-number-here`