# Can I suggest questions in the comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, questions

I have asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060108/wellpointed-for-dual-to-prearrow-class) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and have not got an answer yet. I know a person on the site who I reckon to be able to answer it (as they are the author of the library at hand). Unfortunately, I have got no social media of theirs and cannot share the question with them directly. Instead, I have found [one of their posts on a similar matter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31120454/11143763). Is it OK to link my question in the comments? Or just comment the question itself in a concise form? Or is there some other way?

Comment: Related: [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel thank you for your comment - it is useful. If You do not mind, I will leave the question up as I am still interested in what I could post in comments and what I could not.

Comment: Certainly! I have a [dupehammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/295232) and I'm not afraid to use it. I don't mind being commented to have a look at a question or help with moderation (and people don't do it too often), but I state more or less so in my profile. Sometimes I ping a user in chat as well, but only if I 'know' them well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I would say yes!

Just remember to be polite and respectful. I see nothing wrong with something along the lines of:

> Hey, @user, I posted `[this question](link)`<sup>(*)</sup> about the XYZ library. I'd
> appreciate it if you can have a look at it whenever you have the time.
> Thank you!

If they have the time and are interested, they can check it out. If not, they can ignore the comment (or leave a polite reply) and move on; not a big deal. Once the comment serves its purpose, it can be flagged as "no longer needed" and deleted.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> <sub>As suggested [in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351274/can-i-suggest-questions-in-the-comments#comment1176497_351280), it might be better to include the id of the post instead of the link (unless you're commenting on a post that's *actually related* to your question).</sub>

Answer (score 7):

The culture of each SE site (there are [almost 200 of them](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest)!) is different. In my experience most sites are pretty comfortable with an occasional well-placed short comment alerting a post author to a related question, and in some sites it's welcomed and happens all the time.

*In Stack Overflow however* I have received indignant scoldings for exactly the same thing that I've been thanked for in other sites.

One way to proceed would be to just use the single word "related:" then the link to your question. It doesn't say "Can you answer this?" but if they can then and they're active then they may just go ahead and do so.

By the way, an additional benefit to linking to one question in a comment on another ***related*** question or its answer is that *the two questions become permanently linked!* At the top of a question page on the right sidebar (on a laptop web browser at least, don't know about phones) there is a Linked section. All future readers of one page will be able to see the links to the other questions.

This will permanently increase the chances of your question getting an answer because more people will see it!

These are permanent and even if you delete your comment, the items in the Linked sidebar remain.

Comment: This adds ***noise*** to the system if the two questions are not really related (it will affect the content of the "Linked" section in the right-hand panel). It would be better to only provide the post ID.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q `WellPointed` in Haskell is the topic in both posts so it definitely will be better to do as I've recommend. But I'll add "related" to the sentence so as to avoid the erstwhile serene SO suddenly becoming ***noisy*** ;-)

Comment: FYI: I'm on a Samsung Galaxy S8 phone with Chrome browser and there is no sidebar with a linked section but it exists on PC. In fact, the site looks very different on mobile compared to PC, so I doubt it's just an imcompatibility. Perhaps you can probably remove the parentheses part in the fourth paragraph now that you know.

Comment: @mindstormsboi thanks, some phone users use the SE App and some phone users use a browser. Since I don't have the full picture I don't know what to write. Please feel free to edit that sentence as you see fit.

Comment: @mindstormsboi The "mobile" view doesn't show Linked (or Related) questions, but you can see them on a phone (below the Answers) if you switch to the "full site" view, using the link at the bottom of the page.