# People changing other people's tags to make it wrong

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

This happened to me more then once and it annoys me because I (may) get completely different answers.

One example is https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1771216/list. Because of the retagging, my first few responses were C#/.NET-specific and I had wanted to ask about exceptions in general.

Another occurrence is this question
[Why String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) and not str.IsNullOrEmpty()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978000/why-string-isnulloremptystr-and-not-str-isnullorempty). I asked why a .NET class was designed the way it was and someone decided to tag it as C# when VB.NET people could have answered just as well. As far as anyone knows I could have been using VB.

I would like people to stop changing other people's tags incorrectly. I don't know of a solution but I thought I'd mention this for awareness.

Comment: Then add `vb.net` and `C#` to your second question. The point of tags is to have as many relevant tags as possible. Both are relevant, they ought to be used.

Comment: Would F# be relevant? and Boo? and any other language that uses .NET and can call .NET libaries? I cant tag them all (5 limit). Also, i was talking about .NET NOT a language

Comment: @acidzombie24 Yes; you were talking about .NET, but people don't program .NET -- it's a framework, they use a .NET Language. Picking the most popular two will certainly net more views than the generic `.NET` (which, as you say, is not a language).

Comment: This is great man, I hate it when that happens.

Comment: @George Stocker:  I think the point being made is that he was asking a framework question. in that case using .net is relevant, not C# and VB.net

Comment: @Aaron M: Either he wants the best answer to his question, or he doesn't. If he does, including the two most popular .NET Languages as tags will get the most eyes on it; and with regards to a .NET datatype, they are implemented by those two languages explicitly -- making them great choices for tags.

Comment: @George Stocker: No. They are completely wrong. Imagine asking a question about a binary search and somebody adds the tag `Python` to it, just because your code sample was in Python. The same for Cocoa. Cocoa can be accessed using Objective-C, Python, Ruby and Java, should one really use all those tags if the question is about a certain aspect of the framework. This just doesn't seem right. As far as I see it tags narrow the scope of a question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You guys need to really think about this practice of overtagging.

I just saw that Jon Skeet got a [vb.net] gold badge based on the number of questions he answered that were really general [.net] questions -- but had been tagged with both [c#] and [vb.net]

If the question is general (e.g. exceptions) and could apply to both .net languages just leave it as [.net]

Comment: +1 Yeah.. As I understand tagging it is for organization purposes not for increasing pages views.

Answer (score 11):

If it's your question rollback the edit.

If it's someone else's question you have a number of options:

1. Rework your answer to reflect the new information.
2. Delete your answer.
3. Retag the question yourself, assuming you have enough rep and you are convinced that the original tagging was correct.
4. Flag the post for moderator attention, explaining why.

Personally, I'd go for 1 or 2. In rare cases 3 and 4 only if you're engaged in an edit/roll-back war (thanks Bill).

Comment: #4 is okay if someone is persistently rolling back reasonable changes to a question.  Edit wars are (thankfully) a lot less common than they used to be, but we still have to step in and stop one occasionally.

Comment: About rolling back, the problem is i leave after asking a question and can check in after 2, 5, 10 and 20mins when changes may occur. and a lot of answers may be written if i take a 30 min break after thinking about and writing a question with facts to illuminate my example.

Answer (score 4):

Roll the changes back and leave a comment on the question. No more is necessary.

Alternately, edit out the tags, and describe your rationale in the "Edit Summary" field.

Or, inscribe your reasoning on the side of an aluminum baseball bat, drive to the editor's house, and beat him soundly with it. That'll show him...

Comment: It still doesnt show the editor he/she made a mistake. Maybe 1 way user profile comments would work

Comment: You mean private messages? Yeah, that's a great idea. Why don't you suggest it in a new question on Meta?

Comment: It will if they look back at the question.

Comment: Done http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34126/user-profile-comments not a PM but close.

Comment: Good job detecting my facetiousness there.

Comment: this person makes a good point http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user/448#448

Answer (score 4):

If you want language-agnostic answers, add the `language-agnostic` tag to your question.

Comment: Good point. I'll do this now but using library-agnostic. However i still see the same mistake happening but this may greatly help.