# User profile comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, profile-page

> **Related Posts**:
>
> [Private Message
>   Feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4830/private-message-feature)
>   [Any way to send a personal message to
>   another
>   user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

I was thinking about [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34123/people-changing-other-peoples-tags-to-make-it-wrong).

and I thought being able to leave a comment on a user profile would be a nice solution. Once in a while I have a question for a specific person. Once I notice a person doing OSdev and wanted to know about his projects he was working on. I remember a person mentioning a paper he did and I wanted to ask him more. I'm sure he didn;t notice my comment because he has many replies (which get commented on) and isn't on the site for days at a time. If he decided to look at his profile comments I am sure he would have a higher chance of noticing it.

I would like comments on user profiles. I dont think flamewars would be an issue and would be hard to follow if you cant reply back on the same page (you either cant post on your own profile and if you can the other person would be notified of the comment which may slow it down)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

Comment: i didnt ask for a PM -_-

Comment: If you want to contact a user about his or her interests, you're basically asking for PM. Making it a public message on their profile is really the same thing.

Comment: I think it is pretty clear that the OP is asking for comments *on* users rather than messages *to* users. Still a bad idea, but not a duplicate of the linked issues...

Comment: This question isn't a dupe, but a different functionality and should be reopened.

Comment: Re-opened, although it's covered pretty thoroughly in other proposals. This idea traces straight back to http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/16805-user-messaging-or-wall and opens a huge can of worms WRT moderation of user messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can contact a user now by @tting them in a comment on some post, but this just clogs up the post with useless comments.  This proposal would allow the comments to be on some logical place like the user profile.  The profilee should be able to delete them, set a flag on certain users to not be able to comment there, or just turn off that capability if they wish.

The comments would not need to be publicly seen, but only by the profilee and the user who left the message.

There are practical reasons to contact people, and this would keep things the simplest.

Comment: wtf why did everyone DV you? that was stupid. Also when i wrote this @ didnt exist. Now it does and if i wanted to ask someone something they did they'll notice which is nice

Comment: I think most people just don't have the experience.  I've had to actually contact people, and it's a mess trying to get the stupid contact comments cleaned up, sometimes they never are.  It's amazing how reality will change your point of view.  You can always change your accept.

Comment: i did before i saw your comment. Yeah exactly. Accepted

Answer (score 8):

No thanks.

While it seems like a good feature, there are a number of problems with implementing it:

If you implement that, you have to

- add a place on a profile page for comments (add tab)
- Allow those comments to be edited (add edit)
- police for spam (add spam button)
- Add delete mechanism
- Add new relationship to database (right now comments are put on posts, a user is not a post)
- spec, design, and implement this change

Just too much effort for something that doesn't have an immediate benefit that isn't already provided.

If the user wants to be contacted, they'll put contact information on their profile page, much like you did for yours.

Answer (score 6):

If someone wants to be available they can post an email address or link on their profile. If no such link exists, you should assume that person wants to be left alone.

Answer (score 5):

Various forms of private messages have been shot done more times than I can count.

Or did you mean a publicly visible comment on a user? If so, bad idea. Way too much potential for abuse of various forms (I mean, griefing on SO?!?).

The rule has generally been that we rate *content* here, not *users*. Of course, the resulting rep accruses to users, so there is a rough and ready user rating.