# Send a personal question to a particular User?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

Send a personal question to a particular User? Possible?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=private+message

Comment: yes, I already thought that this one has duplicates

Answer (score 3):

You should ask personal questions on [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com).

In all seriousness though.  If you need/want to contact a user in particular, take a look at their profile. If they offer personal contact info, use that. Otherwise, they don't want to be contacted.

Comment: @yonan, well, if I need to contact a user in particular, take a look at their profile.  If they offer personal contact info, use that.  Otherwise, they don't want to be contacted.

Comment: do you? ............... I thought a professional answers a question professionally and precisely. My question is answerable by YES or NO (then some explanations if you like). I remember what my professor said that if someone asks you a question, you should answer what is asked, and what is only relevant to that question. You answer too much, comprehend a little. No offense.

Comment: @yonan, whether or not I do something is not relevant.  You should follow the advice in my answer if you want to contact a user on Stack Overflow.  If I want to contact users outside on the Site, I go to their profile page, and find their information there.

Answer (score 0):

If you comment on a post of the user, they will see the comment. So, you can send a personal but not private question to a particular user.

There's no way to send a private message in SO, but users often have contact info or a link to a website that contains contact info in their profile.