# How can you nominate someone other than yourself for being a moderator?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, nominations

The nomination just began, and I'm a bit confused. I hear "nominate" and don't think "nominate myself."  I have no desire to be a moderator, but I do have people I think would do well in mind.  Any way to nominate them?

Comment: Ask them to nominate themselves...? (Seriously!)

Comment: @Arjan [How](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)? :)

Comment: You're not planning to nominate total strangers, are you, @Michael?

Comment: @Arjan I plan to nominate people that have never been to the site -- I'm out of control

Comment: This is why I wish I could nominate @Michael.

Comment: @badp I [wish I could nominate @Michael too](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/75389/getting-a-cat-when-i-tried-to-nominate-myself)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Community Moderator Election Format and Design](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/community-moderator-election-format-and-design)

> All nominations are by definition self-nominations. Nominating others is absolutely not supported.

Comment: Thanks, that's not on the S.O. nomination side-bar.

Comment: Why "by definition"? I don't know of any definition of "nomination" that excludes nomination by another person.

Comment: It's S.O. definition I think...it should read "All StackExchange nomination are by definition...."

Comment: How about permitting other uses to 'second' you,  or right a short recommendation etc.

Answer (score 2):

see

[What is the reason for insisting on self-nomination?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/what-is-the-reason-for-insisting-on-self-nomination)

Comment: Thank you Jeff, I figured it was something like that, but I had no way of being sure.

Comment: I think its a bad idea to send someone to to Mathematics site when they are searching for how to nominate someone for Stack Overflow. There's nothing intuitive about finding the information on an unrelated site. Perhaps the [Elections page](http://stackoverflow.com/election) should either provide the information directly; or corral all these related questions into a Meta Overflow FAQ that gets cited. The easiest and obvious choice for dumb folks like me is to simply state it on the election's page.

Comment: Or call it "Requesting people to Stand for Election"  - Nominations generally imply selecting someone else.