# Change "nominate" to "volunteer"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, nominations, election

I think using the word "nominate" has caused [some confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75382/how-can-you-nominate-someone-other-than-yourself-for-being-a-moderator) about the nomination process for the moderator elections, as the term typically conotes an action by a third party. I suggest that instead of "nominate", "self-nominate", or "nominee", the word "volunteer" is substituted as it fits the process better.

Comment: +1 'Volunteer' is more specificity suited to the scenario.

Comment: Elections have nominations. The Elected have powers(Much like the mods.) Although the word _volunteer_ has a more altruistic ring to it.  I am divided on the issue. Is the difference on pay? The Elected get paid, the volunteers do not? Because both eventually work for the community(The elected one's are expected to work.) But it's the volunteers who _generally_ work selflessly. But moderators do have an (unwritten) obligation to the community once they get elected, don't they? I guess you have to beat to death the meaning of both terms and how it all relates to SO before deciding to change.

Comment: Someone suggested "application" in a deleted comment, hence "apply" might fit?

Comment: How about at least using "self-nominations" in the banner text?

Answer (score 1):

You don't "volunteer" to be elected into an office -- you are nominated or you nominate yourself.

http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=nominate

> S: (v) nominate, put up, put forward (propose as a candidate for some honor)
>   S: (v) nominate, propose (put forward; nominate for appointment to an office or for an honor or position) "The President nominated her as head of the Civil Rights Commission"
>   S: (v) name, nominate, make (charge with a function; charge to be) "She was named Head of the Committee"; "She was made president of the club"
>   S: (v) appoint, name, nominate, constitute (create and charge with a task or function) "nominate a committee"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominate

> "Nomination" is part of the process of selecting a candidate for either election to an office, or the bestowing of an honor or award. "Presumptive nominee" is a term used when a person or organization believes that the nomination is inevitable. The act of being a candidate in a race is called a "candidacy."

Comment: As someone who actually holds an elected office -- I have 'registered to be on the ballot' or 'filed to be a candidate', but I don't believe that I have ever 'nominated' myself.  (for one -- nomination suggests that it's for an honor, and most municipal officials can tell you, it's not.)

Comment: @joe see also http://www.google.com/search?q=%22self-nomination%22

Comment: @Joe: I guess we're just too used to partisan politics, where typically people get nominated to be candidates for their party, and then the party picks which nominee(s) actually will be their candidate(s).

Comment: @SamB : in my case, it's non-partisan ... we don't even have political affiliation on the ballot for our municipal elections.  Some do, but they rarely go through the primary process.