# is it possible to message another user directly?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

So I saw a really interesting post and it was just over a year old. I was wondering if there was any way that I could message that user directly.

Any solutions?

Comment: If you answer a question or comment on an answer, then the person to whom you're replying is more-or-less notified that you replied. Apart from that, this feature has been requested before (and declined).

Comment: Vote for private messaging here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172688/vote-for-private-messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can comment on that post and the user who posted it will be notified.

Comment: ...the next time they visit.  If they never come back, they may never be notified.

Answer (score 3):

No, but I think it's a good thing that this isn't a feature. Encouraging private messaging inevitably discourages open questions and answers, and since that's what SO is all about I don't see the benefit.

There are times when a more real time conversation would be useful, but that's what chat is for! And as already said, if you just want to notify the user you can comment on the post and it'll appear in their stack exchange inbox.