# Vote for Private Messages!

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, private-messaging

I have an idea! How about we make a fair-and-square vote about whether we should have a private messaging system or not?

You can make a public announcement in the side bar of all the Stack Exchange websites and make a simple poll where people can vote (anyone, without any reputation restrictions).

CURRENT RESULTS ON POLL:
64% (32)    Yes
36% (18)    No

Edit: Please use the poll here instead so anyone can vote, even without 125 reputation: http://www.misterpoll.com/polls/577005

EDIT: I don't have time anymore to do this. I have too much work.

See here: [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user/172686#172686) there are quite some answers that are for PMs.

For spam prevention, it could be possible to block a person from sending messages to you.

There should be a private messaging system if someone wants to give a work offer to someone privately, or if you just want to ask them a very specific question only they know the answer to, or if your post is closed and you want to explain why you think the post should be opened, or if you revised the post and want to notify the moderators.

Also, private messaging allows you to contact people without both sides knowing each other's email. So, that means more people would agree to allow people to contact them.

> Every user on the StackExchange sites has the right to include contact info on their profile page. If they don't, then they probably do not want to be contacted by email or through a private message.

NOT TRUE! Some people don't put their emails in their profile so that there wouldn't be a hundred accounts created using it by some troll! This already happened to me a couple of times.

Also, I agree that the mods would receive a million PMs hourly, but we can limit Private Messaging to people with high reputation. That would keep spammers out, because you would need to work to get Private Messaging enabled.

Comment: A vote? For what?

Comment: Upvote this post if you want private messageing.  Downvote if you don't

Comment: @Bart: Edited the question to answer your question

Comment: Ah, well....I guess you have just created your poll then. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: Isn't this kind of a poll already...

Comment: Repeat after me: Stack Overflow is *not* a social network. Anyone that wants to be contacted can easily add contact information in their profile.

Comment: There should be a private messaging system if someone wants to give a work offer to someone privately, or if you just want to ask them a very specific question only they know the answer for, or if your post is closed and you want to explain why you think the post should be opened.

Comment: Case 1: That's why we have careers.stackoverflow.com. Case 2: If they want to be contacted, they'll have their contact info in their profile. Case 3: Use comments and flag for moderator attention in extreme cases.

Comment: Case 2: What if they don't want to give out their email? Private messaging allow you to contact people without both sides knowing each other's emails.

Comment: Private messaging would drive away our high-quality, high-profile users.

Comment: That's not what I meant in my comment [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172686/152859)... never mind and sorry for misleading you.

Comment: @Andrew Barber: Why do you think so?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It might not be a social network, and yet, we have all the drama, personal relationships, and other associated stuff that comes along with being on one.  If it walks like a duck, talks like a duck, etc.

Comment: Because people would bug them with PM's. Think Jon Skeet or Eric Lippert.

Comment: @casperone that's a good point, imo. It's certainly *different from what we call Social Networks, but I think it qualifies. Not that PMs are a good idea...

Comment: @casperOne: Anywhere humans get involved, there will be a social aspect. That is not to say we thus should make this into a social networking site. It's a Q&A site, we focus on the questions and answers here, private messaging would (in my opinion) detract from that focus. Yeah, it's a bit of a popular phrasing; but one of the arguments I see again and again in favour of private messaging is that people want SO to be a social network, really.

Comment: @AndrewBarber No, definitely not a good idea.  The point being, using "SO is not a social network" really isn't a good answer to this.  There are plenty of *other* good answers as to why this is a bad idea.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't disagree, see my comment above to Andrew indicating that I don't believe that statement is really the proper justification as to why the answer is "no".

Comment: Private messaging doesn't make SO a social network! It just adds a little social aspect.

Comment: Yep, indeed. So....no thanks.

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN There is already a social aspect, it is called _chat_.

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN Can you please update your question to tell us how the feature you propose would be beneficial to the wider community? And by beneficial I mean how it would help in regards to Stack Overflow's stated goal of being a high quality programming Q&A.

Comment: @SamIam: I downvoted because I don't want a poll on private messages, not because I don't want private messages.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen plenty of mSO discussions on this before and even commented on one or two.  A key  point of the SE architecture is to discourage forum chat and flame wars.  A private message facility would do little but enable private harassment of users, both low and high profile.  This goes even more so now that SO is the de-facto go to site for many topics.  Private messages are idiot bait and serve no useful purpose on a site like this but to enable morons to drive good contributors away.

Comment: I just cast my vote by downvoting this feature suggestion.

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN - So, this question currently sits at a vote total of -59. Are you getting the message, yet? The ability to send private messages to users **is not a feature that is needed in the Stack Exchange network of sites.**

Comment: @JackManey: take a look at the poll LINK in the post!!! 64% - Yes; 36% - No;

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN - That's not the poll that matters, and I suspect you know that.

Comment: @JackManey: Please clarify.

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN - I'll use small words, since you seem to be (willingly?) dense: the poll in your question does not matter. The results do not matter. There will not be private messages in Stack Overflow. This question has even been tagged with the [status-declined] tag. That's the tag that is used for feature suggestions that have been declined. Do you understand, now?

Comment: @JackManey: Trust me, one day, one day I will do it. I will make a better Q&A platform than StackOverflow! For now, I have too much work.

Comment: `<sarcasm>`there just are not enough forums, chat sites, twitter, facebook, blah etc out there. we must have private messages on here too.</sarcasm>`. it would be bad for many reasons. - PM: "James, what did you mean on my question, help me please". on the question: "James I've pmd you, can you explain please". PM: "hey you helped with my last question, can you tell me why this badly designed code with many syntax errors doesn't work...". I'd get nothing done.. But mostly, you lose a large chunk of publicly available answers and help if people helped out in PrivateMs

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN - By all means, leave and create one.

Comment: As @JackManey says, your off-site poll isn't at all meaningful for this purpose. Off-site polls are not at all part of the process for determining if features are implemented here. The fact that your poll shows such a widely different result from the voting here should tell you why that is. But ultimately, polls of any kind aren't necessarily the determining factors; plenty of things have been done against the apparent 'will' of the community. (Like the 'problem' title block)

Comment: **plenty of things** have been done **against** the apparent 'will' of **the community**.

Comment: It is a very good idea, and an essential addition to the network.  SE has just become a very negative place recently, unfortunately.

Answer (score 25):

You stated in the comments [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172688/vote-for-private-messages#comment512601_172688) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172688/vote-for-private-messages#comment512609_172688)  that this system would be good for several reasons:

> Job Offers

The [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) should be the place for this type of contact, unless a user has included contact info on their profile page.

> if you just want to ask them a very specific question only they know the answer for

StackOverflow and the StackExchange sites are Q&A, so how would you know that the person you are messaging is the only person what will know the answer?  There are many users on these sites that should be able to answer any of your questions.

> if your post is closed and you want to explain why you think the post should be opened.

Unless your post was closed directly by a mod, then you will have up to 5 people to contact about the closure.  Obviously, if your post was closed there was some reason for it and contacting those involved doesn't mean they will re-open it.  I can just see this type of private messaging turning into arguments about why a post should or shouldn't have been closed.  If you truly think your post shouldn't have been closed, then you have options to take it to chat to discuss or even post on meta to get feedback.

> What if they don't want to give out their email? Private messaging allow you to contact people without both sides knowing each other's emails.

Every user on the StackExchange sites has the right to include contact info on their profile page.  If they don't, then they probably do not want to be contacted by email or through a private message.

I personally do not think this type of system is needed within the StackExchange network.  Currently, you can contact users multiple ways:

- chat - a minimum rep of 20 is needed to talk in chat and at least 100 rep to create new chat rooms
- by commenting on any of their posts and they will get notification

You have not provided any real reasoning as to why or how this will improve the entire network.

My experience on StackOverflow has shown me that even though I don't have my contact details on my profile, other users can get a hold of me.  They will comment on an old answer asking for additional help or request a chat.  In my opinion that is enough, I don't need to be inundated with private messages just because I previously helped a user.

I cannot even imagine the number of private messages Jon Skeet or even the mods would get with this type of system.

Comment: +50 Just got a notification a user is trying to contact me through my blog for help. No private messaging please.

Comment: @bluefeet "Obviously, if your post was closed there was some reason for it and contacting those involved doesn't mean they will re-open it. I can just see this type of private messaging turning into arguments about why a post should or shouldn't have been closed. If you truly think your post shouldn't have been closed, then you have options to take it to chat to discuss or even post on meta to get feedback."  What if you made changes to your question and want the people who closed it to see if the changes make it worthy for reopening?

Answer (score 6):

I don't understand why we need this. There's a way to inform people of another service in the case of privacy.

There are other services that do this much better. Google groups for one can emulate private messaging and private broadcasts as well as public broadcasts.

You can have a secondary email if you want private messaging.

I, for one, have several emails.

Why reinvent the wheel unless you can make a better wheel. And given the structure of the site, we wouldn't be able to outperform existing services in the area of private messaging.

Comment: Sometimes the communication is directly related to SE activity. Most users don't provide a contact method in their profiles. I would normally use comments, but I just wanted this in a case where the user posted a comment complaining about my downvote of his question before he deleted the question, so now there's no place for me to put my comment saying I didn't downvote him.

Comment: That scenario, and all the scenarios I can think of are really trivial giving the grand scope of things.

Plus, the site tends to favor open discussion. Last I checked, you couldn't make a private chat, you could only make speaking allowed by invite.

I'm very careful when I oppose an idea, because I absolutely hate it when people tell me how things are and how they should stay as if their opinion is more important. But in this case it's just a very slightly marginal benefit, for infrastructure that I have no evidence even exists.

Comment: And what I'm afraid, is that any scenario you will think of, you'll be told to invite to chat instead.

They're very adamant here that all discussion is as public as possible.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the chat system, I've only ever used it when continuing a long string of comments in chat. Where is documentation of the chat system? I tried to figure out how to invite him to chat, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think a private messaging system *within* SO has any benefit, since much *better* private messaging systems are already used by people, including email, IM and social networking tools like G+ sharing or facebook lists or whatever they have already integrated into their personal communications.

I feel that the ability to contact a user is a valid feature and as such those options should be clearly available on the user profile where the user can give the best ways to contact them and this be well facilitated by the SO/SE web site.  I think that's already readily available in the profile, if not perhaps as well designed/integrated with the various communications modalities as it could be.

Personally - that's why I put my email there, and I think if someone does not put personal contact details there, they probably aren't interested in you privately messaging them.

I'm not sure it needs to be any easier than that.  There are a lot of casual SO users who barely fill out a profile and I can't imagine that they want to be contacted privately and all these details would be opt-in in any sensible system anyway.

Comment: Indeed; I get enough unsolicited contacts via Twitter, and that takes a couple extra steps.