# Asking specific users a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta

Stackoverflow has no "inbox" for users, yet in some circles (uncommon or new languages, specific topics) there are very few "experts" and some important questions get passed over as a result.  Is there any way to reach out to an "expert" (someone who has answered a question very well in a field related to the poster's question) without violating Stackoverflow rules like

1) Do not comment on one question asking a specific user to look at another question

2) Do not answer one question with a request for a specific user to look at another question?

Why has a messaging inbox not been implemented?

Comment: And [Vote for Private Messages!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172688)

Comment: If we had that, it'd have to be opt-in since not everyone is interested in participating. And then, how useful would it really be?

Answer (score 7):

Because Stack Overflow is fundamentally designed to be about facts, not people; it's really not a social network, and the community will resist attempts to make it into one.

Also, this would allow anyone to pester good users. Good users are free to come and go as they like, and answer whatever questions they like. This makes the site fun for good users, so they keep coming back. Nagging them would be, in the end, very counter productive.