# how to contact people directly thru SO?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, chat, users, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

for example, I answered a question, and PO is interested in direct communication with me. How can he contact me directly? Or how can I contact him directly?

Comment: You're talking about [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951592/which-is-the-best-way-to-encode-batch-videos-on-server-side/4951863#4951863), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you'll see in the duplicate question, it's not possible. Just make sure to log in regularly and you'll see any new comments on your answers in the StackExchange inbox.

Comment: so the single way is to post my email in comments?

Comment: @Andy Or in your profile and hope the OP will be smart enough to view it. :)

Comment: put your e-mail in your pofile and @the OP to view the profile.

Comment: @Andy, if you're paranoid, invite the OP to a "private" chat room, post your mail, then remove the post when they've acknowledged reception :)

Comment: @Ben taking part in chat requires more reputation than comment - this can be big difference when dealing with total newbies in SO. :/

Comment: @Shadow, depends where. [20 for chat and 50 for comment anywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges). And IIRC a high rep user can invite anyone to a chat room.

Comment: @Benj good point, got confused about chat vs. comment anywhere and didn't know about invitation part. :)