# contact a user on stackoverflow if there is no email address in his profile

Tags: support, stack-overflow, users, contact

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

I want to send a private message or a email to a stackover user. Is this possible? Is there any way I can contact him?

Comment: If there is no contact information in the user's profile, the user likely does not want to be contacted..

Comment: Asked many, many times before, even though it was officially declined here: [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

Comment: Having said that, if you want to ask about a question or answer that the user wrote, just leave a comment on it, they will be notified.