# Somebody broke moderator messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderation

[image: you cannot post an additional message]

???

Comment: A *[real man](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83748/eeeek-how-does-this-question-have-28-and-growing-close-votes-without-being-cl/83752#83752)* could still post a message. ;)

Comment: I just realized what happened.  There's a user who is severely butthurt over getting sidelined, and is constantly replying to the initial mod message trying to suck enough butt to get his suspension lifted.  Man, <strike>somebody</strike> Marc needs to test his code a little better.

Comment: Seems to be an SE-wide problem, it's also broken on Skeptics.

Comment: we're deploying everywhere except SO; we'll follow up with SO when load is sensible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the plus side, you don't have masses of replies now... ;p

K, this was me. As you can guess by the message, we were limiting the replies to avoid 28 follow-ons from the same person. I guess I dropped a spanner somewhere. Looking for the spanner now...

Fixed next build

Comment: Somebody needs to buy some more bad code offsets...

Comment: @Will hrmphhhhh...

Answer (score 4):

Moderators have [private messaging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)?!?!?!?!?

## YOU HYPOCRITES!!!

Comment: Awww, you edited it. And I here I was trying to come up with a good Hippocrates joke.

Comment: Stupid Chrome spell checker.

Comment: Well clearly not any more.  :)  Plus they weren't exactly private, which I suspect is why someone is trying to put a cap on them in the first place.