# Can we get a better mechanism to communicate with the OP?

Tags: feature-request, comments

In some posts - we need to ask the OP for a lot of information, since not everyone knows how to post a perfect question.

Currently the only way to do it is by posting comments - which messes the question and usually becomes irrelevant soon.

Example:

1. OP posted a question
2. I comment with request for more data
3. OP edits the post and comments: "Added more data"
4. I comment again - give data of type X
5. OP edits again and comments: "Added data X"
6. ...

Eventually - all these comments are no longer relevant, and not helpful to anyone.

Can we get some feature which allows to ask the OP directly for more information about a particular issue? Or any other idea that can improve this interaction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While flagging the comments as obsolete is useful, consider if the comment can serve a greater purpose: a warning to the future. A user that flies in from a search engine on a specific question, sees the big `ask question` button, and goes for it, might ask a better question if they see a comment that says *What have you tried? How did it fail?* or *Please paste your source code here, not a pastebin, so this site remains a source of high-quality questions and answers*.

Or at least that's my wishful thinking.

Comment: A noble effort. I bequeath upon you unicorn dreams and rainbow kisses.

Comment: @Jeff: ♥ <-- a double rainbow! -->

Comment: One gets the impression that @Jeff's experiments with democratically-run Q&A has severely dented his faith in humanity, at least the *homo netiens* variety :)

Comment: @benjol come with me if you want to live.

Answer (score 8):

Flag the comments, marking them as *obsolete*, and they'll be deleted by a moderator.

Comment: Sounds a bit like an overhead, no?

Comment: @RonK Wouldn't adding in a completely new feature to deal with this one small problem be even more of an overhead?

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just delete your redundant comment after the update?

Comment: I can, but if I delete mine and the OP's comments remain, the comment conversation becomes unclear

Answer (score 1):

Can't there be a "send message to op" button?

Comment: -1 because it doesn't address the return comments and is essentially a duplicate of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user/433#433

Comment: Yup, easy, here you go: `$('#question').find('.comments-link').text('send message to op');`

Comment: You don't have to call it 'send message' - it can just be 'request more info' - same way you do it when QA opens an unclear JIRA ...

Comment: Seems like this should be a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a pattern while going over the recent meta post at [The Stack Exchange reputation system: What's working? What's not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356) and it spurred me to revive this nearly-12-year-old complaint.

Several of the responses there, asked to find specific faults in the reputation system, point at the 50-rep requirement to comment. Of course, this exists for good reason - to keep out comment spam etc. - but there's a clear common reason why people don't like this requirement: because it *prevents new users, who want to help by answering questions right out of the gate, from commenting to give specific feedback* about how to improve the question to make it answerable.

Close-vote reasons don't help OP very much. For example, the system telling you to "add more details or clarity" doesn't give you insight into what people find unclear about your phrasing, or where they see ambiguity in your specification of the task (or description of the problem), or what details are missing. Ironically, the system's communication - both from the shaded blue boxes and automatically-generated Community comments from the review queue - is horrendously unclear and lacking in detail.

Because new users can't comment to explain the issue, they'll post in the answer section. And then perhaps get told off (and downvoted for good disciplinary measure). Getting the inappropriate answer cleaned up requires either public shaming, moderator intervention (acting on a NAA flag) or four actions from the community (a downvote and then three delete votes) - and of course there's no telling how long it will take OP to *see* that answer, and thus whether it was left around long enough to do the job.

More experienced users might be tempted sometimes, too, simply because the comment box is very restrictive in its formatting.

As a 2k+ user on Stack Overflow, there have been times I was tempted to edit a question, leave a bunch of `<OP: please fill in [specific thing] here>` markers for parts I couldn't do myself, and then just leave a comment highlighting the edit and hoping for OP to fix it. This is, of course, **clearly** not an ideal approach.

My overall conclusion is that we really need something **that is not comments or answers** to communicate. Something that:

- builds off of templated messages (to keep the feedback-offerers focused, and discourage them from abusive ranting);
- has a lot of such templates (far more than the number of close reasons, because each close reason could motivate multiple kinds of advice);
- can be designed and tweaked by the community, on a per-site basis (i.e., add/remove/modify templates following Meta discussion, without needing to put in feature requests);
- and most importantly **does not leave a visible trace on the question page after the problems have been resolved**. (One of the biggest problems with comment feedback is that people don't always know they can delete their own comments, and even when they do it takes cooperation to clean everything up. Either that, or spamming a diamond with NLN comment flags.)

The existing chat system could work great for this IMO if the templates were integrated somehow. There would be a chat transcript that would be out of the way, for mod purposes only. It would indulge the instinct/need that many OPs have to discuss an issue in order to figure out *whether there is a site-suitable question in the first place*, and avoid airing too much dirty laundry. And while there is supposedly no sense of urgency to questions, the invitation to *chat* - i.e., *real-time* communication - is a hook to get actual engagement from OP and thus *actually fix the problems* with the question.

Comment: One of the primary purposes of NLN flags is to be used to clean up comments which have been acted upon and are **No Longer Needed**. The problem isn't that such comments aren't cleaned up, it's that nobody involved or reading the question flagged the comments they couldn't personally delete as NLN in order for the comments to be cleaned up. While there might be other reasons to have some additional method of communication, in spite of the fact that *comments are explicitly for that*, the fact that NLN comments are still around **isn't** a valid reason for some other method to be created.

Comment: "it's that nobody involved or reading the question flagged the comments they couldn't personally delete as NLN in order for the comments to be cleaned up." - well, yes. The point I'm making is that we shouldn't make it a social problem if it can be solved at a technical level. We can identify, algorithmically, a category of content to act upon automatically. We shouldn't create button-clicking busy-work for ourselves past that point.

Comment: So, how to you programmatically recognize that content? How do you programmatically recognize that the requested changes/additions have *actually* been made, rather than the OP just thinking they made them, but not really having done so? How is that different from someone leaving a comment and the OP making an edit and then flagging the comment as NLN? How is it different from the author of one of the comments deleting the comment? How is it different from 3 users flagging the comment as NLN, which will delete the comment? or a moderator seeing the NLN flag, verifying the change, & deleting?

Comment: "So, how to you programmatically recognize that content?" By the fact that it used the feedback mechanism I propose, rather than the standard commenting mechanism. "How do you programmatically recognize that the requested changes/additions have actually been made" Admittedly, by manual action of the users, but something more streamlined. Unfortunately I can't really just drop an entire package of site redesign on Meta, and several of the ideas I think are my best are interdependent; if it worked like I want, questions would start out closed, and opening them would also delete this feedback.

Comment: But if I can't have that, I'd be happy if, say, a gold-badger were empowered to take that specific action without having to bother mods about it, and it were one click for the entire feedback exchange (which the system would automatically recognize as a coherent unit, again, by the fact that it used the alternate mechanism).

Comment: Just FYI: "[Staging Ground Beta 1 Recap, and Reviewers needed for Beta 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423469/3773011)" and "[Introducing the Staging Ground, an attempt at improving the first-time asker experience - What was asking your first question like?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416428/3773011)"