# The Stack Exchange reputation system: What's working? What's not?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges, research

### Update

Thank you everyone for the feedback you have provided. At this time, we will work through the feedback we have received to help us determine where to take our research on reputation next.

Please remember that this is just research and does not impact any product decision now or in the immediate future. We look forward to returning to the community to discuss more related and adjacent topics before embarking on any product development.

---

Having incentive systems to participate in online communities (like Stack Overflow) is not a new concept. Basically every Q&A site or forum has had some type of points or karma system, and they all work to varying degrees.

But [as we’ve seen](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/22/the-loop-2-understanding-site-satisfaction-summer-2019/), our system and community in its current state has a high barrier to entry. Asking or answering a question back in 2009 was a lot easier as we were building the library of knowledge that exists today. There were a lot more questions yet to be asked!

We still want users to be able to participate on our site and feel as though they are a part of this community. But unfortunately, we’ve heard from so many of our users, particularly newer ones, that the learning curve is steep and it’s difficult to find ways to engage on the site.

In order to combat some of that, we’ve been experimenting with the [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416652/new-user-experience-deep-dive-into-our-research-on-the-staging-ground-how-do) work and with better [onboarding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416322/feature-test-ask-wizard-for-new-users-trial-has-completed) for new users ([currently only on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377768/how-might-the-staging-ground-the-new-ask-wizard-work-on-the-stack-exchange-net)). These are just a few early attempts, and we know there could be additional solutions out there.

However, as the network has grown and changed, we’ve started thinking about our reputation and privilege system and how we might want to evolve it. Our Research and Community teams internally have been doing a lot of work to understand incentive systems more broadly, but we also wanted to hear from you all about what you think works really well with Stack Exchange’s reputation/privilege systems, as well as what is broken with reputation. We’d also love to hear about other rep/karma/incentive systems from other online communities that you think are exemplary that we could learn something from.

We don’t have any concrete plans yet. This is really the first part of a long process to see how we could potentially rethink reputation and privileges on this site and our larger network. We’ll be doing several rounds of research as a part of this larger exploration, and will update you on our findings as we go, so please be on the lookout for future updates.

So, for now, our questions for you are:

- What is really great about our reputation & privilege system? What do you think makes it great, and why is it worth keeping?
- What is broken about it, and why? Are there any solutions to it?
- What other systems work really well that we could learn from?

Since there are many answers already written now, if you'd like to add one but want to check first that someone hasn't already said what you want to say, try using the searchbar with [`inquestion:387356 is:answer ...`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A387356+is%3Aanswer).

Comment: Some [inspiration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+reputation+-status-completed+-status-declined) (both for the research and users here who might want to contribute)

Comment: Possibly related: [Help us identify new roles for community members](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384169/241919) (some of them are also related to reputation/privilege)

Comment: How is reputation connected to there being an entry barrier? The only privilege that newbies frequently miss is the ability to post comments, they mostly don't care about moderation tools.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. Quite related. This question is in part inspired by a lot of the feedback we got there.

Comment: Don't try to fix something that is not broken. You will just break it, without any shred of doubt.

Comment: FWIW, I joined about three years ago, and a few minutes with the site tour was plenty to make the workings clear. The rep/privileges/badges system was and is, for me, a great incentive system.

Comment: _"its current state has a high barrier to entry"_ - This is good. Quantity dillutes quality. The problem is frustration, not the barrier. You minimize frustration putting good explanation in the barriers BEFORE any interaction, so people understand why this barriers are protecting and promoting knowlege and trust. Currently the network says "c'mon, you can do everything", then slaps the rules at the user's face after his actions with close and downvotes. Somewhat like a carnivore plant. Also, you need to choose between qty of users, or the original network mission (so we know what to follow).

Comment: Also remember: views is not tied to # of registered users, but content. The recent inflation of registered user numbers maybe was very good to sell the company, but we are past that, so maybe we can focus on content again to atract views, help people (mostly in read-only mode) and keep the high reputation the network still has only because the "tough old times".

Comment: I agree with @Bacco's comment: "*you need to choose between qty of users, or the original network mission (so we know what to follow)*". Decide once and for all what you want. The official position is still "quality", but all actions in the last years favors "quantity". And we've seen how incompatible those two things are. This is one of the main reasons behind new users frustation, BTW. The site says they can ask anything, but users worried about quality says: "_wait, there are rules_" - and then the latter are called "toxic" by the former.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Slow down there. There are no plans to remove reputation or privileges. This is quite literally the opening question to the community before we have even engaged in serious research on our reputation system. We want to hear what people consider pain points, opportunities, and things they love.

Comment: @CypherPotato well, I don't think SE are doing it out of greed, they just see so many people complain about reputation, how broken and toxic it is (try to have a comment discussion with a new user who got a downvote, their vocabulary of bad words is amazing) and since the amount of those people, who rant and complain and send tickets is x1000 than those few who trust the reputation system, they are doing what they deem right for more people.

Comment: @SpencerG The most crucial point is how hard it is to instruct new users to understand what our community is actually about. It's not clear enough for them to understand, and that is why thousands of posts are closed every day. Also, the entire community's effort to filter content is decreasing because we don't have the right tools or the community entry point is not effectively doing its job in showing what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: @SpencerG it's clearly mentioned in the question here: "as well as what is broken with reputation" - not "**if** something is broken" but rather "**what** is broken", word choice means a lot, in this case it means SE thinks reputation system is broken, due to "we’ve heard from so many of our users, particularly newer ones, that the learning curve is steep and it’s difficult to find ways to engage on the site" which means great many new user keep hammering you with contact forms and emails after getting downvotes, complaining how the system is broken.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I can understand how that can seem to indicate that; however, that is not a position of SE. We do not internally believe that reputation is broken and needs to be replaced. We think there are opportunities for improvement, like any system as old as ours. This is a healthy process for us to hear what the community thinks/feels on the matter. Our only intention is to collect and consider feedback to help guide our research to see if suggestions made here could help improve the system.

Comment: This SE's positioning leads us to understand that SE intends to attract both Q&A and social media audiences to their products. Q&A users and social media audiences interact differently, behave differently, and seek different things.

Comment: BTW, I believe the reputation system isn't a problem (or at least not the biggest concern right now). There are other things you should focus on. Ex: IMO, if you do things like [**this**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/401803), the user experience would improve a lot and it would solve (or at least minimize) the problems reported by new users (regardless of the reputation system).

Comment: I think a good way to get users started, rather than blocking the answers, would be to actually make a system where the beginner answers have to be approved by a trusted member. I remember having to answer things as comments when I did not have reputation, and I eventually see people doing it

Comment: Getting an answer isn't apparently enough motivation for people to write a reasonable post let alone inform themselves about the site. So immediately everything else is moot.

Comment: @OverclockedSkid that doesn't make sense: it takes no rep to answer but there is a minimal rep before you can comment, so how were you "answer[ing] things as comments" when you did not have reputation?

Comment: @SpencerG the link between reputation and entry barrier isn't clear to me at all. I realize it seems self-evident to you, but it isn't self evident so can you please explain it? Answering "why is there a link between A and B" with ["Because"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356/the-stack-exchange-reputation-system-whats-working-whats-not#comment1291386_387356) isn't very helpful. Since you seem to be basing a lot of this on that assumed link, it would be helpful to explain it in the question. It takes 0 rep to answer or ask.

Comment: It is not a direct link. But if you need more info and you cannot comment for  more informations you have to wait someone other asks for the same thing you have in mind.

Comment: If that was answer #40 I'd've missed it. It hits the pin with a forging hammer. *What's wrong with rep?* It exists. It's a necessary evil, if you want ad revenue. Which is goal #1, don't BS us. #2 is the 'mission statement' and why it made it +10y. It's 'good' because its points are an order of magnitude more points than other sites, and you can nickle and dime us for stuff. The LC is what keeps this from being Yahoo. And once you surmount it, ahead of you is the cliff everyone jumps off because no one does SE (curates) the way you're supposed to. Edit a comment into a user's post and get +25?

Comment: @Mazura if that's a reply to nobody's comment, please move your reply to [their answer post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387433/997587).

Comment: @terdon My bad, I meant actually writing an answer on what should be a comment. I feel it's nice to achieve the trust in the website, but maybe it'd be nice to have the comments rather approved or disapproved by someone who is already trusted

Comment: I agree with this post, I joined SO 2 months ago and I find it really hard to gain reputation. All the questions I have have already been asked and answered like 5-10 years ago, which, don't get me wrong, is very helpful, no complaints there. Its just that it makes it very hard for me to gain rep with the current system.

Comment: I mean apparently ["there are users with thousands of reputation points who have absolutely no idea how site mechanics or policies work"](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9443412) although I know how all this works (as far as I know) but with this system, I can't do anything (well not much) as I lack the rep.

Comment: A person who wrote a common question or answer 10 years ago will naturally get a lot of upvotes as people will have the same question for years to come, However, this dosen't mean they have any experience on the site. There has to be some sort of system to quantify site "experience" which that gives you access to editing, closing posts, mod tools etc., separate from rep in my opinion.

Comment: I get the feeling much of this discussion is from a Stack Overflow point of view---some of these proposals could be harmful at smaller sites, where being constantly swamped by questions is not (yet) a thing.

Comment: @NasserKessas if you want rep, answer questions (just don't answer dupes or poorly-asked questions - *please*). Take a look at any [very high rep user](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/?sort=totalreputation)'s profile (SO link) and see how they got so much - almost uniformly, it is by answering questions. And, along with community curation, it's one of the best ways of positively contributing to the site. You'll also find that as you accumulate rep, it becomes less and less important to you.

Comment: It'll become less important to me once I accumulate enough to get most of the privileges.  Then I probably won't care.

Comment: The people who answered the very basic C/C++ or bash questions years back have infinite points answering questions which are searched for all the time (and most other seasoned programmers could have answered).Maybe it would make sense to limit the maximum of points you can get for upvotes on questions and answers.

Comment: @Blindleistung go see [OverLordGoldDragon's idea](/a/387358/997587) and [SQB's duplicate post](/a/387484/997587).

Comment: It's good to see SE reaching out to the community to get feedback. Hopefully this will be a continuing trend. Come to think of it, more community-driven sites should do this, in general.

Comment: regarding your note about many answers, consider having a look at [this feature request](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168 "When there are many answers already, help me check that mine won't repeat others") (tl;dr when I'm going to post 10th, 11th etc answer let me review prior answers one by one, instead of torturing me with search through whole page). Speaking of evolving privileges system, I wonder if you have seen the old related proposal made by Jeff Atwood about [augmenting reputation with "citizenship level"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165179/165773)

Comment: @gnat: To be clear, that note at the end about searching the answers was edited in by a regular user. (It seems to be good advice, but not something we added ourselves.)

Comment: At a certain point, your rep just keeps growing. You never lose moderation privileges, even after having been inactive for years.

Comment: @V2Blast please forgive me, I missed to check edits of this question because my brain was so much excausted after checking whole page of 19 prior answers to make sure that mine will add to discussion. At some point I even contemplated ignoring this whole question hoping that somebody else made or will make my point anyway. Guess that's why newer answers to such questions are that rarely good - people willing to _responsibly_ contribute something new and worthy just give up brain-damaging checking of endless page and abstain of answering

Comment: One of the critical issues with dupe closures is that new answers to old questions get little to no traction, even when answers are now sorted by modification date instead of score. There needs to be an incentive to add new, high quality content to aging questions (especially on StackOverflow) that is then rewarded by driving views and upvotes to the new, valuable answers. That will help lead to more duplicates on questions that can have a staggering number of usable answers for nuanced edge cases.

Comment: @DavidL what does that have to do with reputation?

Comment: @starball It has everything do with reputation. One of the reasons duplicate questions receive so much attention is because the answers are more likely to receive upvotes than newer answers on old questions with 10+ answers. As a result, it is more attractive to answer the duplicate. If there was a mechanism to reward answering old questions with new, relevant, high-quality answers, I suspect we'd see a lot less duplicate-answering and a lot more duplicate-to-new-answer redirecting.

Comment: The irony that this very discussion exhibits all of the problems of the reputation system, itself, is delicious.

Comment: Without an explanation of when a decision will be made, who will make it, and how it will be made; why should anyone bother to take time to post feedback?  Catharsis?

Comment: Just curious, how would people who later turned out to be Albert Einstein etc. fare? Would they have got voted off of Stack Exchange for asking nonsense questions, etc.?

Comment: @DanJacobson depends how much grit they have, and how willing/motivated they are to learn the etiquette of the community.

Comment: Please excuse my question, but I come from the province and don't know my way around the big city: What do you mean by "high barrier to entry"? I signed up for an account and that was it. When I feel like it, I ask or answer questions or comment. I get messages by the machinery about all sorts of odds and ends like badges and privileges that don't interest me and where I am too lazy to learn what they are about. I don't participate for virtual reputation and badges, but for real questions and real answers.

Comment: @UlrichDiez there's a big group of people who interact with the site outside of questions and answers, or those who are better off commenting but can't.

Comment: @bixb0012: Feedback on this post will not directly lead to a change being made, but it will help inform future research by staff into these issues and possible solutions to them.

Comment: @V2Blast, thanks for reaching out and providing more information.  It seems some of these issues/questions/concerns have been around for a while, is there any rough timelines for researching and possibly implementing changes?

Answer (score 196):

**What's broken:** uncapped rep per post. Long-time users have had the luck to answer basic questions that are very popular to search, and gather hundreds, thousands, or 10k+ upvotes. This rep gain is **completely meaningless** - it doesn't reflect greater skill, knowledge, or any other trait that should reflect 'authority'. Meanwhile, newer or more specialized questions are inherently less prone to such a boost, yet at the same time demand much greater skill. From my observation, this is very pronounced. A hard-earned `+2` post isn't worth x50 less because it didn't make it to HNQ and get `+100`.

**Solution**: cap rep gain per post, and apply retroactively. I don't know where exactly, but `+100` net votes seems reasonable.

**Solution 2**: every upvote after `+50` earns 5 rep; 2 after `+100`; 1 after `+200`. Catches up with the first solution at `+250` while affecting more posts but keeps a permanent incentive. Also retroactive.

It doesn't have to be these exact solutions. I think this should be its own featured Meta Q&A.

Comment: the rep gained per post is mostly garnered through quantity, not a single post receiving 10k upvtes. There's certianly a few edge cases, but posts with 100+ upvotes isn't where long-term users are getting their rep. A very large portion of the rep from these posts get voided due to the daily rep cap.

Comment: @KevinB That's the point, for most users this won't matter much. But I've encountered cases where users have earned a lot of rep asking a couple of basic questions without research many years ago, and still ask and bounty basic questions without demonstrating research effort every now and then that can't get closed when bountied. It won't affect most users, but will fix a rare but annoying issue imo.

Comment: I think a stronger connection needs to be made for why this affects new users getting started. It can be frustrating from a competitive aspect — I experience that from time to time — but it's not clear how that impacts new users. FWIW, I wouldn't want my own per-post rep capped because I was late to the party, so to speak.

Comment: @ErikA right, but, what i'm saying is the users who gain rep from these posts are users who have 1-3 posts at most. Users like me, with 2k, getting 3k upvotes on an answer gave  me only *maybe* 3k rep, not the 30k that the score would seem to indicate. It's not about the singular high scored question, it's about over time receiving 1-5 upvotes on the other 2k answers. This long-tail of receiving rep for old contributions encourages quanitity over quality, the opposite of a single post receiving 10k upvotes.

Comment: @KevinB That would seem to beg the question of why poor-quality posts are getting so many upvotes. It sounds like the broken part of the system is the downvoting, which, for low-quality posts, should also accumulate over time, eventually dropping such posts "out of contention", so to speak.

Comment: I mean, they don't tend to receive downvotes. correct answers tend to continue being correct.

Comment: I will agree that this perception, that because there's highly-active high rep users with contributions from 10 years ago that have a high score, that that can discourage particularly competitive new users who feel like they're going up against an insurmountable challenge. I don't really know what could be done about that. No longer praising users publicly every time they reach 1mil was a good start.

Comment: "completely meaningless" - Yup, 100% right about that. LOL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field

Comment: @VE7JRO Is that meant to indicate all that user's rep is from one question? Because it's not; you could delete that question and that user would still have over 15,000 reputation. You may notice, if you bother to look at their profile, that they have _numerous_ **answers** near or above 100 score, for example.

Comment: @TylerH - This answer is about limiting the total rep limit per Q+A. Your comment ignores the fact that the top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field  received 20550 rep. I guess you missed the point of OverLordGoldDragon's  answer.

Comment: I would like to see a system where you get 10 points for an upvote on an answer up to 100 upvotes and then it starts diminishing.  Something like 8 points for 101-200, 6 pts for 201-300, etc.  The numbers are just for conversation.

Comment: @VE7JRO You are incorrect. The top answer there is a Community Wiki answer and has been since 2012, so no rep has been awarded beyond the initial 100 or so upvotes that were cast. Maybe do a little more homework before dismissing someone's criticism of a [vague comment with no explanation or justification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356/the-stack-exchange-reputation-system-whats-working-whats-not/387358?noredirect=1#comment1291471_387358)

Comment: I've seen one case of a user who posted a question 10 years back, didn't check in since, and now has all sorts of moderator privileges they don't know what to do with. Someone who doesn't know the site should not be able to collect so much rep, if the rep is tied to moderation privileges. Either decouple the two, or limit rep gain to weeks where the user has logged on or something like that.

Comment: @TylerH - And maybe you should do a little more homework too. Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all , then look at the top rep holder's individual profiles. Next, sort the top answers by "Score". For example, this answer got 117,710 rep: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/10292145 Is it **really** that good?

Comment: @VE7JRO there's no indication that the answerer got the maximum of 117710 reps because there's a 200-rep daily limit. But then, it's [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134/241919), and it's really a revelation for someone who has been bitten by timezone quirks.

Comment: If you want to argue about 'worth' of posts, this reminds me mostly of current economic circumstances: An old fart used his first few paychecks to buy a cheap home for himself, and over the years that increased in value, to a point where if he had to buy it today, he wouldn't be able to. Young people nowadays can't buy homes because they're all too expensive too. Capping whatever income the old fart has had over his lifetime, making him pay back large chunks of it, and limiting what income he still gets isn't magically going to make his home worth less, nor any new homes worth more, though.

Comment: Similarly, capping reputation gain (or decaying it over time) from an old post isn't magically going to make new posts worth more.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell "lowering old won't raise new" - if everyone but me earned 0.01 per upvote, I'd top Jon Skeet. As all measures, rep is **relative**, so deflating old/popular posts _does_ prop up everything else.

Comment: If your main problem with SO is posts with lots of upvotes, new questions in your frequented tags must look vastly different from the garbage dumps in python and java. I agree that it's not great if some users gain tons of rep from popular but basic answers or questions, but it's a niche edge case compared to everything else that's wrong with the rep system, so IMO this is a really low priority.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Yes, and that would create a false impression of what your posts are 'worth'. The fact remains that if you cap the reputation gained from a post, it doesn't suddenly become worth less, nor do your posts suddenly become worth more. If you cap the reputation gained from a single post, it does say nothing about the *worth* of that post. It will only make it easier for you as a user to seem *worth* more than another user, despite the 'worth' of your posts. Your problem doesn't seem to be with the 'worth' of posts, but of users, yet you present this as being about posts.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, and [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387421/612423)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I really don't follow. False impressions are my exact quarrel with the current system. Newer/unpopular posts aren't worth less just because fewer people in total looked at them. What people see at end of the day is the total rep of a user, and that shouldn't be so heavily controlled by popularity. Any given post has finite worth, and if you maximize your rewards on it, good for you - smile and move on; demanding more is pointless greed. Putting some down _does_ prop others up.

Comment: Unpopular posts *are* worth less if their worth is defined as the number of users that find them useful. Newer posts have yet to prove their usefulness, it's no use comparing a post that has had 10 years to prove its usefulness to one that has had for example just a week. Putting some down *does* prop others up, for sure, but it will be just a statistical trick to make some feel better about themselves and will make reputation points even worse at representing the worth of a user's posts/contributions like edits, not better.

Comment: As an example, I've got most of my rep from one question here, on superuser: https://superuser.com/users/113848/ancientswordrage I haven't done much to earn it though and that feels unrepresentative of my actually ability and knowledge on that site.

Comment: I'd like to see quantification on this. There are certainly _edge cases_, but that's the case for most systems. A system should be tuned to work well in the majority of cases, rather than penalize the majority for a few odd cases. As an example, I have one _very_ simple answer in C++ that has gotten me an ungodly amount of reputation -- though not as much as the score would indicate, due to the daily cap -- and at the beginning it felt unfair... but I've come to terms with it: it compensates for all the elaborate answers to complex questions I've only ever got 1 or 2 votes for...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Agreed re: "don't change over edge cases", and there should be a quantification effort. But from my 3 years of observation, I'd certainly not call it only edge cases. I've also thought exactly same re: "compensates", but I think we're both just coping - the 1-2 would be worth more with 100's deflated.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon: A logarithmic contribution may be worth it, indeed. +10 rep/vote for 1-9, +1 rep/vote for 10-99, +1 rep/10 votes for 100-999, +1 rep/100 votes for 1000-9999, etc...

Comment: I stand to lose a ton of reputation from a policy like this, but I think it makes sense and I would be happy to lose that reputation for this reason. I don't contribute anywhere near as much as I used to, but I keep earning "interest" on my past contributions, inflating my rep. It doesn't make a whole lot of sense, as it's largely from luck that I got there first, especially when my answers don't necessarily apply anymore, but I'm still earning rep. I would say, have the rep stop coming in over time rather than a hard cap. Like, no more rep after 12 months. So really good posts still get rep.

Comment: Users that would be affected by this, rarely interact with the site (if they do it at all) after the post. Most users that gain reputation and actively interact with the site do it by pumping questions or answers. I don't think this will solve anything.

Comment: I won't edit it in for now but I like the following: +8 after 10 upvotes, +6 after 20, +4 after 30, +2 after 40, +1 after 50. Looks linear but the real effect is: 25%, 67%, 150%, 400%, 900% reduction. Affects many more posts. 50 upvotes = +300 rep. I'm totally cool with that, or something a bit more stringent, but I think @MatthieuM. 's is rather extreme. But really it should be a data-driven heuristic.

Comment: I agree that you've pointed out a problem here, but I don't think capping the rep gain of answers is the answer.  The problem is that *mundane answers get more upvotes than answers that required high skill*, and that's true at any scale.  The answer isn't to add a leveling effect so all good answers wind up close to the same, but to change the incentives so that *different* answers wind up with the highest scores.

Comment: @Brilliand _"change the incentives"_ like what? How do you get people to read what they have no interest in or ability to review? And compensate for other posts having years uptime or advertising boost? In engineering there's a simple idea - if a problem can be fixed directly, do it. Incentives won't change the fact that rep gain past 100 upvotes is meaningless and unnecessary. It's a "nice on paper bad in practice" idea to me, as I cannot imagine it affecting adequately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/how-do-i-cast-int-to-enum-in-c <-- massive rep for a basic question and answer. Judge for yourself. I sometimes wonder if rep should just have a sliding window.  Ada Lovelace or Charles Babbage would be god-level if SO started back then, but their answers wouldn't be relevant now. Just spit-balling.

Comment: I agree. As an anecdotic evidence, I have only ever asked one single question on Lifehacks.SE, and don't recall making any other contribution ever; however, that question went viral, became the 2nd top question there ever, and I got more than 1k reputation from it overnight, granting me some basic moderator-ish permissions (review queue etc.). For asking one single question, that wasn't even *that* good, only relatable for many.

Comment: I agree with this for SO and other main communities, but not on Meta (MSO, MSE, etc.). 200 downvotes or upvotes on meta actually means something. (P.S. we don't get any reps on MSO tho).

Comment: It's also possible to use a non-linear curve, e.g. a cube-root or logarithmic curve

Comment: @Kit what do you mean by massive rep? The asker [has asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493/lomaxx) several questions with >100 score and have not used most of the privileges granted by the system if at all. That's the system working as intended.

Comment: @Braiam I'm not disputing "as intended". I'm merely pointing out that activity prior to 2011 for what (admittedly, "I", personally) someone may consider "fluff" questions might not be all that useful to the community *now*, and as such, aging out the contribution doesn't seem particularly controversial.

Comment: Applying a fixed cap means there will be thousands of posts with exactly 100 upvotes, without any way to know which one is better than another. Also that feels like a zero sum game - we'd be discouraging long term users in order to give a chance to newer users. Perhaps there's a solution that would benefit everyone?

Comment: @laurent the reputation can be capped without affecting the vote count. Most answers don't gain near 1000 reputation anyways - and those that do likely already hit the daily reputation cap - so I don't think it would have a negative impact on long-term user incentives.

Comment: I'm of two minds about the reputation cap. My single most productive (rep-wise) answer garners me an up-vote practically every week: **but** it's not even my answer! I found the answer on another SE site and reposted it (with attribution) on AskUbuntu. I _really_ don't deserve that rep, but for answer that are totally original, I feel it's only fair to let me gain reputation _every_ time somebody finds it useful

Comment: Other users have admitted this is 'rare' problem, but you risk introducing issues here. Some, really good answers, are _very_ long and take a _lot_ of time, in part incentivised by the possibility for 100s/1000s votes. By introducing a +100 votes, you're quickly incentivising the answering of _lots_ of questions, but with less quality. And this is coming from someone who supports an income cap in real life.

Comment: @user2979044 I don't know how true that is, and even if, that's their problem and they should adjust. I've authored many articles that have taken 10+ hours and gotten <10 upvotes, *knowing* this would happen ([example](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/83299/50076)). Another took a [month](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78513/50076), +23. They are good articles, just the network (DSP.SE) has a self-admitted voting epidemic. And it's not just me or non-SO. And no, I don't agree the problem is "rare". My answer says 50 but I support lower income starting from 10 votes, as in my previous comment.

Comment: There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later.

Comment: I agree with the "whats broken bit", but the solution doesn't help for me.

Comment: I think another solution to that is just making those 'basic' questions community wiki.

Answer (score 157):

This is something I was hoping you all would explore sometime soon, and I'm excited that you've posted about this now.

For awhile now, I've felt that tying moderation privileges to reputation... Doesn't really make a whole lot of sense. Whether one is capable of utilizing particular moderation privileges to better the community should not necessarily be determined by the quality, or quantity, of their answers on a given site. Rewarding users who know how to use particular moderation privileges well with more power in those particular areas is, in my opinion, the better way to go. You guys currently do this with the [flag posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) privilege, where you get 1 bonus flag per day per every 10 helpful flags, up to a maximum of 100. That's *great*, but you stop there. No other moderation privileges are expanded upon when you've shown that you're a "good" user of them. Giving close votes and delete votes this treatment could prove to be difficult (the question of "What is a good close vote?" is a difficult question to answer!) but there are [some nice folks I know on Stack Overflow](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) who would appreciate the ability to do more without committing to something like becoming a diamond moderator.

I'll take your questions one at a time and give my 2 cents:

> What is really great about our reputation & privilege system? What do you think makes it great, and why is it worth keeping?

For the privilege system, super simply put, the biggest contributors get more access to help guide the site the way they see fit. The ability to unilaterally edit, vote to close, review posts and edits by lesser-privileged users, see deleted content... All of that empowers a veteran user to just *do more* with the site. The reputation levels that are currently chosen for the more powerful privileges (such as [access to moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) and [trusted user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)) are intentionally high to ensure that community members that have contributed a lot, and likely over a long period of time, have access to them.

This model has worked for a long time, and for good reason. Reputation as a number alone provides incentive to post, and tying the ability to *do more* with the site provides even further incentive. I would never suggest that we do away with reputation because it's a core part of the Stack Exchange model.

When we're just looking at reputation the number... I mean, it's just overall a great way to incentivize good contribution. There's a degree of accomplishment one feels when they answer a question that leads to resolving a problem someone has, but getting "paid" for it? That never gets old.

> What is broken about it, and why? Are there any solutions to it?

Well... As you noted, the more saturated a given site becomes with good quality Q&A content, the more difficult it is for newer users to find a place where they can contribute meaningfully. Someone who is interested in helping with site cleanup efforts has a *long* way to go to get access to the ability to review, edit posts without review, and vote to close. They *do* get access to the ability to flag quite early, which is quite important and quite powerful, but the march towards getting anything beyond that is long and, sometimes, difficult when attempting it on a site that's quite saturated with good content. You will eventually experience a situation where a user has thousands of helpful flags, a great suggested edit history, a great knowledge of how the site works, and a good head for user-level moderation... And they simply can't contribute in the way someone who has posted more questions/answers can. I have one particular user in mind as I type this who is an *absolutely exceptional* example of someone I'd like to see be able to do more. And... That kind of sucks.

This sort of touches on a personal note for me, as well. I've got 500 reputation on Stack Overflow, which allows me to see some review queues, but... I frequently find that there are a lot of situations where I wish I had the privileges I do on this site. Unilateral edits (and the ability to help out with Stack Overflow's [suggested edit review problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351728/11171084)), the ability to vote to close, the ability to help to delete posts that need it... I mean, if I review any post, I frequently find myself skipping because the post needs an edit but the suggested edit queue is full. I've got thousands of helpful flags and plenty of approved suggested edits, and I'm trying to help improve a question that was presented to me in review. Why am I being stopped here?

The inability for newer users to find questions they can post answers to on saturated sites also encourages answering questions that are either known duplicates or that are duplicates but the duplicate just isn't found (yet?). The thing is, there's no [incentive to find a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37466/622284), whereas there's plenty of incentive to just answer a duplicate. Better duplicate discoverability would be *good*, but some incentive for finding a good duplicate would be *great*. However, if you explore this, I would exercise caution, as it *may* incentivize incorrect duplicate closure, which is an extremely frustrating experience for a new user.

> What other systems work really well that we could learn from?

There are not a lot of sites that reward user participation with (moderation) privileges like Stack Exchange does. From a reputation/content scoring level, there are a fair few sites that allow upvoting but remove downvoting, which... I don't know if I particularly care for, since there's no way for old content that may have become obsolete to be reduced in "usefulness-level", but I suppose it does make for an experience free of the typical derision that downvotes receive here on SE.

While I don't feel like you'd particularly appreciate the mention, Codidact does feature [an abilities system](https://meta.codidact.com/help/abilities), all of which reward users who have a good user-level-moderation track record with the ability to do more, which is *in addition to* a reputation system. Competitor site or not, there's something to respect about users who created a whole platform (out of their love for *this* platform!) rebuilding the privilege system in their own vision, and in a way that *makes sense*.

I think you're essentially going to be paving your own way here. My suggestion would be an implementation of something that's side-along to reputation, rewarding the good curation work that many users are interested in performing without invalidating reputation's longstanding meaning. A good idea you've been exploring is [roles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384169/622284), but I feel like none of the suggestions tackled a particular pain point that can be useful across the network: The idea of opening up the full edit privilege to more users who have shown to be good editors. That's a **great** privilege to start this sort of exploration with.

Comment: Re: Abilities system, I wrote a blog post which included a part where I give a brief overview of what's wrong with SE's rep system. I've quoted the relevant part [in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9443412).

Comment: I think users with a good track of suggested edits should just receive the full edit privilege. I don't know how many approved suggested edits is enough, but maybe after 500 you get the full-edit privilege.

Comment: @Mithical: That's a great writeup – I'd encourage you to post it (or some version of it) as an answer if you can :)

Comment: Regarding the Suggested Edits queues being full, I proposed a role for that [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384263/422926). On Arqade there is a user who almost exclusively has marked duplicates. I would love to see them being rewarded for that, as it becomes increasingly important as a site grows (as well as harder).

Comment: @Joachim I'm pretty sure I'm familiar with that user, and yes, absolutely. The work they've done in cleaning up old duplicates and ensuring newly-posted ones have a good duplicate proposal has been really impressive.

Comment: I think gating certain privileges behind reputation works, but we should scale up the frequency of using those privileges based on usage of those privileges. Just like how you get more flags by casting useful flags, and similar to how you get more delete votes per day as you rise in reputation beyond 10k/20k, you should get more close votes or more review 'rounds' the more helpful actions of those types you perform. This would allow for hybridization of things like suggested edits: you can suggest an edit any time, but starting at 500 rep, you get 1 unilateral edit per day; at 600 you get 2...

Comment: If users still had to suggest edits at 2k reputation, for example, but could make 15 edits per day before having to start submitting them to the review queue, I think they'd be a lot less frustrated due to running into the "the queue is full" issue so often. And once you've done 1,000 reviews in a queue (assuming some additional metric is met as well, like < n review suspensions during that time), you earn additional daily reviews. Doesn't have to be a lot, but something like 80 or 100 max instead of 40 would make a big difference and go a long way toward encouraging users to review more.

Comment: RE: Incentivizing duplicates - maybe only award reputation if a proposed duplicate is accepted by the Asker or a Moderator, not just because enough people suggested the same. This skews towards under-rewarding when a moderator doesn't get to it in time or the asker is stubborn about their question being unique, but I think that's a good thing.

Comment: "Whether one is capable of utilizing particular moderation privileges to better the community should not necessarily be determined by the quality, or quantity, of their answers on a given site." Maybe not _necessarily_, but having a history of well-received contributions to the site is certainly a _very good predictor_ of one's ability to use moderation tools in ways that enhance its quality and generally demonstrates that one probably knows what does or doesn't belong and what does or doesn't break rules. Someone brand new to the site simply won't know the rules well enough to enforce them.

Comment: @reirab Of course! But there must certainly be better metrics we can gauge a user on when determining whether they're ready for certain moderation privileges than reputation alone, and that's the idea I think is worth exploring.

Comment: That's reasonable. I could see things like a significant history of edit suggestions with a high acceptance rate unlocking direct edit, perhaps with some rate limits that increase with proper use over time. Same for users who have a long history of proper use of moderation tools on other SE sites getting rate-limited access to those tools. I don't think think they should start out with unlimited use of the tools on other sites, though, since site rules can be quite different from one SE site to another.

Comment: @reirab Yeah, if we start exploring this sort of thing, the requirements for early access, potential limits, and all sorts of other distinguishing criteria will definitely need to be thought about quite hard. I'm deliberately trying to avoid spitballing arbitrary criteria because I don't have access to data that would reveal a target audience for early access to specific privileges, but I definitely agree there's a lot of discussion to be had there if this direction is explored.

Comment: fantastically well written and insightful post 

Comment: @JeffAtwood That means a lot coming from you, Jeff! Thanks!

Comment: [Done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387462/294691), @V2Blast

Comment: *"the more saturated a given site becomes with good quality Q&A content, the more difficult it is for newer users to find a place where they can contribute meaningfully."* 100% yes. For a microcosm of this issue, look no further than small Teams sites, e.g. the Moderator's one. Most of the general questions have been answered years ago, such that new mods (when they get access) do not have any rep and can't do stuff like downvote. (Incidentally, the mods worked around this by having a question where the sole purpose is to post answers to farm rep so we can downvote!)

Comment: I'd also agree with this suggestion. Just as an example, on SO, I have 434 rep right now. I also have 1,373 post flags (spam/rude flags excluded), of which 1,189 of them are helpful, four are declined (and 1x disputed, 145x aged away, 33x retracted, 1x waiting for review). My most recent declined flag on SO was about six months ago. IMO, I have a pretty good idea of what constitutes a good post and what needs to be closed, and having CV privileges + queue access would be useful, as I spend _vastly_ more of my time on SE doing moderation-related tasks than posting questions/answers

Comment: Upvoted esp. re: new-user rep-farming to try to get to mod abilities encourages answering duplicates, and little-to-no incentive for correctly identifying and citing duplicates instead. (I've seen myself being aware of target dupe[s] but answering instead to try to get to required-rep threshold, esp. because the 'suggested edit queue full' discourages me from trying to improve existing content. In combination with new-question-askers being frustrated with their question closed as duplicate, and struggling to figure out how to adjust the target dupe code to fit their scenario, bad experience.)

Comment: As an anecdotic evidence, I also don't really trust this system. I have only ever asked one single question on Lifehacks.SE, and don't recall any other contribution; however, that question went viral and I got more than 1k reputation from it, granting me some basic moderator-ish permissions (review queue etc.). For asking one single question, that wasn't even *that* good, only relatable for many.

Comment: The reason that moderation privileges are given for number of answers is that both are tied to *how much the user interacts with the site.* - the purpose of the system is what it does, and the reputation system gives moderation tools to users who use the site a lot without getting told to go away.

Comment: I really like the idea of an abilities system, especially for editing. If I have hundreds of "good" edits, and proportionally few "bad" edits, why should I still have to have my edits reviewed?

Comment: As an idea, there could be a mini rep system for editing. You could get points for an accepted edit, based on what was edited (question, answer, etc.), how well it was received (number of "Looks OK" votes vs others), and how "big" or substantial the edit was (this may be slightly controversial, but I think it would work). Rejected edits would decrease your score. Having enough points unlocks the full edit privilege.

Answer (score 97):

Just a friendly reminder that these proposals exist:

- [Reward duplicate closing: +5 for the first voter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226016/997587)
- [Reward finding duplicate questions - +10, +2, -5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90620/997587)
- [Duplicates Mark II, Canonicals, more aggressive duplicate prevention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230507/997587)
- The top answer to [Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252009/11107541) (on Meta Stack Overflow)
- [People MUST be rewarded with reputation for finding duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387333/11107541) (on Meta Stack Overflow)
- [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199050/997587) to [Create CW answer for every "Vote to close as duplicate" vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198958/997587)

Comment: You basically say that instead of asking for new ideas SO should "do their homework" and look at already posted ideas in the past first?

Comment: @Trilarion I'm not against asking for new ideas (where'd you get that idea?). But I also hope that old ideas aren't being forgotten or neglected- both by SE Inc. _and_ by other community users.

Comment: I got the idea from you posting old ideas to a post that seemed to ask for new ideas and accounting for that the staff likely cannot do all those things at the same time (thinking about old and new ideas) but I didn't want bother anyone. New and old ideas - the more, the merrier.

Comment: Strong -1 for these proposals. I regularly see users blindly close vote or leave 'possible duplicate of...' comments on questions that absolutely aren't duplicates, but perhaps have some of the same words in the title.

Comment: @dauphic the dup-closure system requires 3-5 users with the close-vote privilege to _agree_ that the dup is a dup. The first listed proposal provides _zero incentive_ for pile-on close-voting. The second listed proposal has a lesser incentive for non-first dup-votes and a _punishment mechanism_ for wrong duplicate-closure. Don't those address your concerns?

Comment: No: the problem is that many users close vote without reading or understanding the question content. It's not just a lone close vote here and there, and I suspect others are willing to blindly throw their vote in when they see 'possible duplicate of [similar wording]' from a high reputation user. That aside, it's also a bad new user experience, even if the question isn't ultimately closed.

Comment: @dauphic how big is that problem compared to askers and answerers not searching for duplicates and the resulting fragmentation of information for all users of SE? I'd wager not _as_ big. I've heard my fair share of complaints about wrong dup-closure, but consider that rarely does anyone praise a system like SE when it works (invisibly for most users) for their good. We just hear the complaints when things happen wrong, and I'm not convinced they happen wrong more often than right (data needed).

Comment: The reopen system is a thing and I'm pretty sure mod-flagging patterns of bad closure is valid. To users with dup-vote privileges, closure is public, non-repudiated info, discussible on meta sites. Not that I don't agree that wrong dup-votes is bad though.

Comment: @dauphic in my experience as a curator, it's relatively rare to see questions closed that shouldn't be. It's much more common to see questions closed *with the wrong canonical*, and this often happens because the right one *is hard to find, largely because of previous failures to close questions that should be closed*.

Comment: I've seen more than a few questions closed on other Stack Exchange sites because users either didn't like the question content or just piled on. Question: "How do I do X?" comment: "it depends, what is your Y?" *question closed as needing information* comment: "hang on, all X's are mostly the same regardless of Y, this is already answerable with different Y's being a footnote"

Comment: Duplicate questions are a minor annoyance, essentially an offense against taxonomy. However incorrect identification of "duplicates" is a much bigger problem, creating hostile unhelpful environment, and in extreme cases leading into irreversible mistakes, such as merging of unrelated questions, and subsequent mass downvoting of (now retroactively off-topic) answers from the source question. On some sites (particularly SO) its a plague. *Encouraging more* of this kind of behavior is a horrible idea, and the fact that you've turned up 6 proposals for doing so is proof of the problem.

Answer (score 95):

It’s better than nothing… but I have many complaints regardless.

The following is a rough sketch listing some observations and ideas about the reputation system I had accumulated over the years.  I didn’t have much time to properly flesh out the explanations here, so expect some simplifications and leaps of logic.  (I can also recommend [@Karl Knechtel’s answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387550/620615) with a similar list, but I think much better written, and it manages to cover a few issues I overlooked writing this one; yet another case of the FGITW problem.)

A number of answers here express the sentiment that “oh, reputation doesn’t really mean all that much”; suspiciously often, it seems to come from users who have accumulated tens or hundreds of thousands of points.  That makes it sound just as believable as a billionaire telling you that money doesn’t buy happiness; well, I am not falling for this trite so-above-it-all and holier-than-thou humblebrag countersignalling.  This post takes the stance that reputation influences at least *some* people’s behaviour (especially those at the bottom of the ladder), and that’s enough for it to matter; it better not be ignored.

So here goes:

- **Reputation concentration** (the early-vs-late adopter problem): in early stages of a site, users can easily earn reputation by asking (and answering) basic questions, then earn “passive income”, as those questions accumulate views and duplicate links.  This means reputation is awarded to early users disproportionately to their level of expertise, merely by virtue of them having asked or answered popular, low-hanging-fruit questions in the past.

  Meanwhile, for latecomers it can be hard to accumulate enough reputation to use a site comfortably, as *their* questions get closed as duplicates of the former… even though the older questions aren’t necessarily all that good themselves once you look closely: they implicitly mix unrelated concerns together, fail to state background assumptions or define circumstances in a sufficiently concrete way, are ambiguously phrased, attract redundant answers and ones addressing completely unrelated circumstances to the asker’s ([the “Long Tail of Crap” problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390907/)) due to poor wording, and sometimes have bad titles.  What is worse is that the moderators and the community tend to be apathetic towards those problems and sometimes actively thwart attempts to remedy them.

  The dearth of opportunities to earn reputation is very visible on Stack Overflow, where the only way to gain enough points to meaningfully participate and not be written off as a newbie is by collecting bounties; which is not all that easy, as bountied questions tend to be ridiculously specialised and demand complicated set-ups to even begin replicating the issue at hand.  And even those are slowly drying out at this point: I remember there used to be 16 or so pages of unanswered bountied questions on SO.  Now it’s just 9.
- **Perverse incentives**: Stack Exchange is basically Goodhart’s Law: The Website.

  - The well-known Fastest Gun in the West problem: early answers get the most upvotes and the most visibility, both of which reinforce each other; but usually not in proportion to quality.  This encourages writing answers hastily and sloppily.
  - Highly-viewed questions attract redundant, poor-quality answers long after they have already been explained to death.  (“Protecting”/answer-locking a question ameliorates this, but is not always available.)
  - Answers to poor questions can nevertheless earn the answerer some reputation, which encourages wild-shot answers, discourages voting to close unclear questions, and removes askers’ incentives to put some effort into improving the question.  Additionally, if the question is closed regardless, the fact that it has answers makes it ineligible for automatic deletion.
  - Because downvotes are so underpowered relative to upvotes (more on that below), even a negative-score post will often on net earn the poster reputation.  This means that posters, especially those at the bottom of the ladder, are disincentivised from removing posts judged as bad quality by the community.  Privileged users may cast delete votes on negative-score answers, but negative-score questions are harder to get rid of (said above).
- **Unfair skew towards upvotes**:

  - It costs reputation to cast downvotes on answers, which means the few users who can cast downvotes are disincentivised from it anyway.
  - The threshold to cast upvotes on answers is very low, which means the ratio of upvotes to downvotes is skewed by upvotes cast by low-reputation users, who have not been vetted by the site’s community as having expertise, and are less likely to have internalized how the site is supposed to operate.
  - Hot Network Questions and the association bonus distort voting further.  Answers to HNQs get much more visibility and lots of upvotes from people who may not even be experts in the particular site’s subject area, or familiar with its house rules, but happen to have the +100 bonus from participation elsewhere and upvote based on superficial plausibility.

    I often see this dynamic on Retrocomputing.  On ELU, answers to single-word requests are an embarrassment to read, also, I suspect, primarily for this reason.  But [the real poster child for undue HNQ interference is probably the the LangDev site](/q/391184/620615): it used to attract a lot of opinion-based, bikeshedding topics, still kind of does, and did so even before it launched its public beta.  The [tragedy of LangDev](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/543/) has many aspects, and not all are related to reputation, but to the ones that are, the association bonus has certainly contributed a lot.
  - It takes five downvotes to nullify a reputation gain from a single upvote.  It takes three more to nullify a reputation gain from answer acceptance alone, even though the asker is often a newbie, and therefore the *least* qualified person to judge how good an answer is.  This means answerers are rewarded for posting superficial answers, and are not incentivised to correct mistakes discovered by outsiders that may be easily missed, yet important.
  - When [democracy](/help/why-vote) fails this badly, you might think [plutocracy](/help/bounty) at least has a chance of working better, right?  Unfortunately, the skew towards upvotes manages to spoil even the bounty system.  Because of the large number of users who are not discerning with their upvotes, it’s not that uncommon that a mediocre-but-not-outright-awful answer (or worse) accumulates a score of 2, which is enough for it to get the bounty automatically, regardless of the bounty poster’s wishes.  This means that bountied questions are subject to popularity-based perverse incentives against answer quality just as much as (if not more than, because of the higher stakes) normal questions, with little possibility for a bounty poster to correct for that.  There used to be a way to decline awarding a bounty to anyone else, but now [this can be accomplished only through sockpuppetry](/posts/comments/1318628).

  As a particularly egregious example of vote skew: under this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14488421/3840170, there is a comment explaining why the proposed solution is a poor idea.  When I first wrote this post in March 2023, the comment had 33 upvotes.  The answer itself had only 7 downvotes, and 111 upvotes.<sup>0</sup>  Even worse one: this gibberish post https://stackoverflow.com/a/65856842/3840170 ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220410125443/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c-c/65856842#65856842)) managed to accumulate 66 upvotes and only 3 downvotes when it was finally deleted after me having to flag it *twice*, even though it is basically a [Milla Jovovich answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308441/3840170).

  My impression is that the nerfing of downvotes was meant to prevent toxicity.  If that is the case, then you can declare that objective a miserable failure, as Stack Overflow manages to be incredibly toxic place regardless.  It’s the [wiki whack-a-mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:WikiSpeak&oldid=1174479260#be_bold): invite a lot of newbies to add to the site without first teaching them about research and quality standards, then leave overwhelmed and frustrated curators to drown them in negative feedback, at best wordless or passive-aggressive by virtue of being impersonal canned boilerplate, at worst passive-aggressive by being handcrafted for the occasion.  In fact, you could argue underpowered downvotes make toxicity *worse*: if the curators felt their downvotes actually *matter*, they might not feel the need to also leave nasty comments to make their negative feedback noticeable.  (I am no saint here myself.)  I suspect we are in the worst of both worlds now: newbie askers feel attacked because they see negative numbers next to their questions, while curators feel ignored because their negative feedback, even when thrice as numerous as positive feedback (which is rare), ends up being ineffective and swamped by the latter on the reputation balance sheet anyway.

  Also, in trying to avoiding toxic negativity, the designers of the reputation system have forgotten that toxic positivity also exists.  The number of people who say they *never* cast downvotes no matter what convinces me that discouraging downvotes does not really correct for a claimed bias, but it *exacerbates* an actual opposite bias that would have been problematic even without this measure.  The [Java fanatic downvoting everything .NET](/a/15866/620615) is nothing but a contrived bogeyman – who actually votes like that?

  There is also the bullshit asymmetry principle to take into account: it has always been easier to invent claims that are wrong, but sound plausible to an untrained audience than to conclusively debunk them in a way that is convincing to that same audience (which usually means: from first principles, without relying on shortcuts an expert would take for granted and easily fill gaps within); and with the advent of LLMs, generating large amounts of bullshit has become easier than ever.
- **A measure of popularity, not quality, nor information value** (aka [the dev.to problem](https://wagslane.dev/posts/collapsing-quality-of-devto/)): An answer in a highly specialised area where very little information is otherwise available will probably receive just a couple of upvotes.  Meanwhile, an answer about basics one might as well look up in Wikipedia can receive hundreds.  In itself, it may be argued that this is intended: if an answer is useful to more people, then it’s more useful to the knowledge base, and the author should receive more credit for it.  But given that votes are not necessarily cast by experts (see above), this means that posts will receive upvotes merely for covering a popular subject area, without necessarily covering it *correctly*.  And someone actually knowledgeable in a niche area can have a hard time getting their expertise recognised; having barely a couple hundred of reputation points makes them easily equated with a newbie.
- **Naïve scoring of individual posts**. Computing post score as upvotes minus downvotes is nonsense.  An answer having no votes at all is not worth the same as one having two upvotes and two downvotes: the latter is likely (given the previous point) to be something highly misleading which happens to have been upvoted by a couple of newbies who just don’t know better.
- **No reputation for moderation or curation**. There is no reputation to be gained from moderation tasks (raising flags, reviewing posts, identifying duplicates) or updating outdated answers, which discourages people from performing those otherwise rather dreary tasks.  Only low-reputation users can earn reputation from suggesting edits to posts, and it’s a measly 2 points per approved edit.  This also encourages writing redundant answers (see above), as there is more reputation to be earned from writing your own answer than from editing an existing one, even as a full answer may be not warranted.

All those problems mean that reputation is not a very meaningful or accurate measure of either expertise or contribution to the site, and not a very good incentive towards meaningful participation.

My proposed remedies:

- Make separate downvote and upvote counts on answers visible to everyone, instead of making it a privilege.  Especially that a userscript can circumvent this anyway: ["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/q/3082/).  There is a good reason people hate YouTube for removing the dislike count.
- By default sort answers based on some kind of Wilson score ([shameless plug](https://stackapps.com/q/8912/)), or other more meaningful statistic, not naïve upvote minus downvote score.
- Raise the reputation loss from receiving a downvote *on an answer*.  Perhaps introduce an incremental penalty: first downvote subtracts 2 reputation, second downvote subtracts 6, third and all subsequent ones subtract 10. (Not making them equal from the start should soften the blow from tactical downvotes cast for spurious reasons, which I expect to be rare.)
- Raise the reputation threshold to cast upvotes *on answers* to the same level as for casting downvotes.

  - At the very, *very* least: make the reputation threshold to upvote answers not take the association bonus into account.  The bonus should only grant privileges like commenting and flagging.
- Implementing the previous point will likely incentivise now-“disenfranchised” users to upvote questions more instead (which we might want to encourage anyway: questions tend to be under-upvoted), which may skew question scores upward; to counter this, lower the reputation gain from a question upvote back to 5 points.  Maybe to a bit higher level, but probably no more than 8 points.
- Lower the reputation gain from answer acceptance to just 5 points.  Unpin the asker-selected answer from the top on all sites.
- Implement sub-linear reputation gain from upvotes, e.g. logarithmic (the first *n* upvotes give you 10 reputation each, the next *n* upvotes give you 10⁄2 = 5 reputation each, the next *n* upvotes give you 10⁄3 reputation each, etc.) or square-root (getting the first *n* upvotes gives you 10*n* reputation, the next 2*n* upvotes give you 10*n* reputation, the next 3*n* upvotes give you 10*n* reputation, etc.).  This should solve the “too much reputation from just one very popular post” problem better than the daily reputation cap.
- Deny all reputation to answers on negative-score questions; possibly also on positive-score closed ones.
- (Much later edit:) In the answer author’s “signature box” at the bottom, display the user’s highest absolute score and relative rank in the particular question’s tags, preferably more prominently than overall reputation score.
- (Even later edit:) [Bring back the option to decline awarding a bounty.](/q/166172/620615)  Automatic awarding should only be used as a measure against *inattentive* bounty posters.

Not sure what to do about the moderation bit.  Also, perhaps there should be separate reputation scores for subject-matter expertise and for moderation tasks, as those are definitely separate kinds of skills, but I only have the vaguest ideas how that would look like.

(Even later edit:) Also, we could somehow encourage closing earlier questions as duplicates of later ones.  After all, just because a question was asked first doesn’t mean it’s a better one: questions on Stack Overflow are often formulated badly and mix unrelated concerns in one post, which sometimes gets unnoticed right after it’s asked, and only becomes apparent when answers accumulate.  This could also transfer some attention, and therefore reputation, to newer users, instead of having it accumulate with long-inactive users, thereby ameliorating the “reputation concentration” issue.

---

<sup>0</sup> Since then, as of late October 2023, the answer has earned three more upvotes, only one downvote, while the comment received five more upvotes.  If the meta effect has made any difference here at all, it seems to have made the problem worse.

Comment: "*Make separate downvote and upvote counts on answers visible to everyone*" This is done for performance reasons. While it is possible to get the vote counts, I would not make it obvious to everyone how to do it as it would lead to more load on the servers.

Comment: Implementing logarithmic reputation gain for upvotes would incentivise me to post a few thousand mediocre answers, rather than a couple of good ones.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Upvotes measure popularity, not quality. An exceptionally good answer can be rewarded with a bounty instead. Whether you will get one is another matter…

Comment: This is true – but incentives are as much about people's perceptions as reality.

Comment: "_even though the asker is often the least qualified person to judge how good an answer is_" hm. I don't think this is always true. If it's a "why" question, sure. But if it's a fairly simple "how" question on a technical site, usually answers either work or don't work, and I'd say the asker is in a good position to determine that because they can actually try it with their MRE _and even_ their actual context.

Comment: @starball Not always, but quite often, and even with how-to questions on a technical site. A newbie asker can accept FGITW solutions that neglect multi-codepoint Unicode grapheme clusters, or fail on file names containing spaces, or are susceptible to SQL injection, because it didn’t even occur to the asker that such problems exist. And often enough, the asker posts their question precisely because they’re a newbie. More experienced people can notice such subtleties and react accordingly.

Comment: @Dharman That's right, but I *feel* only because they are hidden to begin with, and every view needs to fetch that information. If the score is transparent from the beginning, this might not be the case (my reason for thinking this is that the result of the upvotes gets parsed (almost) straight away as votes come in, and I can't imagine fetching the *amount* of votes will be that hard on resources).

Comment: @Joachim No, that's not it. Score is cached. You can check the SEDE schema and see that Posts has a column Score. But upvotes and downvotes need to be calculated separately from Votes table.

Comment: @Dharman that's my problem with hidden votes. How difficult/costly is to store ups and downs instead of caching a total? Can't see a reason to not store/cache both.

Comment: @starball I don't know that I agree with that. Newer users often accept the solution that works, or the first one that works. Just because an answer _works_ doesn't even mean it's a _good_ answer, never mind the best one. All too often I have seen people spend much more time on elaborate and better answers, and even post comments indicating why the accepted answer is inferior, but the OP got their quick answer and is gone.

Comment: There's actually a badge for good answers on negatively-scored questions.

Comment: @starball "*But if it's a fairly simple "how" question on a technical site, usually answers either work or don't work,*" not necessarily true. Often there are nuances. An `O(n^2)` solution vs `O(n)` for example - both *work* but one works worse than the other. Also you seem to overlook *partial* solutions. Where an answer may not solve the general case but only works for the sample input in the question. And we know it's a partial solution also because OP accepts it...and then complains it doesn't work for other input. So "how" is more than a boolean "works"/"doesn't work".

Comment: "My impression is that the nerfing of downvotes was meant to avoid toxicity. If that is the case, then you can declare that objective a miserable failure, as Stack Overflow manages to be incredibly toxic regardless" - ... and what makes you think Stack Overflow would've been better (and not worse) with "unnerfed" downvotes?

Comment: I've seen this "passive income" argument come up a lot.  How often does it apply, really?  Does anyone have any SEDE queries we could poke and prod at to determine just how much of a pox this really is?  Otherwise I'm inclined to agree with a point that [Tinkeringbell made in another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356/the-stack-exchange-reputation-system-whats-working-whats-not?page=1&tab=scoredesc#comment1291624_387358).

Comment: Perhaps accepted answers should be clarified as "this solved my problem" rather than "this answer was the most useful", and can be given to multiple answers, or none.

Comment: By removing the downvote count, YouTube killed the value of the upvotes as a quality reference. Nowadays, it's just a bonus that we give to the channel owner, we have to gather the quality scanning the comments section.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Maybe it wouldn’t. But it might actually address at least some sources of frustration: with downvotes so de-powered, easily brushed aside and swamped by upvotes from people who don’t know better, people may feel leaving nasty comments is the only kind of negative feedback that will be heard and acted on. Seeing downvotes do something might actually calm them down. But even this said, I don’t think reforms of the reputation system alone can fix this problem.

Comment: @user3840170: The Wilson score corrects the uncertainty of a few number of votes, it does nothing to solve the issue of a witless mob. What about weighing votes based on the log10 of the reputation of the voter at the moment the vote is cast? The single downvote from a 1000+ user would nullify 100s of upvotes by 10+ users.

Comment: '*"Make separate downvote and upvote counts on answers visible to everyone" This is done for performance reasons*' - Are there any tests showing the performance degradation if this feature is enabled? As pointed above by previous comments, there are ways to do it without sacrificing performance, and unless I see a good test showing I'm wrong, I simply don't buy it.

Comment: " (‘Protecting’/answer-locking a question ameliorates this, but is not always available.)" Not by nearly enough, even when it's available. There gets to be a point where realistically, only people with a gold tag badge ought to be allowed to add another answer.

Comment: My answer has a lot of overlap with this one, and I even forgot some things raised here. In particular, I agree about the problem of votes coming from giving a question lots of attention from unskilled/low-information viewers. I would like to see some kind of "web of trust" model whereby voting counts more when it comes from users trusted in that specific domain.

Comment: @Makoto Anecdotally, thousands of my own rep come from a few of my own highest-voted answers from 10+ years ago, that I regret offering, sometimes on questions that I would VTC without a second thought today. In one case the question was fine but I decided years later that my answer was actually nowhere near as good as I originally perceived it, despite the positive reception; I ended up almost completely rewriting it.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 isn't that the point? Not logarithmic - that is far too steep - 1 point for 1 vote, 2 points for 10 votes, 3 points for 100 votes, wtf - but still something less than linear.

Comment: @user253751 "Logarithmic reputation gain", in this sense, is Θ(n / log n).

Comment: "*Deny all reputation to answers on closed and negative-score questions.*" Be mindful that downvoters often miss the meritorious details of a question. Your suggestion would penalize the author whose answer is aptly premised on those details. Furthermore, in such instances downvoters hardly ever withdraw their downvote/VTC.

Comment: @IñakiViggers we have that in the way of delete votes. The problem is that people simply seldomly vote, much less vote to delete questions.

Comment: @Braiam "*we have that in the way of delete votes.*" Not sure I'm following you. One who misunderstands a question and votes to delete it is in the same situation of those who VTC or downvote instead of deleting. I'm glad to hear that people seldom vote, since the cons of reputation system outweigh the pros.

Comment: @AndrewLeach there are a lot of badges that encourage less-than-stellar use of the site purely for engagement reasons.

Comment: "I can also recommend @Karl Knechtel’s answer with a similar list, but I think much better written, and it manages to cover a few issues I overlooked writing this one; yet another case of the FGITW problem." I don't know if I'd blame FGITW for that. To be totally honest, I read your answer after the initial draft of my own.

Comment: Re the new edit: "if the curators felt their downvotes actually matter, they might not feel the need to also leave nasty comments to make their negative feedback noticeable." - for my part, I try to be courteous but I comment constantly because I don't expect purely numerical feedback to be adequate. If someone naturally takes a -1 as e.g. "oh, I should have researched this more first", why would that same person not have realized the issue *before* posting?

Answer (score 73):

### What is really great about our reputation & privilege system? What do you think makes it great, and why is it worth keeping?

You need some way to sort the noise and votes are a decent way to do that. We also want to reward good posts and posters. You can earn privileges this way. The system does well here.

### What is broken about it, and why? Are there any solutions to it?

How long you got?

There's some odd distortions the system creates with regard to reputation. The first would be the false dichotomy of "high score/rep means good quality". I've seen users in the last month who insisted that their decently scored post indicated it was good quality. I've seen terrible posts that got lots of upvotes. I've even seen rep used to feed posts that are blatantly off-topic (the worst would be [service outages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74258160/is-jcenter-down-permanently-31-oct)).

Then there's the people for whom reputation = life. I've suspended sock puppet masters, only to have them come begging for the lost rep back. One literally told me that his getting a job in India depended on having high rep on Stack Overflow. Wat?

There are too many people who want reputation for... reasons. As I've noted elsewhere, I have seen a direct pattern of people who get into vote fraud, get caught, and then switch to plagiarism (or vice versa). Maybe they like the big number. Maybe they want privileges. ChatGPT has just piled onto that list. It's hard to say. There's not always a clear motive there.

I'm not sure there's any solutions that don't exacerbate the problem.

### What other systems work really well that we could learn from?

- Non-rep privileges. Want to do some rep-based things? Maybe take a test. We have no shortage of people who earn privs and then lose them through bad usage. it's not a great model. Maybe [create a way to train anyone who wants to review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394534/2370483)
- Tag badges - We give you a nifty privilege for earning a gold one. What about silver and bronze?

Comment: My pet peeve in this regard is that a lot of users seem to judge post quality by weight (size of the post). I'm not sure what could be done (reasonably) to fix that though.

Comment: Statistically speaking, at least on a site that isn't purely opinion-based like Meta, it's *vastly* more likely that a long post will be of higher quality than a very short one. Obviously, there's no shortcuts to actually reading the post and directly assessing its quality, but as far as heuristics go, length is a pretty good one, hardly anything to pet your peeve about.

Comment: "high score/rep means good quality" I don't think that is a false dichotomy. It's definitely a positive correlation between score and quality, just not working all the time. For people who disagree: just use random sort (date created might be a good proxy) instead of highest score first for answers for example and see if you get better information faster from the site.

Comment: The motive could be fear. Maybe the reputation points requirement (or online presence in general) for getting a job is a ***myth*** (not actually true in most cases). The plagiarism may be a means for getting the reputation points by the least amount of effort (enter words from the question into a search engine (or ChatGPT) and ***blindly*** enter the result as an answer).

Comment: "Then there's the people for whom reputation = life" - I have been paid six-digit dollars because of my Stack Overflow reputation. What happened to Stack Overflow Jobs, anyway?

Comment: I have significantly more reputation than you, @user253751, but I've been paid a grand total of zero dollars because of my Stack Overflow reputation. What am I doing wrong? (Seriously, I don't understand these claims people make about reputation having some value for getting a job or whatever. I've had a high reputation on SO for *years* now, even while actively looking for jobs, but it hasn't helped me at all. No one cares. It didn't/doesn't even help me to overcome my lack of a CS degree by, oh I don't know, proving that I know what I'm doing even though I majored in something else.)

Comment: @CodyGray What you are missing is the very good luck to get targeted by someone who is recruiting through Stack Overflow. Perhaps you even still think we live in a meritocracy.

Comment: re: badges. I would think this has the same problem as rep, which is a sort of "grandfather" issue. One really good question or answer, many years ago, got you a nice badge. Even finding that kind of Q or A in a long established site today is much harder to do. Maybe kind of boils down to an issue of "what have you done for me *lately*".

Comment: @JamieB are you aware that you should have several post in the tag to be able to get the badge? And it's the aggregated score of all posts under the tag? And that questions doesn't award badges?

Comment: @T.E.D. I think that's true for answers, I'm not convinced it's true for questions. I've found that a succinct question often gets better answers than a long-winded one. That's why we include "minimum" in [mcve] too.

Comment: @simonalexander2005 - That's an interesting perspective. I'd generally go the other way. On History we routinely ask question authors to provide details of all the reasearch they've already done (so 50 users don't waste t*50 time running down the same leads the asker already looked into), and where they got the info in their question (so 50 users don't waste t*50 time double-checking their interpretation), and by the time they've done that a good question will have a decent amount of meat in it. Some **short** words about their goals in asking can be helpful too.

Comment: @simonalexander2005 minimum doesn't mean shortest, it means that it doesn't have extraneous irrelevant information. The problem is that most askers don't know what's relevant and what not, so I prefer them to default to giving too much, so we can polish and clean the diamond, rather than having a chunk of graphite.

Answer (score 65):

> What is really great about our reputation & privilege system? What do you think makes it great, and why is it worth keeping?

I think it's a *great* system for encouraging participation. If there was nothing to signify your long-term participation on the site, a lot of people who are here simply to provide answers would grow bored with it pretty quickly.

> What is broken about it, and why? Are there any solutions to it?

What's broken about it, particularly on Stack Overflow, is it encourages users to answer posts that should be closed as a duplicate or off topic rather than voting to close because one is rewarded and the other isn't and is increasingly difficult to use with each additional one that is answered. It encourages users to ask for upvotes or to beg users to accept their answers, and it encourages users to fight against any moderation that goes against that gain of reputation. The incentives need to be balanced out to counter this conflict. I don't think simply adding reputation to moderation actions is the solution, rather, remove the negative rep of receiving and giving downvotes and reduce the incentives of accept votes and upvotes. Adjust how quickly users are introduced to these systems and allow feedback from anonymous users to be visible, perhaps through a new helpful/not helpful UI element that's available to everyone and doesn't impact reputation (not a replacement of voting, an additional feedback source without barriers).

> What other systems work really well that we could learn from?

A lot of other systems leave out downvotes entirely. They certainly foster a more... "friendly" atmosphere, but where that hurts is with quality and the ability for the avg user to indicate that a given post is wrong/out of date. Limiting that kind of feedback to users leaving comments is a barrier that stops most people from leaving feedback at all. I think we could learn from these systems and better capture feedback from users, possibly in a way that isn't perceived so negatively but still accomplishes the goal.

Comment: "reduce the incentives of accept votes and upvotes" how can you do that, when those are the only sustainable way to gain reputation? If we change the "+10" to "+3", all scores will be about a third of what they are now and the incentive will be the same. (Bounties will of course also be reduced by the same amount because the capital for bounties also comes from upvotes and accepts).

Comment: ideally, this would be combined with some of the higher reputation privileges moving to an alternative method for attaining them, see the "abilities" or "roles" suggestion in [Spevacus's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387365/200898). the point of all this would be to reduce the gamification slightly while removing barriers and the perceived negatives of moderation actions. going to +3 would be a bit extreme, I'm not certain it'd need to actually change from +10, but I'd definitely want to see the -2 and -1 removed.

Comment: I don't hang out on SO as much as I used to, but back when I did (and it was using the same rep system as today), the userbase was far far **too** quick to close questions as dups. All it takes is a few users who don't quite understand the question, but think they do, and SO has thousands of users. I once had the fun nightmare scenario of suddenly starting to get downvotes on a well-recieved answer years later because it had wrongly been closed as a dup, then merged with the supposed (but actually unrelated) "dup", where my good on topic answer was made retroactively completely off-topic.

Comment: So no, last I checked, SO had the exact **opposite** problem to the one related in this question, IMHO as a side effect of it having orders of magnitude more users than the reputation system's designers anticipated.

Comment: I wasn't happy about the rep cost of receiving a downvote being reduced from 10 to 2.  A downvote should fully cancel an upvote. I'm even more not happy with the idea of removing the rep penalty altogether.  There's nothing wrong with penalizing people for posting bad content, especially when the penalty can easily be canceled by deleting the content.  On the flip side, I'm fine with paying rep to cast a downvote, but I'd also be ok with removing that cost, I think.  Consider that the rep cost for downvotes offers some protection against wanton downvoting.

Comment: The primary penalty of downvotes at the moment is the user loses the ability to post entirely if they do not improve. I think that's penalty enough, generally

Comment: "What's broken about it, particularly on Stack Overflow, is it encourages users to answer posts that should be closed as a duplicate or off topic rather than voting to close because one is rewarded and the other isn't" - I completely agree with this.

Comment: I agree that +10 vs -2 for up/down votes is a huge issue. There's a looot of users who leave a stream of crap, but if you get +2/-2 on a post you're in the net positive. Considering that it takes almost zero effort to get enough reputation to upvote, and that clueless masses will upvote literally anything that has an up arrow next to it, this is a pretty bad premise.

Comment: On the raspberrypi.stackexchange.com site the +10 -2 causes anomalies. There is a serial upvoter (practically every question gets upvoted, even those with multiple close votes). I don't particularly care up reputation but this defeats the need for users to have reputation to Comment.

Comment: I fail to understand WHY downvoting a poor answer penalises those who downvote. This is a disincentive to flag poor answers.

Comment: @Milliways See [Why do you lose reputation for downvoting answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15863) for some explanations. I have no strong feelings either way, but I've always been more puzzled by the inconsistency that downvoting answers is penalized, but downvoting questions is not.

Comment: @JohnBollinger "A downvote should fully cancel an upvote" - good idea in theory, but it's problematic in practice. People downvote for all sorts of petty reasons. Getting downvoted for seemingly no reason already sucks, that'll make it suck more. The unequal reputation probably isn't ideal, but most users are human, so we should be considerate of that. If downvotes were more limited, this may be a better idea. The bigger issue, perhaps, is that one can have a negative scoring post that still gives you reputation (this might be easy enough to fix by just ... not having it give you reputation).

Comment: @KevinB "The primary penalty of downvotes at the moment is the user loses the ability to post entirely if they do not improve" - for new users, perhaps. Downvotes may also incentivise users to put more effort into what they post, and to improve their posts (in theory, possibly, although in practice I've found downvotes to do little more than breed resentment and frustration).

Comment: @NotThatGuy, I am well aware of downvotes occurring for petty and / or arbitrary and / or just bad reasons. I have received my share.  I have seen even more posts getting upvotes despite being poor quality or downright wrong (and I've received one or two of those, too).  I think the DV / UV asymmetry is *more* problematic.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've seen my fair share of people commenting and explicitly admitting to upvoting something because someone else downvoted it. I've seen downvotes have very little positive effects (in case of poor quality, the post usually ends up getting deleted anyway) and cause plenty of frustration with the site and users on the site. Making upvotes and downvotes symmetric will make all of that (and votes for bad reasons) worse. It may also aggravate the problem of posts having too many upvotes and too few downvotes, because users may be *less* likely to downvote.

Comment: I've seen too many people say they don't downvote because it removes rep from the user too many times to want to increase the penalty. The penalty *is* a punishment when we should instead be encouraging the user to improve. Penalties should really only come into play once it has been determined that the user isn't improving. Seeing a -1 on their question score is plenty enough to get users who would be impacted by a loss of rep to want to do something about it. Those who don't care won't be influenced by anything we do.

Comment: Dunno whether it helps any, but I would also be ok with reframing the rep gain for post scores so that instead of +rep for upvotes and -rep for downvotes, we had +rep for net positive scores.  The effect would be similar to balanced scoring for individual votes, but conceptualizing it differently may be useful to some.  Also, in the form I just stated it, that would remove any penalty for net negative scores.

Comment: "_rather, remove the negative rep of **receiving** and giving downvotes_" whoa there. I almost missed that while skimming.

Comment: @John Bollinger You should totally post an answer about this penalty stuff. So broken

Comment: You mention rep encouraging answering rather than closing, but what really irks me is how reputation encourages closing rather than *downvoting*. I have seen good questions closed, despite numerous upvotes, simply because 5 people decided *they* couldn't answer it, therefore it was bad, but a downvote costs them rep whereas a VTC is free.

Comment: @JamieB eh, i think you're jumping through a few unnecessary assumptions there.  question downvotes are free, so a close vote instead of a downvote makes no sense there, in terms of it being a reputation issue.

Comment: @JamieB downvoting questions does not cost rep. Only downvoting answers does. So, your observation is off.

Comment: @vlad Ah, interesting. That really makes it extra baffling why people go to VTC when what they should be doing is downvoting. The votes to reopen these wrongful closes gets tedious at times.

Comment: @JamieB Perhaps because it's off topic and should be closed? Just because you have an opinion that it isn't off topic, doesn't mean your opinion is any more right than theirs. Closing questions is a collaborative effort; if on your stack there's a disagreement about what is and isn't off topic, that needs to be dealt with on the per-site meta.

Comment: @KevinB I'm certainly not arguing that all VTCs are wrong. But many are, which brings us back to the topic at hand: "high reputation" does not always mean "good at moderating". When you see questions closed with a bunch of upvotes and an answer by the local moderator, then you have to start questioning where the reputation system has left the rails and put the wrong people in charge of sealing off content.

Comment: Moderation and reputaion should be separate. However Encouraging duplicate close is double edged.. It might inflict much more frustration for false vote to closed.

Comment: Yeah I'm not a fan of suggested edits getting rep much less any other moderation action.

Comment: I remember when I got a bunch of downvotes on an answer back in 2015. I was still a new contributor and it did hurt a bit. But reviewing my answer, it was pretty stupid and I hadn't put two seconds of thought or research into it. The system worked, and from then on I actually thoroughly thought through any question, answer, or edit.

Comment: "*Limiting that kind of feedback to users leaving comments is a barrier that stops most people from leaving feedback at all.*" That is exactly what should happen. Feedback cannot lead to improvement of a post if the downvoter doesn't bother to articulate the reasons for downvoting, which sometimes reduce to animosity toward the author.

Comment: @IñakiViggers Yes, however we lose a valuable metric that is used to determine whether or not a post is actually useful, if we just ignore any feedback from  users who don't wish to enter into a confrontational interaction with someone else on the internet.

Comment: That metric is replaced with something more useful: articulated remarks that prompt others to assess issues which hitherto might have gone unnoticed.

Comment: @IñakiViggers No, it's not replaced at all, it's entirely lost. that's the entire point. If you don't accept anonymous feedback that feedback doesn't exist. It doesn't magically result in more comments.

Answer (score 65):

I was [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356/the-stack-exchange-reputation-system-whats-working-whats-not/387365#comment1291454_387365) to contribute this as an answer, so here goes. I'm going to directly quote from [a blog post I wrote in 2020](https://medium.com/swlh/the-thinking-behind-codidacts-abilities-system-9e235d5ffb8?sk=f226f3d7d044f979ee3236bf2aff77ad):

> ### The problem with Stack’s approach
>
> [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) — which Codidact *largely* grew out of — awards various privileges [based on your reputation score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), which is calculated largely by votes on your posts.
>
> This… is a bit problematic, in a couple different ways.
>
> First off, reputation itself is wearing way too many hats. It’s simultaneously supposed to be acting as:
>
> …a general indication of a user’s proven expertise on the site’s subject matter. (More simply put: It’s supposed to give you a rough idea of how much that user knows about whatever that specific site is about. A high reputation score on a site such as Math shows that you probably know what you’re talking about with math-related stuff.)
>
> …a general indication of a user’s familiarity with the site mechanics. This is why reputation unlocks privileges, and why users who have 200 reputation on another site are [automatically granted 100 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/294691) when they join another site on the network.
>
> …a gamification incentive. Also known as “Pointz”. People love earning points for their contribution; reputation serves as a gamification incentive by awarding people points when they get votes. (See also: Reddit karma; Imgur Internet Points.)
>
> As a result of trying to do all these things at once, it winds up doing all of them… less than ideally.
> Anyone who’s paid any attention to Stack Overflow Meta will notice that there are users with *thousands* of reputation points who have absolutely no idea how site mechanics or policies work. Sure, they’re probably good coders, but they don’t know how to edit a post or what the heck a “review queue” might be.
> You can also earn up to 1,000 reputation by suggesting edits on a site. I’ve personally earned a bunch of reputation across various sites that I know nothing about, just by suggesting edits… but if I decide to post, my reputation score might lead people to think I’m more familiar with the subject than I actually am.
> It works for gamification pretty well, I suppose. Not perfectly, but good enough… and getting into that is really off-topic for this article.
>
> Circling back up to what I just said, I want to emphasize the important part: *“…there are users with thousands of reputation points who have absolutely no idea how site mechanics or policies work.”*
> *That* is the problem… because reputation points give privileges.
>
> As users with thousands of reputation points, they have access to moderation tools such as voting to close posts, voting to delete posts, unilateral edits, and more… because they proved they know how to answer questions.
>
> They don’t have those privileges because they’ve showed they know the rules about when to vote to delete answers. A lot of them have no idea what the policies for deleting posts are, or how the privilege (that they have) works. They earned reputation through answering questions, and suddenly have the ability to vote to delete posts.
>
> ### There’s another way
>
> So now we’ve identified the problem: Users earning privileges through actions that are *entirely unrelated to the privilege itself*.
>
> And now we have an obvious solution.
>
> **Users should earn abilities and privileges through actions that are directly related to the ability they are earning.**

The rest of the post goes on to detail how we went about implementing this idea over there, but since we're talking about changing things here on SE, I can contribute a few more thoughts in that direction.

**Rep is wearing too many hats; let's take at least one of them off**.

Privileges, for the most part, should not be tied to reputation.

This is a point others have raised, mostly focusing on edits. I'd like to expand on that somewhat.

Perhaps the best example in the system we have on SE today is flags. You earn the privilege to raise a flag at 15 reputation<sup>[1]</sup>. When you earn the privilege, you have a maximum of 10 flags per day<sup>[2]</sup>. As you raise flags, you earn more flags to raise per day if your flags are being marked helpful, while you run into warnings and flag-bans if your flags are being declined.

This is how the system should work; as you prove that you know how to properly use each system, you should be trusted more within that particular system.

Extending that thought, if enough of your suggested edits are being consistently approved, you should earn the privilege to edit directly. If your close flags are being marked helpful and the posts that you flagged are getting closed, you should be able to vote to close directly. If your NaA and VLQ flags are consistently helpful, you should be able to VTD directly - and as your close votes and delete votes result in consensus, you should earn more per day.

While it makes sense to set a baseline level of reputation to be able to begin earning those abilities, in order to ensure some level of familiarity with the site and not to overrun people with poor review items<sup>[3]</sup>, we're currently locking a bunch of people out of helping with moderation just because they aren't prolific contributors to Q&A, without taking into consideration any effort they've put into other aspects of the site.

---

<sub><sup>[1]</sup>Aside from custom mod flags on your own posts, which you can raise at any rep, IIRC.</sub>

<sub><sup>[2]</sup>Well, 10 flags for posts and 10 for comments, since they're counted separately.</sub>

<sub><sup>[3]</sup>Although it's a fair argument that that ship has already sailed.</sub>

Comment: Who does the approvals in this system? I'm imagining a full system reset where we all start off with flagging right and....presumably some poor moderators beset with handling them because no one else has that privilege yet? Maybe we unlock the whole shabang. Everyone can flag. Everyone can answer flags. But the bars are all raised. If I VTC then it goes into the queue, which anyone of any rep can handle, but it needs more agreement (and/or a certain ratio) in order to succeed. Hmm. Just spitballing here really. But I'm wondering how to launch from 0 with an already popular site.

Comment: @JamieB: Mods are the only ones who can actually see flags anyway (and that wouldn't change as part of Mithical's suggested system) – and certain flags are automatically handled by the system (e.g. by causing the post to appear in a review queue). But also, the proposed system wouldn't have to "start from scratch", with everyone limited to suggested edits again regardless of their rep; we could potentially use each user's previous actions as a metric by which to recalculate folks' access to privileges, based on the same metrics by which we'd determine that access in the future.

Comment: (...For instance, if we were to automatically grant the ability to edit posts directly after a certain number of approved suggested edits, that same calculation could be done to the users that are here now, based on the actions they've already taken – we wouldn't have to start with no one having any privileges at all.) That's just one way to address your concern, if we were to implement this.

Comment: Well said.  I believe that I am in agreement with this.  For some time,. I've been wondering if there was a way to assign privileges based on demostrated need for the tool and ability to use it correctly.  And unassign them when no longer needed.

Comment: And what of the consequence of removing so many votes and users from the community moderation effort? How is that being quantified and qualified here? How many users with thousands of reputation truly fall into these broad generalizations?

Comment: @V2Blast "the proposed system wouldn't have to "start from scratch", with everyone limited to suggested edits again regardless of their rep" except that we want a system that works well for freshly created sites and established ones. The full reset scenario is any site that comes out of Area51.

Comment: @Braiam - Similarly to how private beta works now, I'd say. At the moment, during private beta anyone can VTC and edits have a very low rep bar. CMs handle flags. At the end of private beta, mods are appointed and public beta begins. I'd think that anyone who voted to close or reopen a certain number of times which resulted in the action happening would then keep that ability, along the same lines with edits. I don't have specific numbers worked out for SE right now.

Comment: @Mithical I am mostly worried about the ability to upvote. [I see that anyone can upvote during the private beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/213575), but I'm still worried about the participation of those users during the open beta or full site.

Answer (score 46):

Reputation is meant to be a gamified system - do a good, get a shiny. That already motivates some people to play the game to get shiny, not because they want to do good.

Add to that, reputation is meant to reflect the quality of action a user has taken, most significantly in the content provided for the sites, and it seems clear that the shiny you get for doing good must be balanced by the shiny you lose for doing bad.

**Upvotes and downvotes *must* have the same impact on reputation**, otherwise it becomes meaningless at any scale worth discussing.

Consider some situations that are extremely common.

A user who posts on a small site with a +1/-1 will have a net gain of 8 rep. Is this post really contributing the same value as four distinct approved edits, or most of the same value as a post with +1/0 score? A post on a larger site with a score of +10/-10 will have a net gain of 80 rep. Do we really believe such a post is at the same level of quality as one with +8/0 score? I absolutely don't think so. This only encourages controversy and appealing to a popular interest instead of fact-based informative content.

A user with enough rep earned off historic posts has cleared any barriers to posting. They won't get Q-banned without a moderator intervening, which most are loath to do to someone who's been around for a while. They have a silly idea pop into their head, and they ask a question. +1/-3 and, oh, wait, they've gained rep for posting a bad question?! And that's just a small site. Getting +3/-7 on some sites isn't hard, but that person is still gaining half the rep of a post at +3/0 score, despite being clearly of the opposite quality by the standards of the site.

A user finds a question that is definitively off-topic by the consensus policies established. They disagree and they want to answer it. +1/-4 because the unhelpful question asker is happy they got what they want, site standards be damned, and that's a net gain in rep for going against the community. Even larger if the answer was accepted.

If we're meant to be about using rep to gauge value created, value added quality generated, then we have to be doing that in both directions. We can't even get people into negative number reps anyway, so it's not like we know anybody below a certain threshold is a net drain on content and quality (and an increase in curation and moderation workload). The only way we can see a user's net contributions are not valuable, is if the only corresponding public measure is reduced.

And that requires losing the same shiny for doing bad as one gains for doing good. Anything imbalanced as we have now, makes rep into a certificate for participation, not quality assurance.

Comment: A small problem with this is that it will also make it easier and more worthwhile for users, who are, for some reason, upset about another user's action, to affect that person's contributions. With the small loss of the current downvote such an action of revenge simply doesn't have such a dramatic impact.

Comment: I'm probably not a typical user, but my experience with getting multiple downvotes on non-technical sites is that its about 30% because my take was generally judged to be horrible (no or almost no upvotes), and about 70% because some people don't **want** what I wrote to be true (net positive vote result). Giving downvotes the same weight as upvotes would seriously deter people from weighing in on subjects like religion or politics, and would empower some of the worst actors on our sites. Perhaps the ratio could be adjusted some, but making them equal is a seriously *Bad Idea*.

Comment: Equalizing the change between up and downvotes would be a big mistake. Instead we should undo the change from a few years ago that made question upvotes worth 10 rep and instead make them 5 again.

Comment: Writing comments on a post that makes clear the reason to do something is a pretty bad place to argue for doing a bad thing in multiple places instead.. @TylerH

Comment: That's one form of abuse of the system which we already address in several ways. It is a terrible excuse to build in other ways to abuse the system, some of which are described in this very answer, and have no solution beyond *not building abuse into the system*. The number of unfixed revenge downvotes is tiny compared to the amount of rep unduly earned by crap posts that get sympathy and/or popularity-based support. @Joachim

Comment: I think I agree, if the main thrust here is that we should lean more on "the overall community" and less on "reputation is king". +10/-10 being better than +7/0 is a great highlight of community input being of secondary concern to reputation gain, but this extends across many aspects. 5 people doing a VTC on a popular topic because they, personally, have a different interpretation of the rules than the rest of the community is a wrong I frequently see, too. Community input needs to count for more, and reputation needs some counterweight.

Comment: This would deter asking 'expert' questions that require a domain expert to answer. These are frequently downvoted, either because readers don't have the level of expertise to understand the question and assume it's bad, or assume that the person asking must be doing something wrong if they need that information.

Comment: @T.E.D. Kudos. This is the first comment here that *truly* gave me pause and made me consider that the policy surrounding reputation should perhaps be different for different network sites. (Aside, perhaps, from the issue of smaller sites needing more curators and thus desiring a lower threshold to assign those privileges; but the entire rep=privilege system is broken in my view anyway.)

Comment: @Nij I disagree. Lesser reputation penalty for downvotes certainly doesn't make the system meaningless and here's why: 1- If the goal is to gauge **individual content quality**, the post's score is enough to some extent. 2- As an **incentive to improve**, for new users it's also enough to see a negative value, as evidenced by the frustration felt (enough for some to leave and not return) despite rep not going below 1. 3- If the purpose is to value **a user's overall contribution**, not getting points where others do is also enough to leave one behind, in relative terms.

Comment: Furthermore, a higher loss in rep would make the decision to downvote even harder than it already is (as mentioned in Kevin B's comment in his answer above). Since a negative vote has a higher signal than a positive one, why should they be equal in terms of reputation? A small loss is indicative of wanting it to work as an incentive to improve, not as a punishment or stigma (why would anyone want users with negative rep?). The point shouldn't be about making the system mathematically symmetric, or even fair for that matter, but to make it work in a way that encourages good content production.

Comment: Interesting perspective. Not a useful one, as far as what can be actually observed to happen on the network in general, but thanks for adding your 2¢.

Comment: Indeed it is my 2 cents, although I won't take credit for all of it. It's also the perspective of a relatively new user, I am sorry you didn't find it useful.

Comment: @T.E.D. Would it be fair to catagorize such sites as "more opinion based". I'm not quite sure the word "technical" paints the line in the right place.  The meta sites themselves would fall into this same characterisation. Purely fact based sites tend to suffer less with what people *want* to believe.

Comment: @PhilipCouling - No it would not. Asking a question that is asking for opinions is a damn good way to get your question closed within the hour on History (to be fair, there are a lot of good ways). I believe the same could be said for Politics, Physics, SciFi, RPG, English, etc., but I don't moderate there so perhaps I'm wrong on one or two of those.

Comment: @PhilipCouling - Good History is also based on verifiable / verified evidence (and the analysis thereof). There are differences of course (we largely have to rely on "natural experiments" and can't just go make our own) but there's really much less difference there than you appear to think there is.

Comment: Well, even for Politics, as a user I see good questions on that site being along the lines of "Why do Greens tend to be against *issuex*?", where a good answer will reference articles explaining the Green argument against *issuex* and why they feel that's important. Its quite objectively answerable, even by someone who isn't a Green and totally disagrees with them, and good answers should look similar (unless there are actually tons of reasons on that issue).

Comment: @T.E.D. Sure. But the problem with "opinion" is complex WRT Politics in a way that is less common for Physics. In your example, the answers are likely to cite reference material published by the subject themselves. Though such answers might be interesting and informative, there is a problem of whether the subject was being honest.  And there lies the challenge of "what people want to believe".  Even where the answer's author might claim it was backed up with evidence, belief of that evidence might itself come down to opinion.

Answer (score 40):

Two things to add:

- A few users on my site (I'm a mod on [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)) have done a lot of community moderation work (retagging, posting on meta, voting to close, editing, etc.) and would be good candidates for moderators. But, they have relatively low reputations, which effectively makes them unelectable. I realize "incentivizing" moderation actions is potentially problematic, but our current solution (not offering any reward at all) is perhaps a bit extreme.
- There is a huge [first mover advantage](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/case-study-first-answer-bias) -- answers posted in the first few hours will usually outperform answers posted a day later in terms of votes (and therefore visibility, and reputation). The green checkmark counteracts this to some extent, but this introduces its own tyranny -- askers sometimes make non-sensical selections, or do not select anything at all. There are several possible improvements here, the simplest of which is to introduce a post sorting order that will rank posts based on a combination of newness and upvote-to-view ratio, and allowing alternative ways to award the checkmark (or killing it entirely).

Comment: Or kill entirely the checkmark. One user chooses now, you are proposing exchanging "one" for "a few". Same problem. Votes are enough. We can still have a checkmark that OP can choose, but without any consequences, points and less visible.

Comment: Good point, I generalized a bit, don't want this answer to become a referendum on the checkmark solution.

Comment: BTW, I'm currently a mod too, nothing against mods, but the concept itself.

Comment: `But, they have relatively low reputations, which effectively makes them unelectable.` I can relate :( voters will not vote for users who have low reputation despite being active, simply because new users need a very long time to reach a high reputation score

Comment: *"the simplest of which is to introduce a post sorting order that will rank posts based on a combination of newness and upvote-to-view ratio, and allowing alternative ways to award the checkmark"* that was actually implemented recently on SO, research "trending sort." I wonder if it'd have value outside of SO?

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu - agree. On SO especially, I use SO everyday and would be willing to contribute, but virtually all of the questions/answers I have are already there and so there is nothing to do except upvote. The reputation system definitely favors a certain type of user.

Comment: The checkmark could be attached to the question, just to indicate that OP has the answer they were looking for, without pointing at any specific answer, and without any rep gain for the answerers.

Comment: Well maybe that's appropriate. There's so many very good questions closed as it is already we don't want a flood of noobs coming in and thinking they have to close as many questions as they like.

Comment: @Bacco: I would be on the losing of that one. I've seen too many cases of a +50 bad answer and a +5 good answer that got the checkmark. It's not a great tool but it's the best tool against the first mover advantage.

Comment: related feature-request that I'm thinking of eventually "re-hashing" with much more detail: [Why there isn't reputation points for successful flagging?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80852/997587)

Comment: @Bacco The checkmark is useful because the highest-voted answer is not always the correct one. Often, someone posts an answer that is usually useful but actually not useful for the question where it was posted because of some detail in the question the answerer and voters did not consider.

Comment: @user253751 you described a situation that don't represent the majority of cases, we can't evaluate something based on this. Usually when the check don't match votes the check is wrong because some "helpdesk" factor. Answers are not "for the OP" only, the check usually promotes undesired helpdesk. I'm not saying that what you describe isn't a problem, but it probably deserves a real solution (maybe pre-a filter of questions before letting someone answer).

Comment: @bacco Getting rid of the checkmark is a great point. One of the purposes of questions is to be *generally* useful, not just to that individual asker, but to a broader spectrum of future searchers. Knowing which answer worked best for the asker is often irrelevant. Certainly in Stack Overflow, I frequently find the answer I used further down, because I had the same issue, with slightly different circumstances, so his checkmark served no purpose.

Comment: "We can still have a checkmark that OP can choose, but without any consequences, points and less visible." Or we could track them separately from reputation, and have the system know that certain people offer answers that OPs like without giving a rep reward. Of course, what the system *does with* that information is up in the air a bit...

Comment: "and would be good candidates for moderators. But, they have relatively low reputations"  This has been debated quite a bit on SO. The sound reason for requiring rep from moderator candidates is to ensure that they actually have some foothold on the actual site and don't spend 100% of their time in some "meta-reality", spending 100% of their time doing meta tasks instead of participating on the actual site. There are lots of people like this. The problem is that they lose touch with the actual site culture and what the site is actually about - doing moderation is not the goal of any site.

Comment: Both the checkmark and the voting are useful. Notice that votes mainly come from people who do not have the problem in question. Isn't it useful to know which answer is verified to have actually solved the problem by the person who had the problem, as well as which ones the community thinks are most useful?

Comment: @user253751 trivial to prove that the checkmark is incorrect: an answer gets posted, let's say, a week after another answer was accepted. But OP, having had the problem solved already, doesn't come back to re-verify the solution. The new solution might be *better* but would never get accepted. If you think that's a contrived example - many answers are posted more than a week after - months or years later. Many of the question authors never come back to see them for one reason or another. And most importantly **the answer is not for the question author but everybody**.

Comment: @VLAZ that's why I say both are useful. At different points in its history SO has made the mistake of prioritizing one or the other in sorting.

Answer (score 34):

**Make downvote criteria the same as upvotes.**

Downvotes are not worse or any less important than upvotes. On the contrary, with the current system, downvotes are more important than upvotes, as they can only be cast by more experienced users and there are fewer of them.

Remove the -1 rep cost for downvoting answers.

Increase the reputation necessary to upvote to 125.

The only thing which I would leave the same is the reputation loss from receiving downvotes. With -10, users could feel like participation is too difficult. With the abundant revenge downvotes, this problem would be bad for psychological health of SE's users.

Comment: I agree with almost everything here, but I do want to point out that new sites should have a different (lower) threshold for upvoting as otherwise no user will ever have the privilege, and some thought needs to put into what that should be and when to increase it.

Comment: I'm not particularly concerned about revenge voting, but for those who are, one could consider increasing the rep cost for downvoting.  I would be happy with a -10 rep penalty for being downvoted (like in the good old days :-)) and a -5 or even -10 cost for *casting* DVs.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I would be left with 0 reputation points if every downvote cost -10. Downvotes should not cost rep as this discourages voting.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how "-1" was arrived at. Did someone actually do a study and found -1 was the sweet spot for encouraging needed dv's, but discouraging flip ones, or was it just a SWAG?

Comment: @T.E.D. This is where it would be helpful to still have Shog around...

Comment: @TylerH - Well, he's not *dead*. I think I follow him on Twitter still. However, this number probably goes back to the Jeff Atwod days, no?

Comment: @T.E.D. Maybe? I've seen some "OG" people talking about downvotes costing -10 before though... And a _lot_ changed between late 2008 and ~2010/2011, after which point a lot has been more or less the same... Plus I mentioned Shog because, aside from having been here since around then, he was always particularly adept at translating technical details into user-friendly speak, not to mention usually excellent at the justification part, too.

Comment: One consequence of the discrepancy between upvote and downvotes is that any HNQ post tend to get skewed in terms of votes. HNQ attracts people from across the network who can upvote thanks to the association bonus but cannot downvote. Moreover, people attracted from HNQ also seem to upvote on what seems most fun (on some sites, at least) not what actually answers a question of what is useful. Thus further skewing the results.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh how many times I wish I could downvote with my 100 bonus.

Comment: @Dharman discouraging downvoting was precisely the point.

Comment: "The only thing which I would leave the same is the reputation loss from receiving downvotes. With -10..." We don't need to make downvotes have less effect than upvotes in order to soften the blow. IMX questions at +1/-1 are more likely to be worse than ones at 0/0, not better (*partly* because the upvoter could be someone in the 15-125 rep range), but currently they net +8 reputation. Several other proposals suggest *treating the net score on a post in a non-linear fashion*, and this could also be used to limit the reputation damage of downvoted posts. IMX it doesn't mean much past -3 anyway.

Comment: I wish it took a CV Reviewer badge to down-vote *without comment*.

Comment: @T.E.D. it's easy to figure out. The cost of downvoting was thought of by Jeff to dissuade people from downvoting and be more judiciously. What he didn't count was the effect of people trying to hoard as much rep as possible (I'm sure it has a name, fear of <something>) so downvoting, which was something people avoided, now had a objective reason to avoid.

Comment: [Loss aversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion) explains a lot of behavior surrounding voting and the greater reputation system here, @Braiam. And yes, Jeff was very much counting on this effect - what has ended up causing more issues is the disproportionate growth in posting vs voting, which has resulted in a "vote" being worth a lot more (+ and -) in 2023 than in 2009.

Answer (score 33):

**Reputation should not be gained from closed (non-duplicate) questions and their answers.**

A closed question means that it should not receive answers. If it has received answers nonetheless, then these answers should be treated as invalid. Users should not be rewarded for asking popular off-topic questions. Users should not be rewarded for answering questions that should not be answered.

The only exception to this are questions closed as duplicates that serve as useful signposts.

Comment: but what about super popular closed questions that the company likes to point to as examples of great contributions?

Comment: @KevinB They have been mostly all been deleted now. All remaining ones should either get a historical lock or be deleted too.

Comment: I support this, rep cap the canonicals and rep lock de dups.

Comment: "Closed questions should have all answers hidden from public view."...What would this accomplish?

Comment: @Heartspring-CDR It would hide potentially unuseful answers from normal visitors of the site.

Comment: Very good idea! One caveat (if this were to be applied retroactively): policies change throughout the course of some of the sites. On Worldbuilding, for example, I believe this would cause a lot of frustration, as users are finding the amount of questions being closed already annoying at times. Still not sure if that would be a bad thing, but it would be unfair to users having asked and answered questions that once were definitely on-topic (identification questions come to mind).

Comment: Do you mean to exclude questions closed as dupes from the answer-hiding proposal, too, or just from the no-reputation-gain idea?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Both.

Comment: This seems to be blurring the distinction between closed and deleted questions. It reads like you'd like all closed questions to be deleted.

Comment: @T.E.D. The second part of this proposal is less important. The main part is about not getting reputation from closed questions.

Comment: I agree that closed dups should have all +/- votes  negated.  I don't particularly care if they are hidden or not.

Comment: I don't know if I agree with this.  Closure *can* be a temporal thing and the mob can get things wrong.  Why should someone's reputation growth be stunted because a group of people decided to close their question, and it took *some time* for that to be reversed?

Comment: @Makoto Then it will motivate that person to get the question reopened. Win win.

Comment: I disagree. I answered too many questions that later got closed for bad reasons.

Comment: Many well-answered questions get closed as duplicate when a similar question hits Hot Network Questions.  Removing rep from (or worse, hiding) questions that were answered before the replacement question was posted would be wrong.

Comment: Agree with the first part and disagree with the second. If a question get closed, then quickly opened, answers would flickr (i.e. disappear and appear again). I don't think this is helpful.

Comment: What's bad about dupes? They lead two searchers via two potential routes to similar problems & solutions. They *increase* engagement. Unless the question is "What is 2 + 2?" there is invariably more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: @Joshua "I answered too many questions that later got closed for bad reasons" - Were those really "bad" reasons, or were those just reasons you don't approve of?

Comment: SE isn't all about SO. A closure means different things on different networks. On less-popular ones, new, vague duplicates encourage new perspectives on old topics that'd otherwise not be posted, as I've often observed. I strongly disagree with this proposal.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Duplicates are excluded from this proposal. A closure means that the question should not receive answers. If it can receive helpful answers then why close it?

Comment: _"If it can receive helpful answers then why close it?"_ Agreed in theory disagreed in practice. It takes more energy to consider reopening than to close, and it's strongly pronounced on less active networks. But also not entirely agreed, closed != useless, closed = doesn't meet site's rules. Many examples of objectively helpful answers closed as "opinion-based", for one. Or on non-coding sites, if a question asks for code, it's closed, yet code-providing answers remain very useful - "move it to SO" is another theory vs practice hurdle.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: The ability to answer the question and get upvotes on the answer shows more ability to understand it than the ability to close it. I've had to fight hard to get questions reopened so I could answer them more than once. Most people simply don't have the energy to overcome a bad close reason on most questions that get closed long after answering them.

Comment: @Joshua If you believe you understand a question perfectly, but other people don't understand it, rather than fighting to reopen it, it probably makes more sense to edit it so other people can understand it. Not to mention that having the "ability to understand" the question only really relates to one close reason, whereas knowing the site rules and what's on topic is more relevant to closure. You being able to answer a question doesn't mean it belongs here.

Comment: @Dharman:  Reopening a question can be a gargantuan effort.  I mean, there's a whole lot of people who are just chomping at the bit to play rules laywer on why specifically your question was bad enough to not warrant your reopen vote, for instance. There's also this whole fatigue of just...not wanting to touch a question which has been super downvoted.  [Maybe if those kinds of questions were "forgiven",](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259077/175248) I could agree with your suggestion.  But otherwise, I don't think this proposal makes sense.

Comment: @makoto If reopening questions is near to impossible then this needs to be looked at first. It should not be this way and I rarely encounter this.

Comment: *My Brother in Christ*, you hang out on Meta Stack Overflow. How do you *not* know that question reopening is near impossible with the parade of people who ask about it there?

Comment: Question closure (at least on Stack Overflow) is a problem right now, and has been for several years now. This would only amplify that problem.

Comment: Regarding the problem of questions being closed too much or reopened too little: Mind that one reason for this is that many people who answer questions do not care enough to improve questions, engage in reopening, or Meta discussions to better delineate what should be closed or not. I have even witnessed (and worked against) site cultures where the same people answer and vote to close certain types of question. Denying reputation for answering closed questions creates an incentive to solve this.

Comment: Duplicate questions [aren't that bad](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Comment: “ The second part of this proposal is less important” Then remove it or make a separate answer to allow to  vote them separately. I downvoted your answer because answers to closed questions still maybe useful. “closed” means that no new answers are allowed for different reasons(sometimes arguable)

Comment: "The only exception to this are questions closed as duplicates that serve as useful signposts." There should be some systems in place to make it easier to migrate good content from duplicates to the canonical.

Comment: I'm wary about hiding answers publicly on closed questions, simply because I imagine a world where search engine results mostly show questions with no publicly viewable answers and no way to contribute. It looks like that got edited out of the proposal, though. I'm generally very much on board with this.

Comment: @NeilG "There are so many badly closed good questions it's not funny." My experience has been that people expressing this sentiment typically go on to defend questions that I'd find quite poor. I'd welcome your own examples, though.

Comment: @Makoto the real problem is the downvote "well" on initially-poor questions that get improved. Past -3, downvotes don't really carry meaning (the -3 questions are just as bad) or consequences (-3 enables deletion), and it's hard to get people to reverse their downvotes even if there has been a radical improvement (if only because the downvoters have **moved on**). In many cases, it would make much more sense for all parties to just delete the question and start over - except for the part where this angers the Q-ban algorithm.

Comment: @TravisJ "Question closure (at least on Stack Overflow) is a problem right now, and has been for several years now." I agree. We don't close **remotely anywhere near enough** questions. New questions are bad enough that the closure rate ought to be over 90% ([as Sturgeon predicted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon's_Law)). Much better yet, questions should start closed, and hopefully the opening rate would stay under 10%.

Comment: "The internet does not care about questions which didn't get closed with a little discerning sad face on them" - I care, when I am trying to use an external search engine to find a canonical, and the results are flooded with terrible questions that aren't related to what I'm looking for but happen to have several keywords in common. Presumably, everyone else who uses a search engine for Stack Overflow cares, and **that is primarily what we are trying to support** (hence the "library" phrasing in the tour). Fewer results is better, because the right result **will** show up - and sooner.

Comment: "as the current narrow set of topic, by design, only allows questions which most users find unsavory to answer" - ??? "narrow set of topics"? `select count(*) from Tags where Count > 50` on SEDE tells me that Stack Overflow has nearly 30,000 tags having at least 50 questions.

Comment: Thanks for responding @KarlKnechtel (I think?). That's fine if you like to work from prejudice. I call it a good question if it's highly voted, or if one or more answers are highly voted. I'd call dozens or hundreds of votes "highly rated".

Comment: @NeilG I like to work from what the site policies say are the requirements for questions. Feel free to show a badly closed, highly-voted question, though. When I try searches like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3A1+score%3A50), I don't see them.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, those types of questions that get flooded with loser answers are usually the simpler questions. I'm certainly not saying there are *no* questions/answers that could be closed. But this sort of swamping is more a result of that breed of losers who answer a question *again*, a year after it was already answered with an accepted answer, but with the half the information, and no grammar. I presume this is some sort of rep mining going that could be addressed individually. For instance, if you have too many zero vote answers below a certain word count - they all get deleted?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, questions like "what's the diff between inner & outer join" are obviously going to have duplicates. I'm not sure how many of the q&a I've seen over the years are inside that list of 10,000 questions. Policies are not always enforced properly. Admins determine a dupe and then get hit by a chorus from users who actually have expertise in the area. Sometimes it's quite glaring how ignorant the admins are. Closure is sometimes due to "opinion" but there's dozens begging to hear respondents expert opinion because a technical answer sometimes is opinion. No convenient list for these.

Comment: @NeilG I struggle to imagine an argument that "What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?" and "Determine the type of an object [in Python]?" are somehow not the same question. However, I have gone back and forth to some extent trying to decide which of those two should be the canonical. I have a chat room where I discuss these topics: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247434/python-canon-discussion. What I do not have is income from closing questions. I resent the implication that I am motivated by anything other than a desire to improve the quality of the site.

Comment: "Admins determine a dupe and then get hit by a chorus from users who actually have expertise in the area." If you mean diamond mods, it's relatively rare that they attempt to close duplicates (they have their hands full with many, many other tasks, like deleting NLN comments and enforcing the new ChatGPT policy) and IMX they're **paranoid** about doing so without subject matter expertise.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "I struggle to imagine...": you seem to have misinterpreted my point. I was not arguing that they were. Not that I can find my comment where I mention that now ...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I'm pretty sure a number of my comments seem to have been deleted or somehow gone missing. As far as I remember our conversation was on this answer. You were of course my antagonist; can you confirm that comments that you read here earlier are now gone? Do you have ability to delete other users comments?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel to be quite honest at least on SO, in aggregate, the closed questions that i've found tend to be more useful than open ones. 

the closing/reopening system has been a massive failure in that the most on topic and googleable questions are closed.

Comment: @justcool393 But that's exactly why you found them. Otherwise they would be deleted.

Comment: my point is that perfectly good questions are often closed for nonsensical reasons and getting good (or at the very least, useful) questions reopened is a sisyphean task. 

it's ok to reward good questions and answers even if they're closed.

Comment: @justcool393 Then there is something wrong. It takes 3 reopen votes to reopen the question, same as it takes 3 close votes to close it. If a question is really good then it should not be difficult to find 3 people who agree. Could it be that what you consider good is generally considered unsuitable for the site?

Comment: @justcool393 there are countless questions that are highly googleable and very much "about programming" that are nevertheless considered off topic because they are subjective and/or invitations to discussion.

Comment: @Dharman and yet... it doesn't happen with extreme frequency, as Makato mentioned.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i'm clearly not talking about those. but it still stands that "xyz was closed 5 years ago for some meme reason" is a common problem, especially on SO. it's such that i kinda just roll my eyes when people say there needs to be more closed stuff.

it's especially bad with duplicates since a lot of the times the questions are different in a subtle but important way.

editing almost always works better most of the time if it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @Dharman: Here's an example of a gold badge holder closing a question that should not be closed. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55081462/14768 What's actually going on here is there's some problems with how gcc on Windows picks up its target libraries, and there's a specific workaround that makes the general question inapplicable.

Comment: @Joshua Vote to reopen it then. What's the issue?

Comment: @Dharman: I did before. It remained closed.

Comment: "it still stands that "xyz was closed 5 years ago for some meme reason" is a common problem, especially on SO." They **aren't meme reasons**. They're the official, well-considered policy of the site, which exists for reasons that have been discussed forever on Meta. The fact that we used to tolerate questions that we blatantly should not have, doesn't change this fact. " it's especially bad with duplicates since a lot of the times the questions are different in a subtle but important way." No, these differences are usually not actually relevant, and when they are, there's a **different** dupe.

Comment: @justcool393 if you think you have any concrete examples, you are always welcome to post about them on meta.stackoverflow.com - that's what it's there for. WRT question closures, my experience is that we aren't perfect, but we are much better than detractors claim. I have also found detractors usually have serious misconceptions powered by either ignorance of clearly stated policy or an incoherent belief that Stack Overflow *should* work a certain way *just because other sites do*, even though we *explicitly* set out to be *not like* those other sites.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel lol no. it is absolutely a meme that SO closes questions for the most inane reasons, even if they put on the facade of using site policy to do so, and SO is bad about it.

no one (outside of the people who close them) actually takes question closure seriously because of the 3ks that tend to close things they have no expertise in. it's part of the site's reputation at this point.

Comment: @justcool393 that's because the world outside of Stack Overflow is full of people who don't understand how Stack Overflow is intended to work - which is also exactly why those questions exist in the first place. Policy is very clear. I've looked at the popular videos people make on the subject, and over and over again you get things like "LOL SO HATES OPINIONS" - well, no, there's nothing emotional about it, it's just black-letter topicality policy.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel oh people understand what the rules are. it's just that most 3ks ideas of the site rules are frankly out of line with stated policy and don't have the domain knowledge to judge quality questions or the site rules *OR* they just want to play internet mall cop and the network gives an easy way for people do so automatically.

Comment: Frankly, my extensive experience is that the opposite is true. But feel free to show me an example of a question you think has been treated unfairly. Better yet, post about it on meta.SO - that's what it's there for.

Answer (score 33):

(This answer is primarily driven by my experience with Stack Overflow, and my understanding of the Stack Overflow tour page; but I have confidence that the same principles should apply more or less network-wide.)

Whoo boy. I have *so* many complaints about the reputation system generally (and even more about how voting impacts on *the Q&A*, as opposed to users). I actually have a blog post planned about it for the somewhat near term, but I stumbled upon this Meta post so I might as well take the opportunity to gather some thoughts.

### Perverse incentives

- Getting your question or answer upvoted awards 10 reputation; getting it downvoted only takes away 2. That incentivizes people to be controversial rather than boring. Boring is usually higher-quality and more encyclopedic.
- Getting your answer accepted awards an additional 15 reputation on top of the +10 from OP's upvote. This incentivizes tailoring answers to OP's specific circumstances, rather than trying to write in a broadly-applicable way that will be helpful to people who find the Q with a search engine. It also incentivizes tolerating questions that are clearly too broad (if you help OP with multiple issues, and make code with multiple issues work, that increases the likelihood of OP being positively overwhelmed with the helpfulness). Also, anything with *that* effect, has the ripple effect of discouraging editing (since Q&A are now more tightly coupled, the minimum unit of coherent editing increases).
- Accepting the answer also gives 2 reputation to OP. This incentivizes OP to accept an answer even if none of the provided answers actually get it right.
- Reputation is awarded the same way for answers even if the question is downvoted and/or closed. This incentivizes answering questions that are clear duplicates, because of the likelihood that OP will upvote and accept that answer. Such answers interfere with the deletion of low-quality signposts (although I am personally of the opinion that keeping around duplicate questions is useful because it helps establish the importance of their canonicals). It also incentivizes trying to mind-read OPs who don't express themselves clearly.
- There's an especially obnoxious cumulative effect here: the first upvote on a "[fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533)" answer, along with the accept vote, nets a total of +25. It takes **thirteen** downvotes from concerned curators to make it unprofitable for unscrupulous reputation-seekers to answer questions that they ought to know shouldn't be answered. I've interacted with users like that many times. They often have 10+ user accounts and hundreds of thousands of rep; and their response to comments explaining the damage they're doing to the site ranges from a shrug to extreme indignation.
- There's a lock-in for votes on Q&A that weren't edited, which doesn't respect the fact that sometimes people genuinely change their mind. (One thing that's happened to me a few times is that I upvoted something because I thought it was the best canonical available, then found something much better and actually discovered serious issues with the first option.) This incentivizes 2k+ users to make dummy edits in order to reflect that changed viewpoint. (I try to make my edits substantial, but there have been times where I improved a post while also changing my upvote to a downvote... because I really don't know what I was thinking with the original upvote. Sometimes the upvote was literally years ago, and I still had to edit because of the lock-in.)
- Getting an edit approved awards reputation, but making unilateral edits does not. This means that people who reach the 2k threshold have a sudden shift from extrinsic to intrinsic motivation for improving the site. (This makes me want to launch into a whole separate diatribe about the edit queue, but I don't think it's on topic here.)
- Downvoting costs a point. I doubt that many people are seriously discouraged by this, but it bears noticing that the stats show a heavy upvote bias among logged-in users. Last time I checked the statistics, votes from users were more than 90% up, while "anonymous feedback" is close to 60%. (This is, admittedly, skewed by the fact that users between 15 and 125 reputation can upvote normally but have attempted downvotes logged as feedback.)
- Meanwhile, there is **no** reputation incentive for most curation activities. As above, that includes unilateral edits (2k+ users), and also:

  - closing duplicates
  - casting close votes on things that should be closed
  - casting delete votes on things that should be deleted
  - using the review queues (in any capacity whatsoever) - the only thing one can get from using the review queues is a ban from the review queues

(There are finer points I could make about the curation experience, but again I think they drift off topic.)

- Comments can be upvoted, but not downvoted. While this doesn't award reputation, it has psychological implications. I've [NLN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420)-flagged quite a few old comments now that had a significant vote tally on them - typically, comments on an answer complaining that the problem shouldn't exist or should be simpler to address, and typically ones that show a serious (but common) lack of insight or understanding.
- I'm not entirely sure how this works, but it's clear from my experience that moderators are disincentivized to delete duplicate *answers* on old questions if they're contemporary with the post. I don't get why, because this apparently [would not significantly impact on the answerer's reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261698) - but I do think it bears mention in this section.
- Currently, Q&A get rewarded the same regardless of the topic matter (or the inherent difficulty of the problem). This incentivizes people to stay in already popular tags and allows less popular tags (where answers are often more *needed*) to languish in obscurity. While the ["no sense of urgency"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569) culture is a net positive, good questions really should get answered *eventually*. As it stands, our only workaround for this is an extremely clumsy "bounty" system. Which segues nicely into...

### Linearity

In my mind, it makes very little sense to count each upvote and downvote on a Q or A the same, and it makes barely more sense to tally per-post reputation to give an overall score to a user.

- In my experience, both Q and A aren't really any higher quality past a score of +10 or so; they're just *older*. Often they're *lower* quality because a) the information has become deprecated or b) it's an A for a Q that used to meet site standards, but now it doesn't. There are any number of psychological barriers to downvoting things that already have a lot of upvotes, and even with "trending sort" it can be quite hard to lower them on the page. Personally, my highest-voted answer is at +346/-2 on a Q that's +444/-5 - and I've thought more than once about deleting it, because the question is still blatantly two unrelated questions, even after extensive editing to make sense of a barely coherent mess.
- In my experience, questions below -3 aren't really any lower quality than ones at -3 (except for spam/vandalism/trolling, which we do an excellent job of cleaning up). Even from -1 to -3 is a rather shallow gradient. A -3 score makes posts eligible for manual deletion; there's little point in going further than that.
- On the other hand, in my experience, answers at +2 are **much** higher quality than ones at +1 on average - because the +1 category is swamped by things that were upvoted by OP and nobody else. A +2 typically entails some kind of confirmation from someone with relevant knowledge and understanding. Most people asking don't have that (or they would have self-answered).
- Summing reputation gained across multiple questions doesn't make a lot of sense. For people who didn't get in early (and thus have the ability to gain "dividends" on old questions that come up a lot in search engines), the easiest way to game the system is quantity over quality. The first upvote on a question ought to count less (per the previous point), but it counts more (because of the accept system). But being able to write a lot of answers each day isn't evidence of expertise; it's evidence of addiction to a particular mode of using the site. (I shudder to think what would happen if the daily reputation cap had not been implemented.)

### One-dimensionality

Even if the system worked as intended in the above regards, and incentivized people to write high-quality Q&A (and put A only on Q that should have them), and take positive steps towards curating the site:

- The ability to be *helpful* or *insightful* has little to do with the ability to be *responsible* - but we use the reputation system to award moderation-like privileges. (This has a knock-on effect that off-site critics mistakenly describe non-diamonds as "moderators".)
- Clear communication is totally separate from expertise, but we reward both on the same scale. A reputation score can't tell you who's an X guru vs. who is obsessed with X and wants to find a lot of things to do with it vs. who is skilled at creating simple demonstrations for common X gotchas.
- The site already has a separate system for recognizing expertise: tag badges. Why is, for example, editing of a tag wiki tied to overall reputation, and not to experience **with that tag**? Which leads me to...

### Quirks of the privilege tower

- It takes 15 reputation to upvote, but 125 to downvote. I mentioned earlier that this contributes to a bias in the voting/feedback stats. It's also inconsistent with the widely-held view (at least on Stack Overflow meta) that downvoting is a vital curation tool. In particular, that makes it that much harder to sink old content that is deprecated (assuming it can't be salvaged; but trying to add up-to-date information to old As that aren't CW often gets you yelled at) or which no longer meets site standards (which changed since the content was posted).
- The site association bonus is enough to allow people to create chat rooms and edit CW posts, but not enough to downvote. This strikes me as very backwards. It shouldn't take subject matter expertise to recognize that a question or answer is unclear or unhelpful (or, say, politically inflammatory - and it's usually *very* hard to get site moderators to agree with [R/A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor) flags for that); but it might well require an [SME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert) to recognize a technical inaccuracy or an opportunity to rephrase something in proper domain language, and it definitely requires SME to chat about the subject matter of that SE site.
- It takes 50 reputation to comment on other users' questions. This means that a lot of new users who know a little and want to be helpful, end up trying to use the answer section to give feedback on questions (that should be closed). Even flagging takes 15 reputation, and doesn't let these new users explain specifically how they think the question should be improved. (Speaking of which, the flagging system is also a mess, insofar as low-rep users have additional flagging reasons that copy the close vote reasons, but work differently and independently from actual close votes, and are hidden in that interface.)
- It takes **3000** reputation to vote to close questions. That's **absurd**. It's saying that "I think this question has issues that need to be fixed and shouldn't be answered in its current state", *and getting two other people to agree with you before anything is actually done about it anyway*, is somehow a greater and more dangerous responsibility than *unilaterally attempting to fix it yourself* (2000 reputation). (It's especially absurd in an environment like Stack Overflow, where the large majority of incoming questions are terrible and the site would be much better off if new questions *started* in a closed state and had to petition to get opened.)
- It takes only 1500 reputation to create new tags, but 2500 to synonimize them. This is another bias towards creating junk and away from curation.
- It takes only **ten** reputation to answer protected questions. This is definitely not enough, at least for Stack Overflow. Lots of old, famous questions have way more answers than they need - and we don't close them because they meet site standards and closure is seen as a black mark, but we still let almost anyone contribute additional redundant garbage to them. There have been times when I had something useful to contribute to a question that already had dozens of answers - but it's accompanied by a sincere wish that half those existing answers would just disappear.

Comment: "_That incentivizes people to be controversial rather than boring._" what does it even mean for something to be controversial on a tech site about facts? If anything, I'd expect a controversial post to get more downvotes on SO.

Comment: "_But being able to write a lot of answers each day isn't evidence of expertise; it's evidence of addition to a particular mode of using the site. (I shudder to think what would happen if the daily reputation cap had not been implemented_" Note sure I understand what you're saying here. The daily rep cap is geared more toward limiting "passive income": ["_Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to this daily reputation limit._"](/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: To your point about 2k edit and 3k CV, some close-reasons are not fixable by anyone other than the asker, such as needs detail and (on SO) needs debugging details. And edits are not for anything that violates the post owner's intent, so what you're really left with is mostly cosmetic changes. Granted, you can often (with non-trivial effort) fix things like opinion-based and needs-focus, so I see your point there.

Comment: "(It's especially absurd in an environment like Stack Overflow, where [...] the site would be much better off if new questions started in a closed state and had to petition to get opened.)" – This is basically what the Staging Ground is (which is currently in testing on SO, as mentioned in the question post).

Comment: IMHO that first point about incentivising controversy is wrong. What it does is incentivises sloppiness: an answer that is one-third right is worth posting, because its upvotes will outweigh its downvotes.

Comment: Answers on SO can be "controversial" by injecting opinion on the "right way" to solve a problem based on some subjective factor - even if the question didn't ask for such opinions. But thinking about it more, I think @SteveBennett has the right take on the issue there. Being controversial might be more incentivized on other sites though, like the ones to do with politics or religion.

Comment: @starball What I mean about the rep cap: there are a handful of people on Stack Overflow who answer *way too many* questions, seemingly just hoping to get 20 +1s and 20 accepts a day. These are often people with 6-digit rep totals who seem to be motivated purely by making that number go up. It would be *even worse* if the 21st answer gave them +25 instead of +15. Any time that a site supports user-generated content, you will end up with a long tail of a very few users who spend *way too much time* generating content. (Incidentally, thanks for highlighting the typo.)

Comment: @V2Blast the staging ground seems like a splendid idea. I hope this time, the shiny "get new users to actually ask questions properly" toy actually functions as advertised. The current "Ask Question Wizard" does basically nothing except demand that users fill out the form sequentially (trivially circumvented, and often counterproductive anyway) and split the body in two (in a way that is often unnatural and leads to a bunch of questions where substantial portions are just duplicated, while doing absolutely nothing to improve clarity or focus).

Comment: What do you mean by *"if they're contemporary with the post"*?

Comment: Re *"motivated purely by making that number go up"*: There *could* also be [a financial incentive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417632/request-to-let-banned-users-ask-one-question-every-week#comment906279_417632) that we don't know much about. Or altruism (*"I just want to help."*).

Comment: "answer contemporary with the post" is straightforward: i.e. posted near the time that the question was originally asked.

Comment: you illustrate a lot of potential exploits in the system, which I have never even thought to investigate in this way, so thank you! is there evidence for the degree to which this are exploited? I tend to have a simplistic response of "well couldn't SO detect and cap such-and-such exploit" which is possibly unrealistic

Answer (score 29):

In my not so humble opinion (active Stack Overflow user for 10+ years, active forum user for 20+), you're coming at this from entirely the wrong direction. Paraphrased, this is your concern:

> *"We want more users to like our site, so they stick around and make our numbers bigger, because eternal growth is totally not a capitalistic fable and we're not yet big enough and still don't make enough money for our shareholders"*.

You can then tweak the reputation system, but people (most notably the ones you need to keep the site alive) don't come nor stay for the reputation system. People stay because they have time to spend and want to hang out with likeminded people, and/or they want to display their knowledge, and/or they want to help people who run into the same challenges they have.

And then there's people who use Stack Overflow as their resume, so they think they have to have a profile full of badges and points so potential employers will notice them.

Just accept that there are only so many people wanting and capable of giving meaningful, helpful, constructive, qualitative answers that actually improve the value of your Q&A site, and you're not scaring those away with any reputation system, and that there never has been and never will be a lack of people daring to ask questions.

Comment: This is wrong because you need to renew the userbase, and [it's now become unreasonably harder for the next generation to establish themselves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383670). Your fundamental premise is also wrong: devs come here because they need to find solutions, if there were be a better repository elsewhere that's where people would be. I'm also not enthusiastic about the vets who got lucky rep-wise in the early days and never contributed anything afterwards (be it Q&A or curation) it might just be time to level the field and return some meaning to rep.

Comment: People needing help can't be bothered about reputation points, they just want answers. The people that need to be retained, are people who can write, research, explain, and they generally don't care about reputation either. The premise of this question is how to retain more users overall by tweaking the reputation system, which is in my opinion a fallacy.

Comment: @bad_coder Why do you need to "renew the userbase"? And your claim that "if there were be a better repository elsewhere that's where people would be" is also obviously false, since it entirely ignores the effectiveness of SEO and name recognition.

Comment: A large number of users can write, research, and explain that care a lot about **reputation** and wish to have more. Both for “number go big” gamification and for “I need/want that privilege.

Comment: @James then why do I see so few? People don't _need_ gamification, they generally want _recognition_. Big numbers and lots of badges are but one way to provide that. See also: [Where's the new boatload of experts who can explain stuff to me like I'm five?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392414/wheres-the-new-boatload-of-experts-who-can-explain-stuff-to-me-like-im-five).

Comment: I don’t have 20k helpful flags because I’m cool. It’s due to gamification. If I could have 20k rep by answering or asking I would game that. But it’s next to impossible for a user only active for 7 months to ask or answer non-duplicate questions that are clear and have no answers 3 minutes after being asked.

Comment: @James and how is a change to the reputation system going to cause an influx of non-duplicate questions and going to motivate you to write those or answer them? My point is that the focus on reputation and growth is wrong to begin with.

Comment: That might be your point, but it doesn't show from the answer. It seemed to be based on what I believe is a misunderstanding of the motivations. While true, I may be inclined to wish to play the "number go up" game with rep I **need** to ask/answer to get to 10k to be a better moderator: I could then see deleted posts.

Comment: @JamesRisner expect that by posting here, on this site, you have selfselected yourself into a group of users that isn't the 99.99999% of the people that use SE sites. So, your argument while valid and correct, is meaningless. CodeCaster here actually hit something in the crux, reputation is not the main motivator for people asking questions nor it is for people answering questions with well through-out answers. They former has a extrinsic motivator that the site can't control while the later usually have an intrinsic one. See JourneymanGeek's answer for an example.

Comment: @Braiam seeing as in moderation chats it seems to be a common discussion on how reputable seems to be so overpowering that it makes moderation difficult. I guess your point is for the non-reputation seeking and non-moderators make up 99.99999% of the user base. You might be right. I’ve just never witnessed someone with your viewpoint on reputation until now.

Comment: At least, someone with more than 100 rem. I’m not counting the 1 rep people.

Answer (score 28):

Well, at least in my own experience, reputation as a motivator is a bell curve. You'd need to get pulled into being an SE regular for reputation to matter. I turned up on Super User because a site about computer stuff seemed *interesting* and branched off from there. And the last time I actively cared about reputation was when I was trying to work my way to 10k to see a deleted answer of mine (the system changed halfway through me trying to get it... but I got my 10k anyway!).

Most of this isn't *actually* about reputation. Bear with me; I'll come to a point eventually ;)

TLDR: Reputation is overrated.

Unfortunately, some of the actions taken to try to fix new user onboarding - I think Joel [spelled out the problems really well 10 years ago](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/07/20/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/) but to be really blunt, quite a lot of what was done was rather hamfisted and... didn't work quite well. He *is* right about the community dynamics here, just not how it was handled.

To quote Joel

> After a few years, an insider group of old-timers forms. They get to know each other. They know the rules. They know the history and the legends of the community. And it’s only natural to get little bit irritated when newbies show up who don’t know the rules.

And there's so much more here than the reputation. Even if a new user gets past the reputation hump - growing that circle of 'insiders' is essential. The newbies see the number and think that's *important*. It’s an entirely arbitrary number, and frankly past a point gets you nothing.

The problem isn't as much 'reputation' as much as how newcomers being onboarded. A new user with quality posts, or maybe even an intuitive understanding of the system is going to have an easier time than someone who just walked in via Google and/or is expecting a forum. There's different user stories for either as a new user and... neither is going to go "Hey! How do I make this number bigger?"

They are going to remember helpful comments, people editing/improving their posts and guiding them through their fledgling stage.

> But as we’ve seen, our system and community in its current state has a high barrier to entry. Asking or answering a question back in 2009 was a lot easier as we were building the library of knowledge that exists today. There were a lot more questions yet to be asked!

Not entirely true. Our standards were much lower and we ended up often needing to change scope as time went on. Even as a very experienced user, there are new technologies I'm messing with (I'm currently working on and having trouble with Nebula VPN for example) and software and software UXes evolve over time. That there are fewer questions to ask, or we'll ever be done with new questions is a misnomer.

The definition of a *good* question and answer , and the barrier to that has gotten higher. As an oldtimer, working/asking mostly about personal projects on my techie sites, I'm happy to refine a question in my head for *weeks* before asking. I go back and work on old answers and write new ones over several writing sessions because I've had years to work this out.

I'm pretty sure if I started a new account, picked up a few projects, and started using the same tricks I used as a new user, I'd probably be able to hit 10k in a year. It’s not a reputation learning curve; it’s a skills and spoons learning curve.

> We still want users to be able to participate on our site and feel as though they are a part of this community. But unfortunately, we’ve heard from so many of our users, particularly newer ones, that the learning curve is steep and it’s difficult to find ways to engage on the site.

I don't think anyone comes in here worrying about the depth of the mechanics and reputation. Much of the friction is not mechanical and about reputation; it’s cultural, with a mismatch of expectations between new users and experienced one.

The 'learning' curve is as much about learning to deal with how to ask 'good'/better questions, dealing with criticism (textual and votewise) and the mechanics of the site. Worrying about votes is very much an early/middle lifecycle thing for a user—when you're wondering 'can I ask my next question' or 'can I unlock the next privilege?'

I've often said that SE builds communities in spite of itself. Healthy communities need to go beyond the utility of knowledge sharing. As much as main site use, things like chat and meta are also really good, neglected onboarding tools.

*Reputation* isn't broken other than the attention put to it. 5 reputation vs 10 for a question upvote didn't 'break' the network - the reasonings behind it did.

Reputation as a number isn't 'unfriendly'; it’s the actions and meanings behind, say, a downvote that matter more. There are folks who tend to be a little too focused on reputation, but people are going to come here to find answers and stay for the community.

By the time you 'worry' about reputation, you're already hooked, so any new user who complains... isn't really new, just someone who's engaged already, but who is still finding their feet. It’s better to teach them where the ground is, than move the ground to their feet.

As an old user - well, what's the value in my 145k reputation here?

[image: Meme from Jurassic Park. Man in colourful Hawaiian shirt and a man in polo T sitting together. Text in first panel "LOOK THIS GUY HAS 145K rep! Panel 2 "See no one cares!"]

At this point I have name recognition on the site, so my reputation isn't just reputation. I've not unlocked any additional benefits from being a high rep user. My motivation isn't reputation for most parts - it’s what I can do to try to, depending on the time period, protect my *other* sites (where its the same story), push (what I think are) positive changes...

Reputation *isn't* as important as people think it is. Reputation is broken because people focus on it too much. It’s also a handy, mildly arbitrary way to gauge how well people know the system, even if it’s how to break it.

And because of that, well, I don't think 'major' changes are needed. Our privilege system, tied to reputation, could use some consideration though. What would be *positive* actions that could be rewarded outside reputation gain? What are actual pain points for new users? (Downvotes? Not getting the structure of a good post? Not being able to find help and mentorship?)—these feel more important than trying to 'fix' the reputation system.

Comment: I 90% agree with this IMO.

Comment: What's the 10%?

Comment: That this site is full old-timer forums.

Comment: I have been here... 12 or 13 years... I have noooo illusion of not being an old timer. And that's a 9 year old quote 

Comment: But that's just my opinion and thats how I view the site as.

Comment: I sense it's mostly high-rep users who claim reputation doesn't really matter, though. I think that says a little about the relativity of the relativity of reputation :)

Comment: [something like...](https://starecat.com/content/wp-content/uploads/money-doesnt-matter-rich-people-looks-dont-matter-attractive-people.jpg), _"Reputation doesn't matter" -- high rep users_ @Joachim ? :D

Comment: I think you get it.  Reputation is just a number.  But for those of us with six digits worth of numbers we can say that.  For those with less orders of magnitude of numbers, it's *everything*.  But it's also the center of everything, which plays against your perception here (and mine a bit).  But it's the one I agree with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange Journeyman Geek, thank you for posting here! Definitely agree with your answer, not entirely sure on the name recognition thing.

Comment: "Our privilege system, tied to reputation, could use some consideration though." – That is part of what our question is trying to touch on here – not just reputation for reputation's sake, but the way in which reputation touches other parts of the site as well. You may want to elaborate on that part of your post (or link to an existing post where you've already elaborated on it). :)

Comment: @Joachim I'm not high rep *everywhere* - and I still don't really care about reputation on those sites too :D

Comment: @TravisJ If I started a new account as "Journeyman Geek" - people would recognise it, and probably flag it as a fake. Least here and hopefully on my site metas, people 'know' me by more than the size of my... reputation.

Comment: @Joachim: It's been years since I cared about reputation. Until 50K there's the next batch of privileges to unlock, then 100K is a nice round number, and you get swag so that's cool too. After that, though... I mean, what's the incidence of a +1 (or -1 for that matter) on my reputation these days? It'll take 100 upvotes for the "abbreviated" score next to my name to change anyway...

Comment: @MatthieuM. My point exactly. And the swag is no longer a thing, right?

Comment: @Joachim: I got the swag a long time ago, and to be fair I didn't even know I would get it ahead of time ;)

Answer (score 24):

As a mature system, the problem with the reputation system starts with the name, as "reputation" is related to *trust*, but the [current reputation system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) is actually a points system. It's a single bucket for points that might represent different things, such as effort (among other things). A high reputation value doesn't always mean that someone has a high level of trust from the community (understanding community as the real people that use the site, not just as an abstract concept).

Also, the current system assumes that there is a direct relationship between these reputation points and values, skills, and knowledge. It's ok that the points system give access to privileges/benefits, but tasks and especially moderation responsibilities deserve to be handled in a better way.

The designation of [site moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) already have defined things for this and experience alonge more thang 10 year on multiple sites. There might be things that require to be improved there things that could be extended for certain tasks an perhaps not necesarily on a per-site basis.

**Tasks requiring skills**

For tasks that requires skills, one way to handle them better might be to limit the rate of tasks that one user that can do according to the their experience level.

Examples:

**gold tag badge holders**

Those at the beginner level might use the dup hammer once a week, those at the intermediate level might use it once a day, and those at the advanced level could use it without restrictions.

To be promoted to the next level, the posts they closed by using the dup hammer should not be reopened within one month.

**tag creators**

- At the beginner level, they might create one tag.
- At the intermediate level, they might create up to five tags.
- At advanced level, no restrictions

To be promoted to the next level, the tags they create should have a tag wiki approved by an advanced tag creator. A diamond moderator might also approve tag wikis, but only when there are not advanced tag creators available.

**Trust**

For tasks that trustiness is a very important element, I think that we should elevate trust above a mechanical points system. It might be related and might be required to have access to have earned a certain level of reputation points, but privileges/benefits strongly promoted as being related to trust, IMHO, should be reserved for very specific privileges and preferably avoiding "mechanical" access to them (i.e. they might be assigned/removed by an election process and/or by site moderators/CMs).

One example might be participation on disputes of moderation actions. Anyone might start a dispute and anyone starts with the privilege to participate on disputes According to participation history in disputes their participation rate of participation in current disputes might have some limit. Let say, someone that derails conversations / present deceiptful content frequently in disputes might be limited to make one post a day instead of being allowed to post freely.

### Gap

The current system already has several features that allow moderators to suspend specific privileges – i.e. when a user is caught repeatedly approving evidently very low-quality posts, that user could be suspended from doing further revisions, but could continue posting questions and answers, which is fine.

Something that might need to be reviewed regarding trust is the way that moderation disputes are handled. They might deserve their own trust point scale, as failing in conducting a dispute probably should lead to a whole site participation ban.

Comment: "_privileges/benefits strongly promoted as being related to trust \[...\] assigned/removed by an election process and/or by site moderators/CMs_" which privileges are you referring to, and how might this scale with large sites like SO?

Comment: There isn't really a "beginner level" to having a gold tag badge, it is extremely difficult to obtain, and in that process most users become intimately familiar with the site and its functions.

Comment: @TravisJ Someone that recently earned a gold tag bagde might be SME in the topic related to the badge but that doesn't make them experts in the use of the dup hammer... actually a gold tag badge holder might never voted to close a question of duplicate before getting the dup hammer privilege.

Comment: @Rubén - Let's not get too far off the point here (with regards to reputation), but that isn't really the case. As I said, there isn't a beginner level. Read more on the insights and debate around gold tag badges here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders

Comment: @TravisJ The examples here are not descriptive (they are not about the current state) they are imaginative / innovative (they are about a posible future state) .

Comment: @TravisJ the idea is that, having received a gold tag badge, one would hypothetically gain "beginner level mjollnir" access, which promotes to greater levels of mjollnir access after it has been established that previous hammerings were approved by the community. Also, it's just spitballing one of uncountable ways of doing it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - Yeah, I get it. It's just not based in any actual analysis, and highlights the sort of kneejerk reaction aspect of this suggestion. Then again, maybe we should require people to actually have well received questions, before allowing them to judge how to produce them; that would give a much needed insight into using these tools. "Tasks requiring skills"... Skill: Ability to create well received questions, Task access: Question closure.

Comment: "It's just not based in any actual analysis" - I don't think *analysis* is required for the proposition "let's consistently make it so that new privileges are awarded on a trial basis and access to them expands when the user demonstrates a capacity to use them properly".

Comment: Re the dupe hammer: I have it in the Java tag, and there are cases where I wish I _didn't_. Some things are clearly dupes, and I'm happy to wield the hammer. But there have been subtle cases, where I wished I could submit a _vote_ like a normal person, and see if there's agreement among other high-rep members.

Answer (score 23):

### The core mechanics work; don't change them.

- Upvotes and downvotes to earn and lose reputation.
- Earning basic privileges: it's like [a fizzbuzz test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz).
- Downvotes cost something. This makes them meaningful.
- A culture of learning by doing. (But **not** being an asshole about it.)

There are lots of comments here about reputation economics. If this needs fixing, please don't change the core mechanics to do so.

Illustrative examples that don't change the core mechanics:

- [OverLordGoldDragon suggests a decay mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356/the-stack-exchange-reputation-system-whats-working-whats-not/387358#387358)
- Multiple answers hint at separating "moderation rep" from "quality rep". I don't think this conflicts with my suggestion.
- Multiple answers suggest adjusting particular values (e.g. value of a question upvote).

Based on comments on this answer, maybe I should clarify that I believe the core "gameplay loop" provides necessary and sufficient short-term rewards for someone already committed to quality questions and answers. In my opinion, onboarding and longer-term economics are separate concerns (which I am eager to get involved in, e.g. when Staging Ground becomes available).

Comment: Upvotes cost nothing, so they mean nothing? How is needing to earn privileges like a test? Why do you need reputation to learn by doing? Forums and newsgroups haven't had reputation or karma or kudos or likes for ages, yet people matured pretty well there.

Comment: I think that certain parts of the current system work well, but I feel like it'd be helpful to elaborate on which parts of the system you consider "core mechanics" that "work", and what you think works well about them. (I don't think anyone's advocating getting rid of voting or reputation entirely.) But if we better understand which aspects are fundamental to ensuring that the site/network continues to function well, and which aspects *aren't* working well (and what is not working well about them), that'll help us (i.e. staff) research and develop solutions to those issues.

Comment: @V2Blast my point is that the short-term reward structures I listed actively work on a daily basis; how many (non-zero) points are involved is a detail, what happens over a multi-year engagement is an elaboration ... my suggestion is that the core mechanics (listed above) should not change, even if you tweak numbers and/or introduce long-term mechanics; is that clearer? if not I'm happy to expand my answer

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't think forums engender maturity, I think they're an environment where mature, robust contributors can succeed -- I would argue that the SO approach (a meaningful reward system) enables short-term gains for new users and high signal:noise for long-term contributors

Comment: @CodeCaster fwiw I think we agree that utility is the primary incentive!

Comment: @V2Blast I can clarify further that I'm talking about existing incentives for writing accurate, informative questions and answers; in other answers here I read sentiments about improving moderation tools, perhaps even a separate reputation system for moderation, and I defer to users with experience on those issues

Comment: No, the core mechanics really don't work very well. There are several other answers now going over this. They collapse several categories onto a single axis and create countless perverse incentives.

Comment: @V2Blast If I'm really blue-skying it, I't like to see *more* voting and *multiple* forms of reputation. Clicking to give feedback on a post should allow for marking it with several positive and/or negative qualifiers. Users should get separate scores for being helpful/trustworthy/active/good communicators/etc. etc. etc.; and those scores should *separately* feed into *relevant* privileges, and make their votes count more in ways that make sense.

Comment: Instead of displaying numeric scores (for most users), posts should just sort by various mostly-opaque algorithms and have pop-ups with messages like "many [trustworthy] users found this answer [technically accurate]".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel as I mentioned in a comment above, I think numbers could be tweaked, new categories added, long-term numbers dampened, as long as the basic "gameplay loop" outlined in my answer remains; maybe I need to clarify this in my answer

Comment: RE _"Multiple answers hint at separating rep..."_ [There's this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323025/241211) which I opposed at the time. I think [the reasons I outlined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323035/241211) are still relevant, though it's a reasonable debate to have.

Answer (score 22):

> What is broken about it, and why? Are there any solutions to it?

It might not be "broken", but reputation (and voting, to a lesser extent) have an ongoing identity crisis where it is not clear what they mean.  For example:

A user having a higher reputation than another user could mean any of these:

- Has answered more questions
- Has given more useful answers
- Has answered fewer, but more popular questions
- Has given more answers, but on tags that are not relevant to the current question.
- Answers questions that are easier to understand (and therefore, more likely to be voted on)
- Was first to help someone fix a common syntax error 15 years ago

The fact that every question and answer puts the user's reputation in your face encourages people to notice and interpret that number in some way. The problem is that within any random Q&A thread, this number **has no reliable, coherent interpretation**. I think most would agree that if you rely on reputation numbers to make choices about voting, you are using the site wrong, and maybe even harming the community. And yet, the question/answer page is designed as though we want you to notice to them.

There is nothing wrong with having cool Internet points for fun, but we have an incoherent blend of a merit system and an engagement system, with magical numbers displayed everywhere. In my opinion, this seems to be dragging against the goal of having high-quality, self-moderating information.

Comment: The idea in this answers seems to be that rep should be printed smaller or later or not even displayed at all?

Comment: @Trilarion Hiding rep on the Q&A page could be an improvement. Really though, the idea of my post is to try to describe the bigger picture of why reputation *feels* broken.

Comment: I read your post and agreed with it. Just thought about possible fixes to this particular way the reputation might be or feel broken. The obvious direct solution would be to not display rep. Maybe there are different ways to mitigate the problem.

Comment: @Trilarion There's so much to say on this topic, as it goes to the core of the site's design. I may open a new question for that purpose later. In short many common use cases fall onto this blended vote/rep system, simply because that's the only tool available. Sometimes a tool feels broken because you're using it for the wrong job. We need more tools that support how people use the website, rather than piggy-backing everything off the same system.

Comment: The voting system is good at sorting answers on a single question, and the reputation system is good at delivering dopamine and generating engagement. Apart from that, we just take what we can get from those systems and make it work. Those two factors were important enough and done well enough that they made SE as big as it is, but they are not a be-all and end-all.

Comment: There is one coherent thread through all of these: "has used the site a whole bunch". The purpose of a system is what it does.

Comment: here is the entire body of one question: "How do I set, clear, and toggle a bit?" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-i-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit?rq=1 the top answer has 4000 upvotes. assuming each vote it +10 that is 40000 rep. assuming 5 that is still 20000 rep. Most users of C++ with more than 10 years of experience could answer this but one guy gets the crazy rep bonus.

Answer (score 19):

> We still want users to be able to participate on our site and feel as though they are a part of this community. But unfortunately, we’ve heard from so many of our users, particularly newer ones, that the learning curve is steep and it’s difficult to find ways to engage on the site.

That's quite hard to parse for me. What "learning curve" does one need to search for and read answers, or post a question? Or is it the "learning curve" for gaining reputation points while not adding any value to the site?

Also, "find ways to engage": does one not know how to answer questions or edit posts to improve their quality? Or is it about, again, gaining rep points, for... what?

I guess my point is, how are the modifications of the SE reputation system can help "find ways to engage" and/or the "learning curve"?

Perhaps we would want to ask those users who think the learning curve is steep and can't find ways to engage to tell us more?

Comment: It's hard to parse because it's extremely condensed. Every post that spends like only 2-3 lines on the problem will very likely misrepresent it or simplify it so much that it could be all and anything (e.g. "learning new things is hard" is true but doesn't help anyone). I fully agree that more time should be devoted on finding out what exactly the problems are before asking for a solution.

Comment: One of essential limitations for new users is a restriction to comment. When they try to put their comment as an answer, they receive an unrelated advice “consider to answer other question”

Answer (score 18):

I want to add that in my main site, Earth Science, many of the users with privileges to moderate are not participating or doing moderation tasks ([neither upvoting](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1986/28185)). Earlier users have answered the good questions and left the site, and the new users find it difficult to obtain the reputation that the users that have been there since the beginning and are still active (a few) have (they see they obtain a few upvotes for their detailed answers, while top users have 23K).

So as well as a loss in users, we have moderation troubles. For example, after [we banned `id-my-rock` questions](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/ive-had-enough-lets-ban-rock-id-questions), it took months to completely delete the existing questions. [I needed to open a post asking for delete votes](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/list-of-identify-my-rock-questions-to-delete-status-completed) so that the site would stop appearing first for searches as "Help identify my rock" in Google, whose status took two months to complete (while we continued receiving a flood of `id-my-rock` questions). [There is also an accepted proposal of merging synonym tags from 2016](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/should-we-clean-up-the-tags-on-this-site), but the tags were never merged and we do not have people with privileges to vote to merge active in the site (you need to have answered some question with the tags).

I would say then, at least for Earth Science, the reputation gains for upvotes on answers and accepted answers should increase, or the moderation privileges reputation needed should reduce, if the site wants to survive ([it is giving signs of dying](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1986/28185)).

Comment: A site might be dying regardless of the reputation system, but in this special case I'd say that maybe network sites should be able to set their own moderation privileges thresholds. That way the mechanics would be familiar to people (you get the same reputation for an upvote, lose the same for a downvote) but small sites with less questions to answer could adapt to that and give privileges faster to their experts.

Comment: I'm definitely in agreement that faster rep/privilege gain is more important to low-traffic sites. Some of my low-t sites I've been in since beta, so I got that early lift & can now participate fully. Others I'm far too late to the party, & realistically, I'll never achieve those levels, nor will anyone coming in behind me. Even if I answered every single question & gained some rep from it [which of course I would/could never do]; there's just not enough in total to ever get there. *Actual* rep I'm not particularly interested in, most of my frequent sites I'm 'trusted' or thereabouts.

Answer (score 17):

One of the problems on Stack Overflow and many other sites is that it rewards with reputation answers to questions that instead should be closed as duplicates. To fix this:

- Provide **reputation gain** to the user who **correctly** marks the question as duplicate, for example `+10` ("correctly marked" means that the question is finally closed as a duplicate). The reputation gain should be comparable to that from answering a question, because finding the duplicate requires non-trivial effort.
- Provide **badges** for users who **correctly** mark many questions as duplicates ("correctly marked" means that the question is finally closed as a duplicate).

Comment: I'd support a reputation loss to people that post an answer to a question that is later closed as off-topic (not when closed as dupe, it's impossible for newer people to know what has already been asked, and having to do a search before answering is counter-productive IMO).

Comment: did you see [my answer post](/a/387398/997587)? maybe you should get a small reputation loss for writing a duplicate answer? (jk)

Comment: It should not always be a loss - see the "signpost question" concept. If a duplicate helps more people find answers that's a good thing. Perhaps if the question is not a good signpost question, then simply having it deleted and losing any upvote rep is enough? But we definitely need positive reputation for dupe-finders.

Comment: @user253751 Thanks. Edited to remove this suggestion.

Answer (score 16):

### A more specific proposal for handling per-question reputation

Working within the reputation system generally, several previous answers (including my own) seem to have highlighted some points of agreement:

- +10/-2 for up/downvotes is bad, and has negative consequences
- However, downvoting things into oblivion isn't that helpful in terms of correcting user behaviour, and tends to feed resentment
- Super-high-upvoted questions aren't really that much better than sort-of-high-upvoted ones
- However, we should incentivize answerers to aim for quality, rather than mass-producing answers that get +1s

Some citations:

| Answer By | Quote |
| --- | --- |
| [Me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387550) | *[Too much to quote here]* |
| [Lundin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387567) | Reputation is also a measurement of 'I happened to answer some question that went viral'. Some who've asked and answered one particular up-voted post can gain ridiculous amounts of rep just because of that.... Reputation encourages answering duplicate questions over and over again.... Up-voting costs nothing and yields +5 or +10 rep. Down-voting costs 1 rep and yields -2 rep. This is ridiculous and leads to rep inflation. |
| [Minh-Long Luu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387364) | However, I have seen some long-time users who just asked a single, yet basic question, then disappeared forever, still gained thousands of points.... My proposed solution is to consider implementing a decay system. *[Although this seems to propose a *time-based* decay instead]* |
| [Starship is go for launch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387520) | ...rep is supposed to be about trust. Posting something with 1 upvote and 4 downvotes gains rep, but certainly loses trust. |
| [SQB](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387484) | ...the rep cap. That should be *per question* instead of *daily*. |
| [user3840170](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387372) | Answers to poor questions can nevertheless earn the answerer some reputation, which encourages wild-shot answers, discourages voting to close unclear questions, and removes asker’s incentives to put some effort into improving the question.... It takes five downvotes to nullify a reputation gain from a single upvote. It takes three more to nullify a reputation gain from answer acceptance alone, even though the asker is often a newbie, and therefore the *least* qualified person to judge how good an answer is.... Implement sub-linear reputation gain from upvotes *[admittedly, along with some other ideas that don't align well with this proposal]* |
| [Ne Mo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387366) | For that reason, I strongly believe that for new users (not me, real new users) should have a reputation "floor" on their questions." *[although this also seems to propose a *voting* floor]* |
| [OverLordGoldDragon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387358) | Long-time users have had the luck to answer basic questions that are very popular to search, and gather hundreds, thousands, or 10k+ upvotes. This rep gain is **completely meaningless** - it doesn't reflect greater skill, knowledge, or any other trait.... A hard-earned `+2` post isn't worth x50 less because it didn't make it to HNQ and get `+100`.... **Solution 2:** every upvote after `+50` earns 5 rep; 2 after `+100`; 1 after `+200`. |
| [Nij](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387376) | **Upvotes and downvotes *must* have the same impact on reputation**, otherwise it becomes meaningless at any scale worth discussing. |

There are also some pertinent comments as part of the discussion, particularly on [Kevin B's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387360).

To me, the conclusion is clear - we should count upvotes and downvotes the same, but scale per-post reputation in some *non-linear* way based on the *net* vote total. Specifically, the curve should be steeper in some low-positive total range, and shallower elsewhere.

I wanted to spitball some numbers and see how people feel about them:

| Net post score | Total reputation impact | Change from previous |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -3 or below | -10 | 0 |
| -2 | -9 | 1 |
| -1 | -6 | 3 |
| 0 | 0 | 6 |
| 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 30 | 20 |
| 3 | 55 | 25 |
| 4 | 85 | 30 |
| 5 | 120 | 35 |
| 6 | 155 | 35 |
| 7 | 185 | 30 |
| 8 | 210 | 25 |
| 9 | 230 | 20 |
| 10 | 240 | 10 |
| 11-30 | 245-340 | 5 |
| 31-50 | 343-400 | 3 |
| 51-100 | 402-500 | 2 |
| 101+ | 500+ | 1 |

Of course, it could be done with a mathematical formula of some sort rather than a table lookup, but I think this illustrates the sort of curve I have in mind.

The choice of 25 as the maximum marginal/delta of 35 is partly to compensate for re-introducing upvote-downvote parity and partly to compensate for the rep withdrawal on super-popular questions; but mainly to make the numbers nice and have more resolution to work with. I'm assuming that other numbers could be scaled at the same time if need be; but I see how that would have ripple effects on an established userbase.

Comment: I have no idea how that table is supposed to be read. The total reputation impact and change from previous don't seem to align with each other or the existing reputation system. This looks like it's intending downvotes to have a massive impact since you're suggesting something based off of net post score and not upvotes and downvotes separately as it is now.

Comment: @Laurel "change from previous" means the difference between "total reputation" in the current row and the previous row. It hadn't occurred to me that it could be interpreted any other way. The purpose is to show the cumulative effect of each incremental change to the score. Of course "total reputation impact'" doesn't align with the existing system; **the point** is to change the existing system! As for downvotes, not really; I don't want them to have **any** impact past -3, because scores below -3 don't IMX signal worsening quality.

Comment: I would opt for a lower maximum marginal/delta than 35. Personally, I don't see a problem with a max marginal/delta of 10 and having a wider bell curve. I'm not yet convinced either way whether zero-rep-loss downvotes past a certain point is necessarily good. Other than that, I like the idea.

Comment: I think I understand. But downvoting an answer would usually cost the answerer **10–35 rep** per downvote? (A single user could tactically downvote you to lose an entire bounty's worth of rep with two votes! Who's resentful now?) The severe penalty for downvotes is very hard to swallow, even knowing that reputation would be greatly inflated from what it was previously for most users.

Comment: Hmm, yes, well. I guess we've all had an experience or two with inflation lately.

Comment: Not sure how I like tying net reputation gain it to mere net score. A +3 / −3 answer is quite likely to be strictly worse than a +0 / −0 one. I think I could write down a table of my own…

Comment: @user3840170 if you think downvotes should count *more than* upvotes, well... I can see the argument for it, but many people think moving from -2 to -10 reputation adjustment is already radical. (It also occurs to me that maybe the effect on reputation should still be divorced from the effect on page sort order.) I welcome you to write the proposal, though. (I really don't know why I marked this answer CW. It's not like I intended for people to just replace my numbers with their own preference. This is the particular type of discussion that the Stack software is especially unsuited for.)

Answer (score 15):

**Allow low-rep post feedback to be useable**

When talking about limits on participation for new users due to low reputation, an important one is the ability to vote. Low-rep users are allowed to leave feedback, which could signal question askers and answerers that posts could be improved.

However, this feedback is nearly entirely inaccessible to authors of posts, which means new users can't properly indicate that posts are unclear or low quality to the author. Comments don't work but open an avenue for spam, but votes don't really allow for spam.

I understand that allowing 1-rep users to cast votes that affect reputation is undesirable since it could enable voting fraud, so:

Please make post feedback easily visible to the author of posts.

Currently, the only way I know of to view post feedback on your own posts is through SEDE. It would be great if your user profile could reveal post feedback by low-rep users, so it could be used to adjust questions. Ideally I'd have it split between logged in and logged out users, but I understand that might be asking for a little much.

Comment: It could also be worth looking into if the anon feedback can be converted to normal votes, e.g. at 1/10th value.

Comment: The anon feedback would be subject to so much bot activity that it would be practically useless. Once people figured out they could anonymously game a metric that was available everywhere, they would.

Comment: @TravisJ I'm advocating to make it visible for the authors, not public, and also do not think it should pop up notifications, and it already is public through SEDE. The main thing I think that should change is to make it more accessible to the authors. That should make the chance of abuse small, as you can only affect what a single user might or might not look at. However, you may still be right, which is why I'd prefer a split between logged in and anonymous.

Comment: Other than SEDE, where *is* it accessible? Is this the "you do not have reputation to cast a vote but it has been recorded" message?

Comment: @user253751 Indeed, I'm talking about those. They can also be viewed in the 10K+ rep moderator tools under https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback, in an unhelpful overview that mainly reveals voting anomalies, at least for larger sites. Afaik that's it, SEDE + overview pages for >10K rep users.

Comment: It is also possible to see it on the main site using a userscript or plugin ([shameless plug](https://github.com/danthe1st/SO-Userscripts/blob/master/anonymous_feedback.user.js)) by performing SEDE queries automatically but that's ... not a solution for everyone.

Answer (score 13):

Something to call out here before we dive into it:

> ...[W]e’ve heard from so many of our users, particularly newer ones, that the learning curve is steep and it’s difficult to find ways to engage on the site.

This is **orthogonal** to reputation.  Being able to participate on a site is a different problem than what the numbers mean next to your avatar and what you get for having your numbers grow.

Getting users to participate and feel like they're engaging on the site means that you have to give them an incentive to engage.  A lot of people use Stack Overflow as a means to an end - ask a question, get an answer, move on with their day.  The folks who *want* to engage in a community may stay for longer.  The folks who *want* to share their knowledge may stay for longer.  **None of this** has anything to do with reputation.

With that bit out of the way:

> What is really great about our reputation & privilege system? What do you think makes it great, and why is it worth keeping?

A lot of this boils down to familiarity, but it's really the sentiment that the system we have accomplishes a few things:

- Strong bands/divisions based on either participation levels or quality of answers
- Placing tools in the hands of power users, should they choose to use it, when they've had enough winters under their belts
- Something to strive for; while no one will really come close to Jon Skeet, they can at least shoot for the stars

> What is broken about it, and why? Are there any solutions to it?

It is quite fragile, since it's the main measure of two things in my mind:

- How active you are, and
- How expert you are

To that end, these are the things that have broken it in the past:

- Giving *questions* 10 reputation, which inflates the amount of reputation that users actually get/earn from participating in the site
- Previous efforts which rewarded reputation in an unchecked fashion which were never recalculated (looking *right at you*, Documentation)

> What other systems work really well that we could learn from?

While it's not perfect, I think the sentiment is that it's a more social variant [of an Elo rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) for everyone here.  That is to say, the total reputation you have is a factor of how well your content is received against the wave of everyone else.  This does make participation slightly daunting (which fine, you've caught me, I've come a bit full circle on this haven't I?), but it does mean that the system has a very explicit goal in rewarding those who are participating and whose content is comparable or better to others.

You don't explicitly state what your *goals* are for reputation, so it's not really feasible for me to say that something needs to change here.  But I really don't think the system is particularly bad.

We just have to be very judicious when giving reputation out.

Comment: Maybe we should introduce a review queue to review reputation awards. :-p

Comment: While I agree rep and engagement should not be conflated, the rep system design does have a big effect on engagement. Primarily that the current system ties possible engagement types to rep level. But also the sociological effect of stratifying people into "haves" and "have-nots". It's easy for a 50k user to shrug off downvotes or advocate giving bounties, but if you're sitting at the bottom, those point losses hurt, especially if the site then keeps you from participating. -- Perhaps the issue is "you had a popular answer" and "we trust you to downvote responsibly" are orthogonal.

Comment: @R.M.:  This thing about "haves" and "have-nots" implies something about downvoting or rep gain that hasn't changed in the ten-some-odd years that I've been on the site.  Everyone has the same opportunity to get reputation.  The experts are the ones who get *more* of it.  To get more rep, you must become more expert.  Things like downvotes become less of a factor (like, at all) if you focus on good answers and getting things right, without succumbing to the sensationalism of answering one-liners or unclear questions.

Comment: @R.M.:  So again I posit, reputation is still based on both how active you are and how expert you are.  In that vein it is very much identical to an Elo rating in that, just because you think you're "good" at a game doesn't mean you can reasonably compete against someone who is at the upper echelons of the game (with a ranking in the 0.01-percentile).

Comment: @Makoto Sorry, I was unclear on my point - I'm talking mainly about your "call out". I'm just stating that the construction of the reputation system has an effect on engagement & participation. If your ability to interact with the site and your social interactions are determined by the number next to your avatar, a new person's willingness to become active and gain expertise with the system is also going to be affected by that. Reputation system design doesn't happen in the absence of onboarding/engagement criteria (and vice versa, given the "gamified" nature of the site).

Comment: @R.M.:  You're making my point here - just because the number is big or small next to your account, that doesn't really mean you *can't* participate.  You're limited in what you can do on the site because there are sensible limitations to prevent bad actors from creating hordes of puppets to unduly influence things, but *everyone* started there.  If you're expert and you're able to consistently show your expertise, you don't typically run into this barrier of "omg numbers need to go bigger" that you seem to be honing in on.

Comment: "Giving questions 10 reputation, which inflates the amount of reputation that users actually get/earn from participating in the site" - you mean *upvotes on* questions; and we *absolutely should* make it at least as easy to gain reputation for good questions as good answers, because **good questions are hard to ask**. In many cases, it's about as hard as answering them, plus most of it is attempted by people who are uniquely unqualified. The few who rise above that adversity are the heroes of the site.

Answer (score 12):

I think that the reputation penalty for downvoting answers is (became) a broken part of the system.

This was hinted to in [one of the prior answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387372/165773), but I would want to explicitly focus on this. To start with, I believe it worked reasonably well until the recent few months - maybe not quite perfect, but not worthy of raising serious concerns about either. Until recently, I could not even imagine that I would ever complain about this.

As it turned out though, this has been working based on a certain implicit barrier to posting answers. First, you had to have a certain level understanding in the topic of the question and second, you had to put some effort into well... just writing the answer - you know, figuring what to write, finding words, typing them, and stuff like that.

This barrier is no longer with us now that one can just copy the question into ChatGPT and copy its response into the answer field.

This has led to an unprecedented flood of low-quality answers that are in the sore need of downvotes to rate, and rep penalty makes this impossible - at least at the scale corresponding to that of the ChatGPT flood.

If needed, refer [more detailed discussion at MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421868/839601)

> This looks like the most basic and natural way to establish trust model, proven to work reasonably well on questions and well integrated into the system (rate limits etc). This is what we miss for answers...
>
> **answer downvotes should be free unless these are cast on competing answers...**
>
> ...to start with, multiple downvoted answers will throttle low quality posters (bot or not) - this is embedded in the system of rate limits. Besides, all the usual quality mechanisms associated with downvotes and negative score will start working at last: option of 20K-deletion votes, roomba etc etc. The last but not the least, people will just start feeling better getting the ability to rate content as they want and there will be less of bitter feelings (I believe this is very important)

Comment: I think ChatGPT answers are a bad example because you get the lost reputation back once the post is deleted. It doesn't actually take that long for mods to handle a ChatGPT flag.

Comment: @Dharman this was covered in comments under linked discussion at MSO, I can only quote self "there is no knowing that post will be deleted in this case, not for a casual reader / voter unfamiliar with our obscure meta discussions" - this means moderators have to do loads of routine work via flags instead of letting rep/rating system work as intended

Comment: Imagine the impact if downvote rep loss weren't refunded when the posts were deleted... \*shudders\*

Comment: and some months after... *imagine if suddenly something happened that made deletion of those AI generated answers far more difficult to achieve*

Answer (score 12):

First of all, thanks for bringing this up to discussion with the community before jumping the gun and implementing some change.

> - What is really great about our reputation & privilege system? What do you think makes it great, and why is it worth keeping?

As noted many times, some people care a great deal about imaginary internet points and so it works well for attracting those kind of people. They might be people who contribute with high quality content and/or people who just answer endless duplicates, but overall the system works somewhat well for attracting users. Essentially it is the same thing as receiving a golden star sticker from your teacher back in elementary school - it appeals to some basic human need to be recognized.

The rep system works quite well for discouraging low quality and incorrect answers. In fact down votes work much better than up votes for filtering out quality over low quality.

What works *somewhat* well is that moderation tools and privileges are gradually unlocked. Things like review queues should obviously not be unlocked immediately. However, there is not much of a relation between high reputation and moderator suitability.

---

> - What is broken about it, and why? Are there any solutions to it?

So many things.

- As noted above, reputation is a very poor metric for moderator suitability. It is also a somewhat poor metric for community trust in one particular user. If anything, reputation is a metric for how *active* someone is on the site.
- Reputation is completely out of proportion for Q&A under popular tags. Looking at the top users at SO, pretty much everyone in top 50 are active in the most mainstream, active tags. So besides being a metric of how active someone is, it is also a metric of how popular tags the user is following.
- For these reasons, reputation is also a very poor metric of technical knowledge. The bronze, silver and gold badges are somewhat more relevant.
- Reputation is also a measurement of "I happened to answer some question that went viral". Some who've asked and answered one particular up-voted post can gain ridiculous amounts of rep just because of that.

  As a perfect example from SO for those who know programming: [What is the "-->" operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c) This is the single-most up-voted C and C++ question and only because it is about a feature which is curious, intriguing and exotic. Not because it is about relevant technical knowledge or a canonical duplicate. Looking at my own by far most up-voted answers on SO, the top 2 are also about such curious and strangely behaving code - while they are far from my highest quality answers posted on the site.
- Reputation encourages answering duplicate questions over and over again. Some users purposely do this to "grind rep" instead of closing obvious duplicates. It is always the same users.

  This in turn encourages low research effort by the posters. The easier it is to find the answer to a question yourself, the higher the probability that it will also get answered even though it is very likely a duplicate.

  And well, this problem has been debated endlessly over the years and a pretty solid, recurring argument from the answerer's perspective is that "it takes me less effort to answer the question than to find a duplicate". This is true, the lack of working on-site FAQ systems or other easy ways to find high quality duplicates remains an unsolved problem. Various sub communities tend to solve this by implementing their own tag FAQ, either on-site or off-site. I brought this problem up [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285953/170024) as far back as 2016.
- The system is terribly inconsistent. Up-voting costs nothing and yields +5 or +10 rep. Down-voting costs 1 rep and yields -2 rep. This is ridiculous and leads to rep inflation. As noted earlier, down-votes are a much more efficient way to ensure quality than up-votes, so they should weigh as much and be encouraged.

  What about those users who do heavy moderation work in tracking down spam and close voting bad content? Why are those users *penalized* for making the sites a better place? They will no doubt down vote far more frequently than they up vote.

  A stray thought: maybe implement a system where a user must remain within a certain ratio between how many up and down votes they have cast, so that they'll eventually get blocked from up-voting until they start to cast down votes (and maybe vice versa).
- The rep system as well as the Q&A format in general is a *terrible* one for the meta sites. When these sites were designed, the devs were far too much in love with the Q&A format and thought it was the universal format for any kind of site. It is not. It is a system which encourages elitism, populism and discourages discussions. Instead everyone is supposed to be holding their own monologue and then people should silently vote on that monologue without explicitly arguing for/against. Don't you dare raise any unpopular arguments or counter arguments, or you may be down-voted into meta hell.

  And also the system kind of encourages having the same "beat the dead horse" discussions over and over, since it's far too hard to find older discussions, and even if you do find one and add an answer there, nothing will come of it since old posts don't get much attention, they aren't in the "feed".

  This is not a healthy system to use for meta at all. Good systems encourages diverse opinions and debates, bad systems put a lid on such things.

---

> - What other systems work really well that we could learn from?

The badge system isn't ideal either, but it is the best working one in terms of measuring activity and technical knowledge both.

As for unlocking moderation tools and site privileges, it should probably be disconnected from the rep system entirely.

Also, while SE isn't social media, the Q&A format discourages users from hanging out with like-minded people with similar interests, or for discussing things in a less formal manner, without all the rules against subjective topics. There are the chats, but they are well-hidden and very inactive. A place to "hang out" in parallel with the Q&A (which is definitely not the place for such) would give people more reasons to stick around and also ease "on-boarding" of new users, if there was a place encouraging informal mentoring.

One example of such a "hang out place" could be blogs. There is the SO official blog, which rarely ever holds contains anything of interest to me, and on top of it the bloggers have various company associations and likely hidden agendas, making it even less appealing. I'd be much more interested in blogs posted by the site users, maybe attached to the tags. There used to be such a system in place even, though it was so well-hidden that I didn't even know of it until I read the message that it was closing down due to lack of interest.

Comment: "_Things like review queues should obviously not be unlocked immediately._" yes, but when I gained my review privileges, I still did not know how to use them properly. I had to go read the Help Center and FAQs get advice from others and made plenty of mistakes. I don't think having any amount of rep or having written the answers that gained me that rep contributed to knowing how to review at all. Perhaps I had a weird case though. I gained all my early rep on SO from answering bounties, so I had little overall site experience at that point.

Comment: "It is always the same users." - This is worth emphasizing WRT rep grinding. "Various sub communities tend to solve this by implementing their own tag FAQ, either on-site or off-site." Unfortunately, the off-site Python tag FAQ is still not very good. "The rep system as well as the Q&A format in general is a terrible one for the meta sites." Also an excellent point. A major part of the Stack system design is trying to emphasize that the main sites aren't discussion fora, but Meta **needs to be** a discussion forum.

Comment: "A place to "hang out" in parallel with the Q&A (which is definitely not the place for such) would give people more reasons to stick around and also ease "on-boarding" of new users" - chat, perhaps? It's horrendously undiscoverable, though, and diamonds seem to hate ideas like that due to a perceived expectation of them moderating a lot more text.

Comment: @starball Good point about the bounty system. I had forgotten about it but it is completely dysfunctional. Both for the reasons you mention here and because it locks bad posts from getting closed. This system should just be removed IMO.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Regarding the FAQ, that's why it needs to be implemented on-site and ideally in an exposed way so that people asking questions can easily find it. Some tags implement the FAQ below the tag wiki. This allows for maintenance and review by anyone, but the info is very much hidden away for new users. Such tag wiki FAQs are more of a collection of canonical dupes for the benefit of gold badgers etc.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think the chats would be used a lot more indeed if they were advertised better. That diamond mods are supposed to maintain chats is ridiculous - I'd rather see a system where diamond mods are given the privilege to hand out "chat mod" rights to trusted users. "Chat mods" would then have the power to remove inappropriate content and kick out troublesome users from the chat. Diamond mods would only be called in as an escalation - "this user is a spammer/this user keep causing trouble". Or they can be called in (through meta) to mediate in case someone disagrees with chat mods.

Comment: Alternatively if chats were tied to tags, then maybe give anyone with lets say a Python gold badge chat mod privileges to the Python chat.

Comment: RE the up/down vote ratio to allow more voting. I understand the sentiment but I feel whatever the limits are set to would be too strict. One can very reasonably use the website for a decade and never need to cast a downvote (as opposed to abstaining from it). Imagine the user mostly uses it for research and upvotes content that helped them. Introducing a mandatory downvote count for them to continue doing that is not really useful for anybody, IMO.

Answer (score 11):

The one thing I would absolutely change, is the rep cap. That should be *per question* instead of *daily*.

Take someone like Jon Skeet. He doesn't have to answer a single question anymore to still hit the rep cap every day for years to come.
I've met him once and he's a nice guy. I think he deserves the rep he earns. But I still think it's weird that one would earn rep for answers given long ago.

Or take my "home stack", *[SF&F](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)*. It has received an answer to a question about *Groundhog Day* by the screenwriter of the film. Great answer, don't get me wrong. I'm not linking it here, though. That would exacerbate the problem.
But he has earned enough rep from that single answer to cast close and reopen votes, without ever interacting with any other aspect of the site.

This would be remedied by having a rep cap per question. Jon Skeet wouldn't get "rep for jam", Danny Rubin would've gotten 315 rep (200 from votes + 15 for the accepted answer + 100 bounty) instead of 4000+.

In general, people would need to interact and keep interacting to gain rep and earn privileges.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [OverLordGoldDragon's idea](/a/387358/997587)

Comment: @starball darn, missed that one. Thanks. _Edit: I do think I add more justification, though._

Comment: Don't you think it would remove the incentive to go back to your old answers and edit them? Why fix old answers if you can no longer get reputation from them?

Comment: You'd still get upvotes and bragging rights.

Comment: Re _"I still think it's weird that one would earn rep for answers given long ago"_, I think it would be weird if that was not the case. If you wrote an answer 5 years ago that was upvoted today because someone found your answer helpful to them, what on earth is "weird" about that?

Comment: A related issue though is the undesirable "superstar" effect, where I'm convinced votes are granted mindlessly simply because of the name of the person posting, though I have no solution for that. (How else to explain why the nice but vanilla comment "fantastically well written and insightful post" to an answer posted here here received 11 fawning upvotes?)

Comment: What's this about jam? I think I'm missing something about SO lore.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I've seen the term used for "automatic" rep, but I'm not sure where I've seen it.

Answer (score 11):

**Simple answers to common questions get lots of reputation.**

If you are lucky or, old enough to answer a question that is easy to understand and commonly asked, you'll likely get lots of reputation. Even if your answer is simply correct rather than the best possible. This can be true if the question is a (near) duplicate.

To game this system, there is a race to get a valid answer up quickly and improve the answer while the votes accrue.

**Difficult answers to well written but specific questions get almost no reputation.**

If you read a question that others can't quickly understand and provide an expertly written answer that covers all the angles and makes world leading suggestions that answers the question perfectly, you'll probably get 25 points of reputation.

Once these questions are answered, others will rarely invest the effort to understand them and consequently, appreciate your answer.

---

**Giving a better answer to an established question gives unreliable, slow rewards.**

If an existing common question already has a few well "up-voted" answers, there is a disincentive to answer, you feel like it is too late to get reputation. If the world has moved on and there is now a better answer, is it worth adding it to the question?

If the answer is good, it will attract votes, slowly. So slowly that it is unlikely to usurp the outdated previous leader. That old answer got all its rep in flash when the question was new, but now, floats at the top misdirecting the impatient.

Comment: for your second point, that's true, but I feel like it would be hard for the system to know what answer posts demonstrate more subject-matter-expertise just by votes alone. We do have the bounty system to give extra rewards to answers.

Comment: @starball, bounties can be good when the asker chooses. I have only problems, not solutions.

Comment: Well commonly asked questions affect a lot of people and an answer therefore helps a lot of people. Conversely your well written answer to something obscure may only help that one person.

Comment: @RobertLongson, its a good point that I had considered. I guess my counter question is, should rep reward the effort of the answerer or the answers accumulated usefulness to the world? I don't know the answer. As a poor metaphor, should we reward the academic or the celebrity?

Comment: @Jodrell IMO, it's not a good metric for either. As of now, rep mostly correlates with how much time a user has spent on a site and how popular the questions they answer are. It's *very* sketchy to derive any other information. The next Alan Turing can come in and post something so detailed and insightful that it would single-handedly push computer science a decade forward in advancement. Yet if *nobody sees it* then no rep for poor new Mr Turing. Similarly, there are plenty of users who have five and six digit reputation yet only from prolonged exposure over a decade, not pure contribution.

Comment: "Simple answers to common questions get lots of reputation." This isn't *inherently* a problem. Common questions are more valuable exactly because they are common - having them properly asked and answered is beneficial to more people.

Answer (score 10):

I see several long term users award bounties for good answers, nice in itself, but they award 500 rep bounties to new users, often on first answers, sometimes repeatedly.
This creates a user who has access to tools and actions they have not had time to get to know. And I have seen some that did act with that access in a way that I did not see as good. (Not bad enough to hand on to staff but it took a lot of comments, and even some e-mails to the user, to teach them how not to use those options.)

I would suggest that no bounties can be awarded to a user who has fewer rep than the bounty is. (Maybe put it in hold somewhere, to award when they reached a next level of reputation.)

Comment: If it is more than a few bounties, it is probably reputation points laundering (from voting rings) and/or selling reputation points for real money.

Comment: The people offering the bounties are long standing high reputation good users several of whom are in the top 10 of reputation level. The awarded bounties can go to other long standing members or newer (to very new) members. There is no reason to expect faul play.

Comment: Yeah, I can foresee situations where the users who are starting bounties are just doing so because they have a lot of rep and want to support good answers – they're just not thinking about the fact that the rep they're giving out might end up giving the recipient a bunch of new privileges that they didn't have before, due to the way our reputation and privilege systems are connected. (And to be fair, I don't think this should be something they should need to worry about, either – the system should be designed in a way where that isn't a potential problem in the first place.)

Answer (score 9):

This is a very isolated example and not a full-blown "what to improve" post. But it should be a guide when you improve things.

When you think about changes, please always make sure that the user receives **constructive** criticism.

Okay, a downvote is not constructive per se. But it is a pretty clear signal that this content as is is not wanted on this site. And as bad as it sounds, you could still "constructively" delete your own post, if it gets too many downvotes. Not great... not terrible. At least it stops the bleeding and improves the site as a whole.

*However*, once your question received an upvoted answer, you cannot. The system does not allow you to delete your own question.

So now there you are, with a question that is genuinely bad and maybe cannot be improved (lets say it *was* lacking research, you should not retroactively add the research that would invalidate the answer).

A downvote comes in. Nothing you can do. Another. Nothing you can do. Another. Nothing you can do. Just sit there and take the "punishment" with no way out. This is no longer about curating the site, since the obvious option to delete the bad content is banned by the system itself. It is only about revenge. Revenge for having done the bad thing in the first place.

Whatever you change, make sure that there *always* is a way forward for users, other than sitting there and "take it". There should be no traps, where users cannot react to negative feedback in a way to make it stop.

Comment: However there should be a limit - if there are enogh upvotes then you can't delete it., or perhaps you can disassociate yourself from the question. On other sites I often see my answers but to a deleted original - this is not good.

Comment: You can always mod flag, argue why the content is better deleted and cannot be improved, and hope they agree. Especially if the question is closeworthy, you stand a good chance, and questions that aren't closeworthy can usually be improved.

Comment: At a certain (pretty early) threshold, the post is no longer shown in the post listing. I believe that threshold is something like -4. There's the current mercy mechanism. And what about the people who took the time to write an answer? (yes, I know answering bad questions isn't considered good practice, but it's not outright banned). Should they still lose rep when their answer gets deleted with the question? The current mechanism is that they do unless the post existed for 5 months already (or something along those lines).

Comment: Add to the fact that the asker _**gets an answer to their question- even despite it being a low-score (probably bad) question**_. That's pretty constructive to me. I've heard that a lot of askers don't even care about rep and just want answers.

Comment: I'm not sure if that maybe did not come across: I am not advocating for a specific solution here. I have enough of those *answers*, that I understand that deleting it would not be cool either. I am just advocating to stop the punishment if there is no constructive way forward for the punished. Our site is about improving the post, not punishing the poster. If improving the post (even as a last effort by deleting it) is not possible, punishment should stop.

Comment: “ you should not retroactively add the research that would invalidate the answer” imho, if the asker knows, how to improve the question, they definitively showed ( maybe with “UPDATE” mark).

Answer (score 8):

> What is really great about our reputation & privilege system? What do you think makes it great, and why is it worth keeping?

It allows people who have authored very good answers or questions to edit other questions to improve them, close bad questions, etc. I think that stuff stuff should be kept.

> What is broken about it, and why? Are there any solutions to it?

A lot. Just because somebody knows how to make good questions or answers doesn't mean they know what should be deleted. Make it so rep is not attached to privileges and instead actions. For example, [Codidact](https://codidact.com/) (another Q/A site) gives privileges based on relevant actions. For example, editing freely once getting a lot of suggested edits approved. You can also take a look [at roles the community would like](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384169/1117855).

> What other systems work really well that we could learn from?

Like I said before, you can learn from [Codidact](https://codidact.com/) and [Discourse](https://discourse.org/) does with trust levels. You can lose TL3 (trust level 3) (which lets you edit categories and tags) if you are not active enough in the past 100 day by default.

Comment: Maybe not just make a privilege based on actions but a combination between reputation and actions (e.g. at least X rep and action requirement Y)

Answer (score 8):

## What is working:

The rep cap, [as I explained in 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136139/6309): it incentivizes posting not just *an* answer (for votes which are capped anyway), but *the* answer (the one chosen by the OP).
It is at the core of what makes Stack Overflow unique: a Q&A site where finding the *right* answer is actively promoted.

It is not perfect, as others explained in their answers to this question, with the "passive income" issue. But the main goal remains important: more points above rep cap means posting the *right* answers.

## What is not working:

Most of everything else.
As [Mithical explained](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9443412#9443412), **votes represent too many things** (expertise, site familiarity, gamification, but also curation).
See also [Mithical's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387462/6309) on this page.

In particular, I would **like a better way to assess expertise**: I have 2000+ rep on [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) on more than 200 answers (and a gold badge!), and yet, I used those answers to learn enough of that language to understand it was not a good fit for me (as I mentioned in "[How to earn a million reputation on Stack Overflow: be of service to others](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/10/09/how-to-earn-a-million-reputation-on-stack-overflow-be-of-service-to-others/#h-the-last-of-the-stack-overflow-beta-users)").
Or: I have 1300+ rep on [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) (and a silver badge), but I know next to *nothing* about the language: those were questions about Git or Docker, involving Ruby.

The main other pain point is "**what does a downvote mean?**":

Take a legitimate question, validated by [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377768/how-might-the-staging-ground-the-new-ask-wizard-work-on-the-stack-exchange-net), about programming, showing research and what has been tried.
*But* what has been tried is a bit "dumb" (because you are a beginner on that topic): chances are, the question will be downvoted (strike 1).
And, after a few of those (again, good questions, but showing a poor understanding of the topic, as a *beginner*), you won't be able to ask other questions (strike 2: "[We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/6309)")
The experience is quite dreadful for newcomers.
Don't take my word for it: this video "[Uncovering Stack Overflow's TOXICITY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7v0yvdkIHg)" from [Alex Ziskind](https://www.youtube.com/@AZisk/about) illustrates the point nicely.

I do not dispute the merit of downvotes, as they help curate the site and prevent "bad" questions (vague, without research), and I hope the [staging ground new review process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423469/staging-ground-beta-1-recap-and-reviewers-needed-for-beta-2?cb=1) will help mitigate the current questions "downvoted/closed in mere minutes".

But I would like to see a way to express the difference between:

- your question is valid, but expresses an incorrect idea/comprehension (should not be downvoted)
- your question is bad (off-topic, not enough focus, ...) (can be downvoted and/or closed)

Comment: The first of those two things ("your question is valid, but express an incorrect idea/comprehension") should be addressed by *answering the question*. So, we already have this feature. No changes needed. :-) I do agree that we currently offer a *very* poor experience for new users, which is pretty well epitomized by Alex Ziskind's video, if you can get past some of the wrong and/or grating things he says and just look at how the system's operation would be perceived/understood by a new user, even one who was genuinely conscientious.

Comment: The [most upvoted comment on Alex Ziskind's vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7v0yvdkIHg&lc=Ugy3ooW11Bn-zf94lld4AaABAg) says it all - and [Catjia's comment says the rest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356/the-stack-exchange-reputation-system-whats-working-whats-not/387396#comment1291470_387369).

Comment: Not to me it doesn't. I strongly disagree with Catija's comment. I've never once thought downvotes were personal, even when I was a brand-new user. I still struggle to understand how reasonable people can see them as an insult. Yet, there's a lot in Alex's video that shows how poor the education/guidance provided by the system is. None of that has anything to do with downvotes. None of the real problems have anything to do with downvotes, except possibly *not having enough* downvoting.

Comment: Re the video: I don't blame users thinking Stack Overflow is a forum or a help desk (a free service where the unpaid servers are expected to oblige) when it looks like a forum or help desk where the unpaid servers are expected to oblige. I blame the site designers.

Comment: @bad_coder linking to a comment on a clickbait video that's expressly designed to paint SO in the most negative light possible, is not a successful way to make an argument.

Comment: @CodyGray Can you see how calling someone who disagrees with you "unreasonable" might be an insult? Because "_I still struggle to understand how reasonable people can see them as an insult._"  implies you feel that people who do see them that way must be unreasonable. -- Yes, you might not mean it that way, but that's how it comes off. Just like how when you downvote you might not mean "Not only do I feel your contribution isn't valuable enough for an upvote, but I feel it's so egregious I will go out of my way (and spend reputation) to chastise you for it".

Comment: Hi Von, I strongly believe that the issue you highlight with question asking isn't voting related, but related to what users consider to be "on topic" at Stack Overflow. This gets into closure reasons more than voting, as users who view a post as not useful due to being off topic will ultimately downvote that post as well.

Comment: A passing thought - that video touches on [the very thing I had identified back in '18](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367562/1079354) as a problem.  But it represents the double-edged sword of perception in that comments are just *far* too elevated for what they are.  Something to help address the "hey, you know that people are asking the question because they *don't* know this, right?-gap we have could help in that regard, as you're alluding to.

Comment: Not really, @R.M. People can—and do—behave in all sorts of ways that are, upon reflection or dispassionate consideration, unreasonable. Calling an action or a behavior unreasonable is not an insult. (I guess this gets to the core problem, of some people being so sensitive that we can't have a rational conversation without them being offended?) And, I mean, yes, when I downvote a post, it means that I'm going out of my way to mark/indicate the post as not containing any value whatsoever. I'm not chastising anyone for it, though; that's not what it means, and *that claim is unreasonable*.

Comment: Hmm. This answer is a mixed bag for me. I think that vanishingly few people are significantly impacted by the "reputation from accept votes is exempt from the daily cap" rule, and I also think that the OP is often **uniquely unqualified** to choose "the right answer".  I absolutely agree that votes represent too many things.

Comment: "your question is valid, but expresses an incorrect idea/comprehension (should not be downvoted)" If it actually is valid, then it should be neither downvoted nor closed; I agree. If it is bad (off-topic, not enough focus, **lacks MRE**, **is unclear**) then it should usually be both downvoted and closed. So it's hard for me to see why there's a need to do anything else to distinguish these questions; that's a social issue, not a technical (design of the rep system) one.

Comment: There is a related problem that **showing a bad attempt often detracts from a good how-to question**. However, this is *also social rather than technical*: the problem is that people apply the "what have you tried?" mindset too mindlessly, and lose track of the purpose - to have *focused, clear* questions with a *proper MRE* (for how-to questions, "MRE" means precise input and output specifications, and occasionally a rough framework with a "what goes here?" comment).

Comment: After all, the biggest part of "trying something" to solve a problem is *breaking it down into steps*. If the problem **has** steps to break down into, then it inherently needs more focus. So the main reason to get people with how-to questions to "try something" is so they can find a more specific how-to. Unfortunately, what happens is that both askers and comment-feedback-givers interpret this as "you should show code for the whole problem", and then you get an unfocused mess where now it's both a how-to and a debugging question, and there are multiple bugs.

Comment: "this video "Uncovering Stack Overflow's TOXICITY" from Alex Ziskind illustrates the point nicely." Simply looking at the thumbnail for this video makes me want to discount anything that it has to say. The idea that "[I'm](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) new, please [help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236)" ought to be positively received, or that it is "toxic" to keep that out, reflects such a profound and fundamental misunderstanding of the site's goals that no further discussion seems possible. Stack Overflow is **not about** "helping" the OP.

Comment: ... On the other hand, as I mentioned in comments to other answers, downvotes are always going to be perceived that way by an overwhelming fraction of the population, no matter what you say about them. If that's "unreasonable" then I've scarcely met any reasonable people in my 40+ years on this planet. A brief scroll through Reddit is all it should take to prove the point.

Answer (score 8):

It is hard to answer uniformly for every site because the cultures differ. For example, on [the physics site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour) answers are closed if they don't show research or if they are homework like. This is valid. We don't want to do people's homework for them. On the other hand, this is the prime use of Stack Overflow. I am a professional programmer. That is where I go for documentation or to get an easy answer to a problem. And this is valid.

**Reputation keeps me coming back** to answer questions at the physics site. I do it because I like to be helpful. Reputation is what makes me feel helpful.

It also motivates me to write good answers that get lots of votes. It is disappointing when number of votes often does not relate to the quality of the answer. That's life. On the average, better answers get more votes.

**Downvotes discourage new posters**. New posters don't know our rules about what we answer and what we close. They don't know our preferences to how we like questions to be posed. The wrong kind of question often gets downvoted and closed.

We justify downvotes as a way to encourage better questions. But a new poster doesn't know this. The user feels unwelcome and doesn't come back. I often feel that a courteous explanation of why the question doesn't fit our site and restraint on downvotes would improve this.

Here is an example question of a homework-like question that was closed with downvotes. I don't feel this poster should necessarily be discouraged. He should be encouraged to reframe his question so it fits the physics site better. That might not fit his needs - he might be looking for someone to solve the problem for him. If so, he is free to look elsewhere. Or he might ask again in a way that we accept. [Unitary operator corresponding to Galilean transformations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/754941/37364)

**Duplicate answers** are a problem. Closing duplicates does keep us from having lots of duplicates. This does have benefits.

But answers more than a few days old don't get votes. I don't believe many people read them. When I add an answer to an old question it rarely ever gets a vote. When I link an old question to a new one (because it's a duplicate or related or relevant), the linked question seldom gets votes.

When a new poster asks a question and it is closed as a duplicate, it can be discouraging. Particularly when the duplicate answers at an expert level, and the OP is a beginner.

I don't know how to best handle this.

**Downvoting and closing questions that could be answered**. This is similar to duplicates. Some questions get closed too hastily. There are some common reasons for this.

The question contains a mistake or misconception. Or the poster is too confused or new to physics to pose his question clearly.

This is often interpreted as the poster being too ignorant or hostile to physics to understand the answer. There is no point to answering.

This is a valid concern. We get many such posters. Some are religious. Some genuinely confuse physics with movie special effects. Some have their own homemade physics theories and cannot be convinced that anything else is right.

But other posters are just confused. A clear explanation would be of real benefit.

Some posters just pose their question wrong. We only address questions about mainstream physics. A question like "Why can't I go faster than light?" may well get an answer. But "Suppose I go faster than light. Would time go backwards?" smacks of a personal theory and/or poor understanding. It is likely to get closed.

More thought before downvoting and closing these would help.

**Update on questions that could be answered**

Here are some questions that illustrate what I mean.

[If you could zero out your momentum, could you travel faster than the speed of light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/649415/37364)

This is obviously one of the lowest quality questions. The poster had heard something ridiculous and wanted an explanation. Most of the responses were in line with that. But though the poster was not familiar with physics, he was a reasonable person and was willing to listen. Giving a straightforward polite response that this is nonsense was helpful. He learned from it.

[Special Relativity and Simultaneity and Movement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/756019/37364)

This poster has a better understanding of physics. He is learning special relativity (SR). Like many students, he is finding the concepts confusing. He sees what appears to be an absurd implication of SR and asks why it isn't so. This is a perfectly reasonable question right up our alley. If he had worded it differently, it would have been answered and maybe even up voted. People were hasty to down vote because they thought the poster expected silly implications. They were hasty to close as an inappropriate duplicate.

[Is the Multiverse just a new religion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/744334/37364)

This one is dubious. Many religious posters have the idea that truth comes from God, and physics disagrees with this truth. They are often unwilling to listen to ungodly answers. Such posts are downvoted and closed almost as a knee jerk.

You can see that this poster is somewhat sceptical of physics and has some misconceptions. Still he doesn't sound utterly convinced that physics is hogwash. I would have been willing to explain that the [many-worlds interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) is a speculative thought, something that might be true. If we find evidence, we will be more convinced. This makes it different from religion. This means physics isn't as unreasonable as he had thought.

He might have listened, and he might not. But as is, he deleted his question. I would be surprised if we ever see him again. His take surely must be that he asked what he considered a reasonable question. He was shouted down. Physicists are unreasonable and physics is hogwash.

The common thread is that a more tolerant response benefits the posters. It fulfills the mission of the site. It counteracts the reputation the physics site has built of being elitist.

[Are time crystals real?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hV2Vxfxu47k)

Here is one more, a video that shows how [Don Lincoln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Lincoln) of [Fermilab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermilab) handled one such issue. I wouldn't necessarily answer like this. But it is a lot of fun and clearly explains the misconceptions and the real ideas.

Comment: *"We justify down votes as a way to encourage better questions."* Not really, no. The justification for downvotes is as a content-rating mechanism. If they "encourage" anything, they encourage the system not to show poorly-received questions to users who are browsing the list of questions. *"[A] new poster doesn't know this. [Thus, the] user feels unwelcome and doesn't come back."* I tend to read this as "new users who come to our site and ask low-quality questions feel unwelcome and don't want to come back", and I very much want to say in response: "mission accomplished".

Comment: *"New posters don't know our rules about what we answer and what we close. They don't know our preferences to how we like questions to be posed."* I fundamentally agree with this, and I think **this** is what needs to be fixed. The site needs to do a better job of communicating what its expectations are—both to new users (most critically), but also to any/all users with the privileges to close questions. The preferences and rules are both communicated exceptionally poorly. The site tour is great, but it could be a lot better, and built-in, on-page guidance would be even better.

Comment: Wikipedia isn't exactly an inviting community to new contributors, but that works really well for them, since their focus is on high-quality content and getting more *viewers*. Why wouldn't the same model work for us? It's been working nicely for us for the past decade or so. There's a big difference between being elitist and being toxic. Stack Overflow has *always* been elitist, in the sense that there's a huge barrier to entry, and that's entirely by design, because *good* content is harder to create than mere content. I agree it's harmful to "slam the newb" simply because they're new. @tets

Comment: @CodyGray - Wikipedia is to all intents & purposes, read-only for 99.9% of the population, including me. Had a look once, barrier to entry too high for me to bother trying to grok it all. SO isn't all of SE, in fact it's one bit I almost never look at because I've no clue what they're talking about ;) I tend towards the computers but not coding sites, plus some 'arts with tech aspects'. I consider myself a skilled computer *operator*, I don't fiddle with the nuts & bolts.

Comment: @CodyGray - We will have to deal with these problems until we get new posters who read before posting, If they are not posting what we want to read, we can still let them know without ruining their day or making them sorry they visited our site. I do spend time and effort at the site. It makes me feel a bit of ownership. But it is a public site. I don't feel like doing someone's homework for them, but I can tell them that politely. I don't want to stop them from looking for that kind of answer online. I want them not to do it again here.

Comment: Downvoting is discouraging by design. It is an indication to go back and review what was produced because there was a problem with it. If downvotes were encouraging, then that would defeat the entire purpose.

Comment: *"We will have to deal with these problems until we get new posters who read before posting."* Unfortunately, that appears to be true. However, this is what's *great* about downvotes: we only have to deal with these problems a limited number of times because after enough downvotes, the users who don't read before posting get blocked from posting by the system. I've no problem with making people who don't read feel sorry for having visited the site. Where I have a problem is that we don't currently provide the info we want users to read in a sufficiently accessible way, so we have some blame.

Comment: @CodyGray I disagree that being an uninviting community is working well for Wikipedia. The contribution process is so politicized that I gave up on contributing to it long ago. And because that process deters all but the most agenda-driven contributors, there are huge problems with bias. There has been plentiful criticism of Wikipedia due to its bias... anyone curious can do their own research. I try to steer clear of it these days even as a reference. One thing's for certain: it's now too big to fail. (Sorry for the off-topic rant. Couldn't resist.)

Comment: "When a new poster asks a question and it is closed as a duplicate, it can be discouraging. Particularly when the duplicate answers at an expert level, and the OP is a beginner." If beginners can ask a question, it should have beginner-level answers. If they're missing, write one yourself, or offer a bounty. If you know that a canonical has a beginner-level answer that is under-appreciated, mention it in comments when dupe-closing.

Comment: "Some posters just pose their question wrong. We only address questions about mainstream physics. A question like "Why can't I go faster than light?" may well get an answer. But "Suppose I go faster than light. Would time go backwards?" smacks of a personal theory and/or poor understanding. It is likely to get closed." - So, close the latter as a duplicate of the former. The best answer to someone who has an impossible question on a flawed hypothetical, is an explanation of the flaw.

Comment: @Tetsujin even with "wiki" in the name, I suspect most readers of Wikipedia nowadays would *not even have it occur to them* that it can be edited - and most of the rest would want to do things like edit the page about dogs to ask whether Rover's condition is serious enough to go to the vet. (which is a big part of why they have a page protection system.) That said, I agree with Mentalist that the site has huge problem with bias, particularly WRT its "reliable sourcing" policy.

Comment: Regarding the duplicate answers: [Add an option to leave a "This is a duplicate answer" comment when voting to delete an answer from review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371341/)

Answer (score 7):

40 answers and counting, so I won't rehash what's been said, and sorry if my point has already been covered and I missed it.

There's a reputation problem on many small sites, but it isn't due to the design of the reputation system. For reputation to serve its purpose, people need to vote. The majority of the benefit of the Q&A knowledge, and the voting that sorts it, is for people finding the information in a search. They can't vote.

All of the voting is done by site users who have at least minimal reputation, generally meaning they have done some posting that was well-received by the community.

That's all great in theory. But many small sites have very little participation by users with voting privileges. Few of these people visit regularly. Of those who do, few bother to vote.

It becomes a vicious circle, where sites get fewer answers because investing the time to write good answers isn't rewarding on those sites. Lack of interest in writing answers and fewer answers by others means less reason for regulars to visit the site often.

For new contributors, it takes so long, and so many posts, to build the reputation to fully participate, that few continue to do so. Of the few who do, even fewer build the rep for community moderation. So small sites atrophy as participation by experienced users wanes and they are not replaced by involved new users.

Reputation plays a key role, but it doesn't work on many small sites because so few people vote. Tweaking the algorithms won't fix it, and radically changing it corrupts its purpose. It's a user behavior problem, not a reputation system problem.

Comment: Would smaller sites really thrive if there were no reputation thresholds (or much lower ones)? With a small community it still wouldn't be worthwhile to write good answers because still few people would see them and the vicious circle would continue. Sure, you could try to tweak the system a bit but fundamentally, small sites will always fight an uphill battle. Free reputation for all would probably not improve anything.

Comment: @Trilarion, changing the reputation system wouldn't be the solution. During beta, there are lower thresholds, and they work while there's an active core of users. People can accumulate rep an order of magnitude less than on big sites, but that is still enough that with subject matter interest and a sense of community, people find it rewarding.  Sites retain the reduced thresholds after graduating. But if the site doesn't grow to a self-sustaining critical mass of users, it slowly atrophies through core user attrition. Rep is the face of the problem, but the cause is a people problem.

Answer (score 7):

I'm a long-time member of Stack Overflow and many other sites on the Stack Exchange Network. In fact, I think I joined before even the trilogy, when Stack Overflow stood alone. And I've never cared a jot about rep.

I like seeing the little green flag which means that someone somewhere found something I wrote useful. I always click to check which post received an upvote. (It's often something I wrote yonks ago off the top of my head with no effort involved.) It gives me warm fuzzy feelings, seeing that green flag. The actual number attached to it is completely irrelevant. Certainly I have no idea what my reputation on any given site is without checking, and I'd like it to be made less obvious.

(I do care about having enough rep to edit posts, because I do a lot of editing. I actively enjoy proofreading.)

#### What is really great about our reputation & privilege system? What do you think makes it great, and why is it worth keeping?

Allowing basic moderation abilities on the basis of *experience with the system* and *value provided to the community* makes sense, and rep is a reasonable proxy for that. Perhaps some people also find it rewarding in some way? I cannot claim to understand that.

#### What is broken about it, and why? Are there any solutions to it?

It's too big a deal. It's in our face all the time, and people are encouraged to chase it. See [The problem with extrinsic motivation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/the-problem-with-extrinsic-motivation) for more. I cannot imagine that *any* of the truely great contributions to Stack Exchange (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902 comes to mind) were made by someone chasing rep points.

Answer (score 7):

A frustration for me (I currently have ~1300 reputation on Stack Overflow) is that when I want to edit posts, I usually get an error saying the review queue is full. I can't do anything about this because I don't have sufficient reputation to review things in the queue. I usually avoid making edits as a result.

Most of my edits are obvious changes (spelling, fixing broken links). I think it's sad that I've been contributing to Stack Overflow for over 11 years and am unable to make these simple changes.

Comment: Related: my feature request [For edit-suggestors with a streak of N approvals, only require one approval for their next suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383823/997587) and [@journey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135565/journeyman-geek)'s [Opining a successful-edit-count-based two tier suggested edit system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387434/997587)

Answer (score 6):

This is quite a late answer, sorry, but I think the initial premise is wrong; the question is wrong (at least, for Stack Overflow, which is still, I understand, the biggest site in the SE network -- bigger than all the others added together).

SO shouldn't be trying to gain new users. It should be trying to grow the number of programmers on the site. I realise that this is a very similar thing, but I think it's an important distinction and recognising it may throw some light on the problem.

First, there's the 'growth' word. Attracting new users is part of growth, but it also recognises that retaining existing users is also important.

Then there's the 'Programmers' part. We don't want new users -- half the posts I close are off topic for SO. We specifically want to attract programmers. And, mostly, we want (trigger alert) professional programmers.

I've heard it repeated often that SO is unfriendly to new users. I think that anyone working in this community is probably not a snowflake and a couple of rude comments aren't enough to dissuade people. And, the learning curve is ok for programmers because we're programmers.

Having said that, I think the privilege system is broken. The system currently encourages answering duplicates and off-topic questions rather than flagging or downvoting them. That should change. And, I agree with previous posts that reputation doesn't demonstrate good moderation capabilities. Though, length of tenure might. I've been here ten years, and I know how to moderate, but I can't edit a tag wiki without having it reviewed first, which is a bit silly.

I'd remove rep penalties for downvotes, and I'd add a rep penalty for answering a question that is later marked as a dupe, and double that for answering an off-topic question.

I'd give more moderation rights to people based on tenure, but only if requested. We can decide for ourselves if we want that privilege.

Comment: "_The system currently encourages answering duplicates and off-topic questions rather than flagging or downvoting them._" See [Dharman's answer](/a/387377/997587) (and [their other answer](/a/387375/997587)) and [my answer](/a/387398/997587) and others.

Comment: maybe try to think bigger than just SO? This is MSE after all. And do you _really_ mean professional programmers? Or this an XY, and you really want people who can ask good questions as defined in [ask]?

Comment: I'm not a programmer, and quite a few sites I frequent involve no programming whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I do use some of the other SE sites myself. In this case, I'm talking specifically about SO of course. And yeah, I really mean professional programmers. SO is primarily used by professionals for professional purposes. I'd be happy to pay for this service, if we could keep all the non-pro stuff away. And, the SO survey indicates that most users are professionals, so I guess a lot of the industry would feel similarly.

Comment: People answering questions are trying to be helpful. Removing rep gained from answering dupes etc would be fine, but it's unduly draconian to punish the repondent for the laziness of the querent. As a rank amateur I agree that SO itself arguably has enough users, and needs not more but better ones, i.e. professionals

Answer (score 6):

**Users without up/downvoting privileges should be able to vote up and down on answers to *their own questions***

I find it odd that users who haven't yet unlocked the up/downvote privileges—typically new users—has no voting ability on answers to their own question, but has to earn reputation in order to do this. I have no problem in even allowing downvotes in this specific case (to mark an answer seeming to be not helpful).

Comment: I endorse this, but only as a package deal with removing the accept system completely.

Comment: There might be [a small inflation problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMoPR2IA2Uk&t=2m11s). And spammers and voting rings would have a field day (the required effort is much lower (just create two accounts, plagiarise some questions and answers, and start upvoting). We saw what happened with ChatGPT when it replaced mindless googling and mindless copy-pasting some search result).

Answer (score 5):

Speaking about reputation without speaking about voting (the main source of reputation) will be the opposite of intelligence. All the woes caused by reputation that people complain about are caused by our voting culture. One of the most damaging behaviors of our voting culture is penalizing and discouraging downvotes. Users should be able to vote their votes without worries. Negative feedback is more important when there's so much noise, so let’s fix that by removing all disincentives on downvotes: downvoting isn't a separate privilege; it is a single one with upvoting, the voting privilege; upvoting cost nothing, so downvoting should also cost nothing; downvoting makes a post total score to be reduced by one. It should also happen with reputation; the amount of reputation gained by an upvote is the same than a downvote.

Once you implement the first two, track the behavior of the ratio between upvotes and downvotes between users with the voting privilege and users without it (include both anonymous and registered ones). That would address some of the most egregious behaviors of the voting culture, and help towards creating a better voting culture.

The third is mostly aimed towards creating actual disincentives that the voting culture caused: post as often as possible. These three in tandem will steer the communities towards more productive behaviors and reduce further damage.

Those actions however, do not do anything to address the damage already done. I have a couple of ideas:

- More pruning: questions that are asked frequently (by the number of questions that are closed as duplicate against it), should be soft limited to 10 and hard limited to 50. Add some sort of expert queue so that users with knowledge about the topic (make it a badge privilege) can evaluate why users aren't finding the target post and take actions to make it either, easier to find or harder to misinterpret. Allow those users to see the deleted linked posts even if they don't have 10k yet. The limits should be enforced by the roomba and all posts deleted with by this should have the same effect as if it was deleted before the 60 days rule on reputation. How will this fix reputation: this will disincentivize and revert back the damage done by answering duplicate questions.
- Questions locked that are also closed by unclear, too broad or opinion based should have the same treatment deleted posts. All reputation gains of the question and associated answers should be invalidated. Locked posts are usually reserved to posts that would otherwise be deleted, so let’s make sure they have the same treatment as a deleted post without the actual deletion.

Those are the most lowhanging fruits that would disincentivize certain undesired behaviors that are done for reputation points. Others will take more time or require a deeper change of culture, like incentivizing edits to older posts, reducing the effects of popularity on voting behavior, and incentivizing posts that demonstrated both deep knowledge about the topic and accessibility in the presentation.

Comment: "Once you implement the first two, track the behavior of the ratio between upvotes and downvotes between users with the voting privilege and users without it (include both anonymous and registered ones)." I address this in my own answer, BTW. We don't have accurate stats right now because users in the 15-125 rep range get their up-arrow-clicks counted as "upvotes" and their down-arrow-clicks counted as "feedback". But last I checked (with the "moderation tools"), "votes" on Stack Overflow are more than 90% positive, close to 95%, while "feedback" is only about 60% positive.

Comment: "questions that are asked frequently (by the number of questions that are closed as duplicate against it), should be soft limited to 10 and hard limited to 50." Do you mean to have additional duplicates automatically deleted when closed, or just what? I think there is a problem whereby new duplicates of a question might be noticeably higher quality than existing closed ones. There's also a **huge** problem on Stack Overflow with duplicates simply going unrecognized and not closed as such.

Comment: But yes, I absolutely am in support of reversing reputation gains from old, historical-locked questions.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "Do you mean to have additional duplicates automatically deleted when closed, or just what?" not when closed but regularly, like roomba, to limit the tail end and prune the lowest scored ones. The soft limit is more about informing close voters that the target question has already many duplicates closed against it, so they have double check whenever the target is valid.

Answer (score 5):

### Not working: minimum rep to add comments

This has been broken forever. The way people want to enter a complex system like Stack Overflow is by dipping a toe in the water: making a tiny contribution and seeing what happens. The obvious way to do that is to add a comment on a question or answer: "I have a tiny bit of information that may be of use".

But the current system prevents that. It basically says "The only way you can participate here is by taking big, bold steps and doing them right".

It sucks. And since everyone who participates in these discussions has long since passed that minimum threshold, we forget how bad it was.

Comment: It does suck, but comment moderation sucks harder. (I may be one of the people moderating comments, but I recently watched a friend struggle to get started on SE and she only made it to 20 rep or so.)

Comment: While I agree that comment moderation is a pain (and that folks often misuse comments for things that should be posted as answers or new questions, or sometimes not posted at all), I can see your point that the site doesn't really offer a simple "entry point" unless you know how to ask a good question or post a good answer.

Comment: That said, users are able to suggest edits even if they don't yet have the privilege to edit directly (and on most SE network sites, they can even do so without registering an account), which does seem to partly address this issue – especially since the main purpose of comments is to either suggest improvements to the question/answer, or request clarification from the author about it. Suggested edits can be used to make those improvements themselves (which, generally, is what folks should be doing for issues that they can fix on their own without changing the meaning of the post).

Comment: Editing an existing answer is a pretty different path to adding a comment or an answer, and I would guess is even more daunting for a newcomer. Imagine turning up at your first day on the job, and being told, you can't give feedback on someone else's work, but you can just go right ahead and make changes if you want.

Comment: @V2Blast "Suggested edits can be used to make those improvements themselves (which, generally, is what folks should be doing for issues that they can fix on their own without changing the meaning of the post)" Overwhelmingly IMX, when new users make these sorts of comments-in-the-answer-section, they want to ask OP to clarify a particular point, or add a specific piece of missing information, etc. IOW, edits that only OP could possibly make. If it were something they could suggest as an edit themselves, they would presumably just answer as if that edit had been applied.

Answer (score 5):

> What is broken about it, and why? Are there any solutions to it?

It's not broken in the sense "*needs to be fixed*", but something that could maybe be modified/extended. I'm talking about janitorial services. I participate in some stacks, where, for some of them, it's more about reading, and, for some others, about answering/reading. But, for most of them, I'd like to be able to clean what can be, and put some extra efforts in it.

In order to do that, I need to gain reputation, and I can't always do that on that particular stack. So, I see many things I could improve/correct without being a diamond mod or "*trusted*" user (of this stack). But I ***am*** a trusted one on others. If I can edit some posts, VTC/VTD because I'm trusted, why would that trust stop at the border of another stack?

I'd like to think and talk about **moderation rights' portability**. Not for all privileges, but some basic ones (to be determined). The ones you can use to clean some mess, to improve a post by correcting some spelling/typo/grammar. At the moment, on some stacks, I have to go through some process and steps. It's a fair and logical process. But doing so gives more work to the "*cleaning team*" in the review queue. Maybe we could gain in "productivity" if a trusted user on one (or more) stack(s) could gain access to more janitorial tools.

In accordance with procedures to be laid down by SE, for some duties/tools, it could be immediately, or after a kind of probation period, or a number of duties achieved or a lowered thresold for reputation, or even a combination of some of those.

Comment: Wikipedia has a ***waiting period*** and ***a certain number of edits*** (4 days and 10 edits for "[autoconfirmed users](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Autoconfirmed_users#Autoconfirmed_and_confirmed_users)". 30 days and 500 edits for "[extended confirmed users](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Autoconfirmed_users#Extended_confirmed_users)") to prevent drive-by edits, etc. It only applies to a few pages, like *[Justin Bieber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justin_Bieber)* and *[Arab–Israeli conflict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab%E2%80%93Israeli_conflict)*, respectively.

Comment: "If I can edit some posts, VTC/VTD because I'm trusted, why would that trust stop at the border of another stack?" **Some** edits, close reasons and deletion decisions will require subject matter expertise. For example, I wouldn't want the top users of Math Overflow coming to Stack Overflow and VTC questions about [Excel formulas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875) because they think it's "not programming".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: very true indeed. That's why I'm really walking on eggshells here and mention only this as an option. Of course, there's room or not for portability as every stack could have its own specific rules or area of knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

What works - it works extremely well in all the obvious ways that you already know about. It was developed as alternative to forums, where valuable information is buried under a huge tide of noise. As a general principle, it does what it's designed to do, which is foreground good questions and good answers to same, and occlude the bad ones.

Bear that in mind while I say this next bit.

What's broken - humans are animals. If other people like something, you are predisposed to like it too. If they dislike it, you are predisposed to dislike it. No amount of intelligence or education makes you more immune to this tendency than any other human - or animal.

There's a snowball effect. Often vaguely good posts get rewarded way out of proportion, *especially* if the user posting them already has high rep.

As I don't want to disparage the efforts of other users, I'll use one of my own answers as an example:

Question

> Why, in old movies and TV series, do they always use such extremely exaggerated wheel turns when driving a car?

My answer

> In old cars you had to turn the wheel a lot further, because there was
> no power steering. For a feel of that, push a car when the engine is
> dead and try to steer it without engine assistance (it's hard!).
>
> Also the actors would have to act driving with no idea what the screen
> behind them was doing, and often still do.

There are other answers that [are a lot better](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/56562/why-in-old-movies-and-tv-series-do-they-always-use-such-extremely-exaggerated/56567#56567) - go into more detail about old filming techniques, describe how power steering and old cars work more accurately, and even one where someone went and asked a living 1950s actor that they knew. (one of those answers was from a user with higher rep than me but answered 3 days later, so admittedly there are other factors at play).

This snowball effect is not a particularly big deal - there's no way a user will start to rack up points without making some posts which are actually good. The snowball won't pick up lots of snow unless it had already picked up enough to start rolling down the hill. I honestly believe everyone who has rep of 100k plus has that much because they know something useful (note: I am not in that category and don't ever expect to be).

However, the snowball effect is a big deal in the opposite direction. As the question observes, asking an acceptable question these days is really hard. I'm not a newbie on my main site (History SE) but I still consider myself one on SO, even though I made my first post there 9 years ago. If I manage to ask a question that isn't closed, it will still usually not receive any upvotes - and part of needing to ask a question is being unable to always recognise it when answers to other questions tell you what you needed to know.

Looking at other (real) new users' questions, they often get a lot of downvotes before their question is closed. In other words they get much less slack that someone with lots of rep would get. You'd better make your first question perfect, or you're screwed.

For that reason, I strongly believe that for new users (not me, real new users) should have a reputation 'floor' on their questions. I'm aware that a *user's* rep can't fall below zero. I am saying that a new user's questions should never receive a score below zero, and they shouldn't receive notifications telling them that people are downvoting their question. And if a new user actually manages to ask a question which isn't downvoted or closed, they should get an automatic upvote. They won't stick around if their only reward is a zero - better than minus whatever, but still.

If a question is bad enough that it needs to be closed, then there is a mechanism to do that. If a user is trolling, again there are mechanisms to handle that - flagging and deleting questions, destroying user accounts. Neither needs to involve a horrible negative number shoved in a new user's face. (Comments are also a problem with new user's questions, but probably out of scope for this topic).

Second problem with rep system - cultural biases. I went into this one at length [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384169/help-us-identify-new-roles-for-community-members/384207#384207). Just to add - this is mainly a problem at non-technical stacks like History. This is part of the bigger problem that the non-technical stacks don't receive as much attention as they should.

Third problem - [you are not a gadget](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2011/feb/20/jaron-lanier-you-are-not-a-gadget-review). This part is too radical for SO to accept, but I'm going to say it anyway. SO is a company which relies on the free work of very talented people in order to make millions. The real problem with rep is, ultimately, that it's meaningless internet points - this is people's only reward for creating huge wealth for SO's owners and shareholders. If you really want to make it sustainable and better, reward those 100k-plus users - financially. They are the people who, by moral right, own Stack Overflow.

Comment: That's a big no from me. You are making post scores about users. A post score should reflect the quality of the post, not whether the user who asked it is new or not. Imagine that I open a new account and post a question: should it be treated differently than if I did so from my main account?

Comment: If you want to be rewarded, make yourself available on freelancing site and offer your services there. The whole reason behind the SE network is that users can share unbiased knowledge for free and receive it for free.

Comment: I am saying it is immoral for someone to make millions off work that other people do for free. Full stop, no qualifications, no exceptions. You clearly don't agree, which is fine. Re shill accounts, non-issue because methods already exist to detect them... and what would your motive be? To get the authentic new-user-getting-dumped-on experience?

Comment: One other thing re financial rewards - I am not and never shall be in the category of 100k plus users who I said should be paid. Nor did I suggest that users should have to pay to view se content - se has no problem making money without doing that!

Comment: They used to award unicorn paintings for 100k. A lot of users appreciated that, not because of its monetary value, but because of at least the recognition of contribution. However, the current trend here doesn't seem to be in the direction of rewarding content creators.

Comment: `Re shill accounts, non-issue because methods already exist to detect them` -> this is only used to detect multiple accounts that are used to break rules, e.g. to do things that you couldn't do with a single account. There is no problem with me having multiple accounts and asking questions from either of them, as long as I don't "cross the streams" so to speak.

Comment: Re *"Reward ... users ...financially"*: The financially incentive is ***already*** perverse today (it is indirect): [Paid homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417632/request-to-let-banned-users-ask-one-question-every-week#comment906279_417632) (a sort of corruption), CV stuffing with paid-for reputation points, purchased accounts, voting rings, etc.

Comment: I heartily agree with this… right up to the end, then you lost me. I'm all for a less toxic experience. I don't really think the remunerative part of the post belongs to the rest of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

And one more answer:

For me reputation points are mostly gamification and that has only very limited value. It's something attached to a user and may incentivize users to do more of the "right" things and less of the "wrong" things. I mostly treat content as detached from its creator and try to value it based on its own merits. The score of the content gives me a hint how good a certain piece of content could be. That's all I need (want) to know.

However, as a means to control behavior it's working okayish. The following aspects could maybe be tweaked.

- Moderation privileges (maybe the rep thresholds are not optimal, you could play around with these thresholds if only you had a way to measure how well people are performing in moderation)
- Asking privileges (ultimately the capacity of the network to curate, improve and finally answer new content is limited, so the asking privilege might be tied to positive prior interactions like editing, commenting, ...)
- Rep on questions and rep on answers was made equal some years ago, but it was never evaluated if this was actually beneficial to quality or rather decreased the value of the content. There is no intrinsic requirement for this rep to be the same, so maybe play around more with it, if you have a meaningful quantification how it affects content quality.
- Reward people for finding duplicates (but I have given up hope because that idea is super-old and discussed at length without being even experimented upon.).

But all these things might also work without reputation. For example the editing privilege could simply depend on a certain number of approved edits, the review privilege could simply depend on a certain number of approved reviews, .... Reputation mingles all that together into a single number and that is in my eyes its greatest weakness. I would like to de-emphasize reputation more in the future and instead control on quality as the central topic of every action on the network. Always ask yourself: "how does this improve the overall quality of the content". That's the right mindset. Of course keeping a sufficient large user base is part of the endeavor. Somebody needs to ask those really good questions that others then answer.

One of the strongest points of reputation is that you can lose it (via downvotes on created content). That influences behavior a lot and should be kept additionally to the downvotes.

Maybe related: What does Stack Overflow Inc. actually see as purpose of the site. "We ... want users to be able to participate on our site ..." doesn't really say how users should be able to participate on the site. Would for example just reading be a kind of participation?

Comment: With edits - I wonder if parallel paths would be possible. Either someone who does a lot of good edits, or has an understanding of the site (reputation based) ought to be able to do edits. This might also help SO's edit queue issues, especially if the former group is allowed to do *major* edits unattended.

Comment: With regards to the asking privileges, I would rather see someone ask a question rather than goin in the wild to edit other posts or to place their problems in comments. There is also no way to measure quality of edits and comments, aside from a minor amount of rep and hidden comment votes.

Comment: This quote sums up a lot of issues the exchange faces in my opinion, "the capacity of the network to curate, improve and finally answer new content". Content creation is the pinnacle of actions. Curation cannot improve the overall state of content in the same fashion as creation, and I am curious why it is more common to go in the direction of bonzai rather than forest; especially when every tree is geotagged and indexed.

Comment: "_Asking privileges (ultimately the capacity of the network to curate, improve and finally answer new content is limited, so the asking privilege might be tied to positive prior interactions like editing, commenting, ..._" and who will review those edit suggestions and flags? (speaking of limited human resources in the nework)

Comment: @starball You're right in that somebody must do it but I'd argue that evaluation an edit is less work than evaluating a whole question where you have to check that it's on topic, clear, complete, not a duplicate, ... Assuming that everyone can ask a high quality, new question is kind of asking for too much. This is not a small task.

Comment: @TravisJ you're saying that in a place where we nip duplicate trees?

Comment: @starball - You are asking me [like I am not familiar with duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders)? It's not that we don't need to cull these duplicate sets, it's that there is an abnormally large amount of focus on removing content rather than creating it. Look at what got all this started, a group of content creators. How many of them are left?

Answer (score 4):

I'll offer my thoughts as a new-ish contributor, who's slowly contributed maybe a dozen or so Q's and A's over a span of several years.

What about reputation is working to make me a good contributor:

- The existence of a reputation system. When I've thought of an unasked question, or found a question I can answer, the carrot of increasing my rep does motivate me to do more research, pay attention to the approachability of my prose, etc.
- The +10/-2 up/down vote disparity. I don't have the rep to see downvote totals on any sites yet, but I can infer from seeing notifications like "+38 rep from [answer]" that even my good contributions get a fair few drive-by downvotes. The smaller rep impact of downvotes makes this a lot easier to not take personally, and doesn't change the fact that I'm still plenty incentivized to delete a net-negative voted contribution (which I have done before.)
- The association bonus. It's much easier to get comfortable with a new site when I'm able to ease into contributing there by leaving helpful comments. I do wish that comment votes generated notifications; I understand why they don't generate rep, but I'd like to get the feedback on whether I'm leaving helpful comments without having to remember to go back to the question to look later.

What about reputation is **not** working to make me a good contributor:

- Low rep gain from niche answers. I'm getting far enough in my life to have some expertise on some subjects, and I do occasionally go tag spelunking to find niche questions I can answer with that expertise. This is probably the most value I can offer SE as a contributor, and it's the thing I get the least rep gain from doing. It takes a lot of valuable time watching a tag to find an appropriate question, and if I write a good answer it might get an accept and 1 or 2 upvotes.
- The HNQ reputation effect. The vast majority of the rep I've earned on most sites has come from answering HNQ questions when I get lucky and catch one that doesn't already have the answer I'm thinking of. This incentivizes me to use SE casually, checking HNQ every so often like I'm scrolling social media. I just discovered, after writing this answer, that there is a "filtered questions" view on the homepage which partially addresses this problem from the question discoverability side; I'm certainly going to give that a try. (It's not exactly prominent, it appears above the self-promo banner on the page and is hidden when logged out. By the time I started logging in regularly, I'd already tuned this part of the page out as self-advertisement.)

Comment: "_and the lack of a cross-network home page other than HNQ_" https://stackexchange.com? "_if I could simply have a home page with a feed of tag searches from multiple sites._" RSS feed?

Comment: @starball huh, closer inspection of the main page when logged in reveals there is a tab which is basically exactly what i described. editing this answer now

Comment: I'm mostly in agreement, except the point about up/downvote disparity. If the system told you that you got +30 rep, you wouldn't know whether it was +3/-0 or +4/-1 votes, so you still wouldn't take the downvote personally unless you went to the question and expanded vote counts (requires 1k rep). I do think that reaching a *net* -1 on a Q or A shouldn't count as much against a user as a net +1 helps, though, yes.

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR:

In general, the reputation system might be doing a good work as the large user base is using the system properly and most of those having a high reputation have fairly earned it. Unfortunately, there are a few that are taking advantage of some system cracks, like neglected tags or some sites with low participation or have found how to *game the system*.

The reputation system might be benefit from being analysed by using a systems approach, i.e., by using a framework / model like [Viable System Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viable_system_model) (VSM).

Suggestions:

Improve the contingency / correction measures to better palliate the *perverse incentive* effects, better help to avoid *game the system*, and avoid usage vices.

Add more visibility to helpful information for the user and community explicitly pointed to facilitate and require a standard (minimal) self-regulation /  self-organization.

Better align the reputation system to the welcoming, helping goals, participation and community health goals.

---

Using the VSM, the *reputation system* might be seen as a concrete component that interacts with several conceptual systems of this recursive analysis model.

In VSM, the "*system 1*" refers to *autonomous recursive components*. In the case of the Stack Exchange (SE) Network, each user could be seen as a *system 1* who is part of a community that also could be seen as a *system 1*. Each community is part of the SE network, and that could be seen as the *system 1* in focus.

The core concept of the *reputation system* is that *reputation points* are earned by each SE user as the result of their interactions with other SE users through the SE software. Unfortunately, many users and apparently many communities too, don't look to have the *requisite variety* to achieve the *autoregulation* "standards". In other words, the environment and the tasks to be done are too complex in relation to capacity installed understood as the skills, knowledge, being able to participate, willing to participate.

On the other hand, there is also an alignment problem as not all users are willing to participate according to the goals and policies, but they still found ways to earn reputation. Sometimes this is referred to as "game the system".

When a user is suspended, their reputation is temporarily set to 1, but once the suspension finish the reputation is restored completely. The suspension records aren't public.

There are automatic and manual applied bans to restrict specific privileges. The ban records aren't public.

The access to higher privileges is merely based on reputation points, and it doesn't consider suspensions and bans.

There are some pages that show aggregated data about users, i.e., new users, editors, voters, and moderators, and there are leaderboards, but there isn't any clear guidance, and apparently there is a lack of management knowledge and skills (*requisite variety*), i.e., about how can users as individuals and as community might use the reputation system to take control and policy decisions as individual (self management) and as community (self organization).

### Reputation system points

IMO, ideally the reputation system, besides tracking the current points, might do a better representation of trustiness than nowadays do, if it also tracks an indicator about give the community parameter about how the user behavior is aligned to the community values, let’s call it the "karma" indicator. The *karma* indicator might be calculated based on user participation in tasks that doesn't give reputation points, but contributes to the community like comments, votes, etc. will make earn *karma*, by the other hand getting spam flags, abuse flags, suspensions, that some way go against the community will make that the user loose *karma*.

The karma points might be used for instead of the reputation privileges, i.e., to participate in the per-site meta and in the a site chatroom for new users. Also at a certain level it might earn some "one-day pass" that can be given to new users to allow them participate in the per-site meta and in a site chatroom for helping new users to learn the ropes of the site.

### Exceptions

#### Flag for Moderator Attention and CM escalation process

The automatic *algedonic* (pleasure and pain) channel is responsible of handling the notifications about the good and bad expections. The reputation system triggers inbox notifications or emails about achieving milestones that are related to earning a priveling or badge.

The replies to flags and suspensions are other notifitications  of the overall system that should be more clearly related to the reputation system. At this time only the user and the moderators of the correspondig sites might see them in the user profile but they aren't not clearly linked to the reputation system. The closer might be user community moderator process that have a nominee score card showing some metrics and that might block the participation of users for having suspensions.

The reputation systems doesn't have warnings levels and there are important things that are not throwing notifications that help / guide users and communities to better self regulate / organize.

### Incentives

After the site graduation process, the reputation system doesn't track / recognize *commitment*.

The reputation system incentives to interact with the users from other communities and with the environment are minimal. I think that the only incentive in the reputation system are badges earned for views through shared links.

The reputation system incentives have shown causing undesired effects. Probably it might be qualified as [perverse incentive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perverse_incentive) system as in a certain grade, it has caused problems like:

- very low quality posts being answered and upvoted instead of being downvoted, closed and deleted when they aren't improved,
- "[fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533)" (be the first to answer to take advantage of the chronological sorting, being seen first),
- "tactical voting" (to make a post to have a better ranking to another for other reasons than the post content)
- "balance voting" (to compensate an "unfair" vote)
- "welcome voting" (to allow the user to post in the per-site meta and or use the chat)...

#### Vices

Sometimes good-intentioned users take advantage of the flexibility of the system to deviate its usage in order to help a user that "deserve it". The recurrence of this might relax the attention and eventually that might opened opportunities for *gaming the system*.

### Meta System Relative to the whole SE Network

The reputation system aggregates reputation across all the sites only in the chat and in [combined-flair](/questions/tagged/combined-flair)s.

https://stackexchange.com/leagues shows the leaderboard for each site showing only the reputation points.

> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | [image: Reputation box] | When your fellow users vote up your questions and answers on a Stack Exchange site, you generate **reputation**. Reputation is a rough measure of: - how much the community trusts you your communication skills the quality and relevancy of your questions and answers These friendly **reputation leagues** are an informal way of tracking your reputation within the community on a particular Stack Exchange. Reputation is capped at **200** per day, but remember that bounty awards and accepted answers are immune to this daily reputation cap. |

It might be helpful that also shows a leaderboard of participation (comments, votes, reviews, participation in per-site meta, participation in the site main chatroom)

#### Network Wide Policies

All users starts in Meta Stack Exchange with reputation 1 or with the association bonus. That might be fine for certain type of posts, but for posts discussing stuff that might affect all the network it might be convenient to have a better idea of the contribution done across the network without having to individually navigate to the network profile of each user.

Thinking loudly, posts with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) might show the regular user card (reputation earned in Meta SE only). On posts with [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) might be shown a user card similar to [combined-flair](/questions/tagged/combined-flair) showing the total network earned reputation and a selection of the sites where the user have being participating recently more frequently.

## Related answers

### Perverse incentives

- [user3840170's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356/the-stack-exchange-reputation-system-whats-working-whats-not/387372#387372) from March 9

### Karma

- [Mithical's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356/the-stack-exchange-reputation-system-whats-working-whats-not/387462#387462) from March 11

Comment: What is the point of both an image and (HTML formatted) text?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum posterity and accessibility

Answer (score 3):

It is one of the parts needed to make community moderation work, and that is a really important part. It's also flawed enough that only using reputation for access to mod tools is problematic. It's useful enough as a very, very rough measure of how much someone has participated in a positive way.

It is a fundamentally flawed measure and it won't ever accurately measure knowledge nor moderator ability/qualification. But it's useful enough and I think it would be problematic to try and make it more accurate. I don't think you can get a really accurate measurement anyway, and additional restrictions would likely just make the whole thing more complex, harder to understand and more frustrating. It's useful enough as it is right now.

One huge problem is that on larger sites like SO new posts get so few votes on average that achieving the reputation necessary for participating in community moderation can seem impossible to achieve. A large number of questions and answers simply don't receive any votes at all. I'm not sure how to fix this, but this is a rather large barrier for new users compared to users that started much earlier.

My most controversial opinion on the voting system is that I don't think downvotes are useful enough on questions (please visit [this meta post of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325872/151385) if you want to downvote this idea). My impression is that new voters perceive downvotes and close votes as very hostile. Closing is necessary to keep the site working, but close votes at least carry some more constructive meaning and a chance to fix the question compared to downvotes which pretty much just tell new users that they suck. Downvotes on answers are necessary to ensure the good answers are sorted on top, they don't have the same purpose for questions.

Comment: "*new voters perceive downvotes and close votes as very hostile*" This perception needs to be changed, not the vote system.

Comment: "*downvotes which pretty much just tell new users that they suck*" This is absolutely no true. No part of the voting system refers to the person. Upvotes don't mean "you're cool". Downvotes should only be used to rate usefulness of the content, which they do pretty well.

Comment: @Dharman that's a distinction that new users won't understand, and I don't see any promising way to change that.

Comment: Heck, I'm not a new user and have been inundated in the rhetoric of "downvotes aren't personal" and all of that... and I still really don't like it. I see it as valuable and important but the content I created is mine. Telling me my house is ugly and a mess isn't insulting me but I'm still going to take it personally.

Comment: *"Downvotes on answers are necessary... they don't have the same purpose for questions"*, yes, yes they do. Downvotes on questions serve the same purpose as those on answers, they indicate a lack of quality and make moderating that lack of quality possible for users. And it also 'sorts' questions of the homepage, and like with answers, downvotes allow votes for deletion to happen.

Comment: @Catija Lots of people, including me, have problems with accepting criticism - but that is their problem, not Stack Overflow's. Similarly, learning to accept criticism gracefully - and distinguishing between criticism of self versus criticism of content - is also a personal growth area.

Comment: @IanKemp The problem with a downvote is that it's not really criticism, or at least not effective criticism. It's someone shouting "you(r ideas) suck" out the car window as they drive past. Just like an upvote is the equivalent of applause, a downvote is the equivalent to a boo. And yes, it allows you to "read the room", but (depending on culture & context) I'm not sure there are many who would view getting booed an opportunity to learn to accept criticism gracefully or be a personal growth area.

Comment: @R.M. Then what is effective criticism? That can work for a Q&A format?

Comment: @IanKemp I'm not claiming to have all the answers. I'm just pointing out that there is a difference between feedback that's intended to help someone improve, and that which is solely intended to berate ... and that which is indistinguishable in information content from that which is intended to berate.

Comment: Main problem with DV on Qs is that they remain even after the problems have been resolved

Comment: @R.M. The problem with pointing out differences is that doing so doesn't produce something actionable. The same has been true of the Stack Exchange format since its inception: I've seen the "downvotes are hostile and bad because X" argument too many times to count over the years, yet I honestly cannot think of even one single practical, constructive, actionable alternative that has been proposed. Without an actionable plan to address it, an argument really is just a complaint - and complaining about the same thing ad infinitum isn't useful to anyone. You're welcome to do it, (cont)

Comment: @R.M. (cont) just be aware that those of us who have been around for a while are really, really, _really_ tired of hearing this complaint, and really, really, _really_ disincentivised to give any credence to those making it. Bring us a solution to the problem you perceive with downvotes, and we'll listen; but don't expect us to care when the 1,000th boy cries wolf.

Comment: @IanKemp For questions close votes are the alternative, to handle most low quality content. We have two systems there right now with overlapping purposes, close votes and down votes. There are some downstream systems that need the downvote signal right now like automatic question bans, so those would need to be handled in a different way. But I don't think the actual Q&A needs question downvotes if you have close votes. You could also make closing (and reopening) easier to compensate.

Comment: @R.M. Re _"The problem with a downvote is that it's not really criticism, or at least not effective criticism. It's someone shouting "you(r ideas) suck" out the car window as they drive past"_...., downvotes are necessarily impersonal; they are indicating that a question or answer is not good enough to meet site guidelines/requirements. If you want to place a bizarre interpretation on what downvoting means that's on you, not the downvoting system. Downvoting is a vital component of SE sites. Comments can be personal of course, but not downvotes (excluding the edge case of revenge downvoting).

Comment: @R.M. I would recommend you to read Shog's post about comments vs votes. He discovered, as many of us did, that comments rarely produced the results we wanted (ie. improvements on the post) and it was more effective and efficient to simply _"drive-by voting"_. What did the comments achieve? Bickering, in the best of cases.

Comment: @Dharman "downvotes which pretty much just tell new users that they suck" This is absolutely no true. No part of the voting system refers to the person. Upvotes don't mean "you're cool". Downvotes should only be used to rate usefulness of the content, which they do pretty well." Sure, that's the intent. However, there is nothing you can write, and no font large and bold enough for the message, that would convince new users to see things your way. Putting a negative number next to content **will** make a **large** fraction of authors feel personally judged, **no matter what**.

Comment: @skomisa "downvotes are necessarily impersonal; they are indicating that a question or answer is not good enough to meet site guidelines/requirements." Even disregarding that the "bizarre interpretation" described is evidently very common for new users, a downvote *doesn't tell OP how to fix the problem*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel There's no evidence at all that it's _"evidently very common"_ for new users feel that a downvote is like _"someone shouting "you(r ideas) suck" out the car window as they drive past"_. That's just a volatile and colorful claim that the commenter fabricated, and is unhelpful. But even if all downvotes were reasonable (and that is surely not the case) I agree with you that they do nothing to explain _how_ to improve a question or answer. To address that, I'm in favor of downvotes requiring an accompanying explanation/comment, but the larger community doesn't feel that way AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

Concur with [NeMo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387366/301090) in general outline, but I have a slightly different take.  I spend 90% of my time on history, so my opinion may be skewed.

I think it might be more useful to group contributions (questions or answers) into a couple of categories where the reputation system works differently.

Bad contributions aren't really affected by reputation scoring - they are dealt with by votes for closure/deletion/moderation. So let's ignore bad contributions.

I think there is a weak correlation between good contributions and reputation. @NeMo identifies some edge cases where upvotes do not indicate optimal answer. I'm not sure what policy implications I take from the gap - I'm not sure I'd go to the effort of changing anything.  (see below for additional thoughts)

I think the really interesting case is contributions that need refinement, most especially contributions by new users.  I perceive the downvote spiral, and I'm not fond of it.  Increasingly I'm finding new contributions by new users which have merit/worth/value, but which don't fully participate in the SE culture or the site culture.   The reputation system does not serve this category well.

If I were to offer a suggestion, I'd wonder about broad categories of option (refinement welcome - these are outlines, not fully developed). For questions where "refinement" is the correct intervention, downvotes don't count (or are fractional value).  Upvotes count normally.  Users are encouraged to edit & contribute. Gamify this - upscale the badges & incentives that come from refinement of contributions that are on this margin.

How do we decide which contributions belong in the refinement category?  Could be either:

- Users with <= 100 reputation stay in the refinement queue until they exceed 100 rep.  That provides time to acclimate to the site culture.
- "refine" becomes a special label (like "protected")  Normally users vote to apply the label. Mods can apply the tag.  So long as the question has the refine label, downvotes are discounted, and positively voted edits garner reputation.

The goal is to incentivize refinement and community curation ,and to guide users towards meaningful contribution that aligns with the site culture.

(site culture can always be changed through appeal on Meta)

Comment: "Increasingly I'm finding new contributions by new users which have merit/worth/value, but which don't fully participate in the SE culture or the site culture. The reputation system does not serve this category well." That's a very astute observation..! This sounds a lot like the staging ground though, but with fewer steps.

Comment: Completely agree that a question with -1 next to it usually turns into a pinata. And new users obviously don't always have a feel for what's a good stack question, so are more likely to get one downvote because of some (often trivial) mistake. Moreover a lot of the stack rules and incentives don't make much sense for non-technical sites.

Answer (score 3):

> What is really great about our reputation & privilege system? What do you think makes it great, and why is it worth keeping?

There are lots of things that are great about our reputation and privilege system.

The bar for participation is really low on Stack Exchange, and that is a good thing.  We are (by design) primarily a question-and-answer site, and every user, no matter his or her reputation, can post questions and answers.

When other users find your question and answer posts useful, upvotes will cause your reputation to climb quickly.  The system encourages upvotes and subtly discourages downvotes, and upvotes impact your reputation score more than downvotes.  This is a systemic way to avoid penalizing new users too much while they are learning the intricacies of the site and culture, also a great thing.

The most useful privileges are triggered at very low reputations, which is a great thing.  Participating in meta, voting, commenting, flagging posts, using the chat rooms, and more are all available to you, in steady increments, with fewer than 10 upvotes on any of your posts.  And 20 upvotes on any one site gets you expanded access to *all* Stack Exchange sites.  This is a wonderful feature as well, eliminating a lot of noise from spammers and trolls, yet opening up the doors quickly to new users who are actually contributing on even a minimal level.

Community moderation privileges are granted with higher reputation scores, and this is a great design as well.  Increased participation is rewarded, and it makes sense to trust the users who have proven their dedication to the site to be the ones who help moderate the site.

> What is broken about it, and why? Are there any solutions to it?

In the [Stack Overflow Blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/22/the-loop-2-understanding-site-satisfaction-summer-2019/) that is referenced in the Question, in the "What do you find most frustrating?" poll there are two items on the list that I want to discuss that might be considered related to this topic: "Unwelcoming community" (10.6%) and "Barrier to participation" (8.3%)

In my opinion, "Unwelcoming community" really has very little to do with the reputation system.  Instead, new users are made to feel unwelcome by other actions that have little to do with the reputation and privilege system.  Rude comments and questions that are downvoted and/or closed inappropriately or without adequate explanation in the comments are the biggest "unwelcoming" behaviors that I notice on the Stack Exchange sites I frequent.  This would not be solved by revamping the reputation system.  Instead, it needs to be solved by changing the culture of the site to be more inclusive and welcoming.  Writing blog and meta posts to remind people to welcome new users and be more charitable in voting could be a solution, as well as moderators and high rep users modeling positive behavior.

"Barrier to participation" can be frustrating to some new users, but again, our bar for participation is already really low.  We want to, first and foremost, encourage posting questions and answers, which all users can already do.  And as I said earlier, after just a few upvotes, you have access to do all the important things on our sites.

---

In conclusion, I think the current reputation and privilege system works well as is, and does not need a massive overhaul.

Comment: One of essential limitations for new users is a restriction to comment. When they try to put their comment as an answer, they receive an unrelated advice “consider to answer other question”

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim I see users posting answers as comments more often than users posting comments as answers. Comments that are posted as answers can easily by converted to comments by mods, but the reverse is not possible.

Comment: My experience has been that the "unjustified closures" complaint comes overwhelmingly from people who have misconceptions about what the closure reasons are, and about the reasons for those reasons existing.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It’s certainly a matter of opinion, but you must admit that “misconceptions about what the closure reasons are” could just as easily lead to users voting to close questions that should not be closed.

Comment: It could in principle, yes. My experience is that generally speaking it doesn't.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel My experience is very different than yours.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no consideration for reputation across sites when performing cross-network actions, specifically, in terms of migration. Here's a concrete example:

- A user has lots of reputation on site X.
- This user also visits site Y.
- They often find questions on Y that needs to be posted on site X (it could be off-topic on Y, or just more on-topic on X).
- Voting to close questions with a migration path to site Y is treated similarly to other closure votes, often ending in closure without migration.

If you have lots of reputation on site X, there's an understanding that you're well-informed of what types of questions belong on X.

---

This type of situation mainly occurs with Stack Overflow (SO = Y), which acts like a catch-all dumping ground for questions. Many questions that were on topic in (say) 2012 now have dedicated sites to answer that currently just muddy the waters on SO. It's closure review queue is constantly packed (like most other review queues). Using [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1636235/closed-questions-count-by-month) to count closures on SO, this chart displays the monthly closures over time:

[image]

As of the most recent months, between 12k-14k questions are closed every month (400-500 every day). Some of these may be legitimate closures aiming to migrate questions to a more suitable site (possibly from high-rep users on the target site).

There currently exists a migration path when closing to TeX.SE (X), but closure votes due to lack-of-information or debugging-details cause new-user questions to die on SO, when they would have received better feedback/responses on TeX.SE (despite the question quality).

Reference: [What privilege should 30k users get?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252705/168244)

Comment: The first rule of migration is *"don't migrate crap"*. It doesn't matter that the other site would give better feedback - if the question would be closed on the target site for needing details, clarity, focus, topicality, objectivity, or some other reason, that question should just be closed where it is.

Comment: related idea https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384292/237989

Answer (score 3):

There are already some suggestions to handle voting differently depending on the number of votes. We should consider also handling it differently for new users. A current oddity revolves around the timing of downvotes for users hitting the 1-rep minimum. Here's an example:

- User with (say) 1 rep asks a question.
- They receive 4 downvotes ▼ and one ▲.
- Depending on the timing of the votes cast on the question (+1/-4), they could end up with the following reputation:

  - 11 (▼ = 0, ▼ = 0, ▼ = 0, ▼ = 0, ▲ = +10)
  - 10 (▼ = 0, ▼ = 0, ▼ = 0, ▲ = +10, ▼ = -1)
  - 9 (▼ = 0, ▼ = 0, ▲ = +10, ▼ = -1, ▼ = -1)
  - 8 (▼ = 0, ▲ = +10, ▼ = -1, ▼ = -1, ▼ = -1)
  - 7 (▲ = +10, ▼ = -1, ▼ = -1, ▼ = -1, ▼ = -1)

In all of these voting scenarios, the consensus seems to point to a poor question (1 upvote + 4 downvotes). In all scenarios, they end up with higher rep than they started, but it varies because downvotes at 1 rep has no impact.

I agree that the user should receive some reputation, but that it's variable, depending on when the votes are cast, seems out-of-place. In the above example, the order of counting should be upvotes *first*, then downvotes, leaving the OP with 7 rep, regardless of the vote order. In the above case, the new user could circumvent the [new user restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) at 10 reputation, even though it may be doubtful that this should be allowed.

Comment: pretty sure that's by design- or at least, it's a known and accepted behaviour. I'm too lazy to find a link explaining it right now. Also, isn't downvote impact -2?

Comment: @starball: Even if its accepted behaviour, it could be wrong. The question is about things that work or need improvement. It doesn't seem to work properly around that 1 rep boundary. Downvotes on a question are -1; downvotes on an answer is -2.

Comment: I think would be addressed by Karl's table answer.

Comment: Why it wrong, though? I get that it makes calculations not work out with upvotes/downvotes but the end result in the vast majority of cases is a *miniscule* offset to what the "true" reputation would be. Generatlly, at least from my observations, it's a difference of somewhere between 2 and 6 rep. And I don't get why that should be so significant to change the rep calculations done for 1 rep users.

Comment: @VLAZ: The threshold for privilege gains for new users is low. For example, at 10 rep [new user restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) are removed. If new users ask a poor question, they could circumvent the new user limitations in some cases. In the bigger picture, this affects specific users with single-digit rep, yes. It's small potatoes. The variability of the outcome is what is odd about it.

Comment: And...is circumventing the new user restrictions happening often enough to be a problem we should be concerned about? Does it happen at all? Specifically, how many users who received a number of downvotes and then an upvote went and did something they would have been restricted from had the votes came in a different order?

Comment: @VLAZ: It might be a problem on SO where far more poor-quality posts are received. But my statement here is about the logic behind it. I understand that investment in CPU cycles to calculate an accurate reputation might not be worth the time. Note though that historically there was a reputation recalc feature on SE that fixed oddities, so it seemed to be a consideration to make miniscule adjustments here-and-there.

Comment: So, I can only gather that you have no reliable reason to call this a problem. But you want it fixed because... I guess you don't like it? Also, the CPU cycles argument is strange. It takes *more* time to calculate the rep based on the times of when votes came in. Otherwise the calculation is *much* simpler with number_of_votes * 10 - number_of_downvotes * 2 clamp to a minimum of 1.

Comment: @VLAZ: I often wait to downvote new users who ask poor questions if they have 1 rep. It can stay at 1 rep without a downvote, but the community over on [tex.se] have varied habits for upvoting; some consider it a "mark as read" flag and upvote it. To have any impact, I have to change my behaviour to time the voting. That's a reliable reason, since I don't spend my time on SE 24/7; adjusting my voting behaviour to achieve a desirable outcome when it can be programmed seems better to me. Simple isn't always better. Neither is more complicated... but for outcome to be timing-dependent is odd.

Answer (score 2):

> What is broken about it, and why? Are there any solutions to it?

The Reputation point. The page literally says

> Reputation is a rough measure of:
>
> - how much the community trusts you
> - your communication skills
> - the quality and relevancy of your questions and answers

However, I have seen some long-time users ***who just asked a single, yet basic question, then disappeared forever, still gained thousands of points.*** In this case, it is a correct measure of "the quality and relevancy of your questions and answers", but I think it partially measures (or not at all) trust and communication skills. Can we safely say that that guy, who asked one famous question, has better communication skills and trust than a new user who continuously posts questions and answers, but can never achieve that points?

My proposed solution is to consider implementing a decay system. Kaggle ranking system and H-index have done this, and it is working pretty well: you must be active in order to maintain a "high rank". This thing is not perfect, but it's better than nothing.

(High rep users might downvote this because it is not favoring them. This system is not targeting you, this one targets users who post one question and disappear forever.)

EDIT: add a [related paper](https://petertsehsun.github.io/papers/Is_reputation_on_Stack_Overflow_always_a_good_indicator_for_users_expertise_No.pdf)

Comment: My issue with this idea is not the inspiration, but the realities of implementation and the idea that trust somehow fades over time due to not posting answers. I do agree that users gaining rep in this way is problematic, particularly as something that may discourage new users from participating. I'm a high rep user, and I don't post answers anymore unless it's some novel thing that I feel I have a great answer to. however, I'm most certainly not inactive and not participating. Should the fact that I mostly just clean up low quality questions/answers result in me losing the ability to do so?

Comment: `Should the fact that I mostly just clean up low quality questions/answers result in me losing the ability to do so?` We might have to define the definition of "inactive", for example, in your case when you clean up the site, maybe we need an edge case? But for those who asked a single question then disappeared, it is not.

Comment: Could you give an example of this outside [John Carmack](https://superuser.com/questions/419070/transatlantic-ping-faster-than-sending-a-pixel-to-the-screen)? Also, if something is/was useful, why is it being upvoted being a bad thing? Not all answers lose relevance temporally

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, I will give myself as a second example. I have 15k on SO, but for the past 5 to 8 years, I actually only visited SO when a Google search landed me there (or for reading the occasional HNQ). Why should I have more privileges than a user with 101 points?

Comment: You were active then tho, right

Comment: Another flaw, Meta is meant to be for all, yet controlled by few unless it's featured. This answer's sort of identical to mine yet look at the net votes; that's because only the frequentists bothered to read this far. It's why I don't post on Meta much, not even worth arguing as the true population won't see it.

Comment: People downvote this because they’re afraid to lose their precious. But it is true. The culture and rules evolve. Someone who hasn’t logged in in 6 years will not know the rules, no matter how active they were back then. If not reputation, at least privileges should be attached to recency of the interactions with the site.

Comment: @CrisLuengo agree. With respect, people who are active won't care much about this new system. People who are afraid of losing the reps do, so they care. Bart gave a very accurate example, thank you so much for raising your voice.

Comment: @CrisLuengo:  So...they can't like... *re-learn* the rules or something?  Does 6 years of being away from something preclude one's ability to reacquaint yourself with it?

Comment: @Makoto No, not at all. Show you understand the currently rules (by being active) and you'll get your moderation privileges back. I don't understand why someone that hasn't logged on for 6 years should be able to do advanced moderation tasks.

Comment: @CrisLuengo:  There's a <s>thin</s> very thick line between being empowered to do something and actually doing it.  Empowering someone is the first step, but that also comes with copious amounts of documentation on what to do and what not to do with those powers.  **That already exists** and doesn't really *change* all that much.  Any ambiguities can be sorted out over on Meta.  Any error in application can be handled in a one-on-one capacity with a diamond mod who would set them right.  I don't see the problem here.

Comment: @Makoto We've seen plenty of issues with people taking wrong moderation decisions. I'd rather prevent than needing a diamond mod to step in. What is the problem for example with tying the daily number of close votes available with the number of votes (correctly) used over a given recent period? You could do that with everything: the more you up/down vote *consistently*, the more votes you get, the more edit reviews you do, the more posts you can edit without review, etc.

Comment: @CrisLuengo:  I mean, almost every single moderation decision that anyone can make - let alone diamond mods - is *reversible*.  People can make mistakes and diamond mods are there *specifically* to catch those kinds of human errors.  This isn't about downvoting specifically since, well, those are anonymous by design and you don't have to reveal your motive for downvoting something.  But everything else - which is surprisingly just limited to edits and closure - can be *reversed* if it was done in error.  This is not as big a deal as you're making it out to be.

Comment: @KevinB - "the idea that trust somehow fades over time" - the OG problem is using rep for "trust". That was my plan 8y ago. Build up this 'trust' and then abuse it. I never really made good on that but it does make me feel free to take the kid gloves off and be a jerk. Some humbling might be in order, +1. Anything Harper or Valurom says is like word of god with their 200k rep everywhere. I've never meet them. I trust them as far as I can't throw them. ChatGPT is off limits because it could be wrong? So can random people on the internet.

Comment: I regret getting to 10k because now I can see all the deleted crap and then this is just like everywhere else on the internet. I don't deserve 4k rep on ELU just because I called a corner *chamfered* once, five years ago. - Plus one but they won't do it because it does nothing for new users and only angers old ones that they 'trust' so much.

Comment: "Should the fact that I mostly just clean up low quality questions/answers result in me losing the ability to do so?" No! **It should be giving you points for curating** because that's the one thing SE needs, and by more than just the couple of someones who do it. But again... the OP is asking for the opposite of "clean up low quality questions/answers". *You* are the 'barrier to entry' and help keep this place from becoming complete trash.

Comment: Adding one example here: this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1448207/user1448207) asked a highly upvoted question 11 years ago, last active 2 years ago, racking 13k reputation and is in "top 2% this quarter".

Comment: I don't agree with decay as the solution, but did want to chime in that high reputation is honestly more about how long you've been here, and if you got lucky, than anything else. It was way easier to get rep 5 years ago, as the original post states, and there are definitely people who sling that weight around even though they haven't done much of anything lately. 1 question can get you 3k reputation, but most of those kinds of questions have already been asked.

Comment: I agree with this. I'm actually on both sides of this equation. I have one very highly rated answer on SO which is enough to keep me in the top 0.1% of rep each quarter.  But I'd much rather my rep be based on all the hundreds of other answers I've given.

Comment: Upvoting this because I have real-life experience with decay systems.  SE is an absolute seniority system.  Another such system are the "points" systems used by collaborative artist groups.  These have the issue that nobody can ever pass the founders no matter how much they do.  The solution we implemented for OPA was to create a decay system; every artist loses 10% of their points per year.  This was surprisingly effective; within 3 years, founding members who were no longer active had dropped out of leadership positions.

Comment: @FuzzyChef thank you for your words and happy to know that your case worked. In my case, of course, we need to determine what is "active" and what is not. In the first version, I would imagine as the number of questions/answers post, and the frequency of performing actions in the queue for first answer, first question, edit proposal, etc. A lot of people who downvote seem to think "active" means "posting answers/questions/comments" only.

Comment: The decay happened whether you were a currently active member or not.  It's just not a problem for active members because they constantly generate new points, which allowed them to maintain (or even increase) their point totals.  Doing it by % also helped, because losing 200 points isn't a big deal if you have 2000, but it would be devastating if you have only 250.

Comment: At the same time, a member who was *very* active could, in 2-4 years, "pass up" members who were old but less active.

Comment: I'm starting to see reputation not really as a matter of trust or communications skills, but as a measure of how **useful** as user has been to other users. After all, the upvote criteria for questions and answers both are determined by _usefulness_. We really only _use_ reputation as a proxy for trust.

Comment: Would a single *useful* question determine that that user has higher *privilege* than other users, where most privileges are about communication skills and trust? We are talking about editing, reviewing, etc. content. Why does SO put so much privilege on a *single* useful question? Are we waiting for a [history](https://botwiki.org/bot/redscarebot/) to repeat itself?

Answer (score 1):

**Remove reputation gain from accept votes.**

Question askers are the least suitable people to determine the best answer. Yet, the accepted answer feels to a lot of users like it's the be-all and end-all. Answerers are begging and harassing users for accept votes. New users flag posts for moderator's attention asking to change the "correct answer" mark. Users viewing solutions consider the one with a green tick mark as the one and only true solution.

The first step to fixing this mess is to remove the reputation gained from accept votes. And I know I would lose a lot of gained reputation, but that's an acceptable sacrifice. Reputation should be gained from upvotes, not from the whimsical decision of the question asker. This alone would fix a lot of quality issues on our sites.

The end goal could be to completely remove accept votes, or just leave it as a placebo to the question asker and show it only to logged-in users.

Comment: The amount of votes is already very small to non-existent on many new posts. I really dislike the accepted answer system, but removing the rep gain here would likely  seriously mess up the reputation system at the low end.

Comment: @MadScientist Why is the amount of votes so small? What can we do to encourage users to vote?

Comment: I tend to agree, but also think this would be problematic at the bottom end of the reputation system. Without reputation from accepts, there's no source of rep that doesn't require users who already have rep to kick start it.

Comment: The problems that this theoretically causes is way below the problems that this objectively solves. We need to be able to bootstrap sites with only two users. Removing the reputation gained from accepts will spell doom if any site gets unlucky enough to only have 1 active user answering question and no privileges.

Comment: Removing accept votes would be better. They're antithetical to the not-a-discussion-forum, library-of-answers model. @Braiam that could be fixed by tweaking any number of other constants. It's also why there's a commitment phase on Area51.

Comment: I can see the appeal, but I am not sure I would go quite as far. An accept vote creates an incentive to write an answer that is understandable not just by experts, but by the original asker, who is not necessarily an expert yet. So while I don’t think it’s worth quite as much as an upvote from (presumably) expert users, it’s not exactly valueless either.

Answer (score 1):

My main interest in SO are expert level niche answers to rare edge cases.

What's going to happen if you remove the downvote penalty (following Dharman's proposal which I've discussed with him before) is that the irresponsible downvoters will immediately (in the short term) outnumber the experts who do know how to evaluate intricate solutions to rare problems (in the long term).

I think Dharman's perspective can make sense looking at the massive flow of low quality questions on the PHP tag, but I have to remind of Shog9's argument: "not destroying value". Dharman once asked me: "if you think that question is so good why don't you upvote it?" I'll repeat my answer here: "because understanding the question and running some tests takes a minimum of 2 hours, that's how hard it is to make a judgement on the upvote". (While downvoting something you don't have the slightest clue about at zero cost would take no effort at all.)

Now, if you couple Dharman's proposal of removing the downvote cost with Nij's proposal of increasing the downvote penalty for the poster, you've just empowered reckless irresponsible downvoting at the cost of leaving the niche Q&A posters (seeking to solve hard problems) outnumbered and outgunned. You won't be filtering for pearls any longer, nor promoting the production of those rarer pearls.

(It's happened too many times that I've seen downvotes and critiques in comments from experienced engineers who completely failed to understand the question or the answer they were recklessly voting on.)

Comment: The problem here is that you have a higher standard for an upvote than you do for a downvote. If you upvoted a post because it looked high-quality, then it would be equally reasonable for you (and others) to downvote a post because it's viscerally low quality. Instead, you only want to upvote a post after spending hours verifying it and making an informed judgment. That's useful feedback, but it's way too high of a bar for an upvote. Ironically, I think the main reason you have such a high bar for upvotes is that there's too much low-quality content, which happens because of not enough DVing.

Comment: You've got a point here. However, upvoting also happens recklessly. Maybe you don't vote this way but many people do. Upvoting is meant for posts that look useful. It doesn't require you to validate it. Same for downvotes; it's for posts that don't look useful, regardless of whether you can answer them or not.

Comment: If it takes time to understand a question, that sounds to me like what ordinary people would call "unclear", which is supposed to count against question quality. Just because there is a good, interesting *problem* underlying a question doesn't mean the Q itself is good.

Comment: I think this answer is basically getting to the point that people isn't symmetrical on the way they evaluate post. My standard for meh kinds of questions is higher. For example, if a question is clear and specific it's merely meh, because that's the minimum I expect of anyone asking questions. For me to be awarded an upvote, it has to be interesting/through provoking.

Answer (score 1):

> **What is great about the reputation system.**

Over time, really common questions and trusted users start to stand out. This becomes valuable for new users or people who are just learning about a topic and want to know similar information.

> **What is broken about it, and why?**

New users have a difficult time contributing new questions or information to the site. Users that posted a common question years ago and no longer contribute to the site are still gaining lots of reputation. There should be a balance that incentivizes people to add missing information to already existing pages other than answering a question from 10 years ago. If someone provides a better answer to a common question asked many years ago, does that answer really get recognized?

One way that new users can contribute is by answering their own questions, but I am not sure how this type of contribution would be received by current moderators. It may be more intuitive to format the forum as a guide that people can add new technical information to over time and the Q&A portion becomes more specific to different parts of the guide.

> **What other systems work really well?**

I have been a casual user of Stack Overflow for only about a year and my experience using the site is not going to be deep enough to comment on the intricacies what the reputation system was originally designed for. However, I still want to post this answer in case others think it meaningful.

One thing that I have wanted to mention since I began using Stack is that I think questions and answers could be categorized in a way that acts more like tutorial pages or guides rather than an overwhelming thread of Q&A. This could play into the reputation system by providing users an incentive to build and modify guides or technical information and then additional incentive by answering questions posted to those guides. To me, this seems like a more intuitive interface to show users how a task could be conducted or how technical knowledge should be categorized and written (perhaps a more technical and gamified version of a wiki with a Q&A feature).

When I first joined Stack Overflow, it was overwhelming to try to avoid duplicate questions by searching for pre-existing questions that were similar to mine because there were so many questions and not enough tags to filter to what I really wanted to know. It was also frustrating to see answers be accepted that were kind of close but didn’t fit my specific use case. I was worried that if I posted a new question that wasn’t different enough from existing questions, someone would downvote or close the thread for being too similar to a question asked 5 or more years ago that I didn’t see. Which would be fair to downvote if it decreased quality of content.

I use Stack Overflow mostly to help with programming in R. I also mostly use the ggplot package of R in my typical workflow. I can use the tags to filter [r][ggplot][geom-point] to search for questions that have already been asked on the topic of the “geom_point” function, but what if Stack Overflow had an incentive for people to contribute to a guide on this topic rather than a list of questions? Instead of seeing a list of random questions about using the geom_point function in R (usually R studio), I would prefer to see a guide on this topic that has been contributed to by many users over the years. If the existing guide or guides do not answer my question or provide knowledge I am looking for. I can ask a question and post a bounty for someone to add this missing information to the guide. If I ask a question that has clearly already been answered through the guide or other questions on that guide, I could be downvoted and a moderator could remove that redundant question. On the other hand, if I am proactive, I could add to the guide with my own information and get upvoted for adding new and useful information. In a way, this would make Stack websites become community supported guides for technical information in addition to Q&A forums. Think something similar to how Steam community pages allow users to post guides on specific topics for videogames or how Genius.com allows users to comment on song lyrics to provide additional information and sources for what may have inspired those lyrics.

During my journey learning R programming for the past year, I have wanted to post what I have been learning to a website like Stack Overflow so that people going through a similar journey won’t have to spend as much time figuring out the same things I am. For people who want internet points for doing this, I think the reputation system on stack would be a decent incentive for them to start or modify a guide. There is already a prompt at the bottom of questions that tells users they can answer their own questions. I think the reputation system would work better if answering your own questions or creating guides became a main feature of Stack websites.

This would be very valuable to programmers because every new software and software feature could receive a new or updated guide. It would also be valuable to professional experts that want to publicly share their knowledge of old and new topics in their field (think of science, math, photography, design, fitness, and all other Stack websites attracting expert knowledge in this way).

I apologize for a redundant answer if this feature is already available. If it is available, I have not noticed it.

Comment: "_One way that new users can contribute is by answering their own questions, but I am not sure how this type of contribution would be received by current moderators._"  see [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](/q/17463/997587) and [Is there stigma associated with self-answers on certain network sites? Or different etiquette? If so, why?](/q/385418/997587) "_It may be more intuitive to format the forum as a guide that\[...\]_" this is not a discussion forum. Take the [tour].

Comment: "_This could play into the reputation system by providing users an incentive to build and modify guides or technical information and then additional incentive by answering questions posted to those guides._" ... In what way are we not already doing this as the primary purpose of the site and reputation system? You can get rep for asking, answering, and editing.

Comment: "_but what if Stack Overflow had an incentive for people to contribute to a guide on this topic rather than a list of questions?_" [R now has a collective](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423429/11107541), and people [can write articles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/collectives)

Comment: In a way, Q&A are or can be guides. I don't see what is missing.

Comment: @starball - Your responses are valid criticism. A key component of my post is that the current way information is formatted and organized on Stack websites is not very welcoming to people that want to explore existing knowledge and answers. Yes, I can ask and answer my own questions, but I think guides are better than a collection of related Q's and A's. A Q&A forum CAN be a guide, but it will likely be a disorganized guide. A guide with a Q&A section seems better to me. Thanks, I didn't know the R collective and see it was created only a few weeks ago. Though, no articles are published yet

Comment: What you are describing seems to be fundamentally what Stack Exchange is _not_ and was designed explicitly not to be from the very beginning. ["_Stack Overflow is not meant to be a library of reference manuals. It’s supposed to contain the same information as a library of reference manuals, in the form of millions of questions and answers._"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)

Comment: (though things have changed a bit with collectives and articles. [SE even tried documentation at one point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/11107541). I wasn't there, but I heard it went quite poorly- especially with effects on the reputation system that were not though through well)

Comment: Wow, it is interesting to learn that my suggestion for SE was tried in the past but failed. I still think it would be a great idea, but perhaps poorly implemented in the past. SE has clearly tried to evolve into something more or different, and the latest attempt at evolution may be the collective articles. Let's face it, Stack has evolved into the documentation and technical assistance page for many software. It might as well happen in pseudo-official (and profitable) capacity and do the same for other professions. Thanks again for sharing additional information.

Comment: honestly i think the biggest issue SO docs had *was* the fact that reputation was made part of it. If it were curated by people who did so out of wanting to produce useful content rather than people wanting to pursue an endless source of reputation, the generated content may have been more useful.

Comment: "Instead of seeing a list of random questions about using the geom_point function in R (usually R studio), I would prefer to see a guide on this topic that has been contributed to by many users over the years." Aside from collectives, articles, and the old documentation project - this sounds to me more like what the **tag wiki** is supposed to be. Unfortunately, barely anyone seems to know they exist.

Answer (score 1):

## Reputation for tags (1500) vs. edits (2000)

As someone that's been around for a long time (since the private beta), I'm at the stage where reputation is just a target number for earning the privs to what I want to do.

I like answering questions (and asking them), but over time, helping with triage as been great. I had to do some work to make that happen.

Now I'm at about 1250, so access to tags is next. Frankly, I'm not interested that.

Helping with edits is far away (+800), and I see many questions and answers where I'd like to help with cleanup.

If my rep ever gets to 2001, I won't want to increase for the sake of the number, I'll just want to keep questioning, answering, triaging, and editing.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how that actually answers the question. This feels more like a user-experience-report, but there is no mention of the things asked in the question (What is really great about our reputation, What is broken about it, What other systems work really well)

Comment: It very clearly answers the question. After all what is reputation for? What does it do? Why earn it? The answer is directly to the point.

Comment: @Tomerikoo - I admit its kind of a logical fallacy to wave around my seniority (dunno where my `beta` badges went), but wanted to highlight that meta discussions often are tonally too `meta`, and have lost the history of the reputation score. To add more color: the reason I'm complaining about this, I got tired of bookmarking Q's to edit later, because the edit queue is full, and I can't help with it.

Comment: @Tomerikoo - looking at your rep, you got the 2K I'm working towards. How happy are you that you can create tags and work the edit queue? Which do you think is more useful? Do you think that, until you had gotten your last 200 and 700 rep, were you qualified for each priv?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution: consider network reputation for comment privileges**

I am a very low-rep user who has used SE for a long time, mostly as a reader.  The "problem" part of this answer has more-or-less already been posted, but since I have never posted on Meta before I cannot comment.

"Not working: minimum rep to add comments"

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387552/1029183

I understand that needing a minimum reputation to comment prevents some unwanted behaviours.

However, I think that maybe you could consider network reputation when deciding to allow comments.  Specifically, if a user earns comment privileges on one sub-site, allow them to comment on all sub-sites, or at least a group of related sub-sites (e.g. computing).  I believe that transferable comment privileges would probably increase quality.  This is speaking from personal experience based on the number of times I would have left a helpful comment but just ended up closing the tab instead.

I would have been able to post this as a comment on the question I linked if you had considered my network reputation.  But then, I wouldn't have needed to post this as a comment.

**Edit:**

Per the comments, this solution is already implemented as the association bonus.  It sounds fine to me.

If when I had tried to comment on the other answer the denial message had told me about the association bonus, I would not have written this answer.

**Revised solution: advertise the association bonus when blocking actions where having the bonus would make a difference**

For example, instead of "You must have [5 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) to comment", Meta could tell me "You must have [5 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) on Meta to comment, or [200 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work) on any other Stack Exchange site".

Comment: This exists, but you need to reach 200 rep on one site. The you earn the "[association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)" and are awarded 100 rep on every site.

Comment: Speaking of what Laurel said, you're *very* close to the association bonus privilege on Stack Overflow. A couple of answers/edits separate you and the ability to comment on every site, so don't get too discouraged!

Comment: Oh!  Thanks!  I suppose it might be helpful to advertise this bonus to users when blocking actions.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how much you've looked into the question of culture and internationalisation? Because from my perspective, the whole points system feels very American. Here in the UK, small children were awarded gold stars and other such badges for effort and achievement, but we were expected to grow out of that, and as we became older, to value things such as knowledge sharing for their own sake. I still feel that when SO gives me points and badges, they are treating me like a child.

Comment: While I understand the sentiment, this doesn't seem constructive or actionable.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I guess the action would be to abolish reputation. What is missing is an alternative way of distributing privileges. Maybe Michael Key wants all users to be able to close vote? Because they are so mature, maybe.

Comment: I agree. In my answer, I mentioned that I don't care about what my actual rep number is... I just want to earn the privs to contribute where I think I'm useful. Long ago, I think the idea was the number might be useful to an external audience, like in interviews and linked in (Joel or Jeff said that in a podcast once). But I'm earning rep for interviews, or for comparing myself to anyone else in the community.

Comment: @benc: Do you mean *"...I'm* ***not*** *earning rep..."*? (You can repost and flag this for deletion.)

Comment: The actionable part would be to make a conscious effort to make the decision making less US-centric.

Comment: Another actionable part would be to cut out the badges, which are probably the most childish part of the system, and to de-emphasise reputation points so they aren't displayed with every post.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum - thanks for catching my typo.... To clarify: I just want the privs, I have no interest in increasing myself score for any other reason.

Comment: I think the idea of making the reputation system less US-centric should be further developed to make it more visible. Still, I think a large part of the user base has a US-centric bias for different reasons (origin, education, etc.), so it won't be easy to get overwhelming support (many upvotes). On the other hand, one of the core principles is that the platform should be open to anyone. In some way, it should be able to handle people at different stages of human development. It's a big challenge to achieve a good balance between skills and merits.

Answer (score -1):

> What is really great about our reputation & privilege system? What do you think makes it great, and why is it worth keeping?

One thing is that users get the [same amount of rep](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) for each upvote, regardless of whether it is a question or an answer (+10).
This encourages people to post more questions to contribute to both the Q&A database more quickly because the answers will not appear if there are no questions.

> What is broken about it, and why? Are there any solutions to it?

Same as above. Making the same worth of each vote clears the difference between a good answerer and a good questioner. Before that, only looking at the user rep amount was the indicator of power of knowledge for this user on the site. But not anymore. Just look at me, for instance: I mostly ask questions, but rarely give answers. And this leads us to another problem...

... many answers that I posted here were actually not answers, but the posts posted on the answer sections since the OP (staff) asked to post in the answer section just for the case of not creating many other related questions on the newly announced feature on site. Here are examples:

- [Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/339911)
- [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/339911)
- [New post summary designs on site home pages and greatest hits now; everywhere else eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/339911)
- [Tag synonym dashboard 2.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329687/339911)

and so on.

Despite the fact that the number of reputation gained per vote is the same for a question and for an answer, only answer votes contribute towards gold tag badges (that helps close/reopen questions without other user votes). I think that posting good questions should give users a similar ability.

The rest of the issues are related to Meta sites:

- On MSE some questions (mostly tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)) can be answered only by developers (staff), so the only restricted kind of users may actually answer. Mostly, but not always, since some bugs can be resolved in case of a workaround, or the answer may contain the possible solution that can be nevertheless only implemented by developers.
- There is no ability to make a bounty on per-site metas, so there's no regular way to raise additional attention to a question rather than bumping it with meaningless edits.  Here's a feature request for this issue, but on ruSO.meta: [Конкурсный вопрос на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4271/176217)

> What other systems work really well that we could learn from?

IDK, I mostly use only SE now. Unfortunately :)

Comment: _"The same amount of reps for each vote independently is that an answer or a question."_ I may be an idiot, but what does that mean?

Comment: @Heartspring-CDR initially there was +5 rep for upvote on Q, and +10 on A. Now this is the same +10 for any. [Link](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) added to the post.

Comment: I don’t think Meta SE provides good evidence on what works and doesn’t work in terms of reputation on regular sites.

Answer (score -1):

**What's broken 1**: not everything is Stack Overflow / Mathematics. Privileges and voting rights are much harder to gain on some networks. I know many on [DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) who are qualified to close vote, but can't.

**What's broken 2**: `1`-rep can't vote. Some users, especially experts, have nothing to ask or don't wish to participate in Q&A's - yet their votes remain valuable. "Non-participants shouldn't get to vote" - it takes 3 upvotes on a question to change this; good as nothing.

Two in one post because they're related, and emphasis on "not all is SO".

**Solution 1**: allow sites to decide their own privilege thresholds.

**Solution 2**: a verification system that addresses the abuse concerns of letting any new account vote. Phone + e-mail, mod review, are examples.

Comment: It may be a coincidence, but the amount of reputation required to upvote is just enough to prevent a lot of abuse, since it takes 2 upvotes to get, or one accept vote on an answer that doesn't later receive any downvotes. (This "it takes 3 upvotes on a question" is over three years out of date at this point.) Verification sounds like it won't work well (who does it, mods?). Adjusting the privilege thresholds has been talked about recently as an option, though I don't know of any sites that have done it except for small things like posting on meta.

Comment: _"who does it, mods?"_ on some networks yes, it's feasible. Networks could elect whether to allow it at all. I agree it's not great, but think it's a net-improvement. If it's about spam accounts, maybe phone + e-mail solves it. @Laurel

Comment: DSP.SE has a unique problem though. Regulars there just don’t vote on each other’s answers. I wrote about this a while back on the site’s meta: https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1593/33605

Comment: @CrisLuengo It's more about sheer size though, SO is at least x100 bigger in active users and questions, makes no sense for DSP (or any other small network) to share its criteria.

Comment: That is fair. But if people were to vote more, there’d be less of a problem with privileges.

Comment: I feel like this is a under-simplification.  If the experts want to participate on the site, then they should...wait for it...participate on the site.  But their day-to-day job and expertise aren't married to this *one* network on the internet, and they do quite well for themselves without *having* to be here.

Comment: Sounds like DSP.SE should just go back to the privilege system originally designed/intended for beta sites... This isn't an issue with the reputation system. This is merely an issue with the levels. I agree that what levels make sense for SO are not the same levels that make sense for all sites, regardless of size. That much is obvious. On the other hand, allowing anyone who joins to upvote is just a complete non-starter. *Way* too much abuse. Even on a small site. This may not be obvious to anyone who has not held moderator privileges, but it's a *huge* issue. We *need* *some* barrier.

Comment: @CodyGray +1 but, I'm not saying "just anyone". The current system _is_ a verification system, with verification being votes - I'm just saying it could be something else that doesn't require making a post. It's fair to say "burdens mods too much", but maybe let's explore the options first. I've received strong positive feedback on some of my DSP.SE posts from those who couldn't vote, it's a shame to not have this reflected in votes - and from scientific POV, a barrier that skews evaluation of "subjective" topics toward the site's regulars.

Comment: @Makoto Said experts, or whoever, could also just post once and never again, then come back 5 years later and vote on everything. Most such arguments against my proposal can also turn on the _current_ system.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon:  I don't see how that's a *problem*?  If someone who's earned privileged five years ago decides to exercise them now, what's the issue?

Comment: @Makoto I'm saying that one-time post is as good as nothing, on basis of merit. Asking "can rainbows be circles" doesn't qualify one to vote on string theory. It doesn't have to be a stupid example, point is there's plethora ways to get 2 votes with basically zero understanding of or interest in StackExchange. It _is_ an effective effort barrier, that's all.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon:  You're *desperately* clutching for straws here.  Being able to vote on a specific topic and having access to expanded voting/editing privileges are completely orthogonal to each other.  Being an expert in a topic and wanting to participate on Stack Exchange are also likewise orthogonal. I'm just not sure what point you're trying to make here.

Comment: As a note about DSP's situation in particular, there are some relevant site settings that the CMs can customize if needed, e.g. to lower the close vote threshold or to lower the reputation requirement for individual privileges. If the mods of that site feel that this may be warranted, they can have a discussion about the problem with their community, then escalate a request to the CMs to make such a change if the community isn't able to solve the problem on their own (or they can reach out to us via chat/the Contact form if they're not sure which changes are possible or should be requested).

Comment: @V2Blast Good to know, thanks!

Comment: staaaaaaaaahhhhhp the push for more verification.  That's a terrible trend.

Answer (score -1):

One thing that I do not find that is working right is that there is any rep gained from making trivial, meaningless edits to posts. Like changing `SQLServer` to `SqlServer` or `its` to `it's`.  It is a cheap way for some to get an extra 1K rep, because aside from me, how many others are really going to reject that edit?

If someone wants to spend their free time fixing contractions that are missing apostrophes or casing for products to match a brand name (which are things that a script or bot could fix), by all means let them waste their time, but dont reward them for the kind of activity that is supposed to be [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Comment: Related discussions: [1](/q/102228/997587), [2](/q/82865/997587), and [1](/q/149722/997587), [2](/q/239106/997587), [3](/q/142780/997587), [4](/q/121454/997587), [5](/q/193485/997587), [6](/q/107524/997587), [7](/q/82893/997587), [8](/q/116656/997587), [9](/q/74430/997587), [10](/q/112275/997587), [11](/q/78288/997587).

Comment: Then, what we need is reputation loss for accepting bad edits.

Comment: Or to programmatically eliminate the need for these trivial edits.

Comment: The only real reason for discouraging trivial edits is the pressure they place on the review queue. The queue design is the problem here. Currently we get asked to reject edits even though they unambiguously make the site better than it was before. The bigger problem is that we *don't* reward people who make good edits unilaterally (i.e. above the 2k rep threshold).

Comment: It would be good to look for new solutions for the trivial edit rules. Things I want to edit are often in bad shape because only a couple characters makes it pretty terrible content. So, I end up having to spend 50% of my time trying to layer in enough changes to justify the fix I'm trying to provide. So, I agree with the editor queue constraints (I'm hoping to earn that this year), but also, maybe have little events to clean up little junk, etc. so we get better content, but without making the rep. incentives worse.

Comment: @user253751 how would the system pick out specific edits as bad _without_ human oversight? if could already do that, we wouldn't have the edit review system. Are you suggesting we have a review queue to review reviewers?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I agree with the first part of what you said but not the second part. I just enjoy having full edit privileges, I don't particularly need or want rep for edits once I have full edit privileges.

Comment: @starball based on human reviewers, of course. Or flags.

Comment: _The only real reason for discouraging trivial edits is the pressure they place on the review queue._  @KarlKnechtel I'm sure you know there are other reasons. After taking the time to craft a question or answer, often rewriting it to try and ensure the idea is being communicated the way I intended it to be, I find it infuriating to have someone swoop in to make trivial edits that do not improve the conveyance of that idea.  Sometimes it gets uncomfortable when the same person does edits like that to several of my posts .

Comment: I don't "know" this, because the situation you describe honestly sounds like a personal pet peeve and not something that would bother me. If the edits are truly "trivial", then I struggle to fathom how they can also be interfering with "communicat[ing the idea] the way I intended [to]".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I've seen edits that change the 'style' rather than content. e.g. can't -> cannot. They're trivial but can also make it feel like you've lost agency on your text

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - I wouldn't have known the review queue pressure to be a reason for discouraging trivial edits, but I knew there were reasons other then the ones that immediately came to my mind. This is what I meant by you knowing that there were other reasons.   Just because something may not bother you does not mean the same is true for others. The thing you are referring to as a pet peeve is what I would refer to as "Freedom of Speech or Freedom of Expression"

Comment: Strange, I would have thought that editing is as much a question of freedom of speech as providing the original material is. It's not as if the people rephrasing your ideas are trying to censor you. The community looks down on that kind of thing, very strongly. They usually can't even get away with fixing things that are factually incorrect unless they look like typos.

Comment: Changing someone else's words and/or message is the very nature of censorship. There are many laws that exist in both of our countries to protect original works (US BoR, CAN Charter, copyright, etc.). If the editor had built upon the OP's idea to present their own idea or point of view, that would be acceptable and is encouraged and an example of someone exercising FoS/FoE. Typographical corrections do not constitute novel FoS/FoE, and I do not consider them to be a valuable human activity when a program can do the same.

Answer (score -1):

## What is broken about it, and why?

Sometimes bounties are used to "buy" a working piece of code to copy and paste, which rewards answers that simply do the homework for the original poster and discourages users who do the effort to provide a well-explained solution.

Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75688226/440172):

- The OP is stuck on a set of issues, but is aware and directly asking about the major one (involving `viewBox`).
- I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75738957/440172) explaining why the problem occurs, presenting the principles that the OP needs to understand, and including a code snippet that fixes the main issue. I also recommended some improvements to address the minor issues.
- The day after, another user posted a [a new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75740690/440172) expanding on my code snippet to fix the residual issues and received the bounty.

This is not the first time I have seen this attitude in bountied questions, and it is really frustrating for genuine users who consider Stack Overflow a place where developers should look for help to learn how to fix their code
insted of just getting their homework done.

## Are there any solutions to it?

It may be useful to engage the community in the decision about who should receive the bounty. This would help ensure that the bounty goes to the answer that provides the best explanation and solution to the problem, rather than the one that just provides a fix.

Comment: while I like the idea of getting askers to do their homework and read and learn underlying principles, Stack Exchange is... kind of here to "do peoples' homework", and I think it's by design- or at least shouldn't be surprising- that answers which do that get more upvotes. You could have given explanation of underlying principles _and_ given them the final solution. Admittedly, I'd be irked too if what happened to you happened to me.

Comment: the bounty's rep is **the bounty placer's rep**- not the community's. I don't see why the decision of where that rep should go should be decided in a different way than it already is: the decision is the bounty placer's **only** unless they abstain, in which case the community vote _can_ lead to rewarding half the bounty amount. [/help/bounty](/help/bounty)

Comment: Admittedly my solution is not well thought. What I would like is a mean to discourage users being disrespectful of other people's time and willingness to provide quality answers. I understand this is quite tricky to achieve. Thanks for your attention anyways!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm late, but I just read some answers and I didn't see an important point: **Reward for reviews**.

On Stack Overflow, **I made over 13k reviews and the only things I received was badges**. It's cool to have more gold badges than most of people with 3k rep, but if at a time I stopped, it would also be because of the lack of reward.

### Making review takes time

**Making reviews isn't a job, but it takes a lot of time as a job**. Even while being quick, it can take 45 minutes - 1 hour to complete 40 reviews in the same queue. That's long, and after coming back for 25 days and making 40 reviews for each days, you earn one badge. 50 days for normal queue.

### People wants, or not

*I will take me as an example, but maybe I'm not representative of people*

When just reach reputation to be able to review, we made some of them as we feel useful for the website. *We will not talk about [the issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411502/10952503)*. But after a few times, when realizing you just pass 1 hour to do them, or just when you receive the silver badge, you are more able to stop review.

Adding a reward **will encourage people to review**. A few reputation points will give a good reason for some people to do more reviews than now.

### Review are necessary

If no one makes reviews, SE will stop working: question will not so much be closed, beginners not helped, etc. It's required to be sure this part of the system works. And always keep more than 1k post waiting for review on Close Vote is -for me- not a good thing. By giving an advantage, it will help people participate and so, make the system safer.

### Robot and farming

As told in comment, as I quickly think about this, it's possible some people try to farm reputation. To prevent this, there are multiple ways:

- Cap reputation to not so high value. Robot will reach the cap every time and not so much get rep.
- Fix the review audits by better selecting them, make them less obvious, etc.
- Check for others things: time of vote, which one is chosen, the "agreement percent" (if the person always choose something different than the final solution)
- Let moderators more check for recurrent people. For example, people like me will be more able to be checked for bot than people that just do 5 reviews
- Be rude when seeing a bot to discourage this

Another way is to ask for moderators or very high reputation people (100k & more) to check like one time each month if people could get reputation, a sort of checking for reality of people. It will add a new step, but could fix this issue too.

Also, personally, while the bot is doing good review, it's not an issue. I'm sure review could be partially automated. I already  [proposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413441/10952503) (10k+ link) to add automatic management for some post. So, even if I understand the issue, if it's good review, it's not an issue.

### The actual reward

It's only one bronze, one silver and then a gold badge per 1000 reputations. I also reached TOP 1 of reviewers all time on [First question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/stats) (yes, let me flex :p) and I didn't received anything, just the satisfaction to be first on something that help the community.

### Reward advantages

The objective is not to give like 5rep/review, but one of those:

1. **Like 1 rep per review given each days**, capped to 25. If not capped, it could be "too easy" like just spam in all review queue and in one day you reach next privilege.
2. **Review given for each gold badge obtain**. It's easier to make 0.5rep/review for example, and add "step"
3. **Each days, when a review queue is complete** (40/40, 20/20...), you obtain some. It will help people to do all review for one queue, and not necessarily to wait until 1000 review (which is big)

Failing review audit could cancel reputation gain for today or something.

As I told, maybe it's possible to give special reward at 10k review, 100k review, for TOP 1 of month or something. Always give more reason to people to participate, and reward them for their efforts.

### Notes

- It will also help people that doesn't answer/doesn't receive upvote but participate.
- Some mod that comes from another website could get reputation everywhere (and will not be mod with 200 rep :p).
- I totally agree with most of others posts, so I didn't repeat what they explained as not capped post, rep on closed post etc.
- I'm happy to make all of my reviews, but the lack of reward (and sometimes lack of adding feature) make it sad.

Comment: while I also wish I could get rep for doing reviews, I don't think it would be beneficial for the ecosystem. We already have problems with robo-reviewers who want badges. It'll be so much worse with robo-reviewers trying to get rep. Unfortunately, humans.

Comment: @starball I understand. I just add a paragraph for it in my answer. If the only problem is robot-review, I don't think it's a problem as I never see a robot, even for farming badge and as I rarely see people with lot of review on stats. So they seems very discreet xd

Comment: You don't see robo-reviewers because you're not looking for them (and you don't have [the reputation level to see other peoples' reviews very easily](/help/privileges/moderator-tools)). Related: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208985/bad-stack-overflow-reviews

Comment: @Elikill58 robo reviewers are people who mindlessly click OK to every review, likely just to get a badge as quickly as possible. They make designing an effective review system quite difficult. They exist in significant numbers unfortunately.

Comment: @RobertLongson they will be detected with reviews. Also, that's why I reported some issue with review on SO about validating review without doing anything

Answer (score -2):

This is a Stack Overflow-centric answer:

SO wants more user participation, especially new users.
The ability to gain reputation encourages participation.

New users are frustrated with both the inability to gain rep and the ability to get questions answered.  Old users are frustrated with trivial, duplicate, and too-specific questions.

Let's provide a way to gain rep by ensuring questions are answered, not destroyed.
What if there was an **Stack Overflow Overflow** (SOO) site where vote-to-close questions got routed?

That site would allow more conversational interactions geared at ensuring that the question was answered. Answers could provide tips on refining and generalizing the question, explain why a duplicate applies, even help with debugging.  Useful tips gain upvotes, as do well formed questions.  If a question reaches an upvote threshold, it can get migrated back to the main site, and the SOO contributors to it would gain rep on SO in proportion to their contribution.

Comment: There is work ongoing to make Staging Ground. This will be something like you describe. Questions will be vetted before being publicly posted.

Comment: (The site name should be chosen so it is possible to separate the two when using a search engine.)

Comment: "SO wants more user participation, especially new users." - no, no it definitely does not. SO would be better off if it had 2m unclosed questions rather than 23m. (Compare that to ~7m articles on Wikipedia, where the scope is "literally anything" rather than "writing computer programs".) What SO wants is *positive engagement with* new users - which entails new users taking the time to understand how the site works, learning from their mistakes, and ultimately making more contributions per user.

Comment: "The ability to gain reputation encourages participation." - in point of fact, only about a quarter of Stack Overflow accounts have any asked questions at all, and about half of those have only one. It seems like tons of people are happy to sign up for an account just to bypass the splash page and have a "watched tags" list.

Answer (score -5):

I don't find the reputation system to be broken, in need of repair, or a hindrance to the function of the site or community.

I don't see sufficient evidence that the reputation system is in any way associated with barriers to entry, or even that barriers exist outside of the requirement for knowledge or experience.

If I had to make one suggestion, it would be privilege related. In order to keep users involved in the site, and up to date with the current outlook on tooling such as moderation tools, it probably makes sense to associate privileges not with long term totals, but near term totals.

In other words, tie site privileges to a time frame, for example, 2 years. This means, if in the past two years, you haven't earned 10k rep, you don't get access to deleted posts. This will be a strong incentive for users to remain relevant with their activity levels.

After all, these systems are designed in part to encourage participation by rewarding it. Positive reinforcement is important.

Comment: Not that it's likely to happen to me personally, but if I came back after a long hiatus to find I'd lost half of what I'd worked for, I'd be *far* less inclined to want to work for it all over again, I'd be more likely to consider I'd managed without it thus far, bye again.

Comment: @Tetsujin - The reputation would remain, just the access to privilege would cycle. Honestly, do we want people who took a multi year, or 5 year break, coming back and immediately making changes? It makes more sense to ease back in. Moreover, the system was never designed in a way that people could take 10 years to unlock features. It was designed to allow users who were considered to be trusted to have access to community moderation features and other higher end features. Reputation inflation is easily countered by this sliding window.

Comment: I cannot agree, on many levels. My best site, where I'm >100k & 3rd top scorer of all time, I only made 1700 rep so far this year [5th]. At that rate, few others would keep their privileges year on year. At the opposite end, a quiet site i'm a frequent participator, the traffic is too low for me to ever realistically hit 10k. I already find it irritating enough that there are many things on that stack I can't see or do, as I'm so used to the privilege on many other stacks. I honestly have no real interest in an actual score to wave at people.

Comment: @Tetsujin - To your point on lower activity exchanges, I completely agree. The sliding window would mostly be useful in areas where actual inflation over time existed, and the smaller exchanges don't really suffer from that. My vast experience here comes from using Stack Overflow, and that is what I am mostly speaking to here.

Comment: I'm afraid SO is the one bit of SE that's zero use to me. May as well be written in Martian ;)

Comment: this doesn't seem to work as an incentive tbh. How many people go "hoo boy! I get to see deleted posts! This is so exciting!"? Not that many, I'd wager. How many people put in extra effort to post answers so they can see deleted posts? Probably even less. If anything, some of the moderation responsibilities (like dupe-hammer) are like a small burden. However, may I offer a variation... the number displayed next to someone's name should be a near-term number...

Comment: @user253751 - The deleted post point was just an example of one of the higher end privileges. For example, if you hadn't earned any reputation in 2 years, it may be possible you need to earn 50 again to comment. This reduces things like trolling while at the same time encouraging participation for relevance. Closures, for example, would also be limited to those who were actively participating, and considering the amount of changes the system has gone through over the years, it makes sense to try to have users of that system aware of recent guidance and configuration. I could go on...

Comment: The reputation leagues offer near term reputation numbers. However, reputation is generally reflective of total votes on posts, and unless you intend to simply remove votes from posts, I am not sure how it would make sense to remove reputation displays. To be honest, that is rather tangential to this discussion, and in my opinion going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score -8):

Comments from the peanut gallery:

I recently came to the conclusion that "in order to participate in Stack Exchange, you need 3000 reputation". Your input before 3000 reputation really doesn't count, and it's because only at 3k do you get a say in close votes.

I think close votes are the least friendly, most contentious thing Stack Exchange does. I actually think that high rep people are more inclined to vote to close than to downvote. Downvote lumps their opinion in with the riff-raff but VTC elevates their voice to a level most users can't match. It's basically a "super-downvote". I have had high rep users berate me by saying they have more rep than me and therefore their opinions matter more, which to me says they are unlikely to ever downvote and indeed I don't think they do -- questions will have 0 votes but be closed, meaning 5 high rep people voted to close it but did not bother to downvote.

To be sure, "community moderation" is dangerous no matter how you slice it. Relying entirely on up/down votes could wreck the focus of a site, as something that's clearly off-topic (but, perhaps, funny) gets upvoted when it should be closed. But on the other hand, allowing 5 people to close something because *they didn't like it*, leads to absurdity too. It's a good question, it has 5 good answers, it's popular, it has 30 upvotes, and it's closed because 5 people said so. Then you have to vote to reopen and it just gets more absurd from there.

So this creates "reputation pressure". Get to 3k or your opinion doesn't matter.

I'm not totally sure what the solution is. Moderation-through-reputation is risky, and it's more risky when it allows a very small group of people to ignore the wider community. Upvotes and downvotes should have stronger influence on close/reopen than they currently do (which is "no influence at all").

I just think **we need to look for a balance between "community input" and "the close cabal"**.

Comment: "Upvotes and downvotes should have stronger influence on close/reopen than they currently do (which is "no influence at all")." They have some influence. Downvoted and negatively scoring content gets automatically deleted after some time and that is quite a significant chunk while upvoted content has a much higher chance of not getting closed. For that reason I often upvote and reopen vote in those cases I think it's rewarded. I understand what you're saying in this answer but it doesn't convince me that everyone being able to close vote would lead to a better outcome.

Comment: "_allowing 5 people to close something because they didn't like it,_" this should not be a thing. "I don't like this" is not a valid close reason. It can be a downvote reason.

Comment: "_"in order to participate in Stack Exchange, you need 3000 reputation". Your input before 3000 reputation really doesn't count, and it's because only at 3k do you get a say in close votes._" flagging is one of the earliest privileges.

Comment: @starball Moderators don't need to be hassled with hundreds of flags. We have the up/down votes for a reason. But at 3k rep, the up/down votes no longer matter. You just vote to close anything you think needs a downvote. And you need 3k rep to have any voice in that game. And yes, VTC for not liking it should not be a thing, but I have seen it many, many times on Worldbuilding. The rules are loose, the interpretation is looser, and some catch-all VTC reasons have gotten rather out of control. Again, it only need 5 votes, out of thousands of viewers, to close a question.

Comment: @nij Close votes are, unfortunately, also prime for trolling. I love that you are optimistic enough to believe that 3k rep is enough to filter out the trolls, but I'm here to tell you that this is not so. Perhaps more sadly, they really do think they are "helping". I have seen high rep people beat askers to death with the rulebook -- or their personal interpretation of it -- and close votes are way more power than they deserve or have earned.

Comment: @Trilarion For sure I don't think everyone should be able to vote to close! Perhaps closer to the opposite. Or perhaps the numbers of votes required to close a question should vary based on upvotes and answers. On worldbuilding in particular, I have seen 5 people vote to close a question that was even answered by a moderator. The disconnect between the community and the, as I call them, "close cabal" is very visible, and in my opinion shows exactly how the reputation system has gone off the rails.

Comment: @nij I would like to see more people participate in metas, as a general thing, and think that could fix a lot. But I don't know how to promote that, myself. As it stands, the people effectively trolling the system with close votes also tend to be over-represented in the meta. The rank and file simply do not participate (if they even know meta exists). Stack Exchange basically is the free-for-all of reddit, except worse: the people in charge of closing content have nominated themselves for the job. I rarely have issues with moderators, but frequently have issues with the "vote-to-close cabal".

Comment: the answer to actual incorrect close-vote trolling is... mod flagging.

Comment: "_Moderators don't need to be hassled with hundreds of flags_" close-reason flags go to close-vote queues (which are visible to people with the close vote privilege, which shouldn't be a problem if the system isn't overrun with trolls)- not to diamond mods. And even if the system is overrun with trolls, the answer is mod flagging (and then suspensions where appropriate).

Comment: @starball That's good to know, actually, but also highlights what I perceive to be the problem: anyone can flag, but only 3k rep people can do anything with it. Worse, there is no "reopen" flag, so we're better at shutting off content than we are at opening it back up. You also can't participate in the "looks good, keep open" game until 3k rep. 3k rep is basically where your opinion starts to matter. (I'm not pushing to raise or lower this bounds,. I think the whole concept needs rethinking.)

Comment: As a high-rep user (on my 'home' site) I prefer to vote to close instead of downvoting, because I actually think voting to close is friendlier than downvoting. Closing doesn't cost reputation for the asker, it provides actionable feedback (which downvotes don't do) or actually answers the question in case of duplicates, and it is reversible by myself or others if the question improves. And, most importantly, it helps (a bit) to keep the remaining questions focused, clear and on-topic, which benefits the asker too when they continue to use the site.

Comment: Regarding "high rep users berate me by saying they have more rep than me and therefore their opinions matter more": it is usually not the argument that "high rep opinions matter more", but that high-rep users know better how the site (and Q&A in general) works, and therefore it is often simply the case that they are (objectively) right and a low-rep/new user is wrong when it comes to on-topicness, clarity, and what efforts are expected from questioners and answerers. It is still an argument from authority and therefore better avoided, but that does not make it any less true in many cases.

Comment: @Marijn That is indeed the basis of the "argument from authority" fallacy -- even if the high rep user is right, "high rep" is not the actual reason why they are right. The reason may be that the question is off-topic or violates some other rule. There are times, though, where high-reps clash with the rest of the community, firmly believing that their rep elevates their rule interpretations over other people's (and we do have a few really subjective rules). In those cases, we have simply reopened questions but reopening is harder than closing, due to reduced visibility in closed topics.

Comment: @Marijn As for VTC vs downvote, I'd reconsider. People are used to downvotes, as a common phenonea on other sites. It should mean "I dislike this or it's not well worded". VTC should be "this is a flagrant violation of the rules or is an unneeded duplicate". Taking the time to write content and then have it deleted or closed is far more discouraging to users than a downvote.

Comment: I struggle to understand the logic here. Currently, relatively few people can do the thing that you find "unfriendly, contentious"  thing you're complaining about, because of that reputation threshold. No amount of reputation allows you to *prevent others* from voting to close a question, and you can only vote to reopen something *after it has been closed*. That said, I agree that it's very discouraging to write an answer only to have the question closed. That's why people should read the how-to-answer help page, learn to recognize questions that should be closed, and stop answering them.

Comment: Aside from that, my experience has been that votes to close are overwhelmingly correctly cast; if anything we're far too conservative with them on Stack Overflow; and that objections to question closure overwhelmingly come from people who *fundamentally want the site to work differently from how it does and was always designed and intended to work*. Stack Exchange network sites, particularly Stack Overflow, are **not discussion fora**; we have strict requirements for questions, because they primarily exist **for search engine users, not just OP** (who is *greatly outnumbered*).

Comment: "I actually think that high rep people are more inclined to vote to close than to downvote." Yes; I find downvotes on questions to be mostly redundant with the closure reasons, and that the idea of keeping around a question that has been voted to -3 is fundamentally incompatible with the vision of "a library of detailed, high-quality answers" (as it's put in the Stack Overflow tour). There's also the part where closing questions prevents people from answering them (such answers encourage more bad questions, clutter the site in and of themselves, and interfere with the Roomba). Win-win.

Comment: "To be sure, "community moderation" is dangerous no matter how you slice it." I agree. For example, sometimes it leads to blatantly unsuitable questions getting 30 upvotes and 5 answers, and people screaming on Meta about how popular questions should inherently be allowed to remain regardless of how clear the closure reasons are. **Even Reddit** eventually determined that "let the votes decide" just doesn't work 100% of the time. That's how you get front pages full of memes and answers that reference and critique each other more than adding their own useful information.

Comment: "Moderators don't need to be hassled with hundreds of flags. We have the up/down votes for a reason. But at 3k rep, the up/down votes no longer matter. You just vote to close anything you think needs a downvote. And you need 3k rep to have any voice in that game." I think you missed the point: everyone who is entitled to vote up, is also entitled to flag questions, and for people without VTC the flag reasons include all of the VTC reasons.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel There is no "reopen" or "keep open" flag, so that just feeds my point: the system is skewed towards closing. I think VTC of downvoted questions is almost always on point, and VTC of upvoted questions *can* be on point, but frequently enough a well liked question getting VTC'd is the reputation system going off the rails, and 5 people choosing to override the community via their own personal interpretation, which just makes it more work for other people (including mods) to have to go back and fix it. Meanwhile, we probably ran a few more people off the site.

Comment: " the system is skewed towards closing." On the contrary, it is skewed towards questions being open - since they are by default, and action has to be taken to close them. This, in my experience, has had profound negative consequences for the overall quality of the site.

Comment: "frequently enough a well liked question getting VTC'd is the reputation system going off the rails, and 5 people choosing to override the community via their own personal interpretation" - my rebuttal is to consider [the actual cases where this happened most prominently on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3A1+score%3A500+duplicate%3A0): overwhelmingly, it's old questions that are clearly either too broad, opinion-based or not about programming (especially ones that should be on superuser instead).

Comment: (and if I lower the threshold to 50 and sort by newest, I get titles like "Are algorithms with high time complexity ever used in the real world for small inputs?", which - yeah, that's **clearly** not Stack Overflow material, and +73/-8 shows a clear disconnect within the community.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I feel like Stack Overflow is actually the outlier, though, with more problems that are unique to it (which, admittedly, other stacks would aspire to, if they could get that many active users). SO's problem is more people asking questions than interested people able to effectively moderate. In other stacks, it's the other way around, and reputation-based moderation powers easily trumps community input, even to the extent of trampling the community. That's really the issues I'm thinking of: stacks with a lot less users than SO (i.e. most of the rest of SE).

Comment: This is true and a problem that needs to be addressed (in my opinion, it doesn't deserve all these downvotes). Close votes shouldn't even *exist* in the first place. If you think a post should be closed, flag it. High-rep users aren't necessarily fairer then low-rep ones. Moderators should be the ones closing posts via responding to flags. They are elected and chosen by the community, they know all the rules, and almost all of them of them aren't trolls. I can't say the same about high-rep users knowing all the rules sometimes. To get a question closed, *flag it* and let a mod close it.

Answer (score -8):

> What's working?

While not great, it is a basic way to separate newbies from experienced people. It also separates spammers from good posters. It is also a way to allow more experienced and good posters to have more privileges. This allows the community (albeit only a subset of it) to run the site for the most part.

> What's not?

How long do you have?

First, rep is supposed to be about trust. Posting something with 1 upvote and 4 downvotes gains rep, but certainly loses trust.

Second, moderation should not be tied to rep (something gained from good questions/answers). They have little correlation.

Third, the idea that a high-rep user's opinion is worth more than a lower-rep user's. While we don't want this, it is in some ways true (low-rep users can't VTC and some can't downvote).

Finally, there are bounties. While definitely a good idea, I don't think they should really contribute to rep. After all, earning a 500 bounty means that the bounty giver liked your answer. Is that really the same as 50 upvotes? I don't think so.

> What should be fixed?

First, like I said, a separate moderation rep. Accepted flags would be worth 1. Declined flags are worth -1. At 10 mod rep you could use the queues. Voting correctly in them gains 1 mod rep, incorrectly takes 1 mod rep. At 25 mod rep you get access to mod tools. Correctly deleting  gets 1 mod rep, incorrectly takes 1 mod rep. Trusted user is at 50 mod rep. Finally, finding correct dupes gives 2 mod rep and incorrect takes 1 mod rep.

Second, upvotes and downvotes being equal. Each should require 125 reputation to do and each should gain/lose 10 rep. Otherwise a user can post nonsense. One person who has no idea what they are doing upvotes it. 4 others downvote it. That user gained rep, but I don't think that they gained any trust, they lost trust.

Third, lower thresholds for privileges. Do you really need 1,000 rep to see vote counts? No, probably not. I think that 200 is good for that, if not making it a 1 rep feature. Or 2,000 rep to edit without queues. No wonder there is always a backlog. How about after 10 edits or 1000 rep. 1,500 to create tags. I think the beta site requirement of 150 rep is far more reasonable. I could go on, but you get the point. These requirements are too high and too discouraging. This makes it so that low-rep users opinions are less heard.

Finally, lower how much bounties are worth. I have seen users whose nearly entire rep comes from one large bounty and yet have a bunch of privileges.

Comment: I think this is too focused on a specific design for one of the problems, and too lacking on details - I would be interested in seeing how you view the next couple layers of the proverbial iceberg, since I wrote an answer that seems to be in much the same spirit but with a lot more specific objections. I don't really get the downvotes, though - I think in broad strokes you have the right idea. Maybe people object to the notion that "newbies" ought to be "separated" along with the "spammers"?

Comment: _"How long do you have...this is just the tip of the iceberg."_ We have all day, show us the whole iceberg, and explain some stuff in more detail :)

Comment: I have @Heartspring-CDR

Answer (score -8):

What definitely is not working is that the only way for new users to get enough reputation to comment is through either posting or answering a question.
I'm now in the ridiculous position of trying to find a question I can answer on Stack Overflow or make up a fictitious problem and post it, in order to be able to reply to a solution someone else posted to someone else's question, a question that is the same issue that I am actually having.

Comment: If you don't understand an answer, ask a new question seeking an explanation of it, specifying exactly what and why you don't understand. No need to comment and you start earning rep if you do it well. On the other hand, complaining that we can't have nice things because we can't trust everybody all the time will get you nowhere.

Comment: @Nij the number of times I've seen a new user post "I can't comment on X, but I have  a similar question" and get absolutely ripped to shreds (for not commenting, despite not being able to or for asking a duplicate) is too damn high.

Comment: @Nij No StackExchange moderator policy is to not ask duplicate questions. They get swiftly removed. Instead you get asked to comment on the original question. Which it's not possilbe to do for a noob. Also I finally found a question I could answer and tried to post but was told only 1 post allowed in the last 30 min. Absolutely no clue what my other post was because I hadn't posted any other questions recently but just accepting the fact it's an authoritarian regime you can't argue with.

Comment: I agree that not being able to comment is often what prompts the use of the 'not an answer' flag and forces new users to post answers that are only tangentially relevant to the question. On the other hand, as the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) tells you, "_The three most important activities on Meta Stack Exchange are Asking, Answering and Editing - none of which require any reputation at all! Please try to get comfortable with those three activities before looking to expand your participation into other areas._"

Comment: Depending on why you need to comment under an answer, there are a few solutions: 1. Another person who _does_ have the commenting privilege could be having the same issue 2. Your confusion is enough to prompt you to ask a new question that links the other answer and asks for an explanation/clarification of it- make sure that it is still interesting, relevant, and on-topic, for it may be closed as too basic. Make it clear that it isn't a duplicate. 3. Finally, edit! It may seem like a long road to 50 rep with just edits, but there are tons of questions and answers that need improvement.

Comment: @heartspring 1&2: No asking a question that has already been asked incurs the wrath of StackExchange admins, I actually have a high reputation on my personal account so it's not like I'm not an experienced user. Asking similar sounding questions has resulted in mods making me feel like a petty criminal.  Anyway the point of the OPs post was to ask for feedback so I was just giving it. If the authorities in charge don't agree then that's up to them,

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.

Comment: 80-90% of suggested edits on Stack Overflow are nowhere near comprehensive (many are *only* inconsequential formatting changes, while leaving glaring problems untouched). Please don't be part of the 80-90%. Please make your suggestions ***comprehensive***.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Correcting substantial problems within a post (beyond typos, formatting, or simple grammar mistakes) often requires reading the poster’s mind, which is something only the poster is equipped to do. Presumably.

Comment: Further update. I tried to find a question I could answer. I found one but the user did not provide enough detail to identify the root cause so instead I wrote a helpful post about how they might want to try and debug it. Immediately - within a few mins, a mode posted "These are suggestions, and not a definitive answer to OP's issue. This discourse should be done in comments and chat until a solid solution is derived from the conversation". (which clearly I can't do without reputation). One tries to be helpful and one is made to feel like a petty criminal.

Comment: Oh and to add insult to injury they decided to vote down my answer so now my reputation level is back at 1.

Comment: "StackExchange moderator policy is to not ask duplicate questions. They get swiftly removed." - **no**; they get **closed** and linked back to the original, and then you **can** (regardless of reputation) comment on your **own** question,and usually the person who closes the question will be happy to add some clarification. I have even in these cases gone and added my own answer to the duplicate, offered a bounty for a new answer, or edited existing answers for clarity. By the way, the people you are talking about are **not moderators**. I am not a moderator.

Comment: " I actually have a high reputation on my personal account so it's not like I'm not an experienced user." - then *why not use that account to comment*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Because I'm trying to build up my work account so that I'm not having to constantly swap  profiles just to interact with Stack Overflow.

Comment: "I found one but the user did not provide enough detail to identify the root cause so instead I wrote a helpful post about how they might want to try and debug it." You are not supposed to do that. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. And again, you keep speaking of "mods" and "admins" who are **perfectly ordinary members of the community** (although some of them have a bit more reputation than others, sure). Mods are elected, and there are [27 of them on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) out of 23 million accounts. "Admin" isn't a thing.

Comment: "Because I'm trying to build up my work account so that I'm not having to constantly swap profiles" - there is [no sense of urgency](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569) here. My best advice is to make a note and comment when you get home.

Comment: Aside from all of that: if you need a clarification of an existing answer, there are multiple possibilities: 1) it is fundamentally unclear, and someone else will comment or edit eventually. 2) The misunderstanding is personal, and it has to do with some tangential aspect of the answer - e.g., it's showing how to solve a problem, and the example code uses some idiom on one line, and you don't understand the idiom. Then you don't actually have a duplicate question, you have a question about that other aspect - although it is likely a duplicate of a *different* existing question.

Comment: (con't.) 3) the misunderstanding is personal, but it's still fundamentally about the overall problem and the approach described in the answer. We probably can't help with that, because there's no good way for us to understand **why** you don't understand an answer that other readers do understand. If we were to pretend your question weren't a duplicate, and try to answer it normally, we'd *just give the same answer* (or a substantially similar answer) and you'd be no better off than before.

Comment: I used to think that "just throw multiple rephrasings at the wall and see what sticks" is a valid strategy for communicating with programming students who aren't understanding the first explanation of some concept. But after years of talking about and teaching programming, I've come to disagree with that. The problem is generally either caused by some *prior* misconception or knowledge gap, or else can only be solved *by the student's own initiative*. Posting multiple explanations is just a hack to make the student read the explanation multiple times and think more about the problem.

Comment: 1. @KarlKnechtel I never said it was urgent. I said its impratical to use SO during the day and finding I have to keep switching over to my personal account to interact with it. When I get home I won't be thinking about coding matters. It's a matter of user experience not urgency.

Comment: 2. Sorry yes I mean't closed when i said removed. Usually they downvote and then close it. So you lose reputation for having asked a duplicate question which is where my comment about being made to feel like a petty criminal comes from.

Comment: 3. Back to the original point-Is the Reputation system working? To summarize my view, this is the experience of new users trying to get reputation: 
a) Answer a new question: A difficult route as new questions tend to be more uncommon / challenging ones to answer. Common questions have been asked elsewhere and so they get closed
b)Create a new question: But make sure it's not a duplicate as you'll be downvoted and closed
c) Answer an existing question: But make sure it's a proper answer not just helpful tips as you'll be downvoted

Anyway this is the last I'm going to say on the matter.

Comment: I may have to delete this entire post too - everytime someone downvotes me it harms my reputation. Therefore this is not a space for me to mention these matters.

Comment: That is not the case; Meta sites are specifically exempt from those reputation penalties for that exact reason.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Not the central Meta, though.

Comment: @user3840170 sure, but at least that still only applies to reputation *on meta.SE itself*. (And AFAIK, deletion won't change that, it will only evade future votes.)

Answer (score -9):

I think there are already a lot of other good answers, but I did want to contribute one idea that might be a good augmentation on them (and I don't think I saw as I skimmed through them). Overall, we see a lot of issues that seem to stem from fastest to answer gets the most points. We see issues where folks are answering questions that should have been closed.

I would recommend a simple solution, which is that any answers posted within the first 24 hours of a question being posted are held in queue until after 24 hours has past. At that time, everything in queue will get posted simultaneously. While a question is in queue, the respondent can edit all they want as well but those edits won't be tracked.

If the question is closed, all queued answers are *not* posted. If the question is re-opened, the respondents will need to manually approve the posting of their answers because they might've assumed something that's now erroneous in the revised question.

This timing restriction wouldn't apply to any answers on old questions, so if you find something from a year ago that you can meaningfully contribute to, your answer will post immediately.

Comment: won't that mean that new simple questions will suddenly get lots of identical answers after 24 hours. That's not useful surely. Now an answerer can see that someone's answered the question with something pretty much the same as they were going to write and therefore avoid simply writing the same thing again.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not sure how the answers might be presented when initially posted, perhaps randomly. But if that's the case, then you'd see a lot of answers coming to the same conclusion, which means that it's probably the right conclusion. Given it's a simple answer, the vote distribution may be spread out across those randomly posted answers thereby minimizing excessive rep gain by fast answers on easy questions.

Comment: you want to make every Stack Exchange question asker in the world wait a minimum of 1 hour to receive any answers?

Comment: If someone's going to write an identical answer to one that's already been written that's a waste of their time, we'd be better off if they looked at a different unanswered question and answered that instead.

Comment: This doesn't really have a lot to do with *reputation*, earning *reputation* or losing *reputation*, does it?  This is just about asking and answering questions.  (There is more to say about adding yet another queue for this kind of activity but both are orthogonal anyway.)

Comment: @starball "you want to make every Stack Exchange question asker in the world wait a minimum of 1 hour to receive any answers?" There is [not supposed to be any sense of urgency](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569), and it very often takes at least that long to get a not-quite-up-to-standards question into proper shape - even with an engaged, willing and understanding OP.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes. agreed. But the question should be in shape before answering the question anyway. Some people actually write questions that are answerable and of fair quality from the get go. I don't see why make them wait an hour to see any answer. And people already have to wait to accept answers. Not that I don't see some merit in this. But I also wonder things like- if the problem is FGITW answers, why not just make people wait to vote instead of wait to see answers, but allow close-voting? Why this specific idea?

Comment: @starball Hmm, those also seem like interesting approaches worth consideration.

Answer (score -10):

This is a small, specific suggestion, but it may be totally unfeasible given I know nothing of how the Stack Exchange backend is designed, or problematic in other ways.

As a long-time user (I have viewed sooooo many questions in so many disciplines), but first-time poster on this site, I feel I have a good sense of what good questions and answers are, but I don't have the reputation to vote on them, which is frustrating. It would be cool to receive reputation by viewing questions, in which case by this point I would have a lot.

This has obvious problems such as allowing people/bots to game the system easily, and the smallest denomination of (1 reputation) seems too high for viewing a single post, but I thought it would be worthwhile to bring up anyway, in case anyone gets some better ideas by reading this.

Comment: while I can kind of see the point that by reading a lot of Q&A, you will learn things and may learn to know what you're talking about, you haven't "talked" (posted anything). You haven't _helped anyone_ by writing something useful to them, nor have you _proven_ to anyone that [you know what you're talking about](/help/reputation). If you've been here for a long time and want voting privileges, I'm really surprised you don't have them yet. Once you have the site association bonus, it only takes 13 edits to gain downvote privileges.

Comment: Add to that the fact that you only created this network account of your this week. So none of your previous views of posts can even be attributed to it.

Comment: "_This has obvious problems such as allowing people/bots to game the system easily_" this is _trivially_ gamable. It's not even funny how easily gamable this suggestion is. Even if you rate limit requests, it's still easily gamable over time.

Comment: "a long-time user (I have viewed sooooo many questions in so many disciplines), but first-time poster on this site" - any *particular* site? "I feel I have a good sense of what good questions and answers are" - what, in a way that doesn't depend on which SE site it is? Certain things are transferrable, but a lot of domain-specific knowledge is going to be needed to judge that at all accurately for most sites.

Answer (score -11):

I think the first and probably the only thing that should be looked at is to remove the reputation requirement for posting comments. Yes, this could lead to more "useless" comments or answers posted as comment, but it will likely also lower the amount of new users receiving downvotes for posting comments as answers (because they can't post comments), and thus remove (or at least reduce) most of the friction that new users experience with the site.

Comment: This ought to address comments consisting of pure spam.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum As opposed to answers or questions that are spam? In any case, maybe asking questions, answering and commenting should all be disabled by default and only enabled if a user took the tour.

Comment: Down votes on such answers will quickly be nullified once the answer is deleted so this is not a problem that needs fixing.

Comment: Other than lots more of useless comments, I don't get what else would this proposal accomplish.

Comment: @Dharman As far as I'm aware downvotes on an answer will contribute to the answer-ban, even when the answer is deleted. In addition, getting your answer downvoted in itself is taken as a negative signal by new users, so allowing new users to comment removes (or reduces the chance of) the action a lot of new users perform incorrectly.

Comment: How about this instead - let's *not* treat this like some kind of forum where commenting is seen as this vital, essential thing?

Comment: If downvoting is perceived in a bad light, then the site needs to change this perception. We can't make users feel warm and cosy at the cost of reduced quality. While downvotes on deleted answers count towards the ban, it is extremely difficult to get answer ban and even easier to get out of this ban.

Comment: You should see Cody's comments [here under another answer](/posts/comments/1291584)

Comment: @starball Cody approaches from the other end, he is of the opinion that people don't need to comment. I'm approaching it from what I observe when reviewing low quality answers, that new users are very prone to misuse answers to post comments **because they can't comment yet**. They get downvoted and told off for abusing answers, this all contributes to a negative experience. I think having more "bad" or unnecessary comments is better than having such "answers", and the negative experience associated with them for new users.

Comment: @Dharman If you're new, and you're not yet familiar with Stack Overflow yet, I'm not surprised people take downvotes as negative and personal. It takes some experience with the site to get used to things.

Comment: I agree that allowing new users to comment would [nearly] solve our NAA answer epidemic. On the other hand, NAA answers and flags are extremely easy to deal with. A bunch of noisy comments are nearly impossible to moderate, for a variety of reasons. This is why I approach the problem from the other way, just as you said, Mark. I don't want to trade a *manageable* content-moderation problem for a *completely unmanageable* content-moderation problem. (Perhaps you approach it this way b/c you're one of our most prolific & effective reviewers on the front lines dealing with the NAA epidemic? :-))

Comment: There *is* a negative experience for users who want to comment but can't and therefore post answers which get removed, but that's much less of an issue (meaning: both happens at a much smaller scale, and is a much lesser contributor to frustration and bad experiences) than users whose questions get rejected. A major contributor to the problem is that many/most new users who come to the site asking a question are unable to even distinguish between answers and comments. I didn't believe this for the longest time, and I still find it hard to understand why not, but it's a real thing, I promise.

Comment: If anything, maybe commenting should cost reputation, like a downvote. (Maybe you get some of that back if people upvote your comment.) Make people ponder if their comment is really worth spending a little reputation on it or not. Maybe we just need more reputation sinks in general....

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks. I understand where you coming from. Maybe there is middle option of automatic expiring comments for low-reputation users (i.e. they're deleted after a few hours).

Comment: I'm sure arguments in comments (and those users at small sites that must comment on *every* post) chase away many users.  There should be more obstacles to commenting, not fewer.  (Especially when making multiple comments on the same post.)

Comment: @Makoto "How about this instead - let's not treat this like some kind of forum where commenting is seen as this vital, essential thing?" The problem is that *even though this is not a forum*, commenting **is** essential because *we have no other way to communicate specifics to OPs* about improving the question - and in a huge percentage of cases, that feedback is vital. OPs can't clarify a question if they don't see why others find it confusing or ambiguous. They can't provide missing information if they don't know what's missing. They can't focus a question if they don't realize the issue.

Comment: @CodyGray "I agree that allowing new users to comment would [nearly] solve our NAA answer epidemic. On the other hand, NAA answers and flags are extremely easy to deal with." Sure. But what about the off-site discussions where people (very rightly) complain about how they were trying to be helpful, went out of their way to understand the site's question standards, understood a specific issue with a question, tried to help OP to improve it (lacking information needed to even propose an edit themselves) - and **the only way the site enabled them to communicate this, was against the rules**?

Comment: If anything, the problem here is *how the comment section works*, not the fact that these new users want to comment. It should be possible to offer feedback that is visible only to the OP, the feedback provider, and perhaps other selected users such as diamonds/gold-badgers/high rep users. That feedback should perhaps follow some kind of template, but still allow for identifying a *specific* issue - not "this is unclear", but "when you say X did you mean Y, or Z? What should happen if the input is A?".

Comment: (And it should be possible to clean up all such feedback automatically by some normal action that marks the question as meeting standards. This is another reason why I want questions to start in a closed state: once there's a vote to open them, that would be a natural trigger to delete comments aimed at fixing the problems that made them unsuitable for opening.)

Comment: What if we just let new users comment specifically only on their own question? A spam bot would only be able to post a spam comment on their own spam question, so we haven't really created a new spam channel, since new users can already post questions.

Comment: @Karl Users who are new to the site should not be moderating questions. That's the fundamental assumption of the reputation system. The bar for leaving comments is *incredibly* low, far below the point where I'm really comfortable with the user who has earned 50 rep having any idea about what kinds of questions are suitable for the site. Your reply to me suggest that you think users who are new to the site should be involved in moderating content, suggesting how to improve Qs, etc., but that's just not the design, nor does it make sense to me. Leave moderating to when you've more experience.

Comment: @CodyGray I think this is an inappropriate conflation. "suggesting how to improve Qs" is **far** from what I would consider a typical moderation activity.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum it's called the  button and it already exists

Comment: @Cody Gray low rep ≠ new. especially on high traffic sites like SO, it's relatively difficult for a user who is perhaps a hobbyist or whatever to get rep, since a lot of the obvious questions have been asked and answered

Answer (score -11):

## More Detailed Downvotes

### Problem

Having experienced this myself, it is the worst thing ever when you ask a question and it is closed, with the message "off-topic" or "opinion-based" and you don't even get a good explanation on why. I now have no idea why they are off-topic or opinion-based. This makes it difficult for beginners who just want their questions answered.

Note: Yes, I did check the about section in the sites.

Another thing is downvotes. Another thing that is really frustrating is when your post is being downvoted and you have no idea why. Then it is eventually closed and you are really discouraged to ask another question. Worst, you still don't have an answer.

### Solution

When you go to close a question, require at least 25 characters. This will help a lot. Also, make a requirement that when you close a question you help give them a better place to ask it or how to improve the question.

For solving the downvote problem, simply require the person to add a reason why they're downvoting the post or answer. Make sure to as a 25 character requirement as well. Like before, add a requirement where the person must say how to improve the post or where else you should ask the question. What you could do is make all of the comments from the downvote anonymous so that way everyone can see them. Then, just add a button saying "Reason Already Mentioned" that can be pressed to prevent duplicate reasons. Yes, I know voting is a content rating system, but if we give the author feedback then they will be able to provide better content.

Note: Yes, I know people could just type gibberish, but there will still be the people who actually type something useful who will help out the poster.

### Conclusion

Though it may be difficult to do, we need to add a feature where you have to add a private comment whenever you downvote. Right now this post is being downvoted and while one person explained why, the other didn't. If I knew why both people downvoted I could have improved this post even more.

Comment: [Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436)

Comment: [What can we do to encourage downvoting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398537)

Comment: @VLAZ I changed the post a bit to fix some of the problems those posts bring up.

Comment: -1 because of asdkkytrdcfvbnmhbfnlwrbvfwknsdfjhv

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I also added a note into my post about that.

Comment: "*If I knew why both people downvoted I could have improved this post even more.*" here is a ***HUGE*** issue with ***ALL*** proposals like this: multiple people can vote based on the same reason. Do you really think it's viable to get, say, 25 downvotes and 25 comments saying the same thing? Do you think that would be *better*? Because I very strongly suspect the huge influx of comments would be highly annoying. Based on the real world observation where people have also often complained about comments. Yet it's not considered for the almost weekly "downvotes should come with comments".

Comment: @VLAZ I edited it again to have a solution for that.

Comment: Also a huge problem with the assumption is that the downvotes are *for the author*. No, they aren't. Not any more than a review on Amazon is about the seller or the delivery service. Votes are *content rating mechanism*. Similar to how reviews in Amazon should reflect the product. Votes are signal for *anybody* who looks at the content. Not just the author. Because the SE network aims to provide *content*. Large portion of the traffic is users landing from web searches. The goal is to give them the most relevant information.

Comment: And the constant "solutions" that need to be added are a strong signal that this proposal wasn't thought through in the first place if each piece of feedback prompts requires an update with a "solution".

Comment: Let me also throw a curve ball - why should *downvotes* come with explanation? In what way are *upvotes* different?

Comment: @VLAZ Upvotes can also have a explaination, I'm just focusing on downvotes right now, since they are the ones that are causing the problem. Downvotes should come with an explanation to help the author provide better content and know what to improve on next time. Though this is my opinion I do believe an added explanation will help the author get less frustrated if there starting out.

Comment: "*Upvotes can also have a explaination,*" interesting comments-for-downvote proposals throw in something half hearted like this when confronted with why it should comments not apply to upvotes. Usually the response is that yes *maybe* who knows *probably* an upvote *might* also have a comment, *perhaps*. And otherwise offer a response that upvotes might be equal but express uncertainty which so clashes with their certainty downvotes require a comment. As if they didn't consider it before. Did you consider upvotes before I asked? Did you consider what the voting system is and how it is used?

Comment: Because you seem overly focused on how *the author* responds to *a system that is aimed at the wide public* where the author is but one amongst potentially thousands of users who would see the rating.

Comment: Let me say, no, I did not realize nearly how complex this is. However, I am willing to realize flaws in what I say to try to improve this answer. While an upvote will help your question get more attention, your question will have no attention at all if it is downvoted too much. This shows that downvotes have a bigger effect than upvotes, meaning that they should require more thought by the person giving out the downvote.

Comment: Also, if the author ignores upvotes, they will be fine. If they ignore downvotes, then their question will be taken down. This shows that the author will want an explanation for downvotes, since they matter more. If they get upvotes, they don't really need to know why. However, I do now believe that there should be an optional comment when giving an upvote because the feedback could be helpful.

Comment: "*This shows that downvotes have a bigger effect than upvotes*" yet upvotes are cast dramatically more than downvotes. And content which is *not useful* or even *plain wrong* often gets upvotes despite its flaws. There are ***dangerously*** wrong answers out there with high double or even triple digit score. Which makes them essentially immune to any amount of downvotes, in addition to less downvotes being cast, less *users* cast downvotes. As a result, countering 50 or 100 upvotes on *content which should not be recommended* is so hard to be basically impossible in most cases. This is where

Comment: content rating fails. This runs directly counter to the purpose of the network where bad content should sink, good content should float. Check [my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385005) - what you need to read is between "*Let me be the bearer of bad news.*" and "*Which is another reason why it is dangerous to leave wrong content.*" to see an IRL example of dangerously wrong content from SO which was integrated into production. Yet, here you are trying to push for changes to reduce the casting of downvotes by focusing on the wrong side of them.

Comment: Well, those posts clearly are liked by many people, and only bother a few people. This shows that overall those posts are helpful since people are upvoting them since they like them.

Comment: 1) I genuinely don't understand how it's possible to *not understand* why a question is opinion based. I've seen so many people try to raise this about specific questions, and in every single instance, it's plain as day. 2) Re explaining downvotes, this has been rejected **countless** times on meta.SO. **Please** read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436. It's also covered on meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135. 3) This current discussion is supposed to be about **reputation**, not closing questions or voting.

Comment: As for "This makes it difficult for beginners who just want their questions answered." - that is **not the purpose** of the site. We answer questions that belong on the site, because we are building a library. We don't answer "the question that OP asked", because a) it might not be appropriate for the site and b) we aren't offering a discussion forum or help desk.

Comment: "Right now this post is being downvoted and while one person explained why the other didn't. If I knew why both people downvoted I could have improved this post even more." Voting works differently on Meta. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607.

Comment: "Well, those posts clearly are liked by many people, and only bother a few people. This shows that overall those posts are helpful since people are upvoting them since they like them." No, it does not. By this reasoning, adults would eat candy for dinner.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel As for your first comment: 1) I was asking if oranges could peel like how tangerines do, it was an argument me and my friend were having so I wanted somebody to confirm I was correct. The question itself was not opinion based though, because I was asking for a simple fact. 2) Didn't quite realize when posting this. I should have definitely done more research. I will admit I wasn't nearly prepared for writing this proposal. 3) I was stupid and didn't realize. I'm going to post this elsewhere once I finish looking through why proposals failed, so I can make a better one.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Noobs questions can help build the library of information. If there question does not belong to that site, for your reson in the downvote explain why it doesn't.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Good point, we could also add required comments for upvotes. This will in turn make the ratio of upvotes to downvotes the same as before.

Comment: "I was asking if oranges could peel like how tangerines do, it was an argument me and my friend were having so I wanted somebody to confirm I was correct." Assuming this was on topic (cooking.SE?), I would consider it unclear. Prior to you saying that, I wouldn't have considered that there is more than one way that a citrus fruit "can peel", and saying "peel like tangerines do" definitely doesn't put any particular image in my mind.

Comment: "Noobs questions can help build the library of information. If there question does not belong to that site, for your reson in the downvote explain why it doesn't." This is missing the point, which has been beaten to death so many times on meta.SO that the horse is now glue.

Comment: here is my mandatory close comment

Answer (score -21):

Stop the dopamine crack. Information should be shared on the intrinsic motivation for the love of knowledge. To engineer a situation for extrinsic rewards is manipulative and ought to be criminal.

Comment: voting on posts is a general indicator of usefulness. on questions, it's also an indication of  being well-researched and descriptive. reputation is a measure of trust. lots of people don't do things for the rep. but like it or not, this "gamification" is deeply part of the Stack Exchange system.

Comment: There are, however, sites that have reputation counters hidden from user cards, like MathOverflow. Related: [Is there a path for other SE sites to have rep hidden by default like MathOverflow?](/q/382074/997587), and you can write or use an existing userscript to hide them from your local view. Related: [Options to hide reputation information on Stack Overflow?](/q/11586/997587)

Comment: I love sharing knowledge, but I value my time.

Comment: I would be open to this idea (I take it you only want to get rid of reputation not of voting or tying privileges to experience). Maybe there could be an experiment where users can opt in to not see their reputation and the reputation of others. And then after some time the user group that opted in to that is compared to a comparable user group that didn't it to his this group did before.

Comment: Some problems with the rep system:This post gained you rep even with a score of -19 @Seeking answers

Comment: lol. I think that’s a feature, not a bug.

Comment: I know, but it is still dumb @Seekinganswers