# Gift reward offered after accepting an answer

Tags: discussion

I just came across the following comment from the OP on an Answer which made me feel a bit uncomfortable:

> *"Hey btw Dacwe, I'm one of the owners of a clothing company in Australia called Cyanide Clothing - link. Just for that awesome help I'd love to send you a free tee. You've saved me hours of stress! Check out the site and let me know if you're interested :)"*

Here's the question:  [Crashing due to Integer.parseInt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292169/crashing-due-to-integer-parseint)

The guy seems sincerely grateful, and a free T-shirt is obviously only a token reward, but it this kind of behaviour appropriate for SO?

(There is also a touch of "product promotion" going on here too, but that's not the point.)

Comment: Awkward name, Cyanide, but I can't talk. :-)

Comment: His first comment was kind of ok, but the second is starting to step over the line and is really bordering on product promotion.

Comment: @slugster, [I totally agree](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1PCO0.png). Flag as spam!

Comment: @Arjan agreed. --

Comment: @slugster - I originally thought about flagging.  But I thought what he was trying to do excused the "touch of self promotion".  And I wouldn't fault him for making the offer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only potential problems I see in situations like this:

- The asker becomes known for behaviour like this, and people treat his questions differently (not closing bad ones, or spending more attention on them).
- > (There is also a touch of "product promotion" going on here too, but that's not the point.)

  The comment sitting there is a bit like an ad for them, and is entirely off-topic, so I'd prefer it be removed.
- It's actually a scam, somehow.

These things aside, I don't think there's anything wrong with compensating people for helping you.

Comment: These are all good reasons why this kind of thing *might* be a problem.  However, in this case the OP has no direct way to make contact with the guy who provided the answer.  (The answering guy's SO website link serves an empty page.)

Comment: @StephenC: Sure, I don't mean to be accusing him of anything. However, it might be appropriate to delete the comment after they've made contact.

Answer (score 6):

Why not? A person can give another person a tee in real life, why not on SO? Isn't SO a community?

There's nothing inappropriate I can see about this, and there seem to be no downside to this(unless everyone starts asking Jeff for a Tee when their questions get more than ten upvotes)

Comment: +1 - actually, I find it really nice to see that something like this happens occasionally!

Answer (score 4):

I share your feeling that this is off topic. <strike>Maybe there should be a possibility for private messages on Stack Overflow, for these kinds of things?</strike> Because if the gratitude is genuine, then I think it's a nice move but it shouldn't be linked like that in a comment.

In any case, the OP doesn't seem to have repeated this practice, so it's not really typical spam:

http://www.google.ch/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+cyanide+clothing

Comment: The problem is filtering the private messages though to avoid the entirely undesirable ones.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

Comment: @awoodland: You're right. I wasn't aware of that

Comment: But what are people supposed to do if not add a link? Describe the product they're offering (i"t's, like, a purplish green T-Shirt with a giant carrot on it...")? The link is 100% okay to me. However,  the second big comment asking for promotion is not. That's just spam.

Comment: @Eat more Twisters: In general that's true. In the past, I've seen 1-2 promotions along with bogus questions / answers that were somehow related to a product but not really useful. "Disguised spam", I'd say... and they looked similar to this promotion here. That's why I checked on Google, if there were more links from Stack Overflow to that company.

Comment: @Lukas fair point. ----