# Ping Feature should be added

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

I am really missing this feature. I really believe that there should be some way or at least a way, for one user to ping(or send short messages) other user.

Simply what i mean is that, there should be some medium of communication other than chat.

Many a times we find ourselves stuck in the situation where we know that XX user could help you but niether he is avilable in chat nor he has seen your question.

Comment: any reasons for downvotes.......

Comment: Downvotes in meta are more common than in other sites. For feature requests, downvotes typically express disagreement with the request.

Comment: so there is similar question with 108 upvotes! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

Comment: @N-JOY, there are many upvoted and declined features. See the list here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined?sort=votes&pagesize=15

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature is not wanted and is against the concept of a public, community Q&A site. Imagine that everyone pinged Jon Skeet whenever they asked a C# question... The idea is that questions are asked in general and anyone can answer them.

We have already the "@username" mechanism. I think it is more than enough. This is not a social network.

Comment: where shall i use or mention this @username if user is not in chats.

Comment: @N-JOY, we actually use this mechanism to respond to comments the user already posted. The feature that you want (specifically asking someone for an answer) is simply not wanted.

Comment: Thx for using @N_JOY.:D but i would have received notifications about your comment otherwise as you were commenting on my comment.

Comment: thx for edits and i really appreciate your explanation. but dont you think this was just a concept, we could limit the no. of msgs or add some reputation checks or could add some other checks to handle the above stated problem

Comment: @N-JOY Most of the discussion already took place before, see for example the suggested question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user.

Comment: Any way this was my first try in Meta, thx for your help.