# Send direct messages

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

my question goes thus: Is there a way to send a message to a particular user on the forum? Like asking a user a question which he or she can receive in his or her inbox? My reason is because a particular user correctly answered a question I had posted before and I would like to get further hints along same line. His profile showed he is an expert in the area I seek clarification. Thanks Yemi

Comment: You start with the wrong assumption: it is NOT a forum (and this isn't pedantry, they're different is so many ways)

Comment: Not sure why people downvote his question. It's sensible and well asked. I understand the queried functionality is not wanted and that's fine, doesn't seem a reason to downvote.

Comment: I landed on this question because I wanted to contact a person directly and avoid starting a whole discussion in the comments session. So it seems that the accepted way to proceed would be to ask a question myself about the topic I want to discuss...

Answer (score 6):

No this is not social networking site. It's community site. If anyone have time and solution you will get solution. Just post your that problem and link to it.

Comment: This is antisocial networking at its finest.

Comment: It will mainly irritate users present on community.