# Ask question from specific person

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have a question that I want answered by a specific person.

How can I determine if that person answers my question, and how can I inform this person that I need him to look at my question?

Comment: Which question your are talking about? Have you posted yo any of community?

Comment: You mean you want to ask a support question, or a programming (or site topic) question?

Comment: "Ask question from moderator" Seriously, what does the word "moderator" mean to you? We have a number of users flagging their questions asking "can moderator help me answer my question?" and I can't fathom what goes through their minds to think we are in the best position to answer their questions because of the title "moderator".

Comment: And from your last comment, it would seem that you're trying to offer someone a job... you shouldn't do that here, and you definitely shouldn't be doing it if they're not looking for a job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[There is no way to contact a specific user.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)... **That's not what the site is for...** If you do attempt to contact users personally, you might find users unwilling to help because they simply do not have the time or do not appreciate the methods they used to contact you personally.  Be aware that there is a reason that messaging is not a feature on the site...

Please do not harass users to help you on specific questions.  Waiting for a specific user to answer a question will seriously limit your possibilities for an answer.  At any time there are many many many users browsing the question lists looking to help people.  Don't limit yourself to only one person - let the community do its job and help others...

---

> **Disclaimer  - I do not endorse this method.  However with the limitations of the system, this is pretty much the only options available...**

What you could do is leave a comment on a post by that user and that way he/she will receive a notification.  However you should make sure to remove that comment once the user has noticed because **it creates noise in the comment threads...**

---

The only other thing I can think of is to find the user you want to speak to in a chat room and interact that way.

---

I'd like to add here a note (if it was not clear throughout the rest of my post) that this is considered bad behavior by the community.  It is not the right way to get your questions answered.  I detailed this method **and its problems** so that you could see *why* it is a bad idea and perhaps why it is a better choice to just let the community help you no matter who exactly is answering your question.   You might want help from a specific user but at the same time you might be able to get an even better answer compromised from several comments and an answer from two or more different users...

As was said in the [comment section below my post by Slugster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136423/ask-question-from-specific-person#comment381301_136424)

#### `"It's [Stack Overflow] a Q&A site, not a consulting site."`

Comment: People have gotten into trouble with us for bothering other users with unrelated questions through comments, and now I have someone to blame for it :P

Comment: @bolt - It's up to you whether or not to respond... No one is twisting your arm here :P

Comment: @bolt - I've added some extra info hopefully indicating the negative aspects of these methods...

Comment: @Lix. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @meh - No problem.  Please read my post carefully and understand that what you are trying to do might not be received well by users... Try not to step on anyone's toes :)

Comment: I survey your answer again and think about this. all right, if I want to ask a personal question, must be relate to other by facebook or email or etc. thank you.

Comment: The most important thing is to not annoy other users with personal requests.  As Bolt♦ said, people have gotten into trouble by abusing this feature...

Comment: Personally I thought your answer was great until I saw the middle section. Everyone wants Jon Skeet to answer their C# questions, and so on for the other tags, and I always considered that SO maintained a sanctity around that sort of thing. I would be VERY disappointed if anyone started using this approach at all, ever, to bug specific users. It's a Q&A site, not a consulting site.

Comment: I was reconsidering this answer... I believe that it might be better to detail these "frowned apon" methods and at the same time explain *why* they are no good as opposed to letting the user figure them out and not realizing that they are potentially annoying...

Comment: That's a good edit, you've got my +1. They'll work out at some stage that you can do that, but by then they should have some respect for the site and not do it. But give that little nugget to all the n00bs and eventually some of them are going to pull the trigger on it.