# How can I send message to unique member?

Tags: discussion, private-messaging

May I send message or ask question to other member? how?

Vincent

Comment: That feature has been declined: see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)