# Have I been punished or banned by the community?

Tags: support, reputation, comments

After asking a few questions on Stack Overflow, I completely lost my ability to answer to comments on my questions yesterday. The only thing I can do is post more questions.

I am fairly new, and I asked a [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433518/have-i-been-banned-or-punished-in-stackoverflow?noredirect=1#comment21829479_15433518), but was told that I should ask here.

I read the FAQ but it doesn't help me. I also don't think I broke any rules, so I don't get it. In a comment on my previous post, someone mentioned "karma". What is karma? Is it reputation? He says I need more than 100 karma to answer comments, but the truth is that I was able to answer comments when I had less than 100 reputation points (assuming karma == stack rep points) and now suddenly I cannot.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

As an additional question, I have realized that some of my questions are being closed and downvoted by people that don't even take the time to read them. They just read the title and assumed that I am a jerk (I don't think my titles are offensive by any means, but then again I am not a master in expressing my ideas as you can probably see by this wall of text).

What can I do to stop them? I have the feeling there will always be someone that doesn't like me, and if that person has more power, I will always be harmed by it, even if I did nothing wrong.

Last but not least, I always start my posts as polite as possible by typing "Hello gentleman" or something similar, but Stack Overflow always removes that. Why am I not allowed to be polite?

Comment: You are able to place comments on your own questions right away. However, you are not able to place comments on other peoples questions/answers until you reach 50 reputation on stackoverflow. As a note, you can post comments right away on meta no matter whose question/answer.

Comment: If you want 100 reputation all you need to do is gain one upvote or successfully edit 3 posts. You haven't been punished and you shouldn't have much trouble getting there.

Comment: Additinally, how do you know if people are taking the time to read your question? They may just genuinely think it is a bad question.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards What does he need the 100 rep for? It isnt necessary for leaving comments.

Comment: I know @Josh, but that's what the OP is asking.

Comment: Guys, this post is a little misinformed but not particularly antagonistic; can we please avoid downvoting him into oblivion?

Comment: I believe they do not take time to read my questions because their comments show it. Sometimes they answer something different, other times they type 2 lines of a answer that is confusing and not structured, even when I take the time to make my question as clear as possible by enumerating it with numbers and points and links to additional research material. Per example, I always write my questions like the one here. Is this question not clear enough? If so why?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: It is very likely that the title of your question is the cause. The title asks why there is no interface in C++ like Java, which may not be answerable, since it is part of the language design. (Some features in the language can be explained, but there are things that cannot be adequately explained)

Comment: Please don't close this as a dupe. The other one was asked on SO and migrated here, and is being closed as a dupe of this one.

Comment: With regards to your greetings being removed, see this question: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: So, saying a salutation is considered bad to the point that it needs to be automatically removed? Never thought I'd see this day coming.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: it seems you did not take the time to read and consider the linked-to question before posting a comment about its content. Oh, the irony.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix It's 'noise' that makes searching more difficult. Also; you came here looking for advice, presumably. Please consider having a more open mind and considering the advice you are being given.

Comment: I have read the discussion and I have understood the problem. I understand why you people took the measure you did and I accept that with an open mind. It just feels kinda "weird" to me. I mean, I have been told that life has a conduct code and that being nice and saying "hello" to people when they help you is part of that code. In my personal opinion, not being able to thank you for your help is just wrong. However, StackOverflow is a forum, and I guess I can thank people by upvoting their answers. It still feels iffy to me. It's just an opinion.

Comment: It isn't a forum though. `Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers` :)

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: I understand where you're coming from, but you have to keep in mind that those things that make SO "not a forum" are also those things that make SO so much more helpful than the usual forums. "removing greetings" would be very jarring in a forum, but is important here: we want content and content only. (that's also why comments are second-class citizens here and why comment-threads such as the one here are generally seen as a bad thing).

Comment: @Flame: Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange) is different. Definitely review the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) pages to see how.

Comment: `not having the same function definitions repeated all over my God damn child headers. But that is besides the point.` - don't expect people to take you seriously when you write questions like that.

Comment: "What can I do to stop them?" Absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for your salutations, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

You do swear in some of your posts, and the mid paragraph in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432898/why-does-c-does-not-have-real-interfaces-like-in-java) is more like a rant than anything else.  The question was validly down-voted, and validly up voted too. However, the grammar and formatting are off, and I can fully understand it's being closed.

You also only have two downvoted questions, out of 11 upvoted ones.

Comment: So, using the word "sucks" is considered offensive? I guess I was quite frustrated (and still am) when I wrote that, but I never imagined people would be so offended by it. What do I do now? I assume I cannot simply ask the same question again, or else I will be punished.
As far as greetings goes, is it removed automatically? Or is it removed by users? I understand the user's point, but I don't think that typing 2 words and thanking the community for their job is going to waste your time into oblivion. I believe in moderation. I believe that my post should be polite but not too long.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: While I understand that you are frustrated, there is no need for curse words in the question. It does not contribute to the subject matter.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Some greetings are removed automatically. And users are fairly active as well in doing so. See my comment to your question for a link explaining this. And you're right, don't ask the same question again. Improve your existing question. If it's closed, that might help to have it reopened.

Comment: But, if it is closed, even if I improve it, people wont be able to answer it.

Comment: There is a re-open process, similar to votes to close.  Bear in mind that long after your immediate frustration and need have passed, other readers may hope to benefit from the Question you've posted (and its Answers/Comments).  So in StackOverflow, as with other SE forums, decorum and factualness are important.

Comment: @Bart: I doubt people would really want to look at a -10 question after improvement, with the current system. And does an edit bring it to the front page? (I remember there being a limit on the score of the post).

Comment: @nhahtdh It will put it in the reopen queue as far as I'm aware. Any post of a score of -8 or lower will not appear on the front page afaik.

Comment: @Bart: I think lower than -8 is for meta. The limit is higher (> -8) for main site IIRC.

Comment: In regards to that particular question, I just [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15432898/3) it to update the title  to match what's being asked, and removed a few phrases that users might find offensive. Edits will bump questions to the "Active" page so they might get a bit more attention, however questions with a score of -8 (It might be -5) or lower won't show up there, so I don't think your question will show up in the Active list. It *will* show up in the Reopen Review Queue though since I cast a vote to reopen it.

Comment: @Rachel: Thanks for the effort Rachel. I was going to PM you (and thus search in the fAQ or create a new thread about that) to thank you for your time. But now that I am commenting guess that would be silly. Anyway, upvoted!

Comment: There is no private messaging mechanism here.

Comment: There a PM mechanism, however it's use is restricted to moderators and admins, and it's use is very restricted:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

Damn shame. Guess this is the only way I will ever be able to thank someone. It feels "less human" imo, but that's not my choice.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Then again, most of us are not human. I am merely a pair of glasses for example. ;) But kidding aside, we'll just assume a user is thankful and kind. And the advantage is that you can think all kinds of mean things and we'll still assume you're nice. :p

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix It's not well documented, but you can type @EditorUserName in a comment on a post someone has edited and it will send the message to their Inbox. For example, you could type `@Rachel` in a comment to the post I edited, and I would have received the message :)

Comment: @Bart Yep, we even get some doorknobs `:P`

Comment: @Rachel That's not a very *private* means of messaging someone.  SE only has *public* means of messaging someone (there are several of them, but none of them are private).

Comment: @Flame: The way to thank someone is to upvote their post. If an answer was the fix for your issue you _accept_ it. Again, these sites are not like other sites you may be used to.

Comment: @AlEverett:  what if the asnwer is in a comment and not in a "answer"? How should I proceed given that i cannot mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: There's an "upvote" mechanism for comments, but all it does really is make sure the comment is seen. The kind of interaction you're looking for doesn't exist here. If it's not a question or an answer it's probably unnecessary cruft.

Comment: I wish people wouldn't assume brevity is a sign of rudeness. A concise system is neither polite nor rude, it is merely a system. Only you can assign emotions to the system (hint: this is a waste of time).

Comment: @AlEverett: These comments are not answers nor questions, yet alone they are the help I needed to solve my problem (which has been solved thanks to the comments). They are many things, "unnecessary cruft" is definitely not one of them.

Comment: @Flame: Meta is different.

Comment: Fair enough. I marked the only answer as the right one. Not that I had much choice xD

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: Just got back to my computer. And saw 23 unread messages... :\. Thanks for the accept.