# Visitor's Page for Account Profile

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

Just an idea for an Account Profile. If one visits another's profile page, he/she may leave a comment on the profile page. It may be thankful words or general comments about this user. I think it would be a motivation for a user to have a high quality answers to receive positive feedbacks. 
Please let me know what you think too. 
Cheers.

Comment: Orkut/LinkedIn have feature like this ... btw who care about profile viewes

Answer (score 17):

No, Stack Overflow is not a social network. It is a site for questions and their answers, and not so much about the people that post those questions and answers.

I receive positive feedback for my answers by people voting on them. Sometimes they even leave a comment on specific answers. That is plenty of encouragement, and keeps the focus on the answers themselves!

Comment: +1. In addition, that would add one more place for spammers to spam, trolls to troll, and stalkers to harass. That is both more work for the moderators and can potentially be a source of discouragement for a victim of one of the aforementioned things.

Comment: See also this related question, where a PM system was declined for some of the same reasons: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user