# Why doesn't Stack Exchange have ask to answer facility like Quora?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, private-messaging, quora

Regular users of [Quora](http://www.quora.com)  will be aware that when someone asks a question on Quora, he/she can ask this question to any specific person on Quora using the *Ask to Answer* facility provided by Quora. But why there is no such thing available on Stack Exchange? Wouldn’t it be nice if an Stack Exchange user could ask a question to another specific user? What is the reason? Why it is not allowed?

Comment: What are you talking about? Private messages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

Comment: Why do you want this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well really, Stack Exchange sites are to let users post questions about the topic of the site, in this case Stack Overflow, so the entire community can help out, not one-on-one courses.

Our point system can make this idea obsolete as everyone in Stack Overflow will ask Jon Skeet for C questions, Martjin Pieters for Python questions and so on for the top ranked users. Anyways, who knows who is cheating the system by making a second account and always asking the first account so they both get rep.

If you want to personally ask a user, use e-mail or the chat room for the respective language as you can face a more narrow amount of users to ask from.