# "Bouncing" an old question of other user - not enough reputation to comment

Tags: support, reputation, comments, old-questions

I'm new to Stack Overflow (only read till now, that's first time I join to ask), so please correct me if that's not the suitable place to ask this (from what I saw it's the closest to suit).

I encountered an issue in my work which has a corresponding question in Stack Overflow:

[Eclipse interface icons very small on high resolution screen in Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718093/eclipse-interface-icons-very-small-on-high-resolution-screen-in-windows-8-1/23024828#23024828)

The only answer that suited me didn't work, and I'd like to contact the person who answered about this, or try and check if the problem can be solved other way (since I failed to find such by now).

However, I cannot find the appropriate way to do this:

1. I cannot contact him directly, since I understood no such way exists in SO:

[Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

2. I cannot comment on his answer, since I don't have enough reputation (just joined)
3. I'm not sure it'll be appropriate to ask a new question, since I understand it'll be a duplicate.

I googled it for about a hour, but the closest I found is:
[Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Which I cannot use since it's not my question.

What is the proper way to solve this situation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I'm not sure it'll be appropriate to ask a new question, since I understand it'll be a duplicate.

Then make it not a duplicate. "How do I solve X?" is the current question, to which the answer is "Y". So you wanna ask, "How do I solve X when Y doesn't work?"

To be more specific, you'd want to describe in detail how the author's technique of prescaling icons is failing (linking to the answer that describes it for context) and soliciting assistance with making *that specific technique* work for you. This ends up being a very different question from that which sparked the answer you're linking to in the first place...